# Find The Least Common Characters

Tags: code-golf, string

Given a string, find the 10 least common alpha-numeric characters within that string.

Output should be formatted with numbers left-padded with spaces so they look like this:

```
e:      1
t:     16
c:     42
b:    400
z:  50000
a: 100000
```

Use this to test your program: [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/4771/text-compression-and-decompression-nevermore)

Output for test case:

```
j:  2
x:  3
q:  9
k: 32
v: 67
c: 73
w: 79
f: 93
b: 94
p: 96
```

Shortest code wins. You can submit a program or a function.

Comment: Do you want a function or a whole program?

Comment: @marinus: A program or a function, whichever is shorter for you.

Comment: I presume from your output to the test case that uppercase and lowercase letters are treated as the same?

Comment: @Gareth: Yes, they should be treated the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## K, 60

```
{(-:|/#:'f)$f:10#$(!x)[i]!r i:<r:. x:#:'=_x@&x in,/.Q`a`A`n}
```

Answer (score 1):

### Mathematica, <s>102</s> 93:

v2:

```
  Grid[SortBy[
             Tally@StringCases[ToLowerCase@#,x_?LetterQ:>x<>":"],
              Last@# &],
      Alignment->Right]&@s
```

v1:

```
TableForm[
         SortBy[Tally@StringCases[ToLowerCase@#, x_?LetterQ :> x <> ":"],
                #[[2]] &], 
         TableAlignments -> Right] &
```

Comment: You beat me to it (and had more streamlined code).

Comment: @DavidCarraher But MMa is SO verbose! :(

Comment: I detect a hint of irony in your comment.

Answer (score 1):

#### Bash, 72

Assuming no single-letter-named files in the current directory; input from stdin:

```
grep -io [a-z]|sort -f|uniq -ci|sort|head|sed -E 's/(.*)([a-z])/\2:\1/'
```

Works on Linux, but for some reason, my mac's grep seems to ignore the `-i` when used with `-o` (bug or undocumented gotcha?), but the following (78) works:

```
tr A-Z a-z|grep -o [a-z]|sort|uniq -c|sort|head|sed -E 's/(.*)([a-z])/\2:\1/'
```

If the output were allowed to be reversed, the sed part could be dropped to save 30 characters in each of the previous solutions.

Answer (score 1):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), <s><sup>45</sup></s> 36 bytes

```apl
10↑⌷⍨∘⊂∘⍋∘⌽⍨{⍺':',≢⍵}⌸∊⎕(∊⊆⊣)⍥⎕C⎕D,⎕A
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT/9/eNqjtgnVGo96twKRwqPeXZpADEQIka2atVyPOtqcgeosDC0f9WwD8trT/hsaPGqb@Khn@6PeFY86ZjzqagKRvd0gsmcvULAaaIi6lbrOo85FQDNqH/XseNTR9ahvqgaI6mp71LVY8/A0BbDBfVNddICE43@gwf/TFLjUPVJzcvLVAQ)

A full program which accepts a string as input. tio link uses polyfills for `⍥` and `⎕C`.

Shortened and tested with help from Bubbler.

-12 bytes from Adám.

<s>Doesn't work on tio due to some problem with `⎕C`.</s>(Now works, thanks to Adám's help)

### Explanation

```apl
10↑⌷⍨∘⊂∘⍋∘⌽⍨{⍺':',≢⍵}⌸∊⎕(∊⊆⊣)⍥⎕C⎕D,⎕A 
                             ⍥⎕C      lowercase the following:
                                ⎕D,⎕A string of the alphabet and digits
                       ⎕              and the input
                        (∊⊆⊣)         filter out nonalphanumerics
                      ∊               flatten the string
            {⍺':',≢⍵}⌸                create a frequency table for each letter key
   ⌷⍨∘⊂∘⍋∘⌽⍨                          sort the table based on the last row
10↑                                   take the first 10 elements
```

Comment: Gofled a bit: `{10↑⌷⍨∘⊂∘⍋∘⌽⍨{⍺':',≢⍵}⌸∊⍵(∊⊆⊣)⍥⎕C⎕D,⎕A}` which you can make run on TIO by replacing `⍥` and `⎕C` with polyfills: `Ö←{(⍵⍵ ⍺)⍺⍺(⍵⍵ ⍵} ⋄ ∆C←819⌶`. Also, since this only uses the argument once, you can save another 2 bytes by converting to a tradfn.

Comment: @Adám Another interesting use for the `∊⊆⊣` idiom. I'll get it running.

Comment: Listed [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/153435/43319).

Answer (score 1):

### Java <s>452</s> <s>444</s> <s>433</s> 430

```
import java.util.*;
interface L{
static void main(String[]a){
Map<Character,Integer>m=new HashMap<>();
for(char c:a[0].toLowerCase().toCharArray())if(96<c&&c<123) m.merge(c,1,(j,i)->j+i);
int l=String.valueOf(m.values().stream().reduce(0,Integer::max)).length();
m.entrySet().stream().sorted((e,f)->e.getValue()-f.getValue())
.forEachOrdered(e->System.out.println(e.getKey()+"-"+String.format("%"+l+"s",e.getValue())));
}}
```

My first contribution. I know Java will never win this kind of challenges but until now it is at least the shortest java response :)

First argument is used as input. If it contains spaces, it has to be quoted(")

Explained:

```
// there is not a lot you get for free, so import you will
import java.util.*;
interface L{
static void main(String[]a) {                 // java main entry point
    Map<Character,Integer> m=new HashMap<>(); // key=character, value=number of occurances in input text
    for(char c:                               // for each character in
        a[0]                                  // take first argument from command line
        .toLowerCase()                        // convert all characters to lowercase
        .toCharArray())                       // convert to array so we can loop over it
    
      if(96<c&&c<123)                      // accept only a-z
        m.merge(c, 1, (j,i)->j+i);            // fill map, increase corresponding value
    
    int l=String.valueOf(                     // l: to store length of counter
            m.values().stream()               // loop over counter values
              .reduce(0,Integer::max))        // find max value
            .length();                        // count number of digits of max value

    m.entrySet().stream()                     // loop over the counter map
    .sorted((e,f)->e.getValue()-f.getValue()) // sort the map by value ascending
    .forEachOrdered(                          // loop over the ordered result  
        e->System.out.println(                // print for every entry
            e.getKey()                        // - the key
            +"-"                              
            +String.format("%"+l+"s",         // - format using l
                 e.getValue())));             //   the value
}}
```

452 -> 444 : removed spaces

444 -> 433 : class-> interface, <s>public</s>

433 -> 430: 96<c&c<123 (thanks @ceilingcat)

Comment: Nice first post, welcome to the site! I don't know Java, but is there a way some of that indentation could be removed to save some bytes?

Comment: I'm senior developer and it kind a hurts to write unreadable code :). But as this challenge is more about the number of bytes, I removed unnecessary spaces. Thanks

Comment: We also have a [Tips for golfing in Java](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/6671/tips-for-golfing-in-java) page if you're interested in reading (or contributing!) some.

Answer (score 0):

#### Python, <s>206</s> <s>199</s> 195 characters

```
import sys
t=sys.stdin.read().lower()
f={}
for c in t:
 if c.isalnum():f[c]=f.get(c,0)+1
s=lambda x:x[1]
h=sorted(f.items(),key=s)[:10]
for n in h:print n[0]+': '+`n[1]`.rjust(len(`max(h,s)[1]`))
```

Undoubtedly there is a lot of room for improvement, but here's my first attempt. Produces identical output for the test case provided.

206 -> 199: Removed unnecessary newline and keyword argument

199 -> 195: <s>iter</s>items()

Answer (score 0):

### Javascript, 271 characters

I'm not sure whether this breaks the rules of not (it doesn't justify the numbers in the output, but here's my solution anyway:

```
c=[];t=128;while(t--)c[t]=[0,t];i=prompt().toLowerCase();for(n=0;n<i.length;x=i.charCodeAt(n++),c[x][0]+=x>96&&x<123);for(n=i=0,c=c.sort(function(a,b){return(a[0]-b[0])});n<10;i++)if(c[i][0]>0){console.log(String.fromCharCode(c[i][1])+": "+("  "+c[i][0]).slice(-2));n++}
```

I'm pretty sure it can be simplified (I won't win with this character count :P), but now I can't find anything.

Okay, so I completely forgot that the padding was actually a requirement :O
Corrected that and fixed a bug. (250 -> 271)

Answer (score 0):

### Python, 144

```
import os
s=os.read(0,10000).lower()
n=s.count
a=sorted(filter(str.isalnum,set(s)),key=n)[:10]
for c in a:print c+': %%%ii'%len(`n(a[-1])`)%n(c)
```

Comment: I just proposed an edit that saves you 14 characters by switching to the 'raw_input()' function.

Comment: @ESultanik The problem is that `raw_input()` terminates on newlines, so it would stop after the first line of input in the supplied test case.

Comment: @Strigoides: Good point; I missed that the input could have newlines.  My fault for not looking at the test cases.

Comment: `print c+': %%%ii'%len(`n(a[-1])`)%n(c)` saves 3 characters

Answer (score 0):

### Haskell (229)

```
import Char
import Data.List
z=filter
t=show
l=length
k x=[(l$z(==m)x,m)|m<-x]
s z=[b:':':take(1+(maximum$map(l.t.fst)z)-l(t a))(repeat ' ')++t a++"\n"|(a,b)<-z]
main=interact$concat.s.take 10.sort.nub.k.map toLower.z isAlphaNum
```

Answer (score 0):

### Perl, 86 chars

given string is in `$_`

```
s/[a-z]/$h{lc($&)}++/eig;printf"$_:%9d$/",$h{$_}for(sort{$h{$a}<=>$h{$b}}keys%h)[0..9]
```

Answer (score 0):

## JavaScript 1.8 (ES6) 186

```js
F=s=>(
  s.toLowerCase(n={}).replace(/[a-z0-9]/g,c=>n[c]=-~n[c]),
  s=Object.keys(n).sort((a,b)=>n[a]-n[b]),
  s.slice(0,10).map(x=>x+': '+('      '+n[x]).slice(-(n[s[9]]+'').length))
  .join('\n')
)
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 22 bytes

```
Øa;ØD
ŒlċⱮ¢¢żPƇ0ị$Þḣ⁵G
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##vVk9jxzHEc3nV/QtDDCZJRz7AoPUieQBJO/EW4DhoWemZ6d1M9Oj/tj1ho4cKHOkyIGcG3BgwIAdiZb/h/RH6FdVPbt71B18ZxAWBGhuu7u6uj5evSp9bfp@9/Hjh@/06Yfvzoof/9j/69uf//qXH77/4fsf/3n57z/8@qd/fPurD3/66e9//vn3f3v58ePHi7E2Kk1uVFoNthntuouq8Ub7Xam2ne2NOldYbow3DX4x@kbpsaEP7CguNsarQY87HP8maTtGXq2Tty4FtXF9GoxyrWqdX7sYzah6501ZvM@iR9c0JHiEvH6nRj1NdlyXKiT8PuKX2OFmVWuI0Srm5eJZIKHBkfDRqLUZI/b6@XT@UDqqYafqTg8V9Gyc80@LxZOVskHObmyw0fhyAU2GBPX4kYt47/HlslAP/udC9LehZKOMDt@QOsAATxdF8awrVWNDtGNNyp8rbwbDN9motjooO9LrVdWT0c9MzYt4O2QZXXcqmEl7HY1qdiRXzm69S@RDG4Nady5E8S4Jans2wJd6bTxfuLWhMw2vQSnvtr9ZLjdwIi92uoGRWFZ0quL14oV3A9mkcu4GNky@NjoY8QVtWC7lv@RvltuTBq/NiDfDdi/yr17Dp2QTrxurETSDtnA3Ag7iaYMe16YPCAc4aX/64ZZ/i3O9CUFx8JAuBoHKhi/YfnRHsP0N7gx4Z0IW@IiXK59C7MmaeBIbeUp@QqQiomm9WHXe9j2MNkCjdv6EJWOnWrxEw5@1QiB556E/Xata00dVGahhTosrh8sRWKPblmRY7O978bPRMd8MC3dIiFjCDyE6B0OZSZbvil@F8Pf5NH1qSupfBi/uxpmeIuZxB08fZfwVIp5C@L64v/QmSL7iGkRYr9bebPFO7@B1f4qnQzlRCnYZIQBhREtlsbiylK0B4aLOkanw7Bvd6AGm9AkSdy55xhq7MSMFwLmyw9Sz5Z@nKGmga1KO4l@HA@KQqsHNUAJBAjp@Dzmy3hLIHW@YMUndjxolwga/wpe1Rsbwvcgdwj9yc0PCFsslB@u5chNUB8IiI1jfx3vgTPsbfj2D5x1eKIozYyYATMzR2MwnJmM8v4Ysvo8@AeEtlwFebaE2W@XMpSryT1Q0BrqBPwJ5DXdF3XPu0Q0ENU6W9@kwOwXJaMZsmjRW3iE1RXE2wazeWm8MSY68vk9lR5C1dX7WNEy0zsJoGXUsTITtvAdhI5Bysig4Vs8PG@RKPSpTd9A/efyLY5Wub0TSJ@cf7pM3EJ/LwV3@eE43ZH@YffDE5EcJTmDEnC2ENUAqhF6Vl5HYVMDXBGBzSB2KJUPFlrzcu9SQ1A4PFAegHF4lUuw4qULKquo4I43oKpG9tWMDhAeOAOrgwtcmkjLBINIoX4k36Cie0AcY4JcPuwDY2SnzO05KRDWfznAHpTIegozg1swm7jr5uIQQyGQHWvbvbfvDkcUFsk7lDGz7JNijQsesgJ7EDyOYz3Sn7a0X/bCdNxXn4xx/0UyTIScEABkZ8x0CdyRoZ6kZQxq9Yx6zY0@8dZIKKPeoma4yNjAeDxpA0JlTUplZ2pgiXeH4CiAg7tjhq5N0mrW0cl9PWYFNvW7A6BDkNZV8XTkk0i/JzWVez4ywSqRJqy4Rf8ilr@nP@44@3Bv5kgy5Ot4JUCtCfva8qRwMXlm8ozLrZLk8UzKgcKPk1jvJmzDwSlk8Z9KIokJYwVfAOaNqTO18GmYf1C6NoKNsYeJbzEoXq44YDzbgeShTEpGdw3EW1JEXKcpdYs5IKYOEodBlPAcy1Z73FC87eBE@Xns7ZFCpLUW0RMJWZyxVrc@c5y1xb5yg@0wJi64MZb2Z02nHvmSSjB9hmEzr@NyToC4Rhm4EnRIJj0KnrxKsz9LeyRMXb/eMCcnxJoEJgSJrvzFMedgxSBIhi63b9gTtlMREaWFbD1aIajn1vIMKIBuWWKkewxZh09sYQawGownDlsv8N6DHbNirFRcIooxbagBGCv/O9BOAzhsj7ICJFERt6M8uDQxsxJK@pJqzM0KkK@KCXFIjsWY@y/EksUxv@SSYn1vJmopzcc@gQ536KUpJOOTCp@fLRxj@PatE5mWvQtnblp/rY3YLiBHzIlRnQpWsFqxcW1GplNrHFVFYB/VHUraopWhZW64j3F4cbVBUaCHGpTjBgQxInJEtuG/HdYMhUuVGabkUQAIXuLWc4ZA2FCsC85n3EOPDs6T@HLVbF3y89UiPBpSd0hatynauURBzMR41Keq6M9fwJSQDKgmLDL@Nqgi40x0Sni4eRV9N7rsoBnKG3/LJVUTCUxbozF2oZDE9Ed6iqh3xdUplp/TEOT0JYVkwX6JwPC64nOAAITZJUEyfg5AawHx9k1GMIeoLzS0Zowb3AGnsUOhhWk04Jy1UGgdgrG3h5TNUEVpAIvUwiSHMDLluHf9CDiSTSniM68BxAYZBfVklbljNrUpj/dpw6aLtr2B1CSV0XUjdzkHxo5OPaZlb9YRtjeDam/zJp3mQScKhGsz0SFrW/pOCcIXGhucaRPSMYc@hoQuddUS0A7OUkUw6crUTaBjnHMcHU3AuSeUBDACFGwBMsOMN06xzKAS2fENUxfQtAWIva8ULBrREWnHFohIiSzO4E5yjstPQhK/PrABGf7/fQKWk3KNuifaeSww@dMpU6S4ZjyKp1IzDFrV3mtW7HfmZLqNmo11c6zWsh83rhHhmE1SJ8TjsQBcAukTWvKwVK2G2XCoQoygPrWU@tzPUK2yZzLI8GIknDIhuVLWaq8Bqps0MIKJBQ6jP1wrhYRLJSckzCW/qntdn9Mgeh8zsOVmWyGXipdEqcqCsewfaBgs@IVpHsScq54Mb6/rDeb79jvPcy0PAI@x/fUXQBpqBeGbLAdi6Uu1T4aTIQUiMnGczpYxLrJcmGikXiK6C57VpoNQmnADcJvyOxKl5vbjaEsEFTOEPPXVgKNklzsVli9tBlhGflCk52GNqySB5hLR4702sO@ZANXCbh2YgKC/RK8KaHYB5ZJsigCumY2E/04Ew3hLmLcU7EyYbsdXLh9BBA0LOESP8CABnYAIrsJMbsOKrpNu2VK6j6WPbSp7c2KPzZYY6AFZOo6OR1OfkSItL76bOxJMjYJf6SaOkje1PlstJtgh@lVSNq0w0mrwD6W64HK7MMBEok5lK2rHNCxELxEyjY05DFpS@RQtxRGsfHA95iP5QJKWxIYAgL7nMqRs4BKS1J9ug70ZBjlyvL/J6R5UFnntFFdfDYUk2xExJedpSHqYrOHqexw3L5bUN17kRqnQ/EES8RHuvm9/uBew/jmT8X53x330hfQSg4ZXhmsPfFVMUpn1A4pCjGwsU@aCpFWmlm1wuDZfLmW8J@xQKg24MIm1bzt28VFV0ckiKZzQLBVk4jxkKajRfEzWT1DfSwPEh09Iv8qH/Ydb69HN64nnmBkwxaTwX7Jo70wksSqpGtntLBPCE@6oOiX5DAZumEGUfnrR4aQQyZCCzH5fMKTGPi@7riIrXJs@Pqp4ETPx/J0AdtQyUpDekQYk1DDnsN0ErJnCzhGEnDNwy65vnVUjfb5KVWlLdapWJP5wUK30jYisa6DOugWsfDXtZ/3kTIGvIm9p2L@QzemYenuXFPKvupcMoM8ei4L3vl7mwTojR3H48aFhwyldza7@b6brOzBJVashpqpGIA9freRI1jxgPg79DyaVKq6iShTgPImOHVAvCaDtNM6vj/xEiWsxDtb03@K68fY6FQCdyQT@S8AhXXHEeV1DYtgykh5L@Hw)

Doesn't output with a `:` on each row, but given that isn't explicitly specified in the spec (compared to the left padding), I assumed this was OK. [26 bytes](https://tio.run/##vVk9jxzHEc3nVzQXBpjMEo51gSHqRPIAknfiLcCQ6Jnp2WnezPSoP3a9me3EgTJFSuxATg0DDgwYsCPR8v8Q/wj9qqpnd4@6g@8MwoIAzW13V1fXx6tXpbem73cfPrz7Tp@8@@60@PHb/l/fvP/rX374/ofvf/znxb9//8uf/vHNL9798ae//@n9b//29v3v/vz@N3/47OmHDx/Ox9qoNLlRaTXYZrTrLqrGG@13pdp2tjfqTGG5Md40@MXoK6XHhj6wozjfGK8GPe5w/Ouk7Rh5tU7euhTUxvVpMMq1qnV@7WI0o@qdN2XxOoseXdOQ4BHy@p0a9TTZcV2qkPD7iF9ih5tVrSFGq5iXi88DCQ2OhI9Grc0YsdfPp/OH0lENO1V3eqigZ@Ocf1QsHq6UDXJ2Y4ONxpcLaDIkqMePXMRbjy@XhbrzP@eivw0lG2V0@IbUAQZ4tCiKz7tSNTZEO9ak/JnyZjB8k41qq4OyI71eVT0Z/dTUvIi3Q5bRdaeCmbTX0ahmR3Ll7Na7RD60Mah150IU75KgtmcDfKnXxvOFWxs60/AalPJu@9lyuYETebHTDYzEsqJTFa8XT7wbyCaVc1ewYfK10cGIL2jDcin/JX@z3J40eG5GvBm2e5J/9Ro@JZt43ViNoBm0hbsRcBBPG/S4Nn1AOMBJ@9N3t/xLnOtNCIqDh3QxCFQ2fMH2ozuC7a9wZ8A7E7LAR7xc@RRiT9bEk9jIU/ITIhURTevFqvO272G0ARq18ycsGTvV4iUa/qwVAsk7D/3pWtWaPqrKQA1zUlw6XI7AGt22JMNif9@Ln42O@WZYuENCxBJ@CNE5GMpMsnxT/CqEv8@n6VNTUv88eHE3zvQUMfc7eHIv468Q8RTCt8X9hTdB8hXXIMJ6tfZmi3d6B6/7EzwdyolSsMsIAQgjWiqLxaWlbA0IF3WGTIVnX@hGDzClT5C4c8kz1tiNGSkAzpQdpp4t/zhFSQNdk3IU/zocEIdUDW6GEggS0PF7yJH1lkDueMOMSep21CgRNvgVvqw1MobvRe4Q/pGbGxK2WC45WM@Um6A6EBYZwfre3wOn2l/x6xk8b/BCUZwaMwFgYo7GZj4xGeP5NWTxffQJCG@5DPBqC7XZKqcuVZF/oqIx0A38EchruCvqnnOPbiCocbK8T4fZKUhGM2bTpLHyDqkpirMJZvXWemNIcuT1fSo7gqyt87OmYaJ1FkbLqGNhImznPQgbgZQHi4Jj9eywQa7UozJ1B/2Tx784Vun6SiR9dP7uPnkB8bkc3OSPx3RD9ofZB09MfpTgBEbM2UJYA6RC6FV5GYlNBXxNADaH1KFYMlRsycu9Sw1J7fBAcQDK4WUixY6TKqSsqo4z0oiuEtlbOzZAeOAIoA4ufG4iKRMMIo3ylXiDjuIJfYABfvmwC4CdnTK/5qREVPPpDHdQKuMhyAhuzWzippP3SwiBTHagZf9etz8cWZwj61TOwLZPgj0qdMwK6En8MIL5THfa3nrRD9t5U3E2zvEXzTQZckIAkJExXyFwR4J2lpoxpNE75jE79sRLJ6mAco@a6SpjA@PxoAEEnTkhlZmljSnSFY6vAALijh2@OkmnWUsr9/WUFdjU6waMDkFeU8nXlUMi/ZzcXOT1zAirRJq06gLxh1x6S3/edvTu3siXZMjV8UaAWhHys@dN5WDwyuIdlVkny@WZkgGFGyW33knehIFXyuIxk0YUFcIKvgLOGVVjaufTMPugdmkEHWULE99iVrpYdcR4sAHPQ5mSiOwcjrOgjrxIUe4Sc0ZKGSQMhS7jOZCp9ryneNrBi/Dx2tshg0ptKaIlErY6Y6lqfeY8L4l74wTdZ0pYdGUo682cTjv2JZNk/AjDZFrH5x4GdYEwdCPolEi4Fzp9lWB9lvZKnrh4uWdMSI4XCUwIFFn7jWHKw45BkghZbN22J2inJCZKC9t6sEJUy6nnHVQA2bDESvUYtgib3sYIYjUYTRi2XOa/AT1mw16tuEAQZdxSAzBS@HemnwB03hhhB0ykIGpDf3ZpYGAjlvQl1ZydESJdERfkkhqJNfNZjieJZXrLR8H82ErWVJyLewYd6tRPUUrCIRc@Pl/ew/CvWSUyL3sVyl63/Fwfs1tAjJgXoToTqmS1YOXaikql1D6uiMI6qD@SskUtRcvach3h9uJog6JCCzEuxQkOZEDijGzBfTuuGwyRKjdKy6UAErjAteUMh7ShWBGYz7yHGB@eJfXnqN065@OtR3o0oOyUtmhVtnONgpjz8ahJUW868wa@hGRAJWGR4bdRFQF3ukHCo8W96KvJfRfFQM7waz65jEh4ygKduQuVLKYnwltUtSO@TqnslJ44pychLAvmSxSOxwWXExwgxCYJiulzEFIDmK@vMooxRH2huSVj1OAeII0dCj1MqwnnpIVK4wCMtS28fIoqQgtIpB4mMYSZIdet41/IgWRSCY9xHTguwDCoL6vEDau5VWmsXxsuXbT9GawuoYSuC6nbOSh@dPI@LXOrHrKtEVx7kz/8OA8ySThUg5keScvaf1QQLtHY8FyDiJ4x7Dk0dKGzjoh2YJYykklHrnYCDeOc4/hgCs4lqTyAAaBwA4AJdrximnUGhcCWr4iqmL4lQOxlrXjCgJZIK65YVEJkaQZ3gnNUdhqa8PWZFcDor/cbqJSUe9Qt0d5zicGHTpkq3STjXiSVmnHYovZOs3rXIz/TZdRstItrvYb1sHmdEM9sgioxHocd6AJAl8ial7ViJcyWSwViFOWhtczndoZ6hS2TWZYHI/GEAdGNqlZzFVjNtJkBRDRoCPX5WiE8TCI5KXkm4U3d8/qMHtnjkJk9J8sSuUy8NFpFDpR170DbYMGHROso9kTlfHBjXX84z7ffcJ57eQi4h/3fXBK0gWYgntlyALauVPtUeFDkICRGzrOZUsYl1ksTjZQLRFfB89o0UGoTTgBuE35H4tS8XlxuieACpvCHnjowlOwS5@Kyxe0gy4hPypQc7DG1ZJA8Qlq89ibWHXOgGrjNQzMQlKfoFWHNDsA8sk0RwBXTsbCf6UAYbwnzluKVCZON2OrlQ@igASHniBF@BIAzMIEV2MkNWPFV0m1bKtfR9LFtJU@u7NH5MkMdACun0dFI6lNypMWFd1Nn4oMjYJf6SaOkje0fLJeTbBH8KqkaV5loNHkH0t1wOVyZYSJQJjOVtGObFyIWiJlGx5yGLCh9ixbiiNY@OB7yEP2hSEpjQwBBXnKZUzdwCEhrT7ZB342CHLlen@f1jioLPPeMKq6Hw5JsiJmS8rSlPExXcPQsjxuWyzc2vMmNUKX7gSDiKdp73fxqL2D/cSTj/@qM/@4L6SMADc8M1xz@rpiiMO0DEocc3VigyAdNrUgr3eRyabhcznxL2KdQGHRjEGnbcu7mpaqik0NSfE6zUJCFs5ihoEbzNVEzSX0jDRzvMi39Ih/6H2atjz6lJx5nbsAUk8Zzwa65M53AoqRqZLu3RAAfcF/VIdGvKGDTFKLsw5MWT41Ahgxk9uOSOSXmcdFtHVHx3OT5UdWTgIn/7wSoo5aBkvSGNCixhiGH/SZoxQRuljDshIFbZn3zvArp@3WyUkuqa60y8YcHxUpfidiKBvqMa@DaR8Ne1n/eBMga8qa23Qv5hJ6Zh2d5Mc@qe@kwysyxKHhv@2UurBNiNLcfdxoWnPDV3NrvZrquM7NElRpymmok4sD1ep5EzSPGw@DvUHKp0iqqZCHOg8jYIdWCMNpO08zq@H@EiBbzUG3vDb4rb59jIdCJXNCPJNzDFZecxxUUti0D6aGk/wc) to require separating by `:`.

### How it works

```
Øa;ØD - Helper link. Yield a constant value "abc...xyz012...789"
Øa    - Yield "abc...xyz"
   ØD - Yield "0123456789"
  ;   - Concatenate

ŒlċⱮ¢¢żPƇ0ị$Þḣ⁵G - Main link. Takes a string S on the left
Œl               - Convert S to lowercase
    ¢            - Yield "abc...789"
   Ɱ             - For each character:
  ċ              -   Count occurrences in S
     ¢           - Yield "abc...789"
      ż          - Zip with occurrences
        Ƈ        - Keep characters where:
       P         -   There is at least 1 occurrence in S
           $Þ    - Sort by:
         0ị      -   Number of occurrences
             ḣ⁵  - Take the first 10
               G - Convert into a grid format
```

Comment: since all the other answers do output with a `:` character, I think it's  a better idea to post the 26 byte version.

Answer (score 0):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) v2.0a0 [`-R`](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14339/), 28 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

Yet another old challenge hindered by an unnecessarily cumbersome output format.

```
r\W v ü ñÊ®Î¬pZÊÃ¯A yù ®q":
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=2.0a0&flags=LVI&header=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&code=clxXIHYg/CDxyq7OuHBabMOvQSB5%2bSBtcSI6IA) (Note: I'm passing the input in the header here so it can be enclosed in backticks, allowing for the inclusion of both single & double quotes. Doing so, however, makes no difference to the code or byte count.)

```
r\W v ü ñÊ®Î¬pZÊÃ¯A yù ®q":      :Implicit input of string
r                                :Remove
 \W                              :  /[^A-Z0-9]/gi
    v                            :Lowercase
      ü                          :Group & sort
        ñ                        :Sort by
         Ê                       :  Length
          ®                      :Map each Z
           Î                     :  First character
            ¬                    :  Split
             p                   :  Push
              ZÊ                 :    Length of Z
                Ã                :End map
                 ¯               :Slice to
                  A              :  10th element
                    y            :Transpose
                     ù           :Left pad each sub array with spaces to the length of the longest and implicitly transpose back
                       ®         :Map
                        q":      :  Join with ": "
                                 :Implicit output joined with newlines
```

Comment: link says `Error: URI too long`

Comment: Fixed that earlier, @Razetime - thanks.