# Tips for golfing in APL

Tags: code-golf, tips, apl

I started one code golf challenge recently and it seems like the winner is GolfScript (surprise, surprise!). What's interesting is that there was another very strong competitor that had all chances to win over GolfScript. Its name is APL. I see a lot of answers written in APL here. It seems like this language is fairly efficient for code golfing, so I decide to ask for any code golfing tips you know for APL programs. Feel free to post some code examples. It is usually very interesting to see language in action.

Answer (score 28):

**Edit**: for people reading this who don't  know APL at all but want  to take it up, [Mastering Dyalog APL](http://www.dyalog.com/uploads/documents/MasteringDyalogAPL.pdf) is a *very* good resource.

1. Evaluation is strictly right-to-left. This includes setting variables, so take advantage of it.

   `2+a, 1+a←1`  -> `3 4`

   `a` is set to `1`, `1+a` evaluates to `2`, `a,2` evaluates to `1 2` and `2+1 2` evaluates to `3 4`.
2. Like C, `←` can be combined with a function, i.e. `a +← 3`. Unlike C, this is generic: `foo F← bar` sets `foo` to `F bar`. Somewhat unintuitively, as an expression this returns `bar`, not `F bar`.

   It works with anonymous functions too:

   ```
          a←0
          a+←3 ⋄ a
    3
          a+←3 ⋄ a
    6
          a { ⍵/'!' } ←4 ⋄ a
    !!!!
   ```
3. You can assign to an array: `A[3]←8`, like you'd expect. But you can also assign multiple items at the same time: `A[3 5 6]←9 1 4`, or even `A[3 5 6]←9`, setting them all to the same item. You can, of course, add a function to the `←` here too. The  function will then be applied to each element separately, as if you did `F¨`.
4. `⍨` is your friend, even if he doesn't look too happy about it.

   1. If `F` is dyadic, dyadic `⍨` switches the arguments: `a F b` <-> `b F⍨ a`. This comes in handy when golfing because it can save you from using braces:

      ```
      (F G H x) K y      <->     y K⍨ F G H x
      ```

      This does change the evaluation order, as the right hand is always evaluated before the left hand.
   2. If `F` is dyadic, *monadic* `⍨` applies the same argument to both sides of the function:

      ```
            5⍴5
      5 5 5 5 5
            ⍴⍨5
      5 5 5 5 5
      ```

      The argument is only evaluated once. This particularly comes in handy with outer products, i.e. to compare each value in an array with the other values in the same array, you can use `∘.=⍨` instead of having to do `x∘.=x←(whatever)`.
   3. If `F` is monadic, `⍨` does nothing, but it does separate the function from the argument. So it can still save you braces if the function is complex:

      ```
            {⍵+3}⍣5 6
            ∇{⍵+3}              
           ∇ ⍣ 5 6              
            ({⍵+3}⍣5)6
      21
            {⍵+3}⍣5⍨6
      21
      ```
5. [Learn the idioms!](https://aplwiki.com/wiki/FinnAPL_idiom_library) Then golf the idioms. For example:

   ```
    ((((1↑⍴X),⍴Y)↑X)^.=Y)⌿X
   ```

   can be mechanically transformed into:

   ```
    X⌿⍨Y^.=⍨X↑⍨(1↑⍴X),⍴Y
   ```

   and then further into:

   ```
    X⌿⍨Y^.=⍨X↑⍨(⊃⍴X),⍴Y
   ```

   `⊃` (first) being equivalent to `1↑` (take one) in this case. And possibly:

   ```
    X⌿⍨Y^.=⍨X↑⍨(≢X),⍴Y
   ```

   `≢` (tally) being equivalent to `⊃⍴` (the first element of the shape) for all but scalars.

Comment: Is there a way to get a free license beside having the raspberry pi version?

Comment: A legal way to get it, obviously.

Comment: @Fabinout: At dyalog.com you can download a free Windows version. Click "Download Zone" and then "Unregistered Download". It will nag you to register but otherwise it's fully functional and free and legal. If you're a student, you can get the normal version for free by filling out a form. If you don't live in a country where they ruin your life for pirating, well, you know what to do.

Comment: There is also Nars2000, an open source implementation that has many more features than Dyalog (and some bugs.) Some of its features come in handy for golfing, such as the prime number functions or multisets.

Comment: There is GNU APL.

Comment: @M.Alaggan: GNU APL is not very good though, especially for golfing. (It lacks proper d-fns, for one, and it certainly doesn't do trains or other fancy stuff.) If you want an open-source APL for golfing, ngn/apl is probably better. (Though that one's arguably a worse APL, as that one lacks the ∇-functions completely, but you don't use those for golfing anyway.)

Comment: @marinus Should it not be possible to contribute improvements to GNU APL so it kicks the same amount of arse? I have the program installed on Mac OS, how much is it lacking in terms of the language's coverage...?

Comment: +1 Excellent post. Regarding 4.3. `⊢` is better than `⍨` for separating arguments, as it works on dyadic functions too, and doesn't cause syntax errors if the function is strictly monadic.

Answer (score 19):

## [Trains](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7-93GzDqC08)

```
A(f g h)B      ←→  (A f B)g A h B  ⍝ fork
 (f g h)B      ←→  (  f B)g   h B  ⍝ fork
A(  g h)B      ←→         g A h B  ⍝ atop
 (  g h)B      ←→         g   h B  ⍝ atop
 (A g h)       ←→  ({A} g h)       ⍝ "Agh" fork
 (f g h k)     ←→  (f (g h k))     ⍝ 4-train
 (f g h k l)   ←→  (f g (h k l))   ⍝ 5-train, etc
 (f g h k l m) ←→  (f(g h(k l m))) ⍝ groups of 3 from the right, last could be 2
  f∘g B        ←→    f g B         ⍝ "compose" operator, useful in trains
A f∘g B        ←→  A f g B
```

Comment: Does that mean that for the sake of future readers, we shouldn't tell Oberon how to shorten it?

Comment: No, do as you normally would on PPCG. I'll remove that line after the expression reaches (what I believe to be) its shortest. It's an easy exercise - I don't think you personally would benefit from it.

Comment: I can get it down to 16, but I'm not using any of your tips, so maybe I'm way off.

Comment: @Adám well, you are using a train :) mine was similar but longer because I didn't think of ⎕ML

Comment: Isn't it "groups of 3 from the ***right***"?

Comment: @Adám right, I don't know what I was thinking...

Answer (score 11):

## Use `⊥` to combine multiplication with addition

```
(a×b)+C  ->  a⊥b,C
(C)+a×b  ->  a⊥b,C
(a×b)-C  ->  a⊥b,-C
```

Assumptions:

- `a` and `b` are terms that don't require further parentheses when used as a left argument
- `C` is an expression that may need parentheses when used as a left argument
- `a` `b` `C` evaluate to numeric scalars

Answer (score 10):

### Tricks for dealing with `/` and `⌿` in trains

When [using trains](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/43084/43319) you may want to use reductions `f/` like sum `+/` or even replicate reduction `//` . However, if your train has more parts to the left of the reduction you need parentheses to create an atop. Here are some tricks to save bytes.

#### Use `1∊` instead of monadic `∨/` or `∨⌿` on Boolean arrays

Task: Given two equal-length strings A and B, return 2 if any corresponding characters of A and B are equal, 0 otherwise. E.g. `A←'abc'` and `B←'def'` gives `0` and `A←'abc'` and `B←'dec'` gives `2`.

A dfn solution may be `A{2×∨/⍺=⍵}B` but you want to shorten it by going tacit. `A(2×∨/=)B` is not going to work because the rules of train formation parse this as `2 (× ∨/ =)` but you want `2 × (∨/=)` .

Observe that `∨/` or `∨⌿` on a Boolean vector (`∨/,` or `∨⌿,` for higher rank arrays) asks whether there is any 1 present, i.e. `1∊` , so we can write our train as `2×1∊=` .

Note that `∊` ravels its right argument, so you cannot use it to reduce each row or column separately.

#### Use `1⊥` instead of monadic `+/` or `+⌿`

Task: Given a list of lists L and an index N, return thrice the sum of the Nth list. E.g. `L←(3 1 4)(2 7)` and `N←1` gives `24`.

A dfn solution may be `N{3×+/⍺⊃⍵}L` but you want to shorten it by going tacit. `N(3×+/⊃)L` is not going to work because the rules of train formation parse this as `3(× +/ ⊃)` but you want `3 × (+/⊃)` .

Observe that evaluating a list of numbers in unary (base-1) is equivalent to summing the list because ∑{*a*, *b*, *c*, *d*} = *a* + *b* + *c* + *d* = (*a* × 1³) + (*b* × 1²) + (*c* × 1¹) + (*d* × 1⁰). Therefore `+/a b c d` is the same as `1⊥a b c d` , and we can write our train as `3×1⊥⊃` .

Note that on higher-rank arguments, `1⊥` is equivalent to `+⌿`.

#### Use `f.g` instead of `f/g` with scalar and/or vector arguments

Task: Given a list L and a number N, return the range 1 thorough the number of minimum division remainder when the elements of L are divided by N. E.g. `L←31 41 59` and `N←7` gives `1 2 3`.

A dfn solution may be `N{⍳⌊/⍺|⍵}L` but you want to shorten it by going tacit. `N(⍳⌊/|)L` is not going to work because the rules of train formation parse this as `⍳ (⌊/) |` but you want `⍳ (⌊/|)` .

The inner product `A f.g B` of scalar two functions when the arguments are scalars and/or vectors is the same as `f/ A g B` because both are `(A[1] g B[1]) f (A[2] g B[2]) f (A[3] g B[3])` etc., so we can write our train as `⍳⌊.|` .

Note that this does not work for higher-rank arrays.

#### Use `∊⊆` instead of `/` with Boolean left and simple vector right arguments

Task: Given a list L and a number N, filter the list so that only numbers greater than N remain. E.g. `L←3 1 4` and `N←1` gives `3 4`.

A dfn solution may be `N{(⍺<⍵)/⍵}L` but you want to shorten it by going tacit. `N(</⊢)L` is not going to work because the binding rules will parse this as `(</) ⊢` but you want `/` to be the function *replicate* rather than the operator *reduce*.

Dyadic `⊆` with a Boolean left argument partitions the right argument according to runs of 1s in the left argument, dropping elements indicated by 0s. This is almost what we want, save for the unwanted partitioning. However, we can get rid of the partitioning by applying monadic `∊`. Thus `{(⍺<⍵)/⍵}` can become `{∊(⍺<⍵)⊆⍵}` and thus we can write our train as `∊<⊆⊢` .

Note that this does not work for higher-rank arrays.

#### Use `∊⍴¨` instead of `/` with non-Boolean left and simple vector right arguments

Task: Given a list L, replicate Nth item N times. E.g. `L←3 1 4` gives `3 1 1 4 4 4`.

A dfn solution may be `{(⍳⍵)/⍵}L` but you want to shorten it by going tacit. `(⍳/⊢)L` is not going to work because the binding rules will parse this as `(⍳/) ⊢` but you want `/` to be the function *replicate* rather than the operator *reduce*.

Dyadic `⍴` combined with `¨` copies each element of the right argument according to the matching element in the left argument. This is almost what we want (e.g. `1 2 3⍴¨3 1 4 → (3)(1 1)(4 4 4)`). Then, we can get rid of the nesting by applying monadic `∊`. Thus `{(⍳⍵)/⍵}` can become `{∊(⍳⍵)⍴¨⍵}` and thus we can write our train as `∊⍳⍴¨⊢`.

Note that this does not work for higher-rank arrays.

#### Use `0⊥` instead of `⊢/` or `⊢⌿` with numeric arguments

Task: Given a list L and a number N, multiply the N with the rightmost element of L. E.g. `L←3 1 4` and `N←2` gives `8`.

A dfn solution may be `N{⍺×⊢/⍵}L` but you want to shorten it by going tacit. `N(⊣×⊢/⊢)L` is not going to work because the rules of train formation parse this as `⊣ (× ⊢/ ⊢)` but you want `⊣ × (⊢/⊢)` .

Observe that `0⊥` on a numeric array is the same as `⊢⌿` , so we can write our train as `⊣×0⊥⊢` .

Note that this selects the last major cell of higher-rank arrays.

Answer (score 10):

## Complex numbers

Often overlooked, they present wonderful opportunities to shorten expressions dealing with grids, mazes, fractals, or geometry.

```
0j1⊥¨    0j1⊥   ⍝ pair(s) of reals -> complex
11 9∘○¨  11 9○  ⍝ complex -> pair(s) of reals
|z0-z1          ⍝ distance between two points
0j1×z   0j¯1×z  ⍝ rotate by ±90° around (0,0)
0j1*⍳4          ⍝ the four cardinal directions
+z       -+z    ⍝ reflect across x or y axis
+\0,z           ⍝ sequence of steps -> path
¯2-/z           ⍝ path -> sequence of steps
0j1⊥¨n-⍳2⍴1+2×n ⍝ lattice centred on (0,0)
```

Answer (score 7):

## Indexing modulo vector length

`⊃i⌽a` is often shorter than the naive `⊃a[(≢a)|i]` or `a⊃⍨i|⍨≢a` (where `a` is a vector and `i` is an integer, and `⎕io` is 0)

a useful variation on this (thanks EriktheOutgolfer for pointing out) is: `I↑Y⌽⍨I×X` where `Y` is the concatenation of some length-`I` vectors and `X` is the index of the one we want to pick, for instance: `3↑'JanFeb...Dec'⌽⍨3×month`

Answer (score 7):

## Generate [A001057](http://oeis.org/A001057), [A130472](https://oeis.org/A130472), and many variations

A001057 is a simple sequence of alternating integers, starting with `0, 1, -1, 2, -2, 3, -3, ...`. A130472 is its negation, `0, -1, 1, -2, 2, -3, 3, ...`.

APL has a surprisingly short way to generate `n`th term or first `n` terms:

#### nth term of A001057 (0-indexed)

```
⎕IO←1
-/⍳
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT////1HfVE//R20TDLl09R/1bv6fBmQ/6u2DCHc1H1pv/KhtIpAXHOQMJEM8PIP/px1aoWCgYKhgpGCsYKJgqmCmYA4A)

#### nth term of A130472 (1-indexed)

```
⎕IO←0
-/⍳
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT////1HfVE//R20TDLh09R/1bv6fBmQ/6u2DCHc1H1pv/KhtIpAXHOQMJEM8PIP/px1aoWCoYKRgrGCiYKpgpmAOAA)

#### first n terms of A001057, leading 0 removed (`1, -1, 2, -2, ...`)

```
⎕IO←1
-\⍳
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT////1HfVE//R20TDLl0Yx71bv6fBmQ/6u2DCHc1H1pv/KhtIpAXHOQMJEM8PIP/pymYAwA)

#### first n terms of A130472 (`0, -1, 1, -2, 2, ...`)

```
⎕IO←0
-\⍳
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT////1HfVE//R20TDLh0Yx71bv6fBmQ/6u2DCHc1H1pv/KhtIpAXHOQMJEM8PIP/pymYAwA)

Applying various primitive functions to these sequences can give many interesting results which are shorter than other alternatives:

- `1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, ...`: With `⎕IO←1`, `|-\⍳n` is shorter than `n↑2/⍳n` in explicit form
- `0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, ...`: With `⎕IO←0`, `|-\⍳n` is shorter than `⌈2÷⍨⍳n` in explicit form
- `0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 3, ...`: With any `⎕IO`, `|0⌊-\⍳n` or `-0⌊-\⍳n` is shorter than any known alternatives, both tacit and explicit
- `0, -1, 0, -2, 0, -3, ...`: With any `⎕IO`, `0⌊-\⍳n`
- `1, 0, 2, 0, 3, 0, 4, ...`: With `⎕IO←1`, `0⌈-\⍳n`
- `0, 1, 1, 0` repeated: With `⎕IO←0`, `2|-\⍳n`
- `1, 1, 0, 0` repeated: With `⎕IO←1`, `2|-\⍳n`
- Reverse odd then forward even, e.g. `7 → 5 3 1 0 2 4 6`: `⍋-\⍳n` with `⎕IO←0`. `⎕IO←1` gives `7 → 6 4 2 1 3 5 7`.
- Permutation of 0 to `n-1`, alternating front and end, e.g. `7 → 0 6 1 5 2 4 3`: `n|-\⍳n` with `⎕IO←0`.
- First n terms of [A002620](http://oeis.org/A002620), `0, 1, 2, 4, 6, 9, 12, 16, 20, ...`: `-\-\⍳n` with `⎕IO←0` (`⎕IO←1` gives same sequence with leading zero removed), which is shorter than `⌊×⍨2÷⍨⍳n` with `⎕IO←1`.

Answer (score 5):

## Use `⍨`

#### Avoid parentheses

`⍨` (Commute) can save you bytes by avoiding parentheses. Whenever you have a function where the left argument needs to be parenthesised and the right argument does not, you can save a byte, e.g. `(A<B)÷C` → `C÷⍨A<B`.

#### Double arrays

To append a copy of an array to its end, use `,⍨A` or `⍪⍨A`.

#### Double numbers

Instead of using `2∘×` to double, you can use `+⍨` since it adds the argument to itself: `1+2∘×` → `1++⍨`.

#### Square numbers

Instead of using `2*⍨Y` to square, you can use `×⍨Y` since it multiplies the argument with itself: `2*⍨A+B` → `×⍨A+B`.

#### Random permutation

`?⍨N` will give you a random permutation of length `N`.

#### Self-classify

Find the indices of the first occurrence of each major cell with `⍳⍨A`

#### Count trailing 1s in a Boolean vector

Instead of `+/∧\⌽B` to count how many trailing 1s there are in `N` you can use `⊥⍨`.

#### Reverse composition

`A f∘g B` is `A f g B`, but if you want `(g A) f B`, use `f⍨∘g⍨`.

#### Reverse reduce

`f/ a1 a2 a3` is `a1 f (a2 f a3)`. If you want `(a1 f a2) f a3`, use `f⍨/⌽`.

#### Reverse scan

`f\ A B C` is
 `A  (A f B)  (A f (B f C))`.

`f⍨/∘⌽¨,\ A B C` is
 `A  (A f B)  ((A f B) f C)`.

`f⍨\⌽ A B C` is
 `((A f B) f C)  (B f C)  C`.

`⌽f/∘⌽¨,\⌽ A B C`. is
 `(A f (B f C))  (B f C)  C`.

Answer (score 5):

## Generate all nonempty subsequences

I recently discovered the expression `(⊢,,¨)\` in [this answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/211363/78410). If applied to a simple numeric or char vector, it does the following:

- `(⊢,,¨)/ v` gives all subsequences of `v` which include the last item.

```
  (⊢,,¨)/ '1234'
→ '1' (⊢,,¨) '2' (⊢,,¨) '3' (⊢,,¨) '4'
→ '1' (⊢,,¨) '2' (⊢,,¨) '4' '34'
→ '1' (⊢,,¨) '4' '34' '24' '234'
→ '4' '34' '24' '234' '14' '134' '124' '1234'
```

- `(⊢,,¨)\ v` applies `(⊢,,¨)/` to each prefix of `v`, giving all non-empty subsequences as a list of lists of vectors.

```
  (⊢,,¨)\ '1234'
→ '1' ('2' '12') ('3' '23' '13' '123') ('4' '34' '24' '234' '14' '134' '124' '1234')
```

The result can be flattened once using `⊃,/`, which gives the list of nonempty subsequences.

The order is the one imposed by the binary digits of `0..2^n-1`, grouped by the last item. You can use it whenever it suffices to generate all subsequences *in any order*. An interesting feature is that the original vector comes last, so you can also test e.g. "the original satisfies something but any smaller subsequence doesn't" using `</`.

Note that the order is different from plain binary/lexicographic/shortlex order, so it is hard to use when the challenge requires specific ordering of subsequences.

A nice application of this trick is "extract all subsequences of digits of a number": `⍎⍕(⊢,,¨)\⍕n`. Figuring out how it works is left as an exercise to the reader. :)

---

`(⊢,,¨)/` can be used to generate all subsequences (including empty), with the same order as binary order:

```
 ¯1↓¨¨(⊢,,¨)/'1234',0
→ '' '4' '3' '34' '2' '24' '23' '234' '1' '14' '13' '134' '12' '124' '123' '1234'
```

It's longer than the scan version, but it fits in a train better and might be useful when the order is important.

Comment: Very nice, is there a J equivalent of that subsequence trick?

Comment: @Jonah [Inception?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/211350/delicate-primes/211363#comment497749_211363) :P

Comment: Damn, hate being outgolfed by my former self.

Comment: @Jonah Actually, if you want to *reduce* over the subsequences instead of collecting them, J works equally well without explicit boxing.

Answer (score 4):

## Enumerate the characters in a string without `⍳≢`

Task: Given two strings, S and T, list the indices of their concatenation. E.g. `S←'abcd'` and `T←'xyz'` gives `1 2 3 4 5 6 7`.

A dfn solution may be `S{⍳≢⍺,⍵}T` but you want to shorten it by going tacit. `⍳≢,` is not going to work because the train parsing rules will parse this as `(⍳)≢(,)` but you want `(⍳≢),`.

Dyadic `⍋` with an empty left argument grades simple character arrays according to their current order, which is the same as `⍳≢`. Thus `{⍳≢⍺,⍵}`  can become `{⍬⍋⍺,⍵}` , so we can write our train as `⍬⍋,` .

Note that this does not work for numeric or mixed arrays.

Comment: Wow, didn't know that was a thing.

Answer (score 4):

## Constant functions

`=⍨` and `≠⍨` thanks to ngn.

Sometimes you just need a single value for each element of a list. While you might be tempted to use `{value}¨` (it is shorter to use `value⊣¨` or `value⍨¨`), you can get even shorter (using `⎕IO←0`) for some common values:

`¯1`s with `⍬⍸list`

`0`s with `⍬⍳list`

`1`s with `⍬⍷list`

Note that these only work on lists (though they may be nested). For higher-rank simple arrays, you can use the following to get all 0s and all 1s:

`1`s with `=⍨`

`0`s with `≠⍨`

If you set `⎕ML←0`, all numbers can be made into zeros (as if `0×`) with:

`∊`

If you only need a single number, you may be able to use monadic `≡` to get 1 or 0 instead of using `1⊣` or `0⊣`.

Note that Dyalog APL 18.0 added a constant operator which derives an ambivalent function that always returns the constant.

Comment: "_Sometimes you just need a single value for each element of a list._" - It may be noteworthy: when that value is the first element of the list, you can use `⊣\ `

Comment: @ngn I'd say that `⊣` and `⊢` with `/` and `⌿` merit a post of their own.

Answer (score 4):

## Constructing a long complex string (char vector)

[Original idea from @ngn.](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/53165231#53165231)

We can (ab)use rotation `n⌽` and enlist `∊` to shorten multiple concatenations:

```
'(',(⍺∇r),'|',(⍺∇s),')'
  → Rotate the last ')' to front and apply 1⌽
1⌽')(',(⍺∇r),'|',(⍺∇s)  (-1 byte)
  → We don't need parens at the end
1⌽')(',(⍺∇r),'|',⍺∇s    (-3 bytes in total)
  → Remove some concats(,) to use stranding instead and enlist(∊) later
1⌽∊')('(⍺∇r)'|',⍺∇s     (-4 bytes in total)
```

Note that we can't remove the last concat (`,`) in this case; otherwise the recursive call would be screwed up.

The `∊` trick can also be used to shorten construction of numeric arrays:

```
0,(⍳5),0
  →
∊0(⍳5)0   (-1 byte)
```

Answer (score 4):

## `⎕FMT`, the formatting function

[Dyalog documentation page](https://help.dyalog.com/latest/#Language/System%20Functions/Format%20Dyadic.htm)

In [user's answer to ascii art reflection,](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/216797/80214), they used an interesting builtin called `⎕FMT` to split text on a carriage return `\r`. I feel it has potential to save a lot of bytes in [ascii-art](/questions/tagged/ascii-art) and [string](/questions/tagged/string) challenges. It works very well with specific output/input specifications.

### Converting carriage return separated input directly to a matrix

A string with carriage returns can be converted directly to the matrix using monadic `⎕FMT`:

```
      ⎕FMT'Hello'(⎕UCS 13)'There'
 Hello 
 There 
      ⍴⎕FMT'Hello'(⎕UCS 13)'There'
2 7
```

It automatically pads the matrix with spaces, just like `↑`(mix).

---

`⎕FMT` can take arrays as arguments, and can apply a format specification to each of it's elements. However, the rank of the array must not exceed 2, and the format specifier must be a proper match for the elements.

There are multiple format specifiers allowed, which give different results:

```
rAw     Alphanumeric format
rEw.s   Scaled format
rqFw.d  Decimal format
rqG⍞pattern⍞    Pattern
rqIw    Integer format
Tn  Absolute tabulation
Xn  Relative tabulation
⍞t⍞     Text insertion
```

Where:

```
r   is an optional repetition factor indicating that the format phrase is to be applied to r columns of Y
q   is an optional usage of qualifiers or affixtures from those described below.
w   is an integer value specifying the total field width per column of Y, including any affixtures.
s   is an integer value specifying the number of significant digits in Scaled format; s must be less than w-1
d   is an integer value specifying the number of places of decimal in Decimal format; d must be less than w.
n   is an integer value specifying a tab position relative to the notional left margin (for T-format) or relative to the last formatted position (for X-format) at which to begin the next format.
t   is any arbitrary text excluding the surrounding character pair.  Double quotes imply a single quote in the result.
```

This allows a lot of useful tricks like format strings, ASCII tabulation, representation of arbitrary precision floating point values, and allow you to apply them cyclically to the contents of any matrix you choose. `⎕R` might be simpler to use in the case of a single line character vector, however.

These letters and their modifiers are discussed in more depth in the [Documentation](https://help.dyalog.com/latest/#Language/System%20Functions/Format%20Dyadic.htm).

Answer (score 3):

## Base Conversions

The function `b⊥v`, where `b` is a numeric base and `v` is a vector of digit values in that base, converts the vector `v` into its decimal (base-10) equivalent. If you want to convert a base-10 number into base `b`, a naïve approach would be to try to use `⊤`, but this requires figuring out (or calculating) how many digits the number would require in base `b`. Instead, use the Power operator `⍣` with a right operand of `¯1`: `(b∘⊥⍣¯1)`. This will invert the convert-to-decimal function to convert back to base `b` with exactly the minimum necessary number of digits in the base-b representation.

```
      2⊥1 1 0 1            ⍝ Convert the base-2 digit vector 1 1 0 1 to base-10
13
      (2∘⊥⍣¯1)13           ⍝ Convert 13 to its base-2 digit vector
1 1 0 1
```

Comment: Often, you don't need the `∘`:  `2(⊥⍣¯1)13`

Answer (score 3):

## Miscellaneous ideas

[Cross-post of my own J tip](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/205356/78410), because APL and J are so closely related that the two can share many ideas.

### If you're facing `-⍨/`, try `¯1⊥` instead

A common reason to use `-⍨/` is to reverse-subtract over a length-2 axis, e.g. given a 2-element array `x y`, compute `y-x`.

If this is the case, `¯1⊥` is an equivalent expression; just like `2⊥x y` computes `2x+y`, `¯1⊥x y` computes `-x+y`. While the two expressions have same length, `¯1⊥` is more likely to fit well in trains (due to being a dyadic primitive function with a left arg, vs `-⍨/` being a monadic derived function).

Note that, if you apply it to longer axis, `¯1⊥` gives you more similar result to `-/` (alternating sum), with negated result when the length is even.

### Construct a boolean square matrix where the border is ones/zeros and the interior is the opposite

This is mainly for large fixed-size matrices, say 6 by 6.

The matrix

```
1 1 1 1 1 1
1 0 0 0 0 1
1 0 0 0 0 1
1 0 0 0 0 1
1 0 0 0 0 1
1 1 1 1 1 1
```

can be generated by `∘.∨⍨` -ing the boolean vector `1 0 0 0 0 1`. The shortest known way to generate that vector is `6⍴5↑1`, so we can get the matrix above in just **9 bytes**:

```
∘.∨⍨6⍴5↑1
```

We can also get negation of it at no extra cost, by swapping `∨` with `⍱`! (Remember that APL has NOR `⍱` and NAND `⍲`; they are rarely needed, but definitely are a byte saver when we do need them.)

Answer (score 3):

## Repeat with intermediate results

This is originally @ngn's suggestion on [an APL answer of mine](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/207123/78410).

While APL has the power operator `⍣` which can repeat a function certain number of times, it cannot collect intermediate results on its own (unlike J's `^:` allowing `<n` or `i.n` right operand to do the job). Usually one would collect the intermediate results by using an auxiliary variable with modified assignment, or "hack" the left operand of `⍣` to something like `(⊣/,f¨)⍣n⊂x`, or naively write down the iterations like `{⍵(f⍵)(f f⍵)}x`.

But there is a clever way using scan `⊢∘f\`. Since `x ⊢∘f y` ignores `x` and applies `f` to `y` monadically, such a scan over `n` copies of `x` (enclosed if `x` is non-scalar) gives the results of `f` applied to `x` `0..n-1` times:

```
  ⊢∘f\n⍴⊂x
→ ⊢∘f\x x x ... x
→ (x)(x ⊢∘f x)(x ⊢∘f x ⊢∘f x) ...
→ x(f x)(f f x)(f⍣3⊢x) ... (f⍣(n-1)⊢x)
```

This is shorter than several alternatives (assume `x` is a complex expression):

```
{⍵(f⍵)(f f⍵)}x  ⍝ way too long for 2nd or higher iterations
(⊣/,f¨)⍣n⊂x     ⍝ shorter, but still long
⊢∘f\n⍴⊂x        ⍝ shortest
```

Interestingly, the scan expression ties when compared to various expressions that collect only zeroth and first iterations:

```
{⍵(f⍵)}x  ⍝ dfn
(⊂,⊂∘f)x  ⍝ tacit
y(f y←x)  ⍝ intermediate assignment; this wins if f is a single primitive
⊢∘f\2⍴⊂x  ⍝ scan
```

Also note that `⊢∘f\n⍴⊂` without the right arg is also a valid train.

---

As of Dyalog 18.0, you can write `f⍤⊢\` in place of `⊢∘f\`, which may or may not save bytes depending on the structure of `f`. (The conversion never *adds* bytes, so `f⍤⊢\` can be universally used.)

Comment: some times is better not be clever

Answer (score 2):

When you need to encode some arbitrary data (as is common in the Kolmogorov complexity questions), it can be achieved with a string of characters from the [atomic vector](https://aplwiki.com/wiki/Atomic_vector) `⎕AV`.

For example, to encode the array `256 13 16 127 128 168 192` in Dyalog APL:

```
⎕AV[256 13 16 127 128 168 192]      ⍝ the result is: ⍣%⍵⊣⌷∧⊤
```

Then to decode it:

```
⎕AV⍳'⍣%⍵⊣⌷∧⊤'
```

Adám's [SBCS](https://github.com/abrudz/SBCS) (single byte character set) also allows to encode some other characters (`⊆⍠⍤⌸⌺⍸`) as a single byte.

Comment: This, of course, only works if all your integers are 1≤n≤256 (or 0≤n≤255 with `⎕IO←0`). If all your integers are 1≤n≤26 (or 0≤n≤25 with `⎕IO←0`), you can use `⎕A` instead of `⎕AV`.

Comment: Another thing to note is that, if you're unlucky, you will get some chars like linefeed which can't be embedded in the string literal.

Comment: Well, I used it like this `∊(5 5 5⊤⊢)¯6+⎕AV⍳'ÏSSS9i⌶⌶⌶⌶RSÐSS'`. In this case each byte is decoded into three numbers in range 0≤k<5. So you get 45 numbers from 15 characters. But I had to use an offset -6 because I was "unlucky". (And, of course, added logic worsens the "compression rate".)

Comment: …Another trick here is to pick the string so that to avoid using `¨`, of course.

Answer (score 0):

## Encode into base b without digit limit

`b⊥⍣¯1`

Explanation:

```
  ⍣¯1 Do the inverse of...
b⊥    Decoding from base b (which is encoding to base b with no digit limit!!!)
```

Comment: what is digit limit?

Comment: @thejonymyster none, it's how many digits it can get

Comment: i had no idea apl normally had a digit limit for base conversion. that's insane

Comment: Because you need to specify a mixed radix there's a limit, for example `2⊤11` is `1`

Comment: Also high minus is the negative number identifier, which is different from monadic - (negation)