# Love Tester Code Golf

Tags: code-golf, string

Create program that counts the total number of letters common to two names, and finds the product of their lengths, to function as a "love tester."

Conditions: you may not get a 1:1 answer (being 3 out of 3, etc.) output.

### Input

Two names from STDIN or closest alternative.

### Output

Compute `x` as the total number of letters in common between the two names, ignoring case. Compute `y` as the product of the lengths of the names. Then the output, to STDOUT or closest alternative, is

```
Name1 and Name2 have x out of y chances of love.
```

### Examples

Input:

```
Wesley
Polly
```

Output:

```
Wesley and Polly have 2 out of 30 chances of love.
```

Wesley and Polly have 2 letters in common, `y` and `l`, and the product of their lengths is 6 * 5 = 30.

Input:

```
Bill
Jill
```

Output:

```
Bill and Jill have 3 out of 16 chances of love.
```

### Bonuses

- Subtract 30 bytes for using simplified fractions, i.e. `x out of y` is in fully reduced form.

### Scoring

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) answers will be scored in bytes with fewer bytes being better.

Comment: What should the output be for `Aaron\nAhmad`? Or `samename\nsamename`?

Comment: I'm unclear how you're counting total letters in common when letters repeat. If the names have `a` and `b` of some letter, do those count for `min(a,b)` repeats?

Comment: as @xor says, how are you counting repeated letters? From the second example, it appears you're counting repeated characters, so if the first example were reversed, then do you expect a different result?

Comment: Is it totally unrelated to [tag:kolmogorov-complexity]?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Pyth, 40 bytes

```
jd[z"and"Jw"have"/K-lzl.-rz0rJ0i=J*lzlJK"out of"/JiJK"chances of love.
```

The code is **70 bytes** long and qualifies for the **-30 bytes** bonus.

[Try it online.](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=jd%5Bz%22and%22Jw%22have%22%2FK-lzl.-rz0rJ0i%3DJ%2alzlJK%22out+of%22%2FJiJK%22chances+of+love.&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=Wesley%0APolly%0ABill%0AJill&input_size=2)

```
  [                        Begin an array and fill it with the following:
   z                         The first line of input.
   "and"                     That string.
   Jw                        The second line of input, saved in J.
   "have"                    That string.
           rz0rJ0              Convert both lines to lowercase.
         .-                    Remove the characters form the second string
                               from the first, counting multiplicities.
        l                      Get the length.
     -lz                       Subtract it from the length of the first line.
    K                          Save in K.
                  =J*lzlJ      Save the lines' lengths' product in J.
                 i       K     Compute the GCD of J and K.
   /                         The quotient of K and the GCD.
   "out of"                  That string.
   /JiJK                     The quotient of J and the GCD of J and K.
   "chances of love.         That string.
jd                         Join the elements, separated by spaces.
```

Answer (score 3):

## CJam, 55 bytes

```
ll]_~@_{'~,\elfe=}/.e<:+\:,:*]_2>~{_@\%}h;f/"and
have
out of
chances of love."N/.{}S*
```

The code is **85 bytes** long and qualifies for the **-30 bytes** bonus.

Try it online in the [CJam interpreter](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=ll%5D_~%40_%7B'~%2C%5Celfe%3D%7D%2F.e%3C%3A%2B%5C%3A%2C%3A*%5D_2%3E~%7B_%40%5C%25%7Dh%3Bf%2F%22and%0Ahave%0Aout%20of%0Achances%20of%20love.%22N%2F.%7B%7DS*&input=Bill%0AJill).

#### How it works

```
ll]      e# Read two lines and wrap them in an array.
_~       e# Copy the array and dump the lines on the stack.
@_       e# Rotate the array on top and push a copy.
{        e# For each line of the copy.
  '~,    e#   Push the array of all ASCII charcters up to '}'.
  \el    e#   Convert the line to lowercase.
  fe=    e#   Count the occurrences of each character in the line.
}/       e#
.e<      e# Vectorized minimum of the occurrences.
:+       e# Add to find the number of shared charaters.
\:,      e# Compute the length of each line.
:*       e# Push the product.
]_       e# Wrap the stack in an array and push a copy.
2>~      e# Discard the lines of the copy and dump the calculated integers.
{_@\%h}; e# Compute their GCD, using the Euclidean algorithm.
f/       e# Divide each element of the array by the GCD.
         e# This also splits the names, which won't affect printing.

"and
have
out of
chances of love."

N/       e# Split the above string at linefeeds.
.{}      e# Vectorized no-op. Interleaves the arrays.
S*       e# Join the results elements, separated by spaces.
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Dyalog APL](http://goo.gl/9KrKoM), <s>94</s> 91-30= 61 bytes

Usually APL golfing results in code that is more compact – but not more complex – than normal, but in this case I save chars in ugly ways:

```
{1↓(∊' ',¨⍵,⍪'and' 'have'),' love.',⍨∊((⊢÷∨/)(≢⊃∩/32|⎕ucs¨⍵),×/≢¨⍵),⍪'out of' 'chances of'}
```

`,⍪'out of' 'chances of'` create a 2×2 table of numbers (left) and texts (right)
`×/≢¨⍵` product of lengths
`32|⎕UCS¨⍵` harmonize upper- and lowercase UCS values
`≢⊃∩/` tally the intersection of the two sets
`⊢÷∨/` divide the tally and the product with their GCD
`,' love.',⍨∊` make it into a simple list and append *love.*
`⍵,⍪'and' 'have'` create a 2×2 table of names (left) and texts (right)
`∊' ',¨` prepend a space to each table cell and then make into simple list
`1↓` drop the initial superfluous space

Thanks to ngn for -3 bytes.

Comment: It appears this is only a function, whereas the OP specified input from STDIN and output to STDOUT (i.e. a full program rather than just a function).

Comment: @AlexA. APL doesn't have STDIN, but can issue a prompt to accept the two names in the format `'Wesley' 'Polly'`. If you think this would be more fair, feel free to append `⎕` (U+2395) to then very end of the line (after the `}`), and adjust the score to 65.

Answer (score 2):

## Javascript ES6, 123 bytes

```
(a,b)=>a+` and ${b} have ${[...a].map(x=>eval(`/${x}/i.test(b)&&c++`),c=0),c} out of ${a.length*b.length} chances of love.`
```

So much for "love"... I could really do with less bytes.

Run the code snippet in Firefox.

```js
x=(a,b)=>a+` and ${b} have ${[...a].map(x=>eval(`/${x}/i.test(b)&&c++`),c=0),c} out of ${a.length*b.length} chances of love.`
```

```html
<input id="a" value="Bill"><input id="b" value="Jill"><button onclick="o.innerHTML=x(a.value,b.value)">Calculate!</button>
<div id="o"></div>
```

Comment: It appears this is only a function, whereas the OP specified input from STDIN and output to STDOUT (i.e. a full program rather than just a function).

Answer (score 2):

## Julia, 129 bytes

The code is 159 bytes but it qualifies for the -30 bonus.

```julia
A,B=map(chomp,readlines())
a,b=map(lowercase,[A,B])
L=length
r=Rational(L(a∩b),L(a)L(b))
print("$A and $B have $(r.num) out of $(r.den) chances of love.")
```

This could probably be made shorter by *not* going for the bonus, but I wanted to show off Julia's rational number type. :)

Ungolfed:

```julia
# Read two names from STDIN on separate lines
A, B = map(chomp, readlines())

# Construct their lowercase equivalents
a, b = map(lowercase, [A, B])

# Construct a rational number where the numerator is the
# length of the intersection of a and b and the denominator
# is the product of the lengths
r = Rational(length(a ∩ b), length(a) * length(b))

# Tell us about the love
print("$A and $B have $(r.num) out of $(r.den) chances of love.")
```

The `Rational()` function constructs an object of type `Rational` which has fields `num` and `den`, corresponding to the numerator and denominator respectively. The benefit of using this type here is that Julia does the reduction for us; we don't have to worry about reducing the fraction ourselves.

Answer (score 2):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 42 - 30 = 12 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
±à>mª≈◄ΣÇyⁿ`à>²CΔ7ù«▀╦X╠;7╣ⁿ¡♣ë╩■B§F»é▲Y∩«
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=f1853e6da6f711e48079fc60853efd43ff3797aedfcb58cc3b37b9fcad0589cafe421546af821e59efae&i=Wesley%0APolly)

Fractions are great to have.

Answer (score 1):

## Dyalog APL, 84-30= 54 bytes

`∊' and ' ' have' 'out of' 'chances of love.',¨⍨⊢,{+/⌊⌿+⌿↑1↑¨⍨-32|⍉⎕ucs↑⍵}(,÷∨)(×/≢¨)`

This is a [train](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/17665/tips-for-golfing-in-apl#answer-43084), inspired by [Adám's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/60459/love-tester-code-golf#answer-60633).

`×/≢¨` product of the lengths

`{+/⌊⌿+⌿↑1↑¨⍨-32|⍉⎕ucs↑⍵}` chances of love

`(,÷v)` the concatenation divided by the GCD; between the above two expressions, this reduces the fraction

`⊢,` prepend the names

`,¨⍨` shuffles the strings on the left with the values on the right

`∊` flatten

---

"Chances of love" computation in detail:

`{+/⌊⌿+⌿↑1↑¨⍨-32|⍉⎕ucs↑⍵}
                     ↑⍵   arrange the names in a 2×N matrix, pad with spaces
                 ⎕ucs     take ascii codes
                ⍉         transpose the matrix as N×2
             32|          modulo 32 to case-fold
        1↑¨⍨-             for each X create a vector 0 0...0 1 of length X
       ↑                  arrange into a 3d array, pad with 0s
     +⌿                   1st axis sum, obtain freqs per letter and per name
   ⌊⌿                     1st axis min, obt. nr of common occurrences per letter
 +/                       sum`

[test](http://tryapl.org/?a=f%u2190%u220A%27%20and%20%27%20%27%20have%27%20%27out%20of%27%20%27chances%20of%20love.%27%2C%A8%u2368%u22A2%2C%7B+/%u230A%u233F+%u233F%u21911%u2191%A8%u2368%AF32%7C%u2349%u2395ucs%u2191%u2375%7D%28%2C%F7%u2228%29%28%D7/%u2262%A8%29%20%u22C4%20f%27Wesley%27%20%27Polly%27&run), [test2](http://tryapl.org/?a=f%u2190%u220A%27%20and%20%27%20%27%20have%27%20%27out%20of%27%20%27chances%20of%20love.%27%2C%A8%u2368%u22A2%2C%7B+/%u230A%u233F+%u233F%u21911%u2191%A8%u2368%AF32%7C%u2349%u2395ucs%u2191%u2375%7D%28%2C%F7%u2228%29%28%D7/%u2262%A8%29%20%u22C4%20f%27Bill%27%20%27Jill%27&run)

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 44-30 = 14 bytes

```
ÃÙgD¹g²g*DŠ¿U)X/`s¹²“ÿ€ƒ ÿ€¡ ÿ€Ä€‚ ÿÒï€‚„Î.“
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//cPPhmekuh3amH9qUruVydMGh/aGaEfoJxYd2Htr0qGHO4f2PmtYcm6QApg8thNCHW4DEo4ZZQN7hSYfXQziPGuYd7tMDavn/Pzy1OCe1kisgPyenEgA)

Answer (score 0):

## Python 2.7, 161 bytes

```
import string;r=raw_input;a,b=r(),r();print'%s and %s have %i out of %i chances of love'%(a,b,sum(map(lambda c:c in a and c in b,string.letters)),len(a)*len(b))
```

Test it here : http://ideone.com/jeoVgV

And here is a version that simplifies the fraction :

```
import string,fractions;r=raw_input;a,b=r(),r();F=fractions.Fraction(sum(map(lambda c:c in a and c in b,string.letters)),len(a)*len(b))
print'%s and %s have %i out of %i chances of love'%(a,b,F.numerator,F.denominator)
```

Unfortunately this one's score is 219-30=189...

Comment: Here is a compiler you can add: http://ideone.com/jeoVgV

Answer (score 0):

## Java 8, 192 bytes

```java
BiFunction y=(a,b)->a+" and "+b+" have "+(""+a).chars().filter(c->(""+b).toUpperCase().indexOf(c>'Z'?c-32:c)>=0).count()+" out of "+(""+a).length()*(""+b).length()+" chances of love.";
```

Ex:

```java
System.out.println(y.apply("Bill","Jill"));
System.out.println(y.apply("Wesley","Polly"));
```

Answer (score 0):

## Ruby, 153 bytes

Longer than I expected. I don't know if the 30 bytes bonus applies for this.

```
d=[];2.times{d<<gets.chop<<$_.downcase.chars<<$_.length-1};$><<"#{d[0]} and #{d[3]} have #{d[2]-(d[1]-d[4]).length} out of #{d[2]*d[5]} chances of love."
```

Comment: Could you please add a link to a compiler? (I recommend Ideone)