# Find the nth base-b digit of (b^k-1)^-2

Tags: code-golf, math, number, base-conversion

### Task

Your task is simple. Write a program or function which takes three positive integer arguments \$n\$, \$k\$, and \$b\$ in any order, such that \$2 ≤ b ≤ 36\$, and returns or outputs the nth (1-indexed) base-\$b\$ digit after the decimal point of the rational number (\$b^k-1)^{-2}\$.

The output must be correct for \$n\$ and \$b^k\$ up to the largest integer value your language of choice can natively represent. This will most likely mean that you cannot depend on built-in floating point representations to exactly represent the base-\$b\$ expansion of the number.

Fortunately, this class of numbers has a rather nice property [Spoiler Alert!]: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=daro6K6mym8

### Rules

- Base conversion built-ins are permitted.
- Built-in spigot functions capable of indexing digits of exactly represented real numbers are forbidden.
- The digits for base \$b\$ are the first \$b\$ symbols in the string `0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ` or alternately `0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz`. Your choice.

### Winning

This is code golf. Shortest solution in bytes wins.

### Test Cases

(You need not be able to correctly handle all of these if \$n\$ or \$b^k\$ overflows your integer datatype.)

```
Input (n,k,b)               Output
9846658,3,31                5
789234652,4,10              4
4294967295,17,2             1
4294967254,72,15            B
137894695266,3,30           H
184467440737095595,6,26     L
184467440737095514,999,36   T
```

Comment: Is it a part of this challenge to watch the 10-min video and find out what that nice property is? :-)

Comment: Not necessarily...you could look at a few of those numbers and figure out the property for yourself. I would definitely encourage this method. Hence the spoiler alert.

Comment: IMO, it'd probably be better to standardize the n,k,b variables such that testing them, your input is identical.

Comment: I found a bug in my code. It cost me 10 bytes to fix it :-(

Comment: You still win by default.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## [APL (Dyalog Extended)](https://github.com/abrudz/dyalog-apl-extended), 31 bytes

```apl
(⎕D,⎕A)⊃⍨⊃⎕⌽¯1⌽,⍉⎕(⊣⊤⍳⍤*~*-2⍨)⎕
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JYw9CsJAEIVr5yRJSCD7m91SEMFK8AaBJDZBLSy0sRH8CW6wyQlMYWdhbeNR5iLrBJuP9968efmmTop9Xq@XSbnblquiLDy23WyOp3sKpKYLUoybDPByrnxA0SQmjENsjuieA9sOb5/vixFjdFfyATYPbHp0b3R9dIgSTtWQDp5W/KgCAYKBNVJrZYC8BJZCZiwXUis@JCwDDpJbaXXGrYL/UwpMUE1qq7jW8AM)

A full program that takes numbers from stdin in the order of `k`, `b`, `n`. `n` being 1-based cost me 3 bytes `¯1⌽`.

#### How it works

The main mathematical trick is well explained in [Neil's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/70656/78410). The gist is that the repeating part of the base-`b` representation consists of length-`k` base-`b` digits of `0..b^k-1`, except `b^k-2`.

This answer implements it very literally: list all repeating base-`b` digits, cyclically fetch `n`th digit from it, and convert it to `0-9A-Z`. Cyclic indexing uses [ngn's trick](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/177911/78410).

```apl
⎕(...)⎕     ⍝ Take k (the right) and b (the left) from stdin
  ⍳⍤*~*-2⍨  ⍝ Create a list of 0..b^k-1, and remove the number b^k-2
  ⊣⊤        ⍝ Convert these numbers into base-b digits into columns
,⍉          ⍝ Transpose and flatten to get the repeating base-b digits
⊃⎕⌽¯1⌽      ⍝ Take n from stdin and get the nth digit cyclically
(⎕D,⎕A)⊃⍨   ⍝ Convert the number to the corresponding char in 0-9A-Z
```

Comment: ah so you're the one that upvoted the question out of nowhere

Answer (score 4):

### ES7, 59 bytes

```
(n,k,b)=>(1+!(n/k%(d=b**k-1))+d+--n/k%d).toString(b)[n%k+1]
```

ES6-compatible version for people who don't have Firefox Nightly:

```
(n,k,b)=>(1+!(n/k%(d=Math.pow(b,k)-1))+d+--n/k%d).toString(b)[n%k+1]
```

Explanation (possibly the same as in the video; I haven't watched it):

I start with the simple case of (b-1)<sup>-1</sup> in b-ary notation. Obviously b-1 does not divide 1, so we add an extra zero after the b-ary point. 1.0 divided by b-1 is 0.1 remainder 0.1. This continues in the obvious manner to give (b-1)<sup>-1</sup> as being 0.111... in b-ary notation.

(b<sup>k</sup>-1)<sup>-1</sup> is not much harder; the only difference is that we have to add k extra zeros before we can divide. We then have 1.00...00 [k zeros] divided by b<sup>k</sup>-1 is 0.00...01 remainder 0.00...01 [k-1 zeros]. This obviously continues to give (b<sup>k</sup>-1)<sup>-1</sup> as being 0.00...0100...0100... [k-1 zeros each time] in b-ary notation.

To form (b<sup>k</sup>-1)<sup>-2</sup> it merely suffices to divide (b<sup>k</sup>-1)<sup>-1</sup> itself by b<sup>k</sup>-1. Again we consider k digits each time. The first k digits are just 00..01 which obviously don't divide by b<sup>k</sup>-1, so the first k digits of the result are 00..00. The next k digits are of course also 00..01 so we divide b<sup>k</sup>+1 by b<sup>k</sup>-1 giving 1 remainder 2. Considering the next k digits we divide 2b<sup>k</sup>+1 by b<sup>k</sup>-1 giving 2 remainder 3. At each step we have mb<sup>k</sup>+1 = m(b<sup>k</sup>-1)+m+1. This continues until we reach (b<sup>k</sup>-3)b<sup>k</sup>+1 which divides by b<sup>k</sup>-1 giving b<sup>k</sup>-3 remainder b<sup>k</sup>-2. At this point (b<sup>k</sup>-2)b<sup>k</sup>+1 is equal to (b<sup>k</sup>-1-1)(b<sup>k</sup>-1+1)+1 which can be written as (b<sup>k</sup>-1)<sup>2</sup>-1<sup>2</sup>+1 or simply (b<sup>k</sup>-1)<sup>2</sup>, which therefore divides exactly by b<sup>k</sup>-1.

We therefore have managed to divide the first k(b<sup>k</sup>-1) digits of (b<sup>k</sup>-1)<sup>-1</sup> by b<sup>k</sup>-1 exactly, and the sequence therefore repeats at this point. In effect, (b<sup>k</sup>-1)<sup>-2</sup> is formed by concatenating all the (zero-padded) k-digit numbers from 0 to b<sup>k</sup>-3, plus b<sup>k</sup>-1 itself, and then repeating.

My solution divides n-1 by k and then reduces modulo b<sup>k</sup>-1 to find the appropriate k-digit number. If n is an exact multiple of k(b<sup>k</sup>-1) it adds 1 to the number because the last k-digit number is b<sup>k</sup>-1 itself. Having found the number it then adds b<sup>k</sup>, which has the effect of forcing the base conversion to generate any required leading zeros. The appropriate digit of the converted number is then returned.

Comment: what do i need to do to test this?

Comment: @quintopia Does http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/8252/17602 help?

Comment: Okay, it tests fine. I wish more languages had an equivalent to that `toString`!

Answer (score 0):

### Python 2, 110 bytes

```
n,k,b=input()
n=~-n%(k*b**k-k)
print"0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"[(n/k+(n/k+2==b**k))/b**(k-1-n%k)%b]
```

Maybe answering it myself (poorly) will bring this EASY question some more attention. Usually easy questions get more answers...