# g​o​l​f​ ​a​t​a​n​2

Tags: code-golf, math, geometry, trigonometry

Sometimes it really is a struggle to convert Cartesian coordinates `(x,y)` to Polar coordinates `(r,phi)`. While you can calculate `r = sqrt(x^2+y^2)` quite easily, you often need some distinction of cases when calculating the angle `phi` because `arcsin`,`arccos` and `arctan` and all other trigonometric functions have a co-domain that each only spans *half* the circle.

In many languages there are built-ins for converting rectangular to polar coordinates, or at least have an `atan2` function, which - given `(x,y)` - calculate the angle `phi`.

#### Task

Your task is to write a program/function that takes two (floating point, not both zero) Cartesian coordinates `(x,y)`, and outputs the corresponding polar angle `phi`, where `phi` has to be in degrees, radians or grades (with *grades* I mean *gradians* which are 1/400 of the full circle), whichever is more convenient for you.

The angle is measured in positive orientation, and we have the zero angle for `(1,0)`.

#### Details

You may not use built-ins that calculate the angle `phi` given two coordinates, including `atan2`,`rect2polar`,`argOfComplexNumber` and similar functions. However you can use the usual trigonometric functions and their reverses, that only take one argument. Any unit symbols are optional.

The radius `r` must be non-negative, and `phi` must be in the range `[-360°, 360°]` (it does not matter whether you output `270°` or `-90°`).

#### Examples

```
Input       Output
(1,1)       45°
(0,3)       90°
(-1,1)      135°
(-5,0)      180°
(-2,-2)     225°
(0,-1.5)    270°
(4,-5)      308.66°
```

Comment: Required precision in rads/degrees?

Comment: I'd say accurate to about machine precision, depending on what implementation you use (float/double/whatever)

Comment: May we take input as a single complex number?

Answer (score 9):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 12 bytes

```
yYy/X;0G0<?_
```

The result is in radians.

[Try it online!](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=eVl5L1g7MEcwPD9f&input=MAoz) Or [verify all test cases](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=YCAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAlIGxvb3AgdG8gcmVhZCBhbGwgaW5wdXRzCnlZeS9YOzBHMDw_XyAgICAgJSBBQ1RVQUwgQ09ERQpdRFQgICAgICAgICAgICAgICUgZW5kIGlmLCBkaXNwbGF5LCBjbG9zZSBsb29w&input=MQoxCjAKMwotMQoxCi01CjAKLTIKLTIKMAotMS41CjQKLTU).

#### Explanation

MATL doesn't have an `atan` function (it has `atan2`, but it can't be used for this challenge). So I resorted to `acos`.

```
y     % Take x, y implicitly. Duplicate x onto the top of the stack
Yy    % Compute hypothenuse from x, y
/     % Divide x by hypothenuse
X;    % Arccosine (inverse of cosine function)
0G    % Push y again
0<    % Is it negative?
?_    % If so, change sign. Implicitly end conditional branch. Implicitly display
```

Comment: Does matl really have no absolute value builtin? If it does, you could probably use it to replace `0<?_`, shaving off a few bytes

Comment: @Zwei It has ([`|`](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=fA&input=Wy0yLjMgLTEuMSA0LjVd)). But here I'm changing sign of the result based on the sign of _the second input_, `y`. Besides, `y` can be `0`, so I can't multiply by `y/abs(y))`

Answer (score 5):

### JavaScript (ES6), <s>50</s> 40 bytes

```
(x,y)=>(Math.atan(y/x)||0)+Math.PI*(x<0)
```

The result is in radians. Edit: Saved 10 bytes when I noticed that it's allowed for the result to be between -90° and 270°. Previous version with `-Math.PI<=result<Math.PI`:

```
(x,y)=>(Math.atan(y/x)||0)+Math.PI*(x<0)*(y>0||-1)
```

Comment: What units? Please put them into your answer.

Comment: What's the `||0` for?

Comment: @l4m2 For the `x=y=0` case.

Answer (score 4):

## MATLAB / Octave, 24 bytes

```
@(x,y)atan(y/x)+pi*(x<0)
```

This defines an anonymous function that produces the result in radians.

[Try it on ideone](http://ideone.com/u9ePZD).

Answer (score 3):

## Javascript ES6, 54 bytes

```
(x,y,m=Math)=>x<0&!y?m.PI:m.atan(y/(m.hypot(x,y)+x))*2
```

Uses radians.

Answer (score 2):

## Python 3, <s>75</s> 67 bytes

8 bytes thanks to Dennis.

```python
from math import*
lambda x,y:pi*(x<0==y)or atan(y/(hypot(x,y)+x))*2
```

[Ideone it!](http://ideone.com/hWhW2j)

Comment: Do you have to write out `and` and `or`?

Comment: What else can I do?

Comment: Perhaps use `&&` and `||` or something similar?

Comment: @flawr Python only has `and` and `or`.

Comment: `pi*(x<0==y)or atan(y/(hypot(x,y)+x))*2` saves a few bytes.

Comment: How is then `&` different from `and` here?

Comment: @flawr: `&` is a bitwise operator.

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](http://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 11 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
<0×ØP+÷@ÆṬ¥
```

Output is in radians. Jelly had a sign bug in its division atoms which was fixed.

[Try it online!](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=PDDDl8OYUCvDt0DDhuG5rMKl&input=&args=MQ+MQ) or [verify all test cases](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=PDDDl8OYUCvDt0DDhuG5rMKlCsOnIsOGwrBH&input=&args=MSwgMCwgLTEsIC01LCAtMiwgICAgMCwgIDQ+MSwgMywgIDEsICAwLCAtMiwgLTEuNSwgLTU) (converted to degrees).

#### How it works

```
<0×ØP+÷@ÆṬ¥  Main link. Left argument x. Right argument: y

<0           Compare x with 0.
  ×ØP        Multiply the resulting Boolean by Pi.
          ¥  Combine the two links to the left into a dyadic chain.
      ÷@     Divide y by x.
        ÆṬ   Apply arctan to the result.
     +       Add the results to both sides.
```

Comment: Does bugfixing count as making an answer non-competing? That seems odd. If the correct behavior was already specced, the bugfix should be unrelated. (After all, who knows how many other answers you made noncompeting by fixing an unnoticed edge-case?)

Comment: @MarioCarneiro On PPCG, [the interpreter defines the language](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/7833). This is mainly because it's difficult to judge intentions (and most esolangs don't really have a concise spec), while you can't argue with an implementation. Note that altering the interpreter doesn't affect the validity of older answers. They only have to work in some published version of the interpreter.

Comment: I mean that you may have changed the behavior of older answers on some input which was not attempted at the time. How does PPCG handle bad test cases discovered after the fact?

Comment: If test cases prove to be insufficient, more test cases are added. Solutions are expected for all valid inputs, not just the test cases in the question. Re: bug fix. My interpreter only produced the wrong sign for division by **0** (`-1÷0` gave `inf` instead of `-inf`), so it's unlikely to affect most challenges.

Answer (score 2):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), <s>12</s> 10 [bytes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9429/43319)<sup>[SBCS](https://github.com/abrudz/SBCS)</sup>

-2 thanks to ngn.

Anonymous tacit infix function. Uses [alephalpha's formula](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/122685/48198). Takes `x` as right argument and `y` as left argument. Result is in radians.

```apl
11○∘⍟0J1⊥,
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///39Dw0fTuRx0zHvXON/AyfNS1VOd/2qO2CY96@x71TfX0f9TVfGi98aO2iUBecJAzkAzx8Az@b6iQpmDIZQwkDbhA7EPrDbkMwLQp16H1RmCWEZBlqGcKVgMUB9ImAA)

`,` concatenate the `y` and `x`

`0J1⊥` Evaluate as base *i* digits (i.e. y*i*¹+x*i*⁰)

`⍟` natural logarithm of that

`∘` then

`11○` imaginary part of that

Comment: [tip](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/170120)

Comment: `11○∘⍟` -> `12○`

Comment: @ngn *You may not use … `argOfComplexNumber`*

Comment: oh... i see, sorry

Answer (score 1):

## x86 machine language (32 bit Linux), <s>25</s> 13 bytes (noncompeting)

```
0:       55                      push   %ebp
1:       89 e5                   mov    %esp,%ebp
3:       dd 45 08                fldl   0x8(%ebp)
6:       dd 45 10                fldl   0x10(%ebp)
9:       d9 f3                   fpatan  
b:       c9                      leave
c:       c3                      ret
```

To [try it online](https://tio.run/nexus/c-gcc#VYzRaoMwGIXvfYqDZZB0UVZDocO6uz3CrpZdpNFEi8ahKQijr74sme1F4f/PORw@zqazqr/UzXF2dTfm7VuyuTeDdG0ovBrt7KBaOeH8@VWlH2I5vIql2QvO9@/itFrxIpY61JqLRQVXPC2TzjoMsrOE/iSAHieCeryc@ga6ynYl9DHKc5XvQBGRR8igQsRMxMwDBnxPYV0TpE95obFKPGFTBs1gGKSTtiAxUwZC1lWypbfEVqP0TANkKGj5v31N4l@9/1W6l2b2WT/4bODFHw), compile the following C program (don't forget `-m32` flag on x86_64)

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
const char j[]="U\x89\xe5\335E\b\335E\20\xd9\xf3\xc9\xc3";
int main(){
  for(double f=-1;f<1;f+=.1){
    for(double g=-1;g<1;g+=.1){
      printf("%.2f %.2f %f %f\n",f,g,atan2(f,g),((double(*)(double,double))j)(f,g));
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## Mathematica, 16 bytes

I am not sure whether `Log` is considered as a built-in that calculates the angle given two coordinates.

```
N@Im@Log[#+I#2]&
```

#### Example:

```
In[1]:= N@Im@Log[#+I#2]&[1,1]

Out[1]= 0.785398

In[2]:= N@Im@Log[#+I#2]&[4,-5]

Out[2]= -0.896055
```

Comment: That is a clever idea! Could you add an example how to call this function?

Answer (score 1):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 10 bytes

Anonymous tacit infix function. Uses [alephalpha's formula](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/122685/43319). Takes `x` as left argument and `y` as right argument. Result is in radians.

```
11 o.^.@j.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/r/P83WytBQIV8vTs8hS@//f0OFNAVDLgMgacwVD@HEmwIpA654IyAVbwSWizfUM@UyATFMAQ)

`j.` calculate `x` + `y`×*i*

`@` then

`^.` natural logarithm of that

`11 o.` imaginary part of that

Answer (score 0):

## Pyth, 26 bytes

```
AQ?|>G0Hy.tcH+@s^R2Q2G5.n0
```

`theta` in radians.

[Test suite.](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=AQ%3F%7C%3EG0Hy.tcH%2B%40s%5ER2Q2G5.n0&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=%281%2C1%29%0A%280%2C3%29%0A%28-2%2C-2%29%0A%28-2%2C0%29%0A%282%2C0%29&debug=0)

Answer (score 0):

## , 13 chars / 17 bytes

```
î<0)*π+МǍ í/î
```

<kbd>[Try it here (ES6 browsers only).](http://molarmanful.github.io/ESMin/interpreter3.html?eval=true&input=%5B-5%2C0%5D&code=%C3%AE%3C0)*%CF%80%2B%D0%9C%C7%8D%20%C3%AD%2F%C3%AE)</kbd>

Uses `(x<0)*pi+tan(y/x)`.

Answer (score 0):

## Python 3, 65 bytes

```
from math import*
f=lambda x,y:atan(y/x if x else y*inf)+pi*(x<0)
```

This outputs radians in the range `[-π/2, 3π/2)`, equivalent to `[-90, 270)` degrees.

Answer (score 0):

## Axiom, 58 bytes

```
f(a,b)==(a=0 and b=0=>%i;sign(b)*acos(a*1./sqrt(a^2+b^2)))
```

test (i use only acos() it returns radiants )

```
(40) -> [[a,b,f(a,b)*180/%pi] for a in [1,0,-1,-5,-2,0,4] for b in [1,3,1,0,-2,-1.5,-5] ]
   (40)
   [[1.0,1.0,45.0], [0.0,3.0,90.0], [- 1.0,1.0,135.0], [- 5.0,0.0,180.0],
    [- 2.0,- 2.0,- 135.0], [0.0,- 1.5,- 90.0],
    [4.0,- 5.0,- 51.3401917459 09909396]]
                                            Type: List List Complex Float
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 59 bytes

```python
lambda x,y:acos(x/hypot(x,y))/(-1,1)[y>0]
from math import*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TczRDoIgGIbhc6@CzRNooIBi1lY3Uh1QzeEmwogDuXqqMcX/8PnffTZ4ZWYeh8s9TlI/3xIsOJzly3zgUqtgjYc/QKiGhGGGbuFKH8XgjAZaegVGbY3zh2jdOHswwH8D0pWtKFamuNn4RDcmOS9Zk3MiMN283/UcE54eJef7ecIqgZIfc99iItadhvZV18Uv)

Outputs in radians in range `[-pi,pi)`