# ASCII art reflection

Tags: code-golf, ascii-art

In this challenge, you will be given a text block, and you need to perform reflection on the text.

## Input:

1. A string to be reflected. The text may *not* be supplied as an array whose elements are the lines of text. For example, `"ab\ncd"` and `['a','b','\n','c','d']` are allowed, but `['ab','cd']` or `[['a','b'],['c','d']]` are not. You can assume that all of the lines have the same number of characters (padded with whitespace where needed).
2. A boolean where `True` indicates Y reflection and `False` indicates X reflection

The two inputs can be passed in any order.

## Output:

The reflected string. The characters do not change, only their position. The resulting image block should be aligned to the top left (the first row and column must each contain a non-whitespace character). Trailing whitespace (on any of the lines) is allowed.

## Test cases:

```
False
  o /
--|/
  |
 / \

/ o
 /|--
  |
 \ /
```

---

```
True
  o /
--|/
  |
 / \

 / \
  |
--|/
  o /
```

---

```
True
text

text
```

---

```
False
text

txet
```

---

```
True
P
P
C
G

G
C
P
P
```

---

```
False
P
P
C
G

P
P
C
G
```

---

```
True
abcde
fghij
kl mn
opqrs
tuvwx

tuvwx
opqrs
kl mn
fghij
abcde
```

This is a [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so answer with the shortest answer in your favorite language!

Comment: Can we take the boolean in any format (eg. `1` and `0`) or we must use `True` and `False`?

Comment: @TùxCräftîñg any truthy/falsy value is fine.

Comment: @PeterTaylor I don't see how this is unclear even for languages where strings are arrays. In that case it maens that you can't have subarrays for each line, you must have a flat list of characters.

Comment: @PeterTaylor I'm specifically disallowing arrays, where each element in the array is a line of text.  Aka, "ab\ncd" is fine, ["a","b","\n","c","d"] is fine, but ["ab","cd"] or [["a","b"], ["c","d"]] is not

Comment: _Putting each line in an array is not allowed_ For some languages that would be the only way, if they don't allow multiline strings

Comment: @PeterTaylor is that better?

Comment: @LuisMendo If a language natural string representation can't contain an `\n` I would go as far as to say that it's not a string representation.

Comment: Are extra trailing spaces allowed in output lines?

Comment: @LuisMendo yes.

Comment: So i'm confused, doesn't that Array rule disallow any use of string splitting?

Comment: @Phaeze it's a restriction on how you *input* the string, not on what you can do with the string.

Comment: @NathanMerrill Ok, thanks for the clarification.

Comment: Can you clarify the boolean input a bit? Do I get to pick **any** two values, one of which is falsey and the other of which is truthy, and make my program work with those; or should my program handle **all** falsey values one way and **all** truthy values the other way?

Comment: Also, a lot of the answers seem to assume the input is rectangular (all lines are padded to the same length using spaces). Is that assumption okay? Either way, you should clarify this in the question.

Comment: @Lynn bah, I should have come up with better test cases for that.  Yes, that assumption is fine.

Comment: @NathanMerrill I'd recommend adhering to the default definitions of [Truthy/Falsey](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/2194/34718)

Comment: Are you sure you did not get "X-reflection" and "Y-reflection" mixed up? Because for the `True` test cases, it looks like the input string is reflected across the `X` axis and not the `Y` axis.

Comment: @R.Kap I'm not reflecting across the axises, but in the Y direction or the X direction.

Comment: @NathanMerrill Ah, I see. I got a bit confused there. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: @NathanMerrill Is [this](https://gist.github.com/ImpregnableProgrammer/d3b7f1ec2b70a086d1b5f9fa951f1ffb) output okay for test case # 1?

Comment: @R.Kap no, its not.

Comment: Well then, in that case, @Lynn's answer is invalid as his/her answer outputs that exact thing for test case # 1.

Comment: Actually then, in that case, 3 answers are invalid, namely Lynn's Jelly and Python answers and LeakyNun's Pyth answer.

Comment: @R.Kap It seems that you're allowed to require rectangular input.

Comment: @Neil Okay. But then, why did Nathan Merrill say [this](https://gist.github.com/ImpregnableProgrammer/d3b7f1ec2b70a086d1b5f9fa951f1ffb) output is not okay for test case # 1? Also, if that is indeed true, OP should at least say it in the post. Otherwise, I am just assuming that the input won't necessarily be rectangular.

Comment: @R.Kap because that's not valid output.  However, if its generated using input that the program doesn't support, then its not a valid test case

Comment: @NathanMerrill just to clarify Lynn's earlier comment, just 1/0 is acceptable as truthy/falsy input?  Meaning my program doesn't have to handle anything that's truthy, only the 1 or the 0?

Comment: @nmjcman101 correct.

Answer (score 11):

### C#, <s>168</s> <s>144</s> <s>141</s> 120 Bytes

```
using System.Linq;i=>y=>string.Join("\n",y?i.Split('\n').Reverse():i.Split('\n').Select(x=>string.Concat(x.Reverse())));
```

New version utilizes the obvious string.Join overload that takes an IEnumerable, the first solution was using it inadvertently I was just able to use it for the else side of the ternary as well.

#### Update:

New version is an anonymous lambda and uses currying to save 21 bytes total. This changes usage to be `f("text")(false)` where f is the anonymous function.

#### Ungolfed:

```
using System.Linq;

//Using currying to save one byte
input => IsYReflect =>
         //Lambda makes return implicit
         string.Join("\n", IsYReflect
            //Y Reflect, just need to reverse the array
            ? input.Split('\n').Reverse()
            //X Reflect, reverse each line into an IEnumerable
            : input.Split('\n').Select(x => string.Concat(x.Reverse())));
```

Comment: Scott Kaye left a comment that has since been removed that triggered me to try some new things and shave off 24 bytes.

Comment: C#6 expression bodied function saves another 3 bytes

Answer (score 10):

### Pyke, 7 bytes

```
!I_)ncX
```

[Try it here!](http://pyke.catbus.co.uk/?code=%21I_%29ncX&input=1%0A%22++o+%2F%5Cn--%7C%2F+%5Cn++%7C++%5Cn+%2F+%5C%5C+%22&warnings=0)

```
!I )    - if not boolean:
  _     -  input = reversed(input)
    nc  - input.split("\n")
      X - splat(input)
        -  (print lines backwards)
```

Answer (score 9):

## Brainfuck, <s>143</s> <s>140</s> 131 bytes

```
,[,[---------->+<[>-]>[->]<,]<[[<]>[++++++++++.>]++++++++++.<[<]<]],[---------->+<[++++++++++>-]>[-<<[.<]++++++++++.[>]>>]<,]<[.<]
```

Beat<s>s</s> C#.

The challenge was easy enough for Brainfuck, and I apparently was tired enough to just have to do it.

Takes the boolean as a `0x00` (falsy) or any other (truthy) byte in the start of the input, then a rectangle-padded string.

Outputs a trailing newline for the Y flip, and none for the X flip.

Requires an interpreter that supports memory locations to the left of the start (unsure if still required) and gives EOF as `0x00`. One such interpreter is [here](http://www.iamcal.com/misc/bf_debug/). Obviously doesn't support null bytes in the input because of that.

The code has a lot of blocks with 10 `+`'s or `-`'s; those can probably be reduced.

#### Commented version

```
, get mode
[ check truthy input
    ,[ loop thru input
        ---------- subtract newline
        >+ set flag
        < go back to char
        [ was not newline
            > move to flag
            - reset flag
        ]
        > move to flag or one past flag
        [ hit flag; was newline
            - reset flag
            > skip a cell
        ]
        < go to next position
        , read next input
    ]
    < find end of line
    [ loop thru lines
        [<]> find start of line
        [ loop thru line
            ++++++++++ add newline back
            . print this cell
            > go to next cell
        ]
        ++++++++++ change to newline
        . print newline
        <[<]< find end of previous line
    ]
]
,[ loop thru any input left
    ---------- subtract newline
    >+ set flag
    < go back to char
    [ was not newline
        ++++++++++ add newline back
        > move to flag
        - reset flag
    ]
    > move to flag or one past flag
    [ hit flag; was newline
        - clear flag
        < go back to char
        < go back to line chars
        [ loop thru line
            . print this cell
            < go to previous cell
        ]
        ++++++++++. print newline
        [>]>> find empty cell
    ]
    < go to next position
    , read next input
]
< go to line
[ loop thru line
    . print this cell
    < go to previous cell
]
```

Answer (score 6):

## 32-bit x86 machine code, 76 bytes

In hex:

```
31c031c9495789f7fcf2aef7d15192b00a89f7f2ae5829f7f7f787f95f4b89c3741287d94b534b8a041eaa75f95b01dea4e2f2c348f7e101c6b00a5651f3a4595e29ce4f4b0f44c3aa75f0c3
```

Input: `EBX`: direction flag (0/1), `ESI`: input string, `EDI`: output buffer. Input is required to be rectangular.

```
0:  31 c0               xor eax,eax         ;EAX=0
2:  31 c9               xor ecx,ecx         
4:  49                  dec ecx             ;ECX=(uint)-1
5:  57                  push edi            
6:  89 f7               mov edi,esi         
8:  fc                  cld                 
9:  f2 ae               repne scasb         ;Scan input string for terminating NULL
b:  f7 d1               not ecx             ;ECX==<input string length (including NULL)>
d:  51                  push ecx            
e:  92                  xchg edx,eax        ;EDX=0
f:  b0 0a               mov al,0x0a         ;'\n'
11: 89 f7               mov edi,esi         
13: f2 ae               repne scasb         ;Scan input string for the first newline
15: 58                  pop eax             ;EAX==<input string length (including NULL)>
16: 29 f7               sub edi,esi         ;EDI==<single line length (including '\n')>
18: f7 f7               div edi             ;EAX==<# of lines>
1a: 87 f9               xchg ecx,edi        ;ECX=EDI
1c: 5f                  pop edi             ;EDI=<dest buffer>
1d: 4b                  dec ebx             ;Test input flag (0/1)
1e: 89 c3               mov ebx,eax         ;EBX=<# of lines>
20: 74 12               je _vertical        
22: 87 d9               xchg ecx,ebx        ;Horisontal flip, exchange ECX & EBX so we can use LOOP
24: 4b                  dec ebx             ;EBX=<single line length (excluding '\n')>
_hfouter:
25: 53                  push ebx            
_hfinner:
26: 4b                  dec ebx             ;Decrement inner loop counter
27: 8a 04 1e            mov al,[esi+ebx]    ;AL=ESI[EBX]
2a: aa                  stosb               ;*EDI++=AL
2b: 75 f9               jne _hfinner        ;EBX==0 => break
2d: 5b                  pop ebx             
2e: 01 de               add esi,ebx         ;*ESI=='\n' (\0 on the last line)
30: a4                  movsb               ;*EDI++=*ESI++, ESI now points to the next line
31: e2 f2               loop _hfouter       ;--ECX==0 => break
33: c3                  ret                 ;Nothing more to do here
_vertical:
34: 48                  dec eax             ;# of strings less one
35: f7 e1               mul ecx             ;Line length (including '\n')
37: 01 c6               add esi,eax         ;ESI+=ECX*(EAX-1), ESI now points to the beginning of the last line
39: b0 0a               mov al,0x0a         ;'\n'
_vfloop:
3b: 56                  push esi            
3c: 51                  push ecx            
3d: f3 a4               rep movsb           ;Copy the whole line to the output including newline/NULL at the end
3f: 59                  pop ecx             
40: 5e                  pop esi             
41: 29 ce               sub esi,ecx         ;Set ESI to the beginning of the previous line
43: 4f                  dec edi             ;*EDI=='\n' (0 on the first iteration), should overwrite it with correct value
44: 4b                  dec ebx             ;Decrement loop counter
45: 0f 44 c3            cmove eax,ebx       ;if (EBX==0) EAX=EBX, this clears EAX on the last iteration
48: aa                  stosb               ;*EDI++=EBX?'\n':0
49: 75 f0               jne _vfloop         ;EBX==0 => break
4b: c3                  ret
```

Answer (score 5):

### Haskell, <s>51</s> <s>49</s> 45 bytes

```
r=reverse
f b=unlines.last(map r:[r|b]).lines
```

Usage example:

```
f True "abc\ndef\nghi\njkl"
"jkl\nghi\ndef\nabc\n"

f False "abc\ndef\nghi\njkl"
"cba\nfed\nihg\nlkj\n"
```

Split into lines, either reverse the lines (True) or reverse each line (False) and join into a single string again. In case of a `True` input, `map r:[r|b]` is a list of two functions `[<reverse each line>, <reverse lines>]` and for a `False` input a list with one function `[<reverse each line>]`. `last` picks the last element of this list.

Answer (score 5):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 8 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
ṣ⁷ṚU⁴?j⁷
```

[Try it here.](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=4bmj4oG34bmaVeKBtD9q4oG3&input=MA&args=YWJjCmRlZgpnaGk+MQ)

```
ṣ⁷         Split over newlines.
  ṚU⁴?     If ⁴ (2nd argument), then Ṛ (reverse rank ∞), else U (reverse rank 1).
      j⁷   Join with newlines.
```

Answer (score 4):

## Python, 56 bytes

```
lambda s,r:'\n'.join(s[::2*bool(r)-1].split('\n')[::-1])
```

Call with a string `s` and any truthy/falsey value `r`.

Comment: It doesn't work that way. Your program has to either take *any* truthy value, or take only `True`, which could also be `1`. You cannot restrict input to be only `0` or `2`.

Comment: Yeah, I didn't think through my answer.  @mbomb007 is correct here, it needs to work for any truthy/falsy value for your language.

Comment: @NathanMerrill Just an FYI, you can avoid stuff like the 3 byte answer by saying that the input should not encode any additional information. This would have allowed the second answer (which I thought was rather clever), but of course what you would like to see is up to you.

Comment: This answer is invalid [according to OP](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/85363/ascii-art-reflection?noredirect=1#comment209510_85363) as it outputs [this](https://gist.github.com/ImpregnableProgrammer/d3b7f1ec2b70a086d1b5f9fa951f1ffb) for test case # 1 when it should instead be outputting what is given in the post for that test case (i.e. space padded to the length of the first line).

Answer (score 4):

## Python 3.5, 61 bytes:

```
lambda f,j:[print(r[::-1])for r in j[::[1,-1][f]].split('\n')]
```

A simple anonymous lambda function that assumes rectangular input. Call it by by first naming the function, and then calling it wrapped inside `print()`. In other words, if the function were named `H`, call it like `print(H(<Bool value>, <String>))`, where `<Bool Value>` is any true or false value (i.e. `0/1`, `true/false`, etc.) and `<String>` is the input string.

[See it in Action! (repl.it)](https://repl.it/CbmC/2)

Here is another version with the same length that also assumes rectangular input, but this time a *named* function, i.e. you don't have to name it first nor wrap it inside `print()`:

```
def J(f,j):[print(r[::-1])for r in j[::[1,-1][f]].split('\n')]
```

Simply call this one like`J(<Bool Value>,<String>)`.

[See this in Action! (repl.it)](https://repl.it/CbmK/0)

However, I'm not the one to stop there. Although we are allowed to assume rectangular input, I also created a version that does *not* assume that type of input. Therefore, it will space-pad all of the lines to the same length based on the line with the maximum length if and only if the `<Bool>` input is `False`, as only a X-reflection will result in the string being "flipped". Now, without further ado, here is the non-rectangular assuming version with a length of **<s>134</s> 129 bytes** in the form of a normal function:

```
def J(f,j):print('\n'.join([' '*((max([len(i)for i in j.split('\n')])-len(r))*(not f))+r[::-1]for r in j[::[1,-1][f]].split('\n')]))
```

[See this Last One in Action! (repl.it)](https://repl.it/CbmV/1)

Answer (score 2):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), <s>26</s> <s>24</s> 16 bytes

```
t1,?h@nr~@nw|hrw
```

Expects a list containing the string and the boolean `1` or `0`, e.g.

```
run_from_file('code.bl',["P
|    P
|    C
|    G":1]).
```

#### Explanation

```
t1,              If the tail of the input is 1
   ?h@n              Split the string on \n
       r             Reverse the resulting list
        ~@n          Join the list of strings with \n
           w         Write to STDOUT
|                Or
hr                   Reverse the string
  w                  Write to STDOUT
```

Answer (score 2):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 11 bytes

```
10&Ybc2i-&P
```

[**Try it online!**](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=MTAmWWJjaX5RJlA&input=WycgJywgJyAnLCAnbycsICcgJywgJy8nLCAnICcsIDEwLCAnLScsICctJywgJ3wnLCAnLycsIDEwLCAnICcsICcgJywgJ3wnLCAnICcsIDEwLCAnICcsICcvJywgJyAnLCAnXCddCjE)

The **first input** is the multiline string. Since MATL doesn't recognize `\n` as linefeed, the multiline string should be defined as a concatenation of substrings, or individual characters, and `10` (ASCII for line feed, which is interpreted as a character). Concatenation in MATL is `[... ...]` or `[..., ...]` (commas are optional). So for example, input can be as follows (concatenation of a string, linefeed, and another string):

```
['first line' 10 'second']
```

or equivalently (concatenation of individual characters)

```
['f' 'i' 'r' 's' 't' ' ' 'l' 'i' 'n' 'e' 10 's' 'e' 'c' 'o' 'n' 'd']
```

or (same with commas)

```
['f', 'i', 'r', 's', 't', ' ', 'l', 'i', 'n', 'e', 10, 's', 'e', 'c', 'o', 'n', 'd']
```

The **second input** can be entered as `1`/`0` or equivalently as `T`/`F` for `true`/`false` respectively.

#### Explanation

```
10     % Push 10 (ASCII for linefeed)
&Yb    % Take input string implicitly. Split at linefeeds. Gives a cell array
c      % Convert to a 2D char array, right-padding with spaces
i~Q    % Input Boolean value. Negate and add 1. Gives 1/2 for true/false resp.
&P     % Flip along that dimension (1: vertically; 2: horizontally). Display implicitly
```

Comment: [It really doesn't make sense that this doesn't work](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=MTAmWWJjaX5RJlA&input=J2ZpcnN0IGxpbmUKc2Vjb25kJwow)

Comment: @Fatalize It's because of how MATL and MATLAB read the input. Each line is a different input

Answer (score 2):

## Pyth, 10 bytes

```
j?Q_.z_M.z
```

[Test suite.](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=j%3FQ_.z_M.z&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=True%0Aab%0Acd%0AFalse%0Aab%0Acd%0A&debug=0&input_size=3)

```
j?Q_.z_M.z  first line evaluated as Q, all other lines as .z
 ?Q         if Q:
   _.z         yield reverse(.z)
      _M.z  else: yield map(reverse, .z)
j           join by newlines
```

Answer (score 2):

## Julia, 59 bytes

```
x\y=(y=split(y,'
');! =reverse;join(x?!y:[!a for a=y],'
'))
```

[Try it online!](http://julia.tryitonline.net/#code=eFx5PSh5PXNwbGl0KHksJwonKTshID1yZXZlcnNlO2pvaW4oeD8heTpbIWEgZm9yIGE9eV0sJwonKSkKcHJpbnQodHJ1ZVwiYWJjZGUKZmdoaWoKa2wgbW4Kb3BxcnMKdHV2d3giKQ&input=)

Answer (score 2):

### Perl, 35 bytes

**34 bytes code + 1 for `-n`.**

Requires the input lines be padded with spaces. 13 (!) bytes saved thanks to @[Dada](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/55508/dada).

```pl
print/T/?reverse<>:map~~reverse,<>
```

#### Usage

```sh
perl -ne 'print/T/?reverse<>:map~~reverse,<>' <<< 'False
  o /
--|/ 
  |  
 / \ '

/ o  
 /|--
  |  
 \ / 

 perl -ne 'print/T/?reverse<>:map~~reverse,<>' <<< 'True
  o /
--|/ 
  |  
 / \ '
 / \ 
  |  
--|/ 
  o /
```

Comment: `perl -ne 'print/T/?reverse<>:map~~reverse,<>'` should save you 13 bytes :-)

Comment: @Dada that is indeed a big saving! No idea why I wouldn't have done that but I'll update, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), <s>9</s> <s>11</s> 9 bytes (SBCS)

Fixed answer <s>but only had to add 2 bytes</s> and kept it the same length thanks to @[Adám](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/43319/ad%c3%a1m)

```apl
⌽[⎕]⎕FMT⎕
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///qG@qp/@jtgkGXI862tP@P@rZGw0UigViN98QIPkfKPy/CKgAyA51DlYwNObKL8pMz8xLzFEAiiqoKyjkK@ir6xTpqOvq1ugrgFkKCjUKUJa@QoyCOpe6P1SPOlw3l3pIUWlJRqU6VxpCzJBL3S0xpxhV0AAA)

Takes a character vector using `\r` as a separator through STDIN first, then 1 or 0. Requires 0-indexing.

`⎕` accepts input. `⎕FMT` formats it into a character matrix because of `\r`. `⌽[⎕]` reflects that over either the x- or y-axis, depending on the second input. With 0-indexing, `⌽[0]` or just `⌽` reflects over the x-axis, `⌽[1]` or `⊖` over the y-axis.

Comment: It would seem that your input format is prohibited. However, if you take input as a string with `\r`s then `⎕FMT` will give you a matrix. Also, look into [`⌽[ax]`](https://aplcart.info/?q=monadic%20%E2%8C%BD%5Bax%5D#) with `⎕IO←0`.

Comment: Using a full program, you can save 2 bytes: `⌽[⎕]⎕FMT⎕`

Comment: Also, you have to set `⎕IO←0` to abide by the truthy/falsey rule.

Comment: Tends to be the case with older challenges.

Comment: I would be a good idea to add this use of `⎕FMT` to the [tag:tips] thread.

Comment: @Razetime You can just [add an answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/17665/tips-for-golfing-in-apl#show-editor-button).

Comment: `⌽[2]` is not the same as `⍉`

Comment: `⍉` never reflects over a single axis, so it cannot be expressed as `⌽[ax]`.

Comment: `⍉` is actually "reorder axes", by default (i.e monadically) into reverse order.

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript (ES 6) 83 bytes

```
(c,b)=>(p=c.split`
`)&&(b?p.reverse():p.map(a=>a.split``.reverse().join``)).join`
`
```

---

```
f=(c,b)=>(p=c.split`
`)&&(b?p.reverse():p.map(a=>a.split``.reverse().join``)).join`
`

f("abcde\nfghij\nkl mn\nopqrs\ntuvwx",1)

c="
  o / 
--|/
  | 
 / \
";

f(c,1)
" / \
   | 
 --|/
   o / "

f(c,0)
"/ o  
  /|--
   |  
  \ / "
```

Comment: I see a different output for `f(c,0)` when I try - maybe your `c` doesn't have all the spaces in the right places.

Comment: Is the trailing white space after the first "o /" significant?

Comment: @PeterMortensen & Neil: I'm pretty sure that's from my copy-pasting. The javascript console puts your beginning " on the first line and makes everything look terrible so I formatted it a bit when I pasted in here.  Very likely I have a bug too.

Answer (score 1):

## Bash + common linux utils, 16

```bash
(($1))&&tac||rev
```

Boolean value (zero or non-zero) passed as a command-line parameter.  I/O of text block via STDIN/STDOUT.  Assumes that all lines are the same length, as [indicated in the comments](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/85363/ascii-art-reflection#comment209483_85363).

Answer (score 1):

## C (Ansi), 193 Bytes

### Golfed:

```
i,y,x;main(g,o,p)char**o;{p=(o[1][0]=='t');while(o[2][++i]!='\n');p?y=(strlen(o[2])-1)/i:(x=i);do do printf("%c",o[2][x+y*i]);while(p?++x<i:x-->0);while(p?x=0,y--:++y<(x=i-1,strlen(o[2])/i));}
```

### Ungolfed:

```
i,y,x;
main(g,o,p)char**o;{
    p=(o[1][0]=='t');
    while(o[2][++i]!='\n'); 
    p?y=(strlen(o[2])-1)/i:(x=i);
    do{
        do{
            printf("%c",o[2][x+y*i]);
        }while(p?++x<i:x-->0);
    }while(p?x=0,y--:++y<(x=i-1,strlen(o[2])/i));
}
```

### Usage:

#### Compilation Arguments:

```
gcc -O3 -ansi
```

#### Example Input:

Input is a t or not t for true of false followed by a newspace lead and trailed string.

```
./reverseString t "
truck
ducky
quack
moose
"
```

#### Example Output:

```
moose
quack
ducky
truck
```

Answer (score 1):

## J, 29 bytes

```
}:@,@(,.&LF@{|."1,:|.)>@cutLF
```

LHS input is the boolean where 0 is false and 1 is true. RHS is the string input.

Answer (score 1):

## Java 99 bytes

```
public String[] reverse(String[]a){
  int i=-1,j=a.length;
  for(;++i<--j;){
    String b=a[i];
    a[i]=a[j];
    a[j]=b;
  }
  return a;
}
```

Golfed:

```
String[] e(String[]a){int i=-1,j=a.length;for(;++i<--j;){String b=a[i];a[i]=a[j];a[j]=b;}return a;}
```

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 10 bytes

```
U|XiRë€R}»
```

## Explanation

```
U          Remove the first input line and store it in variable X
 |         Aggregate the rest of the input into an array
  XiR      If x is true, revert the array
     ë€R   Else revert each element
        }  End if
         » Join everything with newlines and implicitly display
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/05ab1e#@x9aE5EZdHj1o6Y1QbWHdv//b8iVmJScksqVlp6RmcWVnaOQm8eVX1BYVMxVUlpWXgEA)

Comment: [8 bytes](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f@/5kh7ZtDh1YfX1h7a/f@/IVdiUnJKKldaekZmFld2jkJuHld@QWFRMVdJaVl5BQA) (`U|X` to `|ć` and `€R` to `í`) Perhaps these builtins weren't available when you posted your answer, but they are still available in the legacy version of 05AB1E regardless. :)

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 6 bytes

```
θ¿η‖↓‖
```

Link is to verbose version of code.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z@gKDOvRKNQUyEzTSNDUyEoNS0nNblEw8olvzxPUyE1pzgVJvb/f7SSgkK@gn5Mnq5uDZBUUKgBEvoKMTFKOoax/3VzygA)

Answer (score 0):

### Mathematica, 70 bytes

```
If[#,Reverse,StringReverse]@ImportString[#2,l="Lines"]~ExportString~l&
```

Anonymous function, takes a boolean value as first argument (explicitly `True` or `False` in Mathematica) and the (multiline) string as the second argument. Imports the string as a list of strings corresponding to the lines of the multiline string (the string is NOT passed to the function as an array). If `True`, reverse the list. If `False` `StringReverse` the list, which automatically is applied to each element in turn. Then export the list as a string, where each element is a new line.

Answer (score 0):

## JavaScript (ES6), 76

```js
s=>b=>(s=s.split`
`,b?s.reverse():s.map(r=>[...r].reverse().join``)).join`
`
```

```js
F=s=>b=>(s=s.split`
`,b?s.reverse():s.map(r=>[...r].reverse().join``)).join`
`

function test()
{
  var rows=I.value, r
  
  // Trim trailing newlines, pad to blank
  rows=rows.split('\n')
  while(!(r=rows.pop()));
  rows.push(r)
  var maxlen=Math.max(...rows.map(r=>r.length))
  rows=rows.map(r=>r+' '.repeat(maxlen-r.length)).join`\n`

  var t1=F(rows)(false)
  var t2=F(rows)(true)
  
  O.textContent = 'False\n'+t1+'\n\nTrue\n'+t2
}

test()
```

```css
#I { width:50%; height:10em }
```

```html
<textarea id=I>
  o /
--|/
  |
 / \
</textarea>  
<button onclick=test()>Go</button>
<pre id=O></pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

## Vim, 33 bytes

Changed previous V answer to Vim.  Any V answer would be way different, so it wasn't really fair.

```
DgJ:if@"
g/^/m0
el
se ri
en
cG"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/v#@@@S7mWVmeagxJWuH6efa8CVmsNVnKpQlMmVmseV7C6kxPH/vyGXgkK@gj6Xrm6NvgKQXaMAJPUVYhQA)

Hexdump

```
00000000: 4467 4a3a 6966 4022 0a67 2f5e 2f6d 300a  DgJ:if@".g/^/m0.
00000010: 656c 0a73 6520 7269 0a65 6e0a 6347 1222  el.se ri.en.cG."
00000020: 08                                       .
```

Comment: You could probably save a bunch of bytes with [this mapping](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/V/commit/439edc84892be237dc65eb408ea3e6ba93ceff4d#diff-5139c008a54beacc91501ed44fdb9a5cR137)

Answer (score 0):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 8 bytes

```
|ćiRëí}»
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f@/5kh7ZtDh1YfX1h7a/f@/AZeCQr6CPpeubo2@ApBdowAk9RViFAA)

```
|ćiRëí}»  # full program
       »  # join...
|         # list of lines in input...
 ć        # excluding the first element...
   R      # reversed...
  i       # if...
 ć        # first element of...
|         # list of lines in input...
  i       # is truthy...
    ë     # else...
     í    # with each element in list reversed...
       »  # by newlines
      }   # end if statement
          # implicit output
```