# Find the nearest greater number

Tags: code-golf, array, integer

## The task

Given any array of integers, e.g.:

```
[-1,476,578,27,0,1,-1,1,2]
```

and an index of that array (this example uses **0 based indexing**, though you can use **1 based indexing** as well.):

```
         index = 5
                 v
[-1,476,578,27,0,1,-1,1,2]
```

Then **return the nearest number greater than the element at that index**. In the example, the closest number greater than 1 is 27 (at 2 indices away).

```
         index = 5
                 v
[-1,476,578,27,0,1,-1,1,2]
            ^
Nearest greater number

Output = 27
```

## Assumptions

- Nearest does not include wrapping.
- The program will never be given an array of length 1 (e.g; `[55]`).
- You are to assume there is **always** a number greater than the given element.
- If there are 2 numbers greater than the element at equal distances, you can return **either one**.

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) so the shortest code in bytes wins

## I/O pairs

```
Input:
Index = 45
Array = [69, 43, 89, 93, 62, 25, 4, 11, 115, 87, 174, 60, 84, 58, 28, 67, 71, 157, 47, 8, 33, 192, 187, 87, 175, 32, 135, 25, 137, 92, 183, 151, 147, 7, 133, 7, 41, 12, 96, 147, 9, 134, 197, 3, 107, 164, 90, 199, 21, 71, 77, 62, 190, 122, 33, 127, 185, 58, 92, 106, 26, 24, 56, 79, 71, 24, 24, 114, 17, 84, 121, 188, 6, 177, 114, 159, 159, 102, 50, 136, 47, 32, 1, 199, 74, 141, 125, 23, 118, 9, 12, 100, 94, 166, 12, 9, 179, 147, 149, 178, 90, 71, 141, 49, 74, 100, 199, 160, 120, 14, 195, 112, 176, 164, 68, 88, 108, 72, 124, 173, 155, 146, 193, 30, 2, 186, 102, 45, 147, 99, 178, 84, 83, 93, 153, 11, 171, 186, 157, 32, 90, 57, 181, 5, 157, 106, 20, 5, 194, 130, 100, 97, 3, 87, 116, 57, 125, 157, 190, 83, 148, 90, 44, 156, 167, 131, 100, 58, 139, 183, 53, 91, 151, 65, 121, 61, 40, 80, 40, 68, 73, 20, 135, 197, 124, 190, 108, 66, 21, 27, 147, 118, 192, 29, 193, 27, 155, 93, 33, 129]
Output = 199

Input:
Index = 2
Array = [4,-2,1,-3,5]
Output = 4 OR 5

Input:
Index = 0
Array = [2124, -173, -155, 146, 193, -30, 2, 186, 102, 4545]
Output = 4545

Input:
Index = 0
Array = [1,0,2,3]
Output = 2

Input:
Index = 2
Array = [3,-1,-3,-2,5]
Output = -1 OR -2
```

Comment: Could you add a test case where it looks for a result to the left instead of to the right? i.e. `1; [7,1,-4,2]`

Comment: I think `2; [3,-1,-3,-2,5]` is a nice test case. There are positive numbers, but the result is negative.

Comment: Can I use 2-indexed?

Comment: @Titus I mean if you really want to

Answer (score 7):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 10 bytes

```
yt&y)>fYk)
```

This uses 1-based indexing. [**Try it online!**](https://tio.run/nexus/matl#@19ZolapaZcWma35/3@0rqGOibmZjqm5hY6RuY6BjqEOUMRQxyiWy4wLCAA)

#### Explanation

Consider inputs `[4,-2,1,-3,5]`, `3` as an example.

```
y     % Take two inputs implicitly. Duplicate 2nd-top element in the stack
      % STACK: [4,-2,1,-3,5], 3, [4,-2,1,-3,5]
t     % Duplicate top of the stack
      % STACK: [4,-2,1,-3,5], 3, [4,-2,1,-3,5], [4,-2,1,-3,5]
&y    % Duplicate 3rd-top element in the stack
      % STACK: [4,-2,1,-3,5], 3, [4,-2,1,-3,5], [4,-2,1,-3,5], 3
)     % Index: select elements from first input as indicated by second input
      % STACK: [4,-2,1,-3,5], 3, [4,-2,1,-3,5], 1
>     % Greater than, element-wise
      % STACK: [4,-2,1,-3,5], 3, [1,0,0,0,1]
f     % Find: gives indices of non-zero entries
      % STACK: [4,-2,1,-3,5], 3, [1,5]
Yk    % Closest element: gives closest element of each entry in second input
      % ([1,5]) to each entry in the first input (3). In case of a tie it 
      % gives the left-most one
      % STACK: [4,-2,1,-3,5], 1
)     % Index: select elements from first input as indicated by second input
      % STACK: 4
      % Implicitly display
```

Comment: Do you have an explanation?

Comment: @NickClifford Sure! I was waiting for OP clarification. Explanation added

Answer (score 6):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 10 bytes

```
ị<ṛTạ⁸$ÞḢị
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#bVJLat1AENz7FMJ4KcH0fDWQY3hjHu8wXucIgUCyyRWcePlO8nIRuaq6lYUJSPPpT01XdR/3969f7r@/Pd///Pj7@vZ0@35/@wnbcfv1@HIcta9LWRfDd1wufa5LxXXHPrH3vC65wQY3QwznfeAwYOkJF@xtRxD@DsdgVMOh4oetEHsCxZjmqcAotJTm4FZg9hhGN0IwncHMJxptiJg9fJM@VjWH158Y3WGZiVb4s3k5YzgPkyfnKCozYW9evl5PAM/8yQn7mA7Ae5YCXIaTNsLbTto0jtPd5rkkYDY@WbrLIdJRHPUzZ0UVWJDtTkulIG8ypPcgzkdmkLeq6@5kJTmh6ombTgmsizIXaUWxhT96qNUBQhKWsAy6xHSoEQznfBhHoQBFPerBrbazF2c11IUtnMouMTOqT1ktRGDVTfLD1cLh8ic3iDtfdCW8x5oe65Gb/yUSTpNTQ5GqRoiiZsgCh522MmPQWOC0GLjeoqWdQhIw@U6BqIZELC0mzlXSQFE4donJmil1iM3U3OcZ@slHSSWmJnBe14flAqTNJ2NjVbJlPbCpD9unRmz/6UT1NGC4r1yvHw)

Comment: I was fiddling for ages trying to get sorting to work with the absolute value :(

Answer (score 5):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>11</s> 12 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

+1 byte - No wrapping allowed.

```
Jạż⁸ṢZṪ»\Q2ị
```

1-indexed.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#AScA2P//SuG6ocW84oG44bmiWuG5qsK7XFEy4buL////WzEsMCwyLDNd/zE)**

---

Previous 11 byter (wrapping indexing), 0-indexed:

```
ṙżU$Fµ>ḢTḢị
```

Comment: This fails on e.g. `0` `[1,0,2,3]`.

Comment: @ØrjanJohansen Ah - it returns `3`, which is 1 away so, um, yeah "nearest" is not defined...

Comment: I asked OP to add that test case.

Answer (score 4):

### JavaScript (ES6), <s>57</s> 55 bytes

Takes the array `a` and the index `i` in currying syntax `(a)(i)`.

```js
a=>g=(i,p)=>(x=a[i-p])>a[i]||(x=a[i+p])>a[i]?x:g(i,-~p)
```

#### Test cases

```js
let f =

a=>g=(i,p)=>(x=a[i-p])>a[i]||(x=a[i+p])>a[i]?x:g(i,-~p)

console.log(f([-1, 476, 578, 27, 0, 1, -1, 1, 2])(5))

console.log(f([69, 43, 89, 93, 62, 25, 4, 11, 115, 87, 174, 60, 84, 58, 28, 67, 71, 157, 47, 8, 33, 192, 187, 87, 175, 32, 135, 25, 137, 92, 183, 151, 147, 7, 133, 7, 41, 12, 96, 147, 9, 134, 197, 3, 107, 164, 90, 199, 21, 71, 77, 62, 190, 122, 33, 127, 185, 58, 92, 106, 26, 24, 56, 79, 71, 24, 24, 114, 17, 84, 121, 188, 6, 177, 114, 159, 159, 102, 50, 136, 47, 32, 1, 199, 74, 141, 125, 23, 118, 9, 12, 100, 94, 166, 12, 9, 179, 147, 149, 178, 90, 71, 141, 49, 74, 100, 199, 160, 120, 14, 195, 112, 176, 164, 68, 88, 108, 72, 124, 173, 155, 146, 193, 30, 2, 186, 102, 45, 147, 99, 178, 84, 83, 93, 153, 11, 171, 186, 157, 32, 90, 57, 181, 5, 157, 106, 20, 5, 194, 130, 100, 97, 3, 87, 116, 57, 125, 157, 190, 83, 148, 90, 44, 156, 167, 131, 100, 58, 139, 183, 53, 91, 151, 65, 121, 61, 40, 80, 40, 68, 73, 20, 135, 197, 124, 190, 108, 66, 21, 27, 147, 118, 192, 29, 193, 27, 155, 93, 33, 129])(45))

console.log(f([4, -2, 1, -3, 5])(2))

console.log(f([2124, -173, -155, 146, 193, -30, 2, 186, 102, 4545])(0))
```

Comment: Can you not use `|` instead of `||`?

Comment: @Neil No, we don't want `x` to be overwritten when the first condition is fulfilled.

Answer (score 3):

## PHP, 106 Bytes

```php
<?for($y=($a=$_GET[0])[$x=$_GET[1]];$y>=$a[$x-++$i]&&$y>=$a[$x+$i];);echo$y<$a[$x+$i]?$a[$x+$i]:$a[$x-$i];
```

[Online Version](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/93ffeb6d2cbd58870cbaf8e08d695ad88eaaa9cf)

Comment: Looks like these don't work for the first test case.

Comment: @NickClifford Now it should work. I have take a wrong approach

Answer (score 3):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 48 bytes

```hs
i%l=minimum[[j*j,x]|(j,x)<-zip[-i..]l,x>l!!i]!!1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/haskell#bVLLbtswELz3K2SgAaSCErh8ikGTe845Cj4YqdEysNRAsdG0yL87O0uqh6IHvvYx3Jnd@ZCXu7ycj@vh6fz5spzycnwd5sNL277@@Pnr9vZhOff3j@c1L9@74bI8Xdb1d3vTDevx8K0bJPyab053c17yfJmn6fnLs3rbv7e8d1/7P/ll6vMw7E/q7f602@X9bkfXa@u8aqaQVOOsakY@E5/BqMaww6mGCIvvY@RLZEvQ/ODTjxzEK7AjIsrzxfFim2UQSoxCSCupjGFhsb6Ak2VziUG0BwTSEYx8oMHGESlUX4IPVSV@IEsjOrAlaVjZb6iUE2PhQeIxphZlkDD6Ur78rhncYIETnzEVALyNKIAtFtIEeBpBG8a4uX3aNs2YHl/aUOQQ0rU46EeFFVRAQTQWWlIK5yWEhFCJ45NUyZOT51jIiuSAchuu3iSgIJSxiVYQW/BjqGoFBgEJ0rxFuIRplEYg3CESo2AZRXoUKjfnt15s1UAXtDBJtq0zI/VJlq8ioGov8rPLV0eRXxeDcMePRYnSY5keCjXX/E0EnEyOq4o4aYRQlBmiioNOk0110FBgojpwwdeWBggJQF1OCAQ1RETr68QVlWSgIBy6hGSZKekQmilzb1LVT3yQVMSUCUz77lPLMZNTvVGkeqs8TAw7Gfmil070/7Si/08vHDI/AA) Test framework from Ørjan Johansen.

Comment: You can save a byte by using a list and `!!1` instead (just change `Integer` to `Int` in the header).

Comment: @ØrjanJohansen Thanks, I had tried that and was unsure why it complained about types.

Answer (score 2):

## [Python](https://docs.python.org/), 62 bytes

```python
lambda a,i:min((v<=a[i],abs(j-i),v)for j,v in enumerate(a))[2]
```

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/python3#bVPLjtswDDy3X6HLYu2FDIh6WkH30GNP/YA0By/WAbxo3IXjBO3XpxxKDtqiB0kWhxyRQ/r4/O32fTi9vA5q0NPuNM1Nc/30POyngx5ezs1bN7X62h5/LOpNX9U0q3G@nMZlWMdmaNu9PdyAreN5Bdg0@5i18k6rns/MZ7Ra2cA2rYiw@LtP/JHYEg1f@Aw9O/GKDCR4Bf7wvNjmmIQysxDCSihzOFhcKOTk2Fx84B1AgXA4Ix5ssLFHjhXLwJBV5guiDLwjW7KBlXFLJZ2USh0kiLU1KYuAPpT05XXD5BYLNfGZciHA3YoC2FIpmkBPPcqGMW1wyNtmmDPgSReLHFJ0TQ76UakKKiAh6ktZkgrHZbjEWAvHI7kWT16ufSlWJAeV33jNJgFFKRmbaAWxhT/FqlZkEhRBhrcESCpN0gi4e3hiFByzSI9irc2HrRdbNtAFLcwS7erMSH4SFaoIyDqI/AyFChT5TTFI7XixKFF6LNNDscbaeyDoZHJ8VcRLI6REmSGqPOg0uVwHDQlmqgMXQ21phJAgNOWEQFBDRHShTlxRSQYKwqFLCJaZkg6hmTL3Nlf9BIOkIqZMYD5AxVarZu91ZzXpzunARis2K6900ozun250/2mHR6iRUNJGW@3k3u4@fnhfpnltHr/Mr@PPnXo4P6oH@e33dGjv6OdlGX79hZo/0K@X9f2ybvCxeYJHe8fb2@03)**

Answer (score 2):

## x86-64 Assembly, 40 bytes

Inspired by analyzing [Johan du Toit](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/118802/58518) and [2501](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/118844/58518)'s C solutions, the following is a function that can be assembled with MASM for x86-64 platforms.

It follows the [Microsoft x64 calling convention](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235286.aspx) for passing parameters, so the total length of the array is passed in `ECX`, the position of interest is passed in `EDX`, and the pointer to the integer array is passed in `R8` (it's a 64-bit platform, so it's a 64-bit pointer).

It returns the result (the "nearest greater number") in `EAX`.

```
             FindNearestGreater PROC      
8B F2       \    mov     esi, edx     ; move pos parameter to preferred register
8B D9       |    mov     ebx, ecx     ; make copy of count (ecx == i; ebx == count)
            | MainLoop:
8B C6       |    mov     eax, esi     ; temp  = pos
2B C1       |    sub     eax, ecx     ; temp -= i
99          |    cdq
33 C2       |    xor     eax, edx
2B C2       |    sub     eax, edx     ; temp = AbsValue(temp)
            | 
41 8B 14 B0 |    mov     edx, DWORD PTR [r8+rsi*4]
41 39 14 88 |    cmp     DWORD PTR [r8+rcx*4], edx
7E 04       |    jle     KeepGoing    ; jump if (pValues[i] <= pValues[pos])
3B D8       |    cmp     ebx, eax
77 02       |    ja      Next         ; jump if (count > temp)
            | KeepGoing:
8B C3       |     mov     eax, ebx    ; temp = count
            | Next:
8B D8       |     mov     ebx, eax    ; count = temp
E2 E3       |     loop    MainLoop    ; equivalent to dec ecx + jnz, but smaller (and slower)
            | 
            |     ; Return pValues[temp + pos]
03 C6       |     add     eax, esi
41 8B 04 80 |     mov     eax, DWORD PTR [r8+rax*4]
C3          /     ret
             FindNearestGreater ENDP
```

If you wanted to call it from C code, the prototype would be:

```
extern int FindNearestGreater(unsigned int count,
                              unsigned int pos,
                              const    int *pValues);
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 64 bytes

```ruby
->a,i{a[(0...a.size).select{|j|a[j]>a[i]}.min_by{|j|(i-j).abs}]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/ruby#FYhLCsMgFACv8pYJ6EON9rNoLmKlvAQDii0Fu2kTz251M8zMdrtXPhMLO9lBICJhDj8/YvbJr5/9iAfZ6GaywRV8htdj@fY5BB5HpCUXV@obNlwpJbBKKs2Ay/PUaQwDqU8N196TYKBaXPoRzbTRxjEQ9Q8)

Answer (score 1):

## [Ohm](https://github.com/MiningPotatoes/Ohm), 20 bytes

Basically a translation of [this Ruby answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/118757/65298).

```
Dl#)░┼_ª┼┘ª>;╥┘_-A;ª
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/ohm#PVJLSkRBDNx7igeuhBE6/Um/MCAI3kJkLuBlhFG8gJs5g6s5yrvIWJXkuehfPtWpSm4v7/cP29fHdv49XS/Yt/P39fJ03D5/cDs9Ph@vl9vtVe2w9HZYVpyGU@thqQO2wyLChfs6cZmwaMED51gRhKVwTEYNXDoWbA0gYkARpkUqMBotbQS4NJgjhtGDEExnMPOJRhsiTNNn9LEqw4NZhdEKixVa4a8S5cwZPMQ9tWZRlQnriPL99wLwykVOOKcFAN/VFeA2g7QQXlbSpnHu7mH7VoA5@GXTkMNJZ3HUT4IVVWBBsgYtLwV5xhDVJM5PLMlL9@caZF1yQvUdt@wSiDplbq4VxXb8qamWAoQkpGCbdDnT6Y1geGckR6EBxXukya2PvRd7NdSFLTTPbjkzXp9njRSBVQ@XH66RjpC/hMG588dQInrs0yOaufU/kXA@OT0V6d4Ip@gzJInDTkuzHDQWaJIDpyNbqhSSgCVOCkQ1XMQ2cuJCJR8oCscuMdlnyjvEZvrcV0v93EdJXUyfQHu76@MP)

Explanation will come later when I'm not doing homework.

Answer (score 1):

## Pyth - 28 bytes

```
JEehf>@T1@JQo@NZm(adQ@Jd)UlJ
```

[Try it](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=JEehf%3E%40T1%40JQo%40NZm%28adQ%40Jd%29UlJ&input=2%0A%5B3%2C-1%2C-3%2C-2%2C5%5D&debug=0)

Answer (score 1):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 53 bytes

`(#)` takes an `Int` and a list of `Int`s or `Integer`s (actually any `Ord` type), and returns an element of the list.

```hs
n#l=[x|i<-[1..],x:_<-(`drop`l)<$>[n-i,n+i],x>l!!n]!!0
```

## How it works

- `n` is the given index and `l` is the given list/"array".
- `i`, taking on values from 1 upwards, is the distance from `n` currently being tested.
- For each `i`, we check indices `n-i` and `n+i`.
- `x` is the element of `l` being tested. If it passes the tests it will be an element of the resulting list comprehension.

  - Indexing arbitrary indices with `!!` could give an out of bounds error, while `drop` instead returns either the whole list or an empty list in that case. The pattern match with `x:_` checks that the result is not empty.
  - `x>l!!n` tests that our element is greater than the element at index `n` (which is guaranteed to exist).
  - `!!0` at the end returns the first match/element of the list comprehension.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/haskell#bVLLbtswELz3K2QkBxmhBC6fouH43nOPgtEYiZEIcJhAsZEU6L@7O0uqh6IHvvYx3Jnd18OU76d8Ps6Hx/PtJZ@mfPzoXw/vbfvx8va52Xxn3/Nx7nY/zvOUn9f9JT9e5vlXe7Pu5@Phad1LyjXfnO7Hr9/Tthup7/fqa/Nz27UPT/Pb@8Npvb3djbmbVL6b2LU7rVZ5v1rp67V1XjVjSKpxVjUDn4nPYFRj2OFUQ4TF9yHyJbIlaH7w6QcO4hXYERHl@eJ4sc0yCCVGIaSVVMawsFhfwMmyucQg2gMC6QhGPtBg44gUqi/Bh6oSP5ClER3YkjSs7DdUyomx8CDxGFOLMkgYfClfftcMbrDAic@YCgDeRhTAFgtpAjwNoA1jXNw@LZtmTI8vbShyCOlaHPSjwgoqoCAaCi0phfMSQkKoxPFJquTJyXMoZEVyQLkFVy8SUBDK2EQriC34MVS1AoOABGneIlzCNEojEO4QiVGwjCI9CpWb80svlmqgC1qYJNvWmZH6JMtXEVC1F/nZ5aujyK@LQbjjx6JE6bFMD4Waa/4mAk4mx1VFnDRCKMoMUcVBp8mmOmgoMFEduOBrSwOEBKAuJwSCGiKi9XXiikoyUBAOXUKyzJR0CM2UuTep6ic@SCpiygSm/fpbyzGjU51RpDqrPEwMOxr5opNOdP@0ovtPLxwy/wA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 17 bytes

```
hH&∋₎<.&t:I≜+:H∋₍
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/brachylog2#@5/hofaoo/tRU5@NnlqJleejzjnaVh5gkd7//6Oj4w11TMzNdEzNLXSMzHUMdAx1gCKGOkaxOqax/6MA)

#### Explanation

```
hH                      Call the list H
  &∋₎<.                 Output is greater than the number at the specified index
       &t:I≜            Label I (0, then 1, then -1, then 2, then -2, …)
            +           Sum I with the input Index
             :H∋₍       Output is the element of H at index <the sum>
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Java (OpenJDK 8)](http://openjdk.java.net/), 98 bytes

```java
int f(int n,int[]a){for(int s=1,i=1,x=a[n];;n+=i++*s,s=-s)if(0<=n&n<a.length&&a[n]>x)return a[n];}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/java-openjdk#nVNNj9owED13f0VOKCkO8ndisfQf9LRHxCHdAo3EGkRCuxXit9N5Y6daVSu16sF2PDPveebN5HT5cuifi@dDNwzF566P13sfx2JXYo@C9vWmq66745ktw0qJntbrqlvHzXIZ56t@Pv84iGFVD1W/K@XjKs7iY7c4bON@/DabIe7Ta3XejpdzLBh1u5/Sq8PYjXR8P/Zfixd6u3waz33crzdFd94P1fXhw9PPYdy@LI6XcXEi13iIZdz@4ETLarErrRMFDJzn1QdRWCOKls5Ap9ei0BRhRaEUFn23DX00ZPGSLnS6loJoeXI0iHL0YWmRzRCJCsSiAEtQ4jCwGJfIlSFzikG0AwXgCAYebLBRRPDZF@BDVoEuQElEe7IECSv5tUrpNE2qQ7FH65yUBqB1KX1@XRK5xkJNdDYhEeCuWQFsTSpagV61KBvGZnK7MG2SOB2eND7JwUXn5KCfSlVBBSSk2lQWp0K4gBDvc@F4JOTileVrm4plyUFlJ145SaA8l4yNtYLYzN/4rJYnEhShJG0NXFxpw41AuEUkRsEQC/fI59qsm3oxZQNd0MLAaJNnhvNjlMsiIGvH8pPLZUeSXyYD144XkxKpxzw9ymes/g0EHU@OzYpYbgSXyDOkMg86rUzIg4YEg8oD511uqYeQIJTphEBQg0U0Lk9cUokHCsKhSwDzTHGH0Eyeex2yfuyDpCwmT2C4VdXy77@ofvuHWlFroURthPs3tHyL1px4zf2t/2hw/U6H7f88ooQUWhhG3h5u918)

Checks the indices in the order specified by the partial sums of the following sum:

```java
initial value + 1 - 2 + 3 - 4 + 5 - 6 + ...
```

Comment: I was just reading the question and wanted to start writing an answer.. Btw, why the `s=1,` and `,s=-s`, it has no use in your answer.. Did you forgot to remove it from an old approach?

Comment: @KevinCruijssen it is a mistake and I'm fixing it now. It passed the testcases because in all those testcases, the nearest greater number is to the right.

Answer (score 1):

### C, 69 bytes

```
t;b;f(*d,c,p){for(b=c;c--;)d[c]>d[p]&(t=abs(p-c))<b?b=t:0;*d=d[p+b];}
```

First argument is an in/out argument. Output is stored in its first element.

See it [work online](https://tio.run/nexus/c-clang#fVXbjpswEH3PV1grtcqN1gZscNm0H5JGVTC7Eg@bRAnpQ6N8@9ZzBpuQdBspg5k5PjM@M8B7V9XV63TeLN3yMLu87o/TeuUqlyTVrFm7zfdmfdh8nnarbX2aHhI3mz3XP@pV901W82blg4t6U13fJ5N214m3bbubit/7thGzyWUi/I/c2/VGrMRFGCuWIs@8KWllaWVSb1JNAf9XCoZuy4KWBXmNpHta6ZLQZAyFC8A1LXMyFMiIVVmiVeDoiYgzgzfTIaXKKNZjsU@DEWTYBjbwI0BIayLEAoLCLd2DQmKjIa@VCBEsVaHeogjHVhxP01h2ir2lDkfl0iRlTGEgAq0KG/jgS1k92CKopZBUldALkWJAaTtYSWk0islMEJPFigdAJ1QvAxRExaoMOnCpRGIBNSYqhtw2yqZy9pRBIu4juPMhlxzUU4aVgmW90T9OWpiouCFOHFhJsgUArE7BHcbGHFswgRmR8giYKEauhyYPxUJVDIplrizOLB@BGXSUD6fT3FQC6BjumyqDkzVDLb2IYaB4fpWJTOkNCxLw6OZRzpwbzKrwGKvIi7lSmY0zj0NYFaff6Dg6Bh1BChlWUBhScjcyHce/15mnGvJjBkDFk83tx8zwI5ra2AdGoD3cF34irLiKaniV/HL7s7@uxKn987J/nYqtmImvw91abrxj2FD37x6qLAkTneDcI@L6gbgeEdf3xK4nTvnUCY9X8jhfyQcDlo8LcA8FuFEB7r6Api@ADhQyZCPK5oGyGVE2t5Qwp@54dh2W/PruqeZid36rX449NtYM@rHvsD@1Xbvf3bixuMI2267/GsRo@F18K5exwXgEr2L5D1jtg3WEpR@gnI@5iJIfoBofa/6HGunpi3@U1DvHqtIRb4QNAtCnFTSt3y1F5a/Pt5TesVj47@ZY/EDYbr70LVhGRyg73Efpb1KLw9Hn9CxPn5qfuyePnt/xBTA3aDK5vv8F).

Answer (score 1):

## PHP, 73 bytes

```php
function($i,$a){for(;$b<=$a[$i];)$b=max($a[++$d+$i],$a[$i-$d]);return$b;}
```

closure takes 0-based index and array from arguments. [Verify all test cases](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/66790388992de6caca8d8677f59e4b104bf4be1b).

Comment: Not the next higher value. You need a value with the lowest distance that is higher

Comment: @JörgHülsermann Thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 1):

## R, 59 bytes

```
function(l,i)l[j<-l>l[i]][which.min(abs(1:length(l)-i)[j])]
```

returns an anonymous function. In the event that there are two elements greater at equal distances, will return the first (lesser index).

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/r#PcxBCsIwEEDRfU8RcJOBiZiiTZHqCbxByELTxE6JU6EpevuoXbh9fH48lbiwzzSxTEiQ7NipdE6WnLOvgfywfRDL622W@pgC3/MgEygCOzpwhfi55AvNWXRKeKk07k2DB9NibXCHGr@isYaKuA/vX9SIjZg4qBVCX0X5f@BqUD4)

Answer (score 1):

**Java, 96 Bytes**

```java
int f(int n,int[]a){for(int s=1,i=1,x=a[n];0>(n+=i++*s)|n>=a.length||a[n]<=x;s=-s);return a[n];}
```

Identifiers are named like @Leaky Nun's answer. Furthermore, most parts have been aligned to be basically the same: In comparison, the `if` has been replaced by the `for`-condition (sacrificing the additional semicolon). A colon has been removed by moving increment-part into condition (so the parentheses of the previous if-statement practically "moved") - changing & to | did not have impact on character count.

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 9 bytes

```
>ị@TạÞị⁸Ḣ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bVM9bt4wDL2KkVkGREmkrKXoIboFGbMUuUDGzL1DgXbpFYJ2zEm@XsThe6Q7FAFsS@LPM98j9fXx6en5PD/d/nz7/OX2@8fbd9/9fXm9vf48337dnef9LmVMKzqP0mapRYpbpLSHst3bKtvoZTt8Xb5aK1tTt5VNBK/vj@mb6RarfvBVDw/y19wxEaW@Gf66rTuILEcRpEWqY3RYuga4dDdHDKIVEEhHMPKBBptHLEvfgg9VLT8gqyLa3LIqrO5vEuXMGTyEntayqIaEQ6N8/r06eMMLTr7OFQA4NyqAzwzSAng5QBvGebl1XZ/qmIpfdgs5SDqLg34SrKACCpIjaLEUz1sIMUvi@MlK8jJ4PIIsJQfUuHDrJYEYKeNDrSA28aelWuYgICHVPxMuMp1sBMIHIjEK3VHYI0tuQ69eXNVAF7RwMbvnzLA@ZmmKgKqV8rtL0xHy1zCQO/4YSkSPOT1imdv@JQKOkzNSkcFGkCJnSBIHnZa@ctBQ4JIcONNsqUFIANZYIRDUoIhdc@JCJQ4UhEOXkMyZYofQTM59W6kffZCUYnICF67cKHvDHexFcWyE3tmB/b8W7B/0YDBL/B630rHtuM6O5qj6cGL0LG4In/4O)

### How it works

```
>ị@TạÞị⁸Ḣ - Main link. Takes the array A on the left and the index i on the right
 ị@       - Get the i'th element of A, k
>         - Is k greater than each element of A?
   T      - Get the indices of the 1s
     Þ    - Sort these indices by:
    ạ     -   Absolute difference with i
      ị⁸  - Index back into A
        Ḣ - Take the first element
```

Answer (score 0):

## Pyth, 16 bytes

```
JEh>#@JQ@LJaDQUJ
```

[Test suite](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=JEh>%23%40JQ%40LJaDQUJ&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=45%0A%5B69%2C+43%2C+89%2C+93%2C+62%2C+25%2C+4%2C+11%2C+115%2C+87%2C+174%2C+60%2C+84%2C+58%2C+28%2C+67%2C+71%2C+157%2C+47%2C+8%2C+33%2C+192%2C+187%2C+87%2C+175%2C+32%2C+135%2C+25%2C+137%2C+92%2C+183%2C+151%2C+147%2C+7%2C+133%2C+7%2C+41%2C+12%2C+96%2C+147%2C+9%2C+134%2C+197%2C+3%2C+107%2C+164%2C+90%2C+199%2C+21%2C+71%2C+77%2C+62%2C+190%2C+122%2C+33%2C+127%2C+185%2C+58%2C+92%2C+106%2C+26%2C+24%2C+56%2C+79%2C+71%2C+24%2C+24%2C+114%2C+17%2C+84%2C+121%2C+188%2C+6%2C+177%2C+114%2C+159%2C+159%2C+102%2C+50%2C+136%2C+47%2C+32%2C+1%2C+199%2C+74%2C+141%2C+125%2C+23%2C+118%2C+9%2C+12%2C+100%2C+94%2C+166%2C+12%2C+9%2C+179%2C+147%2C+149%2C+178%2C+90%2C+71%2C+141%2C+49%2C+74%2C+100%2C+199%2C+160%2C+120%2C+14%2C+195%2C+112%2C+176%2C+164%2C+68%2C+88%2C+108%2C+72%2C+124%2C+173%2C+155%2C+146%2C+193%2C+30%2C+2%2C+186%2C+102%2C+45%2C+147%2C+99%2C+178%2C+84%2C+83%2C+93%2C+153%2C+11%2C+171%2C+186%2C+157%2C+32%2C+90%2C+57%2C+181%2C+5%2C+157%2C+106%2C+20%2C+5%2C+194%2C+130%2C+100%2C+97%2C+3%2C+87%2C+116%2C+57%2C+125%2C+157%2C+190%2C+83%2C+148%2C+90%2C+44%2C+156%2C+167%2C+131%2C+100%2C+58%2C+139%2C+183%2C+53%2C+91%2C+151%2C+65%2C+121%2C+61%2C+40%2C+80%2C+40%2C+68%2C+73%2C+20%2C+135%2C+197%2C+124%2C+190%2C+108%2C+66%2C+21%2C+27%2C+147%2C+118%2C+192%2C+29%2C+193%2C+27%2C+155%2C+93%2C+33%2C+129%5D%0A2%0A%5B4%2C+-2%2C+1%2C+-3%2C+5%5D%0A0%0A%5B2124%2C+-173%2C+-155%2C+146%2C+193%2C+-30%2C+2%2C+186%2C+102%2C+4545%5D%0A0%0A%5B1%2C0%2C2%2C3%5D&debug=0&input_size=2).

Answer (score 0):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <s>110</s> 108 bytes

```c
c,o;e(g,l,f)int*g;{for(o=g[l],c=1;c<f;c++)l+c<f&&g[l+c]>o?o=g[l+c],c=f:0,l>=c&&g[l-c]>o?o=g[l-c],c=f:0;g=o;}
```

-2 bytes thanks to ceilingcat!!

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fVPLbttADDw3X7EI0MCqV6i4L2mrOv2Q1IdAtQwDjhWkPtXwt7scLtXERZCD9kFyZskhNdTbYbhcBjv1m8XW7u1Y7Q7HL9v@NE4vi2m1fdiv7bCifvg@9sNyWe2XfLq7Y/tyWN9PPySEjxw0fmvs/n41iLd@9dazt9@upv58eXrcHRbVzenmEz9ljvSwNitzMilbE7w1He@Z9@SscZFt1hDh43PX8qFlS2r4wnvsOIi/xI4WUZEPgT@2eSahzCwEWIEyh4fFx0JOns0lBtERFIAjGHiwwcYROakvw4esMl@AahCd2JIbWNnvqKTTtqUOEo9zmpQDoIslfXm9YXKHDzXx3uZCgLsTBbC0pWgCPXUoG8Z2dsc8Lw1zRjzpU5FDitbkoB@VqqACEqKulCWpMC4jJCUtHI9kLZ6CXLtSrEgOqjDzNrMElKRkLKIVxBb@NqlaiUlQBDW8tHBJpa00AuEBkRgFzyzSo6S1hTj3Ys4GuqCFWdBeZ0byE1RUEZB1FPnZFdVR5G@KQWrHi0WJ0mOZHkqKdf@AoJPJCapIkEZIiTJDpDzoNPmsg4YEM@nApagtTRAShE3ZIRDUEBF91IkrKslAQTh0CWCZKekQmilz77LqJz5IKmLKBGZz7vUHdPoDBls7S7b2Nr46vTqdPFtLd@r/2lO/05/whiMoB2dZAr34nl/YOy5uj8Tez79@Hm6t2SyOVNr7e/dnM418rczX@cLxVVW9hborqBP2Gek@RPorpJfUZqT/EBmukOEKGd5Bni9/AQ)

Comment: Suggest `l/c` instead of `l>=c`

Answer (score 0):

### Clojure, 95 bytes

```
#(%(nth(nth(sort-by first(for[i(range(count %)):when(>(% i)(% %2))][(Math/abs(- i %2))i]))0)1))
```

This is the shortest I could come up with :( I also tried playing around with this but couldn't bring it to the finish line:

```
#(map(fn[f c](f c))[reverse rest](split-at %2 %))
```

Answer (score 0):

## [JavaScript](https://nodejs.org), 44 bytes

```javascript
a=>g=(i,p)=>(x=a[i-p])>a[i]?x:g(i,p<0?-p:~p)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dVPLTiMxELzvV@Q4I9krt59jYMKHoBwiFqIgREaAECd@PXR193DYzR5sj/tR7qruedp/7N/uX4/Lu385/Xk4P87n/bw9zMPRLeO8HT7n/d3RL7txy@fu9vPqAM9NuPXL1dcynq9/3Z9e3k7PD7@fT4fhcbir3W1ycpuJz85njW4TC9vchgiLv6fGH40tNfCFzzJxEK/Kjoaowh@ZF9sSg1BnFEKapjJGgiUVBafEZo1BdAEE0hGMfKDBxhG9mq/Dh6o6X5AVEF3Z0gOs7I@k5bSmPEg8MVpREQlT0fLl9cDgEQuc@GxdAXCPogC2pqQJ8DSBNoxtdZe@boExC55MVeUQ0lYc9CNlBRVQEE1KS0rhvI6QWo04HulGnrJcJyUrkgMqr7hhlYCqUMYmWkFswW/V1KoMAhIUeGtwCdMmjUB4RiRGITGK9Kgat1zWXqzVQBe0sEt2spmR@iSrmAiouoj87CrmUPmDGoQ7XlQltMcyPVQtN/4kAk4mJ5siWRohFGWGyHDQaUrdBg0FdrKBq8VaWiEkAIOeEAhqiIip2MSpSjJQEA5dQrLMlHQIzZS5j930Ex8kFTFlAvtuHHIZx39@w@x8dOR8coVD4oWIKBV4aZT/q1P@QqsygMIFIHLBRZf@403OSxlczlrJ@Rs)

from https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/118765/

Answer (score 0):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 10 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
è›ƶ0K<¹.xè
```

0-based indexing.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//8IpHDbuObTPwtjm0U6/i8Ir//w24og11DHSMdIxjAQ) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##XVKxilRBEPyV5eJ6Mj0zPTMNwiVmfsKycCcamGggiJsZ@QF@xZkYGggmd2DsN9yPrFX9FETYt8z0q66uqn5v392@eP3q8v58c311uH3z8nB1zcPjp888nH/9eHa@uf9yebh7/Pj957fy/On91ycfHu4uuByPx83Q54DPhTpRYGDFUE/wEw7H4wj0hhWIhlFRHR1GhDnWhM2OUbA6nP0LY2LypU@SYqE1WFQYkQl2NN6ai8baRL4jxtnDBkLYwV5eK2JkMVjkyJggsBAyOoI6I1BN0@aUMFOt1hxJI7ZckjSgDFT@KHFghjp4rnLBZ0q7kcgW1fM@97rH/pQKJ3EbMiTxOZiuLUXSCefZkkqNKgi@GiP1ky3SgnWdl2QrHXb2naPsPmxIOx/5ZDKi4k7kdCxQmJWFyaJUT@VFUCeAO2kFCnGk1O57ZPs4OmO4IXzLnWm4kJ5WqMYVlMGzlEEVXeSBvGlHsWt3NhJd/2DZrMX1NNUVmPRqgZZ9zN5a5HY5PCx3PDyjHvTP9qJ/@qMheW@eS06P2iUtM0fCtU2FyJT1MdVI36oyBiWgjceJ5vOD7di0pq3pA65ZqiLdlNz2b3Tbf9mJoGSDQW/a36v6REji5Dz9Bg).

**Explanation:**

```python
è           # Get the item in the second (implicit) input-list at the first (implicit)
            # input-index
 ›          # Check for each value in the second (implicit) input-list if it's larger
            # than this value (1 if truthy; 0 if falsey)
  ƶ         # Multiply each by its 1-based index
   0K       # Remove all 0s from this list
     <      # Decrease each value by 1 to make it a 0-based index
      ¹.x   # Pop the list and get the item closest to the first input-index
         è  # Use that to index into the second (implicit) input-list
            # (after which the result is output implicitly)
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) [`-g`](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14339/), 11 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
gUð>UgV)ñaV
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&flags=LWc&code=Z1XwPlVnVinxYVY&input=Wy0xLDQ3Niw1NzgsMjcsMCwxLC0xLDEsMl0KNQ)

Answer (score 0):

## APL(Dyadic Classic), 21 bytes

```
A[1↑{⍵[⍋|I-⍵]}⍸A>I⌷A]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LVJLilRBENzPKeICDZX1yarcCL3slQcYZtGMIEKDwqxE3c5GexgXHkX0PO8ibUQ@4dWjKisyMyKyzp8uh3efz5eP7w@Pl/PT04fH2/by6/R2e34td0f@PdAbViAavKIOdJjxG1gTNju8YHWMhbrgE5OXY6JPLLQGiwojMsEDjac2VMbaRN4RM5jDBEKYwVweK8IzGAyyZUwQWAjxjigMBKqp25wiZorVmi0rUWuIkhoUR@VHio4ZyuC@SgXXFHdjIVtkz/Pc4yP2VSoGCzeXIJHPxlRtSZJK2M@WWKpVQfDKPfmzWqQE69ov0ZY7zOx7jbLrMBd3LumkMyo1PZX6AolZWZgMivWUXwR1AjiTViATPan2sVu2t6MymhvCt5yZmgs5UgrZDBllGBlKo4oO0sC6KUe2a3bmia7/sUzW4HqK6jJMfDVAyzx6by1yumweljP2kVY79TO96E99FCTtbeSQU6NmScn0kXBNUybSZT2mGqlbUdogBzTxuDvxsfah18vN8d62559ftuvv@@36/evpwN3Dt@369/jmtP34c3y43f4B)

Comment: Welcome to code golf, and nice first answer! Make sure to check out our [tips for golfing in APL](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/17665/tips-for-golfing-in-apl) to see if there's any way to golf your code.

Answer (score 0):

## TI-Basic, 46 bytes

```
Prompt A
Prompt I
seq(abs(J-I),J,1,dim(ʟA→B
SortA(ʟB,ʟA
ʟA(1+sum(not(cumSum(ʟA>ʟA(1
```

Index is 1-based. Output is stored in `Ans` and is displayed at the end.