# type in a random mess of capital letters

Tags: code-golf, string, random

SOMe PEOPle lIkE tO TYpE iN A LoGiCAL MAnNER, WITh CapITals aT tHe bEGiNnIng Of ThE SENtENCE and smaLl LETTErS EVeRYWHErE eLsE. NOT Us. NOt Us. Your joB iS to tAkE A SenTEncE Of A
LL SMAlL LeTTeRS, And rANDOmly ChAnGe sOMe to caPiTAl. ThiS iS a Code gOLF so tHE SmaLleST coDE WIll win.

the input will always be small letters and spaces with punctuation only.

random meaning running the code multiple times will always yield different results.

test cases for this will be hard since it involves random elements.

here is a shitty example with python

https://onlinegdb.com/Hy0_gEEKH

Comment: Welcome to CG&CC! This could do with some test cases, and some formal guarantees about the nature of the input. It can't hurt to define random, either. I think I've seen similar challenges, but can't find anything this is a duplicate of.

Comment: (Also, the link to your example seems to be broken. If it is in fact necessary, consider porting it to something like tio.run)

Comment: The input will be lower case letters only. Does that mean only `a-z`, or can there be spaces and other characters? Is it enough that the first letter is randomly capitalized, or is it required that all characters can be capitalized? Do you require uniform randomness?

Comment: Related: [Random Capitalization](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/149491/20260) That challenge differs in the input having already-capital letters which should stay capital. Maybe still a duplicate.

Comment: The "random" specification as it stands is [incomplete](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10909/36398)

Comment: "unning the code multiple times will always yield different results", I don't think this is possible.  If you run the code enough times there will be a collision, since there are only a limited number of possibilities.

Comment: `randomly change some` could be defined more clearly. For example, is randomly changing only one character to uppercase each time a valid solution? What if the solution only randomly changed several consecutive characters to uppercase but in a random range? (For example the answer may yield `abCDE` or `aBcde` for `abcde` but never `aBcDE`). If they are considered invalid, it is better to define the randomness as: All possible combination of uppercase and lowercase should be able to exist in theory.

Comment: @xnor this challenge specifies lowercase input so any solution for Random Capitalization necessarily works for this, with very little room for meaningful code reduction (except removing some code in some places). I'm not sure I want to use my hammer though.

Comment: (changed my mind) I believe this is far too similar to not be considered an exact duplicate of the other challenge, since the dominant strategy (basically the only one used) is to choose between each character and the character uppercased, which, being valid for both challenges, makes answer tactics fundamentally identical.

Comment: Changing the spec and invalidating existing solutions is an automatic `-1` from me.

Answer (score 4):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 59 bytes

```python
i=input()
while i:print(end={i,i.upper()}.pop()[0]);i=i[1:]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/P9M2M6@gtERDk6s8IzMnVSHTqqAoM69EIzUvxbY6UydTr7SgILVIQ7NWryC/QEMz2iBW0xqoJ9rQKvb/f4/UnJx8hfD8opwUAA)

*-4 bytes thanks to Chas Brown*

Uses `set.pop()` to randomize.

Comment: [63 bytes](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/P8/WgCstv0ghUyEzD4gKSks0NK0KijLzSjRS81JsqzO18nQy9UoLClKLNDS18mr1CvILNDSjDWI1rfO0bQ3//0@EAgA). Never knew `pop` could be used for random choice... nice!

Comment: @ChasBrown good find, thanks! `pop` picks an item based on hash value. From Python 3.something onward, this is completely randomized for a.o. strings. The catch is that it is only assigned once per string per session, so it can only be used in a full program.

Answer (score 4):

## [APL (Dyalog Extended)](https://github.com/abrudz/dyalog-apl-extended), 6 [bytes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9429/43319)<sup>[SBCS](https://github.com/abrudz/SBCS)</sup>

Anonymous tacit prefix function. Assumes `⎕IO←0` (0-based indexing)

```apl
⊢×∘?2¨
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNrShJzUtJTfn/qG@qp/@jtgmG/x91LTo8/VHHDHujQyv@pwGFHvX2QWS7mg@tN37UNhHICw5yBpIhHp7B/9MU1EsyUhUy8wpKSxTKM3NyFBJzyhMrixWSUhWKcxOB/JzUkpLUomKF/LycSj11AA)

`2¨` number two for each character

`?` random index among the first that many indices (i.e. 0 or 1 for each character)

`∘` then

`×` use that to change case (0:lower; 1:upper) on the following:

`⊢` the unmodified argument

Answer (score 2):

## [K (oK)](https://github.com/JohnEarnest/ok), 32 bytes

```
{,/{`c$x-32*1?2*(x<123)*x>96}'x}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##BcHrCkAwAAbQV/lcCovJVoqER7HYSi6T7cckzz7nbIXevFftm5fvNMeu4IxUAyOp6yrGM@L6pv4S93mF0D6XxHpC4Bbnog8c0hhohVlcqxU7dmmtvA2lFMEwRqH/AQ)

Answer (score 1):

## [Red](http://www.red-lang.org), <s>80</s> <s>78</s> 58 bytes

```
func[s][foreach c s[prin do pick[c[uppercase c]]random 2]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Jcw9CgIxEAbQfk/xkV7U2HkM22GKMD@6uGZC4uLxI@I7wOum82ZKvPRSNV7HYaao8Vn8iul7FRpMHt2KPCAY1PpaoYG2ypOE9tasSxkGYf4fyMxzi2jIJ3IkCbXDPTbHOV8SfsEbKfH8Ag)

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) [`-m`](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14339/), 5 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
c^HÑö
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&flags=LW0&code=Y15I0fY&input=ImFiY2RlZmdoaWprbG1ub3BxcnN0dXZ3eHl6Ig)

Comment: the challenge states input will have"small letters and spaces with punctuation", this fails when there are non-letters

Comment: @EmbodimentofIgnorance, it was lowercase letters only at time of posting. Would you believe, though, I also had your solution written up in another tab but copied the Markdown from the wrong one?!

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) [`-m`](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14339/), 4 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
+u)ö
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&flags=LW0&code=K3Up9g&input=ImFiY2RlZmdoaWprbG1ub3BxcnN0dXZ3eHl6OiwuLiwuLCI)

```
-m    //Map all characters in input
+     //Input prepended to
  u)  //Input to uppercase
    ö //Random character
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 72 bytes

```python
lambda i:"".join(choice(x)for x in zip(i,i.upper()))
from random import*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DYsxDsMgDAD3vsJigqrK0LFSf9KFEBCuwLbAUZJ@njKdTrqTSzPTc6T3ZxRf180DvoxZvoxkQ2YM0Z4ucYMTkOCHYvGByy4Sm3XO3VLjCs3TNoFVuOl9SENSSNZojvOSXeHAUsCXw18d1gi9@uklqsbWYd7QxYfYZ6cZZKegu1dkAqZyLcaNPw)

Answer (score 1):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), <s>60</s> <s>46</s> 43 bytes

<sup>-3 bytes thanks to mazzy</sup>

```powershell
-join($args|%{"$_"|%('t*g','*per'|random)})
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfmvkmZb/V83Kz8zT0MlsSi9uEa1WkklXqlGVUO9RCtdXUddqyC1SL2mKDEvJT9Xs1bzfy0Xl0qxgq2CEkh7vkJ5flFOip4Sl5pKmoJDMZT6DwA)

Comment: perhaps toUpper will be better?

Comment: @mazzy Yep, it was. Thanks

Comment: nice. [-3 bytes](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfmvkmZb/V83Kz8zT0MlsSi9uEa1WkklXqlGVUO9RCtdXUddqyC1SL2mKDEvJT9Xs1bzfy0Xl0qxgq2CEkh7vkJ5flFOip4Sl5pKmoJDMZT6DwA "PowerShell – Try It Online") :)

Answer (score 0):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 5 bytes

```
żŒuX€
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///onqOTSiMeNa35//9/Tn55alFyYnEqAA)

Stolen from totallyhuman's solution to [Random Capitalization](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/149512/85334).

My original solution, since I forgot Jelly has `ż`:

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 6 bytes

```
Œu,X¥"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///opFKdiENLlf7//5@TX55alJxYnAoA)

[`,ŒuXƊ€`](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/1/n6KTSiGNdj5rW/P//Pye/PLUoObE4FQA) works for the same byte count.

```
     "    For every element of the input and every corresponding element of
Œu        the input capitalized,
  ,X¥     choose one or the other at random.
```

Answer (score 0):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), <s>51</s> 50 bytes

```php
for(;$l=$argn[$i++];)echo$l>_&&rand()%2?$l^' ':$l;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY/dTsMwDEZf5bso@9FGL7ikwO54CQTI69w2w7WjJKPqy1PSDmlCsmwpsc537Ds/PR187o2FTVXIc0Gh1bfC7Xbv1Zbrzgp5@VytAulps717OBTyscb6sZBqmqL1DM/mhSHui5EMafQMpyCIta4mQU@qHPYYXOpQk3eJJIISUsc4cutUnbawZnmIrIm1ZuRAxJ5EIJwShwj@5jAOHQcGS@QSagmXeJujXQLOdoSLiwplJboRc0K2kv/U/RI0n2e9jKg70jZbzJdlxJ9umdUyMxehthOjNWny0tV4xnFM15/BZfbgtPwxn5xpnO5ffwE)

---

## [PHP](https://php.net/), <s>51</s> 50 bytes

```php
for(;$l=$argn[$i++];)echo rand()%2?ucfirst($l):$l;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY/BTsMwDIZf5T8UadPGDhwpaDdeAnHwMrcNuHaUuFR9eUq2IU1Ili0l1vd/TkNaX46p9s7ypm3ktaHc63sTd7uPdsthMGTS82b78HScQhdz8U0j2@dG2nUtNjISWxKGxC@GG3xJjKggiPUxkGAkVc57zNEHBErRSQrI4QPjxH1UjdrDuutDYXXWwKipKCOJQNidcwF/c17mgTODpfABao6p3OdiU8annRDLVYWqEt2JNaFayX/q/hp0udFGWRAG0r5aXC6riD/dQ1WrzFqEYGdGb9LVpZvxBcfFbz9zrOw56uHHkkfTsj6@/QI)

Answer (score 0):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 22 bytes

```perl
s/./.5<rand?uc$&:$&/ge
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY9BasNADEWv8hchq9RZZVMK3fUeiqOMp5WlYUau8eXryk4hFAQCSbz/VLjKZV3buTt3l7dKenuf@sPx9XA8J465jYzCVoQh@YvhBl8KIysIYin3JBhJlesJc/YBPZXsJA3k8IFx5ZRVsybYfR80VmftGRGGNpIIhN25NvA312UeuDJYGndQc0zt2RebKj7titx2FQolehIjIazkP/W0B22v2SgL@oE0hcX2WSD@dLtQC2YUobcbI5nc4@hhvOG4@WMz52DPWbsfK55N2/oi5eMX)

Answer (score 0):

## [C# (Visual C# Interactive Compiler)](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/releases/5.0.0/#csc), 59 bytes

```cs
x=>x.Select(l=>z.Next()<1?l.ToUpper():l);var z=new Random()
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bZBNT8MwDIbv/Aqrp1SMSlzZWg4IJC4c@BBnL7htwHWqxF3X/fmSdaAJiShSJDt63se28cpGNz8MYmHzeC9DRwG3TJuowUlTrf6pVXU578tqX7wQk1XDZXUonmivJt9c33Lx6t/6noLJbzhf7zDAoRQa4Rnlw3cmn9cX78EpmROuuPNiUU1tsug7gp58zwTsvgjUg049gRNAYN84iwwdilBYwei0BYu9U@QIqKAtwZYaJ5Kw4OulEEmUxBKkdIgdMgOTKoUItKMwjS0FAuJIBYhXGOL5nfwQ4NNvwcVFBZMSnokpIVnxX@pqCQrLrDyBbVGaZHGcLCF@dIuklpjpIlj/QdB4rtOnk/ERR1FPndEl9ugk@932cfOXWZans56/AQ)

Comment: 51 bytes - `x=>x.Select(l=>new Random().Next()<1?l.ToUpper():l)`

Answer (score 0):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <s>109</s> 46 bytes

Thanks to Johan du Toit for -63 bytes

```c
f(char*s){for(;*s++-=(*s-97u<26&rand())*32;);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@r5yZl5xTmpKqYFNckpKZr5dhx4UilJOZBBT7n6aRnJFYpFWsWZ2WX6RhrVWsra1rq6FVrGtpXmpjZKZWlJiXoqGpqWVsZK1pXfs/NzEzT0OzmosTpEuhONrSMtaaizM9taRYo1gTyEqDUAWlUIHa/4kkAwA)

Comment: [46 bytes](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@r5yZl5xTmpKqYFNckpKZr5dhx4UilJOZBBT7n6aRnJFYpFWsWZ2WX6RhrVWsra1rq6FVrGtpXmpjZKZWlJiXoqGpqWVsZK1pXfs/NzEzT0OzmosTpEuhONrSMtaaizM9taRYo1gTyEqDUAWlUIHa/4kkAwA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 8 bytes

```
⭆Ｓ‽⁺↥ι↧ι
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z@gKDOvRCO4BEil@yYWaHjmFZSWQLgamjoKQYl5Kfm5GgE5pcUaoQUFqUXOicWpGplAGZ/8cjgPBKz///dIzcnJ11EIzy/KSVHk@q9blgMA) Link is to verbose version of code. Trivial modification of my answer to [Random Capitalization](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/149491).

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 94 bytes

```python
s=input();from random import*;print("".join([i.upper() if randint(0,1)==1 else i for i in s]))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYpBCsMwDAS/InKySwkNPQa/pPQQsE1UbFlI8qGvd53CMHPY5a@djZ5jaEDibs7vWVoFOSjOYOUmdttZkMwty/ppSO6Fa2dO4jxg/l@v9XHffAgbpKIJEHKTaSTQt/dj2IkKk6MU0Hq5JLMkCrHHpD8)