# Running gene crossover algorithm

Tags: code-golf, array

Your task is to accept as input two gene sequences, and a sequence of "cross over points", and return the gene sequence that results from the indicated cross overs.

What I mean by this is, say you have the sequences `[A, A, A, A, A, A, A]` and `[Z, Z, Z, Z, Z, Z, Z]`, and cross over points of `2` and `5`. The resulting sequence would be `[A, A, Z, Z, Z, A, A]`, because:

```
Cross Here:   V     V
Indices:  0 1 2 3 4 5 6

Genes 1:  A A A A A A A
Genes 2:  Z Z Z Z Z Z Z

Result:   A A Z Z Z A A
              ^     ^
```

Note that while I'm using letters here for clarity, the actual challenge uses numbers for genes.

The result is the first sequence until a cross over point is encountered, then the result takes from the second sequence until another cross over point is encountered, then the result takes from the first sequence until a cross over point is encountered...

## Input:

- Input can be any reasonable form. The two sequences can be a pair, with the points as the second argument, all three can be separate arguments, a single triplet of `(genes 1, genes 2, cross-points)`, a map with named keys...
- The cross points will always be in order, and will always be inbounds. There won't be duplicate points, but the list of cross over points may be empty.
- Gene sequences will always be the same length, and will be non-empty.
- Indices can be 0 or 1 based.
- Genes will always be numbers in the range 0-255.
- It doesn't matter which argument is "genes 1" or "genes 2". In the case of no cross over points, the result can either be either entirely "genes 1" or "genes 2".

---

## Output

- Output can be any reasonable form that isn't ambiguous. It can be a array/list of numbers, an array of string numbers, a *delimited* string of numbers (some non-numeric character must separate the numbers)...
- It can be returned or printed to the std-out.

---

Entries can by full programs or functions.

---

## Test Cases `(genes 1, genes 2, cross points) => result`:

```
[0], [1], [0] => [1]
[0, 1], [9, 8], [1] => [0, 8]
[0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 0], [1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 1], [1, 3, 5] => [0, 3, 5, 6, 8, 1]
[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8], [] => [1, 2, 3, 4]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [0, 2, 3, 6, 8] => [1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1]
```

This is Code Golf.

Comment: Your worked example would be a bit clearer if the crossover indices weren't also elements in the sequences.

Comment: Fixed. Changed it to A's and Z's. Hope that's clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>12</s> 10 bytes

```
ṁ⁹L‘¤ḣ"ḷ"/
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///hzsZHjTt9HjXMOLTk4Y7FSg93bFfS////f3S0qY6CmY6CuY6CRayOQrShjoKRjoKxjoJJbOx/MC8WAA)

Argument 1: seq1, seq2
Argument 2: cross points (0-indexed)

Comment: There was a reason... this does not work for [one of the test cases](https://tio.run/##ATUAyv9qZWxsef//4bmsK1zhu4vFkkThuKL///9bXf9bMSwgMiwgMywgNF0sIFs1LCA2LCA3LCA4XQ)!

Comment: Also fails in other scenarios, [e.g.](https://tio.run/##ATgAx/9qZWxsef//4bmsK1zhu4vFkkThuKL///9bMiwzXf9bMSwgMiwgMywgNF0sIFs1LCA2LCA3LCA4XQ)

Comment: Looks like something like `;⁹ZL‘¤Ṭ+\ịŒDḢ` would be required :(

Comment: @JonathanAllan I actually managed to find a 12-byte version quite different than what you suggested. :)

Comment: @JonathanAllan ...and then I discovered a **completely** different 10-byte version, checked with both your links and another test case (relax, I did remember to change to 0-based indexing). :D

Answer (score 4):

## JavaScript (ES6), <s>47</s> 45 bytes

*Saved 2 bytes thanks to @ETHproductions*

Takes input as a triplet **[a, b, c]** where **a** and **b** are the gene sequences and **c** is the list of 0-indexed cross-points.

```javascript
x=>x[i=j=0].map(_=>x[(j+=x[2][j]==i)&1][i++])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dZDdCoMwDIXv9xS5GhUzre7HedG9SAlDnA7FqcwxfPvOWv9gCqFw0i8np82jb9TE76z@HMrqkahUqFbcWpmJXHByXlHN7lqz3Bat9EnmJERm7T2SmW2TpeKqbKoicYrqyVImJScE6emDE1kWuK6Wuz8MoYdChKuZGGGuO2u8j3BCuHTXCGYLwhHhjBAghIPf0Fu6GcbMrSTxeucOOul5QwZDqvkFM7QWbbOGSJvV/9PorSMuN3q9xwTzSZL6AQ)

#### Commented

```javascript
x =>                    // given x = [ geneSeqA, geneSeqB, crossPoints ]
  x[i = j = 0]          // initialize i = gene sequence pointer and j = cross point pointer
  .map(_ =>             // for each value in the first gene sequence:
    x[(                 //   access x[]
      j += x[2][j] == i //     increment j if i is equal to the next cross point
    ) & 1]              //   access either x[0] or x[1] according to the parity of j
    [i++]               //   read gene at x[0][i] or x[1][i]; increment i
  )                     // end of map()
```

Comment: I believe you can do something like `x[(j+=x[2][j]==i)%2][i++]` to save a couple of bytes.

Comment: @ETHproductions Thanks! I foolishly tried to add a 3rd variable to keep track of the pointer in **x[2]** but overlooked this optimization.

Answer (score 4):

### Haskell, <s>58</s> <s>53</s> <s>51</s> 45 bytes

```
(fst.).foldl(\(a,b)p->(take p a++drop p b,a))
```

The two gene sequences are taken as a pair of lists and the cross points as a second argument.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dU5LDoIwEN17ihfioo0DERCRhSZeQ2RRhKqxQiOc31qobohMZjGZ972J7lErZeT@bJjs@oAHslWVYmcmqOTaP7BePGpoiNWqerXaXiUJzs1T3BvsUbULQL/uTY8lJFi@Lgh5WHDAnlOMEA5wRtiNjPAPIyJsCFtLITgzQkxICCkhGxxGpXtO9eGot8hmUCajT/pL@xM2u9/g2bWG37KxKzsx945uPIJ3cuMNHSJKCvO@SCWunfEvWn8A)

```
foldl           -- fold the pair of genes into the list of
                -- cross points and on each step
    \(a,b) p -> -- let the pair of genes be (a,b) and the next cross point 'p'
      (take p a++drop p b,a)  
                -- let 'b' the new first element of the pair, but
                --   drop the first 'p' elements and 
                --   prepend the first 'p' elements of 'a'
                -- let 'a' the new second element 
fst             -- when finished, return the first gene
```

Answer (score 3):

## [APL (Dyalog 16.0)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 26 bytes

```apl
+/a⎕×(~,⊢)⊂≠\d←1@⎕⊢0⍴⍨≢a←⎕
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///qKNdIe2/tn7io76ph6dr1Ok86lqk@air6VHngpiUR20TDB2AEkAxg0e9Wx71rnjUuSgRKAoUA@n8n8ZlwGUIhFxAhoIhlxGXpYIFF4hnqGCkYKxgwvWodw2XqYKZgjlIHKTISMEEyLVQMOACs4AKjRVMgdKWClBTMCBYiQlICZCFAQE)

Input is **a**, **c**, then **b**. **c** is `1` indexed.

**How?**

`a←⎕` - get **a**.

`0⍴⍨≢` - create array of `0`s at its length.

`1@⎕⊢` - take **c** and change the `0`s to `1`s on the indices.

`d←` - assign to **d**.

`⊂≠\d` - expand **d** with **xor** to create the selection sequence (`0` for **a**, `1` for **b**), and enclose.

`(~,⊢)` - take **d** and its inverse.

`a⎕×` - and multiply respectively with inputted **b** and **a**.

`+/` - sum each pair of elements, yielding the **a**s on `0`s and **b**s on `1`s.

Comment: `⊢0⍴⍨≢` -> `≠⍨` ([tip](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/17665/tips-for-golfing-in-apl/155621#155621))

Comment: @ngn I can't get it to work [[tio](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///qKNdIe2/tn7io76ph6dr1Ok86lqk@air6VHngpiUR20TDB2AEkAxIP9R74pEoAiQD9L1P43LgMsQCLmADAVDLiMuSwULLhDPUMFIwVjBhOtR7xouUwUzBXOQOEiRkYIJkGuhYMAFZgEVGiuYAqUtFaCmYECwEhOQEiALAwIA)]

Comment: you need a `,` before 1-element vectors in the input

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 43 bytes

```python
def f(a,b,l):
 for p in l:a[p:],b=b[p:],a*1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dY7BCoMwEETP5ivmaMoejNWqAb9EcohUMSAxiKX061ON8SgsWWZ232Tdb5sWm3v/HkaMqaaeZi4ZxmWFg7GYpe6cVNS3fej6Ifx3MvMAIVkS9ltj3WdLOUuuAJa41dgN2qddpgidOJ5McbZrQlANoT5H0c0JBeG124QTIjwJJaEiNJGKXmBEYHZZHJMysFVMvUJvK4bdVjj4@uA4SvE/)

[Outputs by modifying](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4942/20260) the argument `a`. Instead as a program:

**50 bytes**

```python
a,b,l=input()
for p in l:a[p:],b=b[p:],a*1
print a
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dY7BCoMwEETvfsXgScscjNW2Cn6J5BCLxYDEIJa2X29NjEdh2WVmebNrf8swmXz9DHrsIer@2z/jOF4VO46NNva9JGn0mmZYaIOxVq2tJbum81NdRGRnbRao1WFJm0miFa5lMo02TXhVEY99FdycKIjbZhM7RFyJkrgTVaCC5xnhmU0WblN69h5Sj9DTCmGn5R8@DrinZPoH)

Answer (score 2):

## Python 3, <s>61</s> 60 bytes

```
f=lambda a,b,c,d=0:c and a[d:c[0]]+f(b,a,c[1:],c[0])or a[d:]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dY5BDoIwFET3nmKWEGdBBRSacJKmi9KGaKJACBtPX9tGo5iQ/C76Xmd@5@d6ncbS@6G7m0fvDAx7WrqukBZmdDDKSasKrY9D1tPQKiE1I8mnJVnt5@U2rtmQBUglwgkyP3wpI2vZJLs1OBEVcSYaIsShBFESNXEhWkL8sE1WpGzAVXxRp44QaeLtf8nuvMt3J/risyh@MjT7Fw)

-1 byte from Jonathan Frech

Explanation:

```
f=lambda a,b,c,d=0:c and a[d:c[0]]+f(b,a,c[1:],c[0])or a[d:]
f=lambda a,b,c,d=0:
 # recursive lambda: a and b are the two lists,
 # c is the crossovers, and d is where to start
                   c and
 # if there is at least one crossover left
 #  then
                         a[d:c[0]]
 #  return the items of the first list from the
 #  starting point up to the first crossover
                                  +f(b,a,c[1:],c[0])
 #  plus the result of the inverted lists with
 #  the remaining crossovers, starting where
 #  the first part left off
                                                    or
 # else
                                                       a[d:]
 #  the first list from the starting point to the end
```

Comment: Possible [60 bytes](https://tio.run/##dY5BDoIwFET3nmKWEGdBBRSacJKmi9KGaKJACBtPX9tGo5iQ/C76Xmd@5@d6ncbS@6G7m0fvDAx7WrqukBZmdDDKSasKrY9D1tPQKiE1I8mnJVnt5@U2rtmQBUglwgkyP3wpI2vZJLs1OBEVcSYaIsShBFESNXEhWkL8sE1WpGzAVXxRp44QaeLtf8nuvMt3J/risyh@MjT7Fw); assuming that `a[d:c[0]]+f(b,a,c[1:],c[0])` will never be false.

Answer (score 2):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) `-a`, <s>45</s> 40 bytes

Give input in the order "control", "second sequence", "first sequence" as separate lines on STDIN

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl -alp
@{$.}=@F}for(map${$.^=$%~~@1}[$%++],@2){
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/9@hWkWv1tbBrTYtv0gjN7FABciPs1VRratzMKyNVlHV1o7VcTDSrP7/31DBWMGUC0wqmCtYKhhyGSgYKZgomClYKBhw/csvKMnMzyv@r5uYU/Bf19dUz9BAzwAA)

Answer (score 2):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/),  <s>84</s> 79 bytes

```r
function(G,K){o=G[,1]
m=1:nrow(G)
for(i in K)o[m>=i]=G[m>=i,match(i,K)%%2+1]
o}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY3LCsIwFET3/YpuCvfiCE191WLcdtFPKF1IaDRgcyFUFMRvj1HQ1cDMOUyINj8so715Mzvx1KLjp@i2hxqySavGB7lTy5mVQC53Pu9Y@umo3ZCgT2I6zeZCLolFUS2SJq9oKbXBPchQiQprbFGjhMIKG@ywh2J4I1ddMQx9AU4fP0s19X92fh7PY6CSOb4B)

Takes input as a matrix of 2 columns and a `vector`.

Answer (score 2):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 24 bytes

```
4 :'(2|+/\1 x}I.#{.y)}y'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/r/P81Wz0TBSl3DqEZbP8ZQoaLWU0@5Wq9Ss7ZS/X9qcka@goFCmoKBjpUhF5hnCOIpGOpYKVgqWMCEjBVMwcJGCiYKZgoWIOVQUXOgMqhOkLQxWBqkFAOCtWBAiFagTpAF6o4QoK5jpR4FAeoQBeqeJQqZxQqJeUCUn1eZm19arJBWmpdckpmfZwVVowE0RFMBl1@xGv4fAA)

I don't count the `f=:` chars, because it works equally well as an anonymous function (as demonstrated in a TIO sample)

Note: It doesn't work for empty list of cross over points!

An explicit oneliner, `x` is the left argument - the list of cross over points, `y` is the right argument, a two-row table of the sequences.

### Explanation:

`4 :' ... '` - a dyadic verb

`(...)}y` - Each atom of operand (...) selects an atom from the corresponding positions of the items of y

`#{.y` - takes the first sequence and find its length

```
    #{. 0 2 4 6 8 0,: 1 3 5 7 9 1
6
```

`I.` creates a list of zeros with length the argument

```
   I.6
0 0 0 0 0 0
```

`1 x}` changes the items of the rigth argument (a list of zeroes) to 1 at indices indicated by `x` (the list of cors over points)

```
   1(1 3 5)}I.6
0 1 0 1 0 1
```

`+/\` running sums of a list

```
   +/\ 0 1 0 1 0 1
0 1 1 2 2 3
```

`2|` modulo 2

```
   2|+/\ 0 1 0 1 0 1
0 1 1 0 0 1
```

Assembled:

```
    0 1 1 0 0 1 } 0 2 4 6 8 0 ,: 1 3 5 7 9 1
0 3 5 6 8 1
```

Answer (score 2):

## SWI-Prolog, 78 bytes

```
A/B/[0|C]/D:-B/A/C/D. [H|A]/[_|B]/C/[H|D]:-maplist(succ,E,C),A/B/E/D. A/_/_/A.
```

Usage: Call "Genes1/Genes2/CrossoverPoints/X" where "Genes1", "Genes2", "CrossoverPoints" are bracket-enclosed, comma-separated lists.

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 13 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
ṬœṗÐ€ż/JḂị"ƊF
```

A dyadic link accepting the (1-indexed) crossover points on the left and a list of the two sequences on the right which returns the resulting list.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///hzjVHJz/cOf3whEdNa47u0fd6uKPp4e5upWNdbv///4820lEw0VEwi/0fHW2gowDl6ShY6CgYxOooRBvqKBjrKJjqKJjrKFjqKBjGxgIA)**

#### How?

```
ṬœṗÐ€ż/JḂị"ƊF - Link: list, C; list, S     e.g. [2,4,6]; [[0,2,4,6,8,0],[1,3,5,7,9,1]]
Ṭ             - untruth C                       [0,1,0,1,0,1]
   Ð€         - map across S with:
 œṗ           -   partition at truthy indices   [[0],[2,4],[6,8],[0]]  /  [[1],[3,5],[7,9],[1]]
      /       - reduce with:
     ż        -   zip                           [[[0],[1]],[[2,4],[3,5]],[[6,8],[7,9]],[[0],[1]]]
           Ɗ  - last three links as a monad:
       J      -   range of length               [1,2,3,4]
        Ḃ     -   bit (modulo by 2)             [1,0,1,0]
          "   -   zip with:
         ị    -     index into                  [[0],[3,5],[6,8],[1]]
            F - flatten                         [0,3,5,6,8,1]
```

Comment: @Carcigenicate - thanks I just noticed after asking :D

Comment: `Ḃ`: What a useless thing for indexing into a 2-element list. `ż/`: How useless of a complication, it's cruelly flattened away by a big truck anyway!

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 19 bytes

```
ＡθＡηＥ§θ⁰§§θＬΦ⊕κ№ηλκ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TYzNCsIwEITvPsWS0wZWSK31h55EEAoK3kMOoQ2mNKZtSMW3jwERnMPwzcBMa3VoR@1Savy0RJx5vfqSzXQPvY940xOeYuM788aZQHCCX/yrr8Y/osVL76IJ2Pg2mKfx0XQ45MF5XPKTJXA8i2DIXqckJROb7e4gGAErymp/LJgikAVBSVApldYv9wE) Link is to verbose version of code. Takes input as a pair of string gene sequences and a 0-indexed list of crossing points. Explanation:

```
Ａθ                  Input the pair of gene sequences into `q`
  Ａη                Input the list of crossing points into `h`
    Ｅ§θ⁰            Loop over one of the gene sequences
              κ     Current index
             ⊕      Incremented
            Φ  №ηλ  Intersect implicit range with crossing points
           Ｌ        Take the length
         §θ         Cyclically index into the pair of gene sequences
        §         κ Take the appropriate element of that sequence
                    Implicitly output on separate lines
```

Alternatively, `⭆` could be subsituted for `Ｅ` to print the result as a string. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TUzLCsIwELz7FUtOG1ihsdYHPYkgFBQEj6WH0oamNKZt2Ip/HwMiOId5wUxjat@MtQ2hcNPCOMt89XUmurvvHeODo3S3esITF67Vb5wJEknwi3/1VbuODV56y9pj4Rqvn9qxbnGIg/O4xD9DYGUEwRA5D6EsRbLZ7g6JIBAqzfZHJSqCUhGkBFlVhfXLfgA)

Answer (score 1):

## [C (clang)](http://clang.llvm.org/), 79 bytes

```c
*g[2],*c,l,m;f(i,j,k){for(i=j=k=0;i<l;g[0][i++]=g[k][i])m&&c[j]==i?k=!k,j++:0;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lVPbbuIwEH3PV8ymahUTd5sb2y0m8APVvu1TGlVRSFJDCCugUoDy7XRsx0kK5WGRpXjOnLmdMel9WiZVcbrhVVq@z7LxZjvjq59vE6OHrHlVIHQaFJEX00FKS7pkucXpnC7IIV@tLR7Ow0XoMD4uWRE5ccRtOw6LaIG3mCzv7tJoHochny7CHws6t@2Rw46nm1mW8yqDZL1OdmVWWTUBq55u@D5b5Wg86BtmJCOHGIaO@IctbWWYVdOSwAFeDJ5bf/4@P0MYQg0fH1CKmyN8kp1bZhSDSdgRuVm5ydAhoqotvHJAJkOrZSIPTTGaduJ3DKX42jZpU97ObjcmhTp65TEFJI@t8t4lZIqgOTJVGk2W5dEWHRy7YRKcAXYU9gRAtHSA734vBghlsZmaXeCuwHfneIrgnl3mQWX6mjONL/v4XrYK13rpbUC0hUtgl7j7LZ7SZR9EYSCcSGl08twi7L@Kvm83lmmSMwFQY7nfZcIrCx@CNLapW0RCroNzpMJ6U5arrFT7WMP2NJuConhNwBOF3wpIdQYd43cxHoWAwi/kUlAFfV2Qgk9hSOGRwpNO7qdfnG3GoGhxT7oCSQ@aXENZ4lF3FDRZ2vBh19DVIyOHXXNXjyKm/RF9NSLWMxJLKKyUVYoSJkGvUOopyRrQL5QkavYGDAo1mxqlAYeF6k8VR1Bs92FgiHcA4qWB/HdMxB1B7FNAYknKL12OMKX3y14k42wdPayNVQQVJKp02xDsbgnCanrpGLLs1dOUu3rkfH2t2/yuTNAyndaMjcHD6RM)

Inputs:
`g[0]` is gene-sequence 1,
`g[1]` is gene-sequence 2,
`c` is cross-over points.
`l` is length of `g[0]` and `g[1]`
`m` is length of `c`
All array inputs are arrays of integers with 0-based index.

Outputs:
Output is stored in `g[0]`

macro a() in footer does pretty-printing of test-cases and result