# The max() is not enough

Tags: code-golf

### Intro

A friend posed this question today in a slightly different way - "Can a single [Python] command determine the largest of some integers AND that they aren't equal?".

While we didn't find a way to do this within *reasonable* definitions of "a single command", I thought it might be a fun problem to golf.

### Challenge

"*Return the largest of a list of integers if-and-only-if they are not all equal.*"

More specifically:

Given a string containing only a comma-separated list of integers:

- If they are all equal, return/output nothing
- Else, return/output the largest

### Rules

- The **input** must be a string containing only a comma-separated list of integers
- The **output** must be either nothing (no output of any kind), or else the largest element from the input, represented as it is in the input

Entries may be a full program or just a function, provided you provide some way to test them!

### Assumptions

- Assume input list elements may be more than one digit but no larger than 
  ( 2<sup>32</sup> − 1 )
- Assume the input list has no more than a million elements
- Assume the input will not include negative values
- Assume the input will never be empty

<sup>For the avoidance of doubt, the explanation of the challenge given just after "More specifically" shall supersede the statement of the challenge above it ("Return the largest...").</sup>

### Examples

(1) All equal:

```
Input: 1,1
Output:
```

(2) Dissimilar:

```
Input: 1,2
Output: 2
```

(3) Zero!:

```
Input: 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0
Output: 1
```

(4) Random:

```
Input: 7,3,8,4,8,3,9,4,6,1,3,7,5
Output: 9
```

(5) Larger numbers, larger list:

```
Input: 627,3894,863,5195,7789,5269,8887,3262,1448,3192
Output: 8887
```

#### Additional examples:

(6) All equal, larger list:

```
Input: 7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7
Output:
```

(7) All equal, larger list, larger numbers:

```
Input: 61976,61976,61976,61976,61976,61976,61976,61976,61976,61976,61976,61976,61976,61976,61976,61976,61976,61976,61976,61976,61976,61976,61976
Output:
```

(8) Not equal, larger list, larger numbers:

```
Input: 96185,482754,96185,96185,96185,96185,96185,96185,7,96185,96185,96185,96185,96185,96185,96185,96185,96185,96185,96185,96185,96185,96185,96185,96185,961185,96185,96185,96185
Output: 961185
```

### Scoring

This is `code-golf`, so the code with the shortest number of bytes wins!

Comment: Is it OK to throw an error when the list contains all equal values? And can we output a null value (such as `None` in python) rather than outputting nothing? Also, why must the input be a string rather than a list? And what do you mean by *the largest element from the input, **represented as it is in the input***

Comment: I'd suggest loosening the input requirements to allow for an array/list of integers, too. Are we guaranteed that the list will contain at least 2 elements? Can we output a consistent, non-numeric value instead of nothing if all integers are equal?

Comment: Please add a test case where the maximum occurs more than once, like `7,3,7,2`.

Comment: Can we have a test case with only one element? Also, can we include a trailing `,` in the input?

Comment: Info: This challenge was sandboxed. /// For OP: Although the sandbox is pretty inactive, (I think) it is only a minor problem. The problem is that some problems with the challenge are not apparent if one only reads the challenge, and can only be discovered when one actually solves it.

Comment: @user202729 Most of the things stated above were also mentioned in the Sandbox though. To quote OP's response on the suggestions: "_I figure I'll try strict requirements this time around and if it's a problem I'll avoid them in future._" So the comma-separated string with empty string output if all items are equal is mandatory for this challenge I'm afraid.. (instead of list/array/stream/new-lines delimited inputs and any distinct falsey output as I would suggest for future challenges)

Comment: I really don't feel like writing a string splitting function for the 100th time right now.

Comment: If there is exactly one element in the list, that means all elements are equal and the program should output nothing, correct? It would be good to add that as a test case.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>50</s> 37 bytes

-33 bytes thanks to digEmAll! -13 bytes thanks to rturnbull!

```r
x=scan(se=",");if(any(diff(x)))max(x)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/v8K2ODkxT6M41VZJR0nTOjNNIzGvUiMlMy1No0JTUzM3sQJI/zfUMdQx1jH8DwA)

Comment: Input *does* (currently) HAVE to be a string, unfortunately.

Comment: [50 bytes taking a comma separated string](https://tio.run/##K/r/PyEzLUGjuDRXoyQxKSdVo8JGtzg5MU@jONVWXUddU7PGUNPGSCc5sURDUyc3sUKjQlPzv6GOoY6xjuF/AA "R – Try It Online")

Comment: Oops I guess my prior link was wrong! [This](https://tio.run/##K/r/PzmxRCM3sUKjwka3ODkxT6M41VZdR11TM7q4NFejJDEpJ1WjQrPGUNPOMFbzv6EOCBr/BwA) should be right, combining digEmAll's idea with the one I intended on posting...

Comment: [37 bytes](https://tio.run/##K/r/v8K2ODkxT6M41VZJR0nTOjNNIzGvUiMlMy1No0JTUzM3sQJI/zfUMdQx1jH8DwA "R – Try It Online") by improving how we test the array for equality.

Answer (score 5):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), <s>26 23</s> 22 bytes

*-1 byte thanks to nwellnhof*

```perl6
{.max if .Set>1}o&EVAL
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJamYKvwv1ovN7FCITNNQS84tcTOsDZfzTXM0ee/NVdxYqVCmoaSoY6hkiYyT8cYiW9maGlupjMISCQ3WZoZWpjqmFgYmZua6EA4@ElzolRRSGKVUNL8DwA)

Returns an empty slip if everything is equal.

#### Explanation

```perl6
                o&EVAL  # Eval the string to a list of integers
{              }         # Pass to code block
 .max            # Return the max
      if .Set>1  # If the list converted to a set has more than one element
```

Comment: The `EVAL` trick is neat and you can even save a byte with `o&EVAL`.

Comment: Wouldn’t `if +.Set` work?

Comment: @Ven No, we need to check if there is more than one element in the Set.

Comment: Mh, and bitwise ~ is 2 bytes in Perl 6 :(

Answer (score 5):

## [MathGolf](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf), 5 bytes

```
è▀s╞╙
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcuxDYAwDATAPlP8CnYSxx6HBihAFDAASwSJhpo92CSLBBevl@7163DM07aMvX9vu8691afVu3cCBQKHgghF8kSYt7gLu6o5SkQmyyhFDZnFoKo@sjAoJT@RcfgB)

### Explanation

```
è      Read whole input as int array
 ▀     Get unique elements
  s    Sort list
   ╞   Discard from left of array
    ╙  Get maximum of list
```

This works because both the max operator and the discard from left operator don't do anything for empty lists. Well, the max operator removes the list and pushes nothing for empty lists.

It could be 4 bytes if input could be taken as a list.

Comment: Input must be a *comma* separated string.

Comment: @Shaggy I missed that. Right now MathGolf doesn't have a "split on character" operator, so it'll take some work to get it right. I'll see what I can do.

Answer (score 5):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 4 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
ḟṀE?
```

A full program accepting the input as a command line argument (unquoted) which prints the required output

(Note that it deals with: empty input like , single item input like `7` and multiple item input like `7,8,7` like the spec seems to currently require.)

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///hjvkPdza42v///99ABxkagkgA)**

#### How?

```
ḟṀE? - Full program: if one argument is present it is evaluated using Python
     -                 so 7,8,7 -> [7,8,7], while 7 -> 7
ḟṀE? - Main Link: list or integer OR no argument (in which case an implicit argument of 0)
   ? - if...
  E  - ...condition: all equal? (for any integer E yields 1 since the argument is
     -                           treated as a list like [integer])
ḟ    - ...then: filter discard (since it's undefined the right argument is implicitly 
     -                          equal to the left; both are treated as lists, so this
     -                          yields an empty list)
 Ṁ   - ...else: maximum (again an integer is treated as a list)
     - implicit print (Jelly's representation of an empty list is an empty string
     -                 furthermore no newline is printed in either case)
```

Answer (score 4):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 12 bytes

Full program. Prompts for string from stdin.

```apl
{1≠≢∪⍵:⌈/⍵}⎕
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##zY49CgJBDIX7OYUHeINmfjPeZkGwWXBbEWt3Qe3sxdLeC81F1qw2ziIi2JgwL0zeR5KqqfViXdWrZZ/bXdNvKHfn3F1ye82H2zzv26nUbT6eBr/XWqvJIxpFIKXKhikbM7wmDVoCERYMJ88iSQ0CWUT4EgtGQE7CBQtPySNGTvAmJDCzmCYYkHMyh5IZ7xjlaDalGPAHWp6VArGHYxO9w/PzWeNX1I/61rgD)

`⎕` prompt for and evaluate expression (commas concatenate the numbers into a list)

`{`…`}` apply the following anonymous lambda (`⍵` is the argument; the list of numbers):

`1≠` [if] 1 is different from…

`≢` the tally of…

`∪` the unique numbers in…

`⍵` the list

`:` then

`⌈/` return the max across (lit. max reduction)…

`⍵` the list

[else: do nothing]

Comment: 1≠≢∪ here it seems find only if its argument is a list not a repetition of the same number so it is not 1 1 1 or 22 . So 1≠≢∪1 1 2 3 3 return true even if 3 is not unique and if that is true would return ⌈/⍵ the max 3 (even if it should return no output). Where is my error? Or possible ':' has a different meaning

Comment: @RosLuP Even if there are repetitions, and even repetitions of the max number, we still have to print the max. Only if the list has exactly one unique number do we print nothing. Look at the last example case in the OP.

Comment: Yes I wrongly understood the problem... thanks

Comment: would this work? `⌈/~⌊/`

Comment: @ngn No, it outputs a newline if all elements are equal.

Comment: `⍪⌈/~⌊/` then?­

Comment: @ngn Yes! That's very nice. Post it!

Comment: Nice way of getting around the input requirement!

Answer (score 4):

## [APL (Dyalog Classic)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 6 bytes

```apl
⍪⌈/~⌊/
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##zY5NCsJADIX3PUUP8ErN/CbHGSoVoaDQlRuXIlLBc3isucg4Tl2IiAhuJOQ9ki8JCduhWe7CsFk13RDGcd2l1MfDpY7na5yO7T5OpzalpuprAlWzq@ILPAfdtfQ9NBgmp4Zkd5lpeNhCncqcJWOnYUksvGeBVU7AzBkqp0DG5HUS9bj4EvMlEu/wB1q@EUdsYVh5azAXn9V/NfWjvgU3)

a [train](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/17665/tips-for-golfing-in-apl/43084#43084) computing the maximum (`⌈/`) without (`~`) the minium (`⌊/`) turned into a matrix (`⍪`)

if the input contains only one distinct element, `⌈/~⌊/` will be empty and `⍪` will return a 0×1 matrix which renders as nothing

otherwise, `⌈/~⌊/` will be a 1-element vector and its `⍪` will be a 1x1 matrix (visually indistinguishable from a scalar) that contains the maximum

Answer (score 3):

## [CJam](https://sourceforge.net/p/cjam), <s>16</s> 13 bytes

```
q',/:iL|$1>W>
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85KzP3/v1BdR98q06dGxdAu3O7/f2MdKAQA)

Answer (score 3):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 49/53 bytes

### My original version using `.every()`, 53 bytes

Does a function returning '' count as no output? Sure this can be improved upon...

```javascript
s=>(a=s.split`,`).every(e=>a[0]==e)?'':Math.max(...a)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dclBCoMwEADAez@SDcRFr8LqC3xBEVx0Yy2pETdIfX0s3ssc580H67gvWyrWOEnOnpQaYFLULSxpcINFOWQ/QajhZ9kTiW2NqTtOL/zwFxCR7WOMq8YgGOIMHkzlbsb@m/JXOV8)

---

### Improved version using `Set()` by [Shaggy](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/58974/shaggy), 49 bytes

```javascript
s=>new Set(a=s.split`,`).size>1?Math.max(...a):``
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/Z9m@7/Y1i4vtVwhOLVEI9G2WK@4ICezJEEnQVOvOLMq1c7Q3jexJEMvN7FCQ09PL1HTKiHh/38A)

Comment: A *very* quick improvement: https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/Z9m@7/Y1i4vtVwhOLVEI9G2WK@4ICezJEEnQVOvOLMq1c7Q3jexJEMvN7FCQ09PL1HTKiHh/38A

Comment: @Shaggy nice! I started off using Set but couldn't get it as short as that

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>42</s> 41 bytes

```python
a=input();print('',max(a))[len(set(a))>1]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/P9E2M6@gtERD07qgKDOvRENdXSc3sUIjUVMzOic1T6M4tQTEtjOM/f//PwA)

Comment: Welcome to PPCG :) I don't know Python but it looks like this requires input as list. Unfortunately (and unnecessarily, my opinion) the spec is (currently) very explicit that input must be a string.

Comment: @Shaggy, this program works if the input is of the form `element, element, ...`. i.e, it doesn't have to be enclosed in brackets.

Comment: A list _does_ work, but is not required because in Python 2, `input` by default `eval`s whatever string is passed from stdin.

Comment: [40 bytes](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/P9E2M6@gtERD07qgKDOvJCE3sUIjUTNBSyMnNU@jOLUEyNFUtDXU/P/fXAcVWgAA "Python 2 – Try It Online"). I don't know if a one element list can have a trailing `,` though, since your solution errors if the input is just a single number

Comment: @JoKing Is there a reason you could not change the `!=` to a `>` as the input will never be empty?

Answer (score 3):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), <s>77</s> <s>75</s> 61 bytes

```hs
f.read.('[':).(++"]")    
f a=[0|any(/=a!!0+0)a]>>show(maximum a)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DclBCoJAFADQfacYJXAGf6ajjn8C3XQBl4G5@Jim5BioUUFnb@ptX0/LrR1Ha2iYWM6GaW1nala2ZWfbBXNLl4B7lXcQAfd9t3bFpmOUV@GHpjff5@Q4oR8Kqoti6e9Pbug1mIdhJKxVMoMYdQKoYkgjnUKWoYZUKg2I@E@pJERJghBHWn6bbqTrYnenY1n@AA)

`('[':).(++"]")` takes a string (e.g. `"1,2,1,3"`) and encloses it in bracket chars (`"[1,2,1,3]"`). Then `read` turns the string into a list of integers (`[1,2,1,3]`).

The function `f` uses [this tip](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/150792/56433) for a shorter conditional if one of the outcomes is the empty list. `any(/=a!!0+0)a` checks whether the list `a` contains any element that is not equal to its first element `a!!0`. (The `+0` is needed such that `read` knows it has to look for a list of numbers.) If all elements are equal this test results in `False` and the empty string is returned. Otherwise `show(maximum a)`, that is the maximum of the list converted to a string, is returned.

Answer (score 3):

## Red, 81 bytes

```
x: split input","forall x[x/1: load x/1]sort x: unique x if 1 <>length? x[last x]
```

Like the R solution, a huge chunk of the code is handling the input string "1,1,2,44,1". If we can have that as a block, eg: `x: [1 1 2 44 1]`, then we can do it in 41 bytes:

```
sort x: unique x if 1 <>length? x[last x]
```

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! We typically ask for a link to an interpreter to verify a solution, and Dennis, one of our mods, has set up [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0pN@Q8EAA) for just such a purpose! It will even format your answer for you! Hope you enjoy your time spent here!

Comment: `sort x: unique load replace/all input","" "if 1 <>length? x[last x]` for 67 bytes. Unfortunately `input` doesn't work in TIO. If you make it a func, it works just fine in TIO: [73 bytes](https://tio.run/##zY7NasMwEITveYpF54FkZf2G0r5Dr8YHE8utQdiJY4Pf3lHIRQkhFHoJy44Y5tOwY2jW79CU1abdr@3cH8qlKs/DONGyp7nvTnOgONQNjeEY60PY1jHSIiAEia4lpo9PiqH/mX6/aCljfU4fq2o9jl0/UUuCwWKTOZm5HfLhq2apRQEHlbaAT69JRAELnTFGJsr5BJkCmr2Gtc5DS@PhnEuhNBKsVCphL@/aHyZvZW8N3kCzm7xhp6GctFrhZl6r/RP1T30aiPUC)

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 37 bytes

outputs to stderr (debug on tio).

```python
a=input();m=max(a);m>min(a)>exit(`m`)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/P9E2M6@gtERD0zrXNjexQiMRyLDLzcwDMuxSKzJLNBJyEzT//7c0M7Qw1TGxMDI3NdGBcPCT5kSpopDEKgEA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Neim](https://github.com/okx-code/Neim), 4 bytes

```
Ξ
```

Explanation:

```
  Ξ   If
    all elements are equal
    not
      then
     get greatest element
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0vNzP3//8PcCROAuO/cPCC54P//aDMjcwVjC0sTBQszYwVTQ0tTBXNzC0sFUyMzSwULCwugpJGZkYKhiYmFgrGhpVEsAA)

Comment: Currently, the input *must* be a comma-delimited string of integers but I've asked if we can take an array instead.

Answer (score 2):

## [K4](http://kx.com/download), <strike>38</strike> 35 bytes

```
{$[1=#:t:?:(7h$","\:x)-48;;*:t@>t]}
```

**Test Cases:**

```
q)k){$[1=#:t:?:(7h$","\:x)-48;;*:t@>t]}"1,2,4,4"
,4
q)k){$[1=#:t:?:(7h$","\:x)-48;;*:t@>t]}"4,4,4,4"
q)
q)k){$[1=#:t:?:(7h$","\:x)-48;;*:t@>t]}"7,3,8,4,8,3,9,4,6,1,3,7,5"
,9
q)k){$[1=#:t:?:(7h$","\:x)-48;;*:t@>t]}"7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7"
q)
```

I'm not very fluent in any of the k variants available on TiO, so no online example available, I'll try to come up with one though

**Explanation**

If you're wondering why certain operations are performed before others, K4 does not have operator precedence, it instead interprets from right to left (though you can use parentheses for precedence). Expressions seperated by semicolons.

```
   $[expr;`True;`False] is the conditional format

{$[1=#:t:?:(7h$","\:x)-48;;*:t@>t]}
               ","\:x                 //split string on commas
            7h$                       //cast strings to long
                      -48             //they'll be from ascii format, so compensate
         ?:                           //get distinct list      
       t:                             //set list to variable t        
     #:                               //get count of t
   1=                                 //check if count t = 1
                         ;;           //return nothing if true
                             t@>t  //if false, sort t descending
                           *:         //return first value
```

Can probably be golfed down more, not a fan of having to use that makeshift max function at the end.

EDIT: If the commas in output are a problem, it can be fixed with two more bytes:

```
q)k){$[1=#:t:?:(7h$","\:x)-48;;*:,/t@>t]}"1,2,4,4"
4
                                 ,/                 //joins the single element lists into one
```

Taking the total to <strike>40</strike> 37, but the comma before the number simply means that it's a single element list as opposed to an atom.

Answer (score 2):

## [Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/), 28 bytes

Returns the maximum (a number, which is an 1x1 matrix) or an empty (1x0) matrix.

```matlab
@(a)max(a)(1+all(a(1)==a):1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y08uSSxL/Z9mq6en999BI1EzN7ECSGoYaifm5Ggkahhq2tomaloZav635krTiDbQAcJYTRjTMFbzPwA)

Comment: Input is a string of comma separated numbers

Answer (score 2):

## Japt, 16 bytes

This would be 9 if not for the unnecessarily strict input format, 7 if throwing an error counts as outputting nothing.

Assumes the string contains at least 2 integers.

```
q, mn
â ÊÉ?Urw:P
```

[Try it](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.6&code=cSwgbW4K4iDKyT9Vcnc6UA==&input=IjgsOCI=)

Answer (score 2):

### PHP (<=5.6) <s>64</s> 74 bytes

```
 echo array_count_values($a=split(',',$argn))[$m=max($a)]==count($a)?'':$m;
```

Run as pipe with `-nR` or test it [online](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/8dd641d7b372b891909904c4dba616ba0b9a8498)

`split` was removed in PHP7, but as I had to add 10 to fix a few issues, it was worth using instead of `explode` which is roughly equivalent in this case.

Comment: `Also this doesn't work when there are more than one element with the max value`  I missread the `If they are all equal, return/output nothing` to be `If they are equal, return/output nothing` meaning if there are more then one to output empty.  Adding `==count($a)` fixes it.  Because `array_count_values` counts the number of times it appears in the array, if that equals the total amount of elements in the array then output '' otherwise output the max

Comment: @JoKing - You shouldn't be taking input via a pre-declared variable - fixed using `$argn` it takes it from stdin (this has been used in multiple golf answers) I can give examples of not only mine but other users.

Answer (score 2):

## Common Lisp, 102 bytes

```
(lambda(x &aux(c(read-from-string(concatenate'string"#.`("x")"))))(or(apply'= c)(princ(apply'max c))))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LcrbCoMwEIThV5Et1AlEoe1136XrakXIiagQnz4u6A9z8zHiljVVVDj2w8gozZP3AkGeeOz@Ofpu3fISZkgMwtsUdO1F9Oh/oEKGjIaYwSm5o/02YpD0ITd4LkpapZd92w@ZegI)

The size is mainly due to inputting the data; with input as a regular list, the length reduces to 46 bytes:

```
(lambda(x)(or(apply'= x)(princ(apply'max x))))
```

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), <s>9</s> 8 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
',¡ZsËiõ
```

-1 byte thanks to *@Cowabunghole*.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f9fXefQwqjiw92Zh7f@/29maGlupkNHEgA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##zYwxCgJBDEX7OcViY/MLk5nJJNXew07BYiuLBWFBWxs7b@AhvIB7Ey8yRmxERAQbCXkheUnW/WLZrep2M7ST5ro/NpN2qFNcTvN@PHTjue5QCRQIHGZ4DrozFEQokmeEeRWfRxTkIOxOzZVEZLKMUtSQWQyq6pKFQSn5KRn7p5cIQlYEf8BgQpqRlEtOeDSfWb7a@pFvxQ0).

**Explanation:**

```python
',¡        '# Split the (implicit) input by ","
   Z        # Push the maximum (without popping the list)
    s       # Swap so the list is at the top of the stack again
     Ëi     # If all elements are equal:
       õ    #  Push an empty string ""
            # (Implicitly output the top of the stack to STDOUT as result)
```

Comment: Pretty similar solution, but you can avoid the else by doing ```',¡ZsËiõ```, saving 1 byte

Comment: @Cowabunghole Smart, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) `-hF`, 8 bytes

```
q, ün Åc
```

[Try it](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.6&code=cSwg/G4gxWM=&input=IjEsMiIKCi1oRgo=)

`-3` bytes if the input could be taken as an array.

Answer (score 2):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), <s>45</s> 49 bytes

*+4 bytes thanks Veskah*

```powershell
($l=$args-split','|sort{+$_}-u)[-1]|?{$l.count-1}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY5BCsIwFET3OcUnfDXBRJouhaIH8AYiRWrUQmxrkqKQ9uyxVKvObubNwDT1Q1t31cZEPEMGITI0GR7txUnXmNIvxKJztfVhiXkvW76X6tBtAppVUbeVl6qPPSFbRmCQYFQJRYH/XEoFpH9eJWOkEk44dDCDMDKs2tuudF4A6mejC69PwxvM39Bq1xo/BPPh5FQdEUX2oVLfv1O@njaU9PEF)

Less golfed:

```powershell
$list=$args-split','|sort{+$_}-unuqie
$max=$list[-1]
$max|?{$list.count-1}
```

Comment: [Fun fact, this actually doesn't work in PS v5 because sort was changed to lexicographical ordering](https://tio.run/##TY5NCsIwFIT3OcUjPDWBRJouhaIH8AYiIjVqIbY1Pyi0PXsM1aqzm/lmYNrmoa27amMinqGALjI0BR7txUnXmsovxKJ3jfUgA99Jte/XHZpl2YTaSzXEgZANI5AkGFVCUeA/l1MB@Z9X2RipjBMOPcygGxnW4batnBeA@tnq0utTeoKHN7TaBeNTME8Hp@qIKLIPlfr@nfLVtKFkiC8 "PowerShell – Try It Online")

Answer (score 2):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 5 bytes

```
≈[¤|G
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCLiiYhbwqR8RyIsIiIsIjYyNywzODk0LDg2Myw1MTk1LDc3ODksNTI2OSw4ODg3LDMyNjIsMTQ0OCwzMTkyIl0=)

```
≈[    # If all same 
  ¤   # ""
   |G # Else max
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 3 bytes

```
ṀḟṂ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##zZE9CgIxEIWvYiu8wpkk83MUkS1tZC9gJzYew2u4tSfJSeJktxEREWxkmPeYfJNHIIf9OB5bq9Op3q51Orf7Zb1tbUegAasw7rbBc1HXfqxIMOToBA@XQAmK0qFwYPOgklDIC1TNUVgcZhaQhUE5x21yXvJeas4hV8EfaH@MC1lBNtaSsQyfVb/a@lHfgvn7hgc)

TIO link uses function I/O for the sake of having a test harness, but [it works just fine with a plain comma-separated list](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///hzoaHO@Y/3Nn0//9/cx1jHQsdEyA21rEE0mY6hkCWuY4pAA). I'd prefer to let a challenge like this stay dead, but if it's been bumped anyways...

```
Ṁ      The maximum,
 ḟ     unless it's equal to
  Ṃ    the minimum.
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 44 bytes

```python
k=eval(input())
if~-len(set(k)):print max(k)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##zY7PTsMwDMbPy1PkllYz0pI2/zb1WK5ceICVErSoXVtlGXQXXr243QUhhEBcJis/x/n8OR4u8dB3Yqr7Z0cLyhibmsK9Vm3iu@EckzQl/uX9rnVdcnIxadJ0OwTfRXqsRqwmNBDiiw15O/jW0cdwdluyiuGCXPl1wXf02s/KsToO2MLWe79H0Y2uTuZvU4L32g2Rlg/3ZQh9mL1PwVUNIcv8v2y0WCbGgTOCFMgNfA4@E181ZGAgx5OBxaxQyUCDRE0JVI1FUWUguZWgtbEghbJgjEFRKAE8z9HMrVimfYl5CrdawQ0Qd7GKGwm5EVrmcC1@pv5V1z/5rcCmDw)

Comment: I'm guessing `eval` in Python converts a comma-delimited string to a list?

Comment: Yes; more exactly a tuple (immutable list). If the input were not a string (i.e., omit quotes in TIO input section), then one could just use `k=input()` and get the same result.

Answer (score 1):

## [Ohm v2](https://github.com/nickbclifford/Ohm), 9 bytes

```
Ul1E?Oq¿↑
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y8/INfr/PzTH0NXev/DQ/kdtE///jzbSAcLY/wA)
Explanation:

```
Ul1E?Oq¿↑
U         Uniquify input
 l        Get length
  1E      Push whether length is equak to 1
    ?Oq   If so immediately quit
       ¿↑ Else print maximum
```

Comment: The input should be a string of comma separated numbers

Answer (score 1):

## Pyth, 7 bytes

```
Itl{QeS
```

[Try it online!](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=Itl%7BQeS&input=1%2C3&debug=0)
[All test cases (slightly different code for better output formatting)](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=Itl%7BQpeS&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=1%2C1%0A1%2C2%0A0%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C1%2C0%2C0%0A7%2C3%2C8%2C4%2C8%2C3%2C9%2C4%2C6%2C1%2C3%2C7%2C5%0A627%2C3894%2C863%2C5195%2C7789%2C5269%2C8887%2C3262%2C1448%2C3192%0A7%2C7%2C7%2C7%2C7%2C7%2C7%2C7%2C7%0A61976%2C61976%2C61976%2C61976%2C61976%2C61976%2C61976%2C61976%2C61976%2C61976%2C61976%2C61976%2C61976%2C61976%2C61976%2C61976%2C61976%2C61976%2C61976%2C61976%2C61976%2C61976%2C61976%0A96185%2C482754%2C96185%2C96185%2C96185%2C96185%2C96185%2C96185%2C7%2C96185%2C96185%2C96185%2C96185%2C96185%2C96185%2C96185%2C96185%2C96185%2C96185%2C96185%2C96185%2C96185%2C96185%2C96185%2C96185%2C961185%2C96185%2C96185%2C96185&debug=0)

As Pyth is based on Python, user input is always interpreted as a string, which then may be passed through `eval()`. All Pyth programs automatically run `Q=eval(input())` as their first instruction.

Explanation:

```
Itl{QeS  | Full code
Itl{QeSQ | with implicit variables filled
---------+-------------------------------
I        | If
 t       | one less than
  l      | the length of
   {Q    | the deduplicated input
         | is truthy (!=0),
         | print
     e   | the last element of
      SQ | the sorted input
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 15 bytes

```
≔Ｉ⪪Ｓ,θ¿›⌈θ⌊θＩ⌈θ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/9@xuDgzPU/DObG4RCO4ICezRMMzr6C0JLikKDMvXUNTR0FJR0kTSBVqWnNlpilouBelJpakFmn4JlZk5pbmahQC5Xwz86BsTU2FAKDGEoh5CDWamtb//5vroMH/umU5AA) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
≔Ｉ⪪Ｓ,θ
```

Split the input on commas and cast each value to integer.

```
¿›⌈θ⌊θ
```

Test whether the maximum value is greater than the minimum value.

```
Ｉ⌈θ
```

If so then cast the maximum value to string and print.

Answer (score 1):

## Mathematica, 43 bytes

```
If[!Equal@@#,Max@#]&@@#~ImportString~"CSV"&
```

Pure function. Takes a comma-separated string as input and returns either a number or `Null`. I believe this is valid, as `Null` is not graphically displayed:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 91 bytes

```c
M(s)char*s;{long m=atol(s),o,l=0;for(;s=strchr(s,44);o<0?m-=o:0)l|=o=m-atol(++s);s=l?m:-1;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##pY9tS8MwEMdfu08RMoTEXaHpU5LWMPZigugQNn3nm1LbbdCH0RQU5r66XTa7YUVEkCN3ubvf/7hLrGWStO2MaJqs4vpKR9u8KpeoUHFT5aYKFeTKjrKqJpFWuqmTVU00eB6Nqmt7XFiqCm2av6tKFdZRMxppatB8XIQWi3bt8CXN1mWKJovFdP5I0rcNRZt6XTYZwROt07pBlzpEeGg6@LnEgMxnjB/ucIhvJrf3T/MppoMiXpeEbgcX3RiLIaXQjGAGDFManRvOue706ifehq/GDr7HyY7j4IIAzzwXpImBYV3g4PdoIQTvBIFjJEIaReCCz6QPnAsJvhNIOGDgOoEDzPPMRCb7y52v4fDNjthptYAx4XekSYQPnnC478Fn8rvnf6L@6X9sHG/YtR9JlsdL3Vqvew)

#### Degolf

```c
M(s)char*s;{
    long m=atol(s),o,l=0; // Read the first integer from string
    for(;s=strchr(s,44); // Advance pointer to next ','
           o<0?m-=o:0) // End of loop: if difference <0, deduct from max, increasing it to new max.
        l|=o=m-atol(++s); // Read next number, and subtract it from current max. 
                          // Bitwise-OR the difference into the l-variable
    s=l?m:-1; // End of function: if l is non-zero, there were at least two different values.
              // Return -1 if l is zero, otherwise the max value.
}
```

Comment: Suggest `M(char*s)` instead of `M(s)char*s;` and `index()` instead of `strchr()`

Answer (score 1):

## XPath 3.1, 54 bytes

with the input string as the context item:

```
let$t:=tokenize(.,',')!xs:int(.)return max($t)[$t!=$t]
```

Could be reduced by one character if you allow the context to bind a shorter prefix than "xs" to the XML Schema namespace.

Explanation: takes the input string, tokenizes on "," separator, applies `xs:int()` to each token to convert to an integer, computes the max of the sequence, outputs the max provided the predicate `$t!=$t` is true. If A and B are sequences, then `A!=B` is true iff there is a pair of items (a from A, b from B) such that `a!=b`.

If the input can be supplied as a sequence of integers $s rather than a comma-separated string then the solution reduces to

```
max($s)[$s!=$s]
```

(15 bytes - which might well be the shortest solution in a language that isn't purpose-designed for brevity)

**NOTE**: this doesn't satisfy the requirement "represented as it is in the input" - if there's an integer with leading zeroes or a plus sign in the input, these will be lost. I suspect that's true of many other solutions as well.

Answer (score 1):

## [Java (JDK)](http://jdk.java.net/), 101 bytes

```java
d->{long m=0,c=-1,b;for(var s:d.split(",")){b=new Long(s);c=c<0|c==b?b:0;m=b>m?b:m;}return c>0?"":m;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##zU/LTsMwELz3K1Y5JdI2ivO0G9z@AJRDj4iD46QoJY8qcYtQ6beHjdoDQohU4oJWnvXuznjHO3VU813@OuhK9T08qLI5zQDKxhTdVukC1mMJ8JjtCm1A2xvTlc0L5E5K/fOMoDfKlBrW0ICEIZ8vT1VLjFp6qOWcYZZu284@qg76Re72@6o0toWW45wy2RRvcE9su3dSLfWd96GlzFbZwktrmS1rutXpuSvMoWtAL72VZY2NIR0X7w9ZRYuv@49tmUNN/q8Wn55BORfzm/feFLXbHoy7p5GpGrtxtW0xZGQjneD4kxwPvwYbcVKTYIAcQzoBCsox6QJMMJpUxj5puSBpHGDERIRJwgVGfiyQc05DP/aRhSE9zYR/g5NvMe2AiSTGf4CTTkXMeIQh95MoxEvxOyY3sf6IPw6ufznPzsMn)

**Explained**

```java
d->{                            // Function taking a String input
    long m=0,c=-1,b;            // Initialise variables
    for(var s:d.split(",")){    // Split by comma and loop over elements
        b=new Long(s);          // Parse String to Long
        c=c<0                   // If c<0 (i.e. this is the first element)
            |c==b               // ...or c is equal to the current element
            ?b                  // Set c to the current element (all elements are the same so far
            :0;                 // Otherwise set c to zero to denote that list is not all same element  
        m=b>m?b:m;              // Set m to max of b and m
    }
    return c>0?""               // If c is not zero then all elements are the same, return nothing
                 :m;            // Else return max element
}
```

**Bonus solution!**

Despite my best efforts I couldn't get this solution using regex and Streams to less than 105 bytes, but I really liked its elegance so had to give it an honourary mention;

```java
d->d.matches("(.+?)(,\\1)+")?"":java.util.Arrays.stream(d.split(",")).map(Long::new).reduce(0L,Long::max)
```

Comment: [100 bytes](https://tio.run/##zY/LbsIwEEX3fMUoK1sMEc7TJgr8QEsXLNsunAdtaOKg2FBVKN@eGsGiqqoGqZvK8rXGc6/neCePcrYr3oa8llrDvazUaQJQKVN2W5mXsD6XAA/ZrswN5GRjukq9QEETe99PrGgjTZXDGhSkMBSz5aluraNJ55gl27YjR9mBXhSu3teVIQ46lDYpyVJVvsOdtRJN6bJZZYsm6Upz6BQUbiNN/lpq4hB3Sgk@PTE6dejKcaypH5Lz3P0hq@3c6/hjWxXQWPwr4eMzSHph33xoUzZuezDu3rZMrYhyc@IwZBYlGfF4o545fl3srKOZGH3kGNjto7BnZHM@xhiOJiPPZrmw0cjHkIkQ45gLDL1IIOfcNr3IQxYE9mkmvBtIvq1xAibiCP@BjpKKiPEQA@7FYYCX4neNb3L9UX9sXP/ST/rhEw) by using a combination of your regex (minus the `?`) and a regular loop and return (instead of stream).

Answer (score 1):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), <s>15</s> 9 bytes

```
U&=?}1MX>
```

[Try it online!](https://matl.suever.net/?code=U%26%3D%3F%7D1MX%3E&inputs=%277%2C7%2C27%2C7%2C7%2C7%2C7%2C7%2C7%27&version=20.10.0)
[Multiple testcases](https://tio.run/##y00syfmf8D9Uzda@1tA3wu5/bIRLVEVI7H91Qx1DdS4gaQQkDXSQoSGIBIqa6xjrWOiYALGxjiWQNgPKGOuY65iC5dAgUMzSzNDCVMfEwsjc1EQHwsFPmhOlikISq4Q6AA)

Just trying to keep my MATL chops from getting too rusty!

*Edit*: rusty after all; saved 6 bytes, thanks to @LuisMendo.

#### Explanation

```
U     % str2num - automatically parses comma-separated strings
&=?   % Are all the values equal? 
}     % if not
1M    % Get the numeric matrix again on the stack
X>    % And find its maximum value.
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip), 13 bytes

```
a^:',MXaRMMNa
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gs@P8/Mc5KXcc3IjHI19cv8f///0Y6UAgA)

Uses the approach from [ngn's APL solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/173840/16766):

```
     MNa  Minimum of the list
  aRM     Remove it from the list
MX        Take the max of the remaining elements
```

The first 5 bytes `a^:',` split the input string on commas.

Alternate 13-byte solutions:

```
I!$=Ya^',PMXy
a^:',$=a?uMXa
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), <s>28</s> 22 bytes

```perl6
{.max x![==] $_}o&EVAL
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##zY4/C8JADMV3P0UtUiwEMfcnl1A6OLg5u4hIBztZFF1axM9@XhHkKiKCi4S88Hg/HjntzwfyTZfVpb/OmqpN2vGmLLfJZHc7Zsv1YuWLS9VN62mKgGmeF6OnVbGdQzzYaxw70MBgwmqQcCkgGhzYGCIVMJZAkQaLYsE5FrCKBJg5hIoUoDGhBUUN@19m0IviCP5A46eEkC0YVs4aeJjP6r6iftS3Qf@2vwM)

-6 bytes thanks to @ASCII-only

Comment: Links on this one as well please :P (just save the explanation somewhere and add it back in after pasting the autogenerated submission)

Comment: I need to get into the habit. Ty

Comment: Preferably with the testcases in the question (and optionally more) :P (use header to assign the function, footer to run testcases)

Comment: Also, seems to be invalid. "The output must be either nothing (no output of any kind), or else the largest element from the input, represented as it is in the input"

Comment: something like [this](https://tio.run/##zY69CsJAEIR7n8IcEhJYxL2fvT1CCBZ21jYiksJUBkUbg/js5wVBLiIi2MiyswzzMexxd9qTb7u0Kf01S9ZluRlPtnlVTdv6kiRC3A7pYjVf@uJcd1mTCQQUeV6MnlbGdgbxYK9xbEEBgw6rwIVLAVFgwcQQyYCxCxQpMOgMWMsOjCQHzBxCSRJQ69CCTg77X2bQi84S/IHGTzlCNqBZWqPhYT6r/Yr6Ud8G/dv@Dg)

Comment: @ASCII-only updated

Comment: `<s>foo</s>` for strikethrough

Comment: Just did that ;-). I always mix up the chat one and the post one

Comment: `~~` is discord/other markdown lol, `---` is SE chat

Comment: I had tried both versions

Answer (score 1):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 12 bytes

```apl
(⌈/↑⍨⍬≢1↓∪)⎕
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##zY5NCsJADIX3cwqXCq9o5jdznILgpmC3XqBWUEHEC7gS8VS5SJ3qxikighsT8kKSjyRlXRXzVVktF52067oby7adSnOQ3UV2N9mcSZqjtNeJ7E890RVFoUYPqxWBlMobOm/M8OrUaw4EGDBsCoOYsk@QQYDLMa8TyDFx3sBRdAiBI5z2EcychtprkLVpD0U9vDHwwW6KweMPNH8remIHyzo4i2fxWcNX1I/6dnAH)

If there were no input requirements, it could just be `⌈/↑⍨⍬≢1↓∪` for 9 bytes.

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3.8 (pre-release)](https://docs.python.org/3.8/), <s>45</s> 44 bytes

```python
if~-len(a:=set(eval(input()))):print(max(a))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM7YoKPr/PzOtTjcnNU8j0cq2OLVEI7UsMUcjM6@gtERDEwisCooy80o0chMrNBI1Nf//tzQztDDVMbEwMjc10YFw8JPmRKmikMQqAQA)

First time golfing; I'm sure this can be improved. 
Also a few months late to the party on this challenge, but whatever. xD

Answer (score 1):

## [Gol><>](https://github.com/Sp3000/Golfish), 36 bytes

```
TIE!tlK1}l4,MF={=}|{?;1W~2K(?$~lM|~h
```

4 bytes golfed off!!! I realized I was using some redundancies in there... next I think I can really make the part for checking if the array is equal smaller!

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8/PScsszvj/P8TTVbEkx9uwNsdEx9fNttq2tqba3towvM7IW8NepS7Ht6YOqMrSzNDCVMfEwsjc1EQHwsFPmhOlikISqwQA)

**# [Gol><>](https://github.com/Sp3000/Golfish), 40 bytes**

```
TIE!tlK1}l4,MF={S&}|{?;1W~2K(Q$~:|~lM|~h
```

Haha, I had my debug stuff in my previous answer, now this has golfed off 2 bytes, but I just realized how to make it even shorter

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8/PScsszvj/P8TTVbEkx9uwNsdEx9fNtjpYrbam2t7aMLzOyFsjUKXOqqYux7emDqjS0szQwlTHxMLI3NREB8LBT5oTpYpCEqsEAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2), 5 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
G$ạ?"
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728JKM0Ly_faMGCpaUlaboWy91VHu5aaK-0pDgpuRgqtuDmakszQwtTHRMLI3NTEx0IBz9pTpQqCkmsEhA3AwA)

##### Explanation

```python
G$ạ?"  "# Implicit input
G       # Push the maximum
 $      # Push the input again
  ạ     # Is it all equal?
   ?    # If it is:
    "  "#  Push an empty string
        # Implicit output
```

Answer (score 1):

## TI-BASIC, <strike>11</strike> 9 bytes

### 9 Bytes

```
If max(Ans≠max(Ans
max(Ans
```

Shaved 2 more bytes - implicit Disp on the final line and optimizing the condition. We instead get a single value from the input list in Ans with max( and check if it is not equal to all the other values of the list with `Ans≠max(Ans`. We then check if at least one of the elements in the list was different with another max( command. Ultimately this is the same number of tokens in the condition but it saves a byte by eliminating the 2 byte ΔList( command.

### 11 Bytes

```
If sum(0≠ΔList(Ans
Disp max(Ans
```

Takes an input list in Ans. The ΔList( command returns a list of the differences of the elements in the provided list. In TI-BASIC logic performed on lists returns a list with the operation performed on each element in that list, so 0≠ returns a list of 1s and 0s identifying if diffs of consecutive elements were 0 and therefore the elements were equal. By summing this list we identify whether all all elements were different to the next and therefore whether they were all different (we would need to sort the list first if trying to identify the number of different elements, but since we only care about whether they're all the same there's no need to sort). That whole chunk is used as the condition for whether to display the max of the input list in Ans. 11 bytes because the ΔList( command is a 2 byte token.

Answer (score 0):

## [Runic Enchantments](https://github.com/Draco18s/RunicEnchantments/tree/Console), 39 bytes

```
/u'!}R:'!=?\~or:}(\
\i|'<\   }n/ ;${;?/
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KyrNy0z@/1@/VF2xNshKXdHWPqYuv8iqViOGKyazRt0mRkFBoTZPX8FapdraXv//f8Ma4xqjGmMA)

Numbers have to be separated with | to be parsed from input correctly (using `,` causes the list to be read as a single number as `,` is the group separator and C# doesn't care where it's located in the string, it ignores all of them).

No possibility of removing the three spaces in the lower line, due to the loop entrance and exit locations.

Does have a limited stack size that can be processed (9 items) due to the mana cost of the sort command (and potential bleed from large stack size and low remaining mana). A [slightly larger](https://tio.run/##KyrNy0z@/18/s1RdsTbISl3R1j6mLr/IqlYjhiumRr3SxiZGQUGhNk9fwVql2tpe//9/wxqjGuMakxrTGrMa8xqLGssauAgA) program can handle up to 14 items.

Answer (score 0):

## [Actually](https://github.com/Mego/Seriously), 9 bytes

```
;M@╔l1<óX
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0wuKU3Myan8/9/a1@HR1Ck5hjaHN0f8/2@oYwgA)

Actually parses comma-separated items as lists on input, so long as the items look like Python literals, so there is no overhead for the restrictive input format.

Explanation:

```
;M@╔l1<óX
;M         make a copy of the input, maximal element
  @╔       remove duplicates from other copy
    l1<    is 1 less than the length of the deduplicated list?
       ó   if so, immediately exit, without printing anything
        X  else, discard the length, and implicitly print the remaining stack element (the maximal element of the input list) at exit
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Tcl](http://tcl.tk/), 88 bytes

```
proc M t {if [set f [lindex [set S [lsort -de [split $t ,]]] 0]]!=[lindex $S e] {set f}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##zVG7CsJAEOzvK1awHMG73LPwE6wswxUSIwSiBnOCEPLtcWMQREQEG1l2ltmZnWZTUQ9Dcz4VtKZEXbWnvC0T8air4668TnTDtD2dEy12JW@auko0T4QYIy1jnK0e7vmGykjdPaLvh/qwbcZYISG5lVjiueSIwiGDh@bOEHha3mdwMMIq1nxgyWYwMhg45wOMsgHeexaVVZBa86kMipNeSlgZnMUfoAhWegPtlTMaE/mM7ivXj/hWED11zSW1lK/5y7Efbg)

Comment: **[Tcl](https://tcl.tk/), 88 bytes** — `proc M t {expr [set f [lindex [set S [lsort -de [split $t ,]]] 0]]!=[lindex $S e]?$f:""}` — [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##zVHLigIxELznK3pljrVgMnkK4hd48jjkIBpBmF3DTARB5tvHFhFEZFnwIk1VU13ddemyaccxd4cNLanQOZ1yR02fCu2oafe/23S6yRXL/tAV@t4mnuR2X6gqhBgjTWP8mt@3qxWluKh2s8lkGNufdb7GCgnJUGKKx5JXFg41PDSjRuBueV7DwQir2POBLVvDyGDgnA8wygZ479lUVkFqzacyKE56KmFlcBYfwCJY6Q20V85o3MTf7P619Sa/NMRA53wsPTVL/nEcxgs)

Answer (score 0):

## Ruby, 39 bytes

```ruby
a=eval gets
puts a.max if a.uniq.size>1
```

Takes an string-form array and prints the result.

Comment: Input should be taken as a string

Answer (score 0):

## Bash (coreutils), 28 bytes

```
sort -n|uniq|tail +2|tail -1
```

Input is a stream, one number on each line

`tail +2` strips the first line, and the output is empty if it's the only line coming out from `uniq`, which squashes identical lines into one after `sort`.

Answer (score 0):

## [Rust](https://www.rust-lang.org/en-US/), 128 bytes

```rust
fn f(s:&str)->Option<u32>{let v=s.split(",").map(|a|a.parse::<u32>().unwrap());let x=v.clone().max();if v.min()==x{None}else{x}}
```

[Try it online!](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=7c657cb61d0b658df0690a60a8e47276&version=beta&mode=debug&edition=2018)

Answer (score 0):

### F#, 112 bytes

```
let m(c:string)=
 let n=c.Split ','|>Seq.map int
 if Seq.distinct n|>Seq.length=1 then None else Seq.max n|>Some
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##zVJNT8MwDL3vV1iVpq3Cm5a0zQew3rgC0o5jh6mkXaQ2HW1AIO2/F68TZUIIIXEhVp7tvGc7B@ftLKsb03Wl8VBNs8vWN9YV4XIExxe3zOarfWk9THBySFfmaV5t92CdH4HN4Zg/2tZbl5H2xJfGFX63ZOB3xsFt7QyYsjVwqn3tZXVluvX1jfPN231NzdLNqJ@/tQ62TfECNJ7OOmDIgqs@Bor5EC/w3NgRB05ihApjuhFq8oL4CCUmg0Jw0ihNEhFhwnSCUiqNCRcalVJEcsGRxTG1YJqfdf5inx2ZlgL/AQ4/0oKpBGPFZRLjKfkZ5a9Uf8RviY8/b3p3SPtVsd40Fqb5swMLGcxSqMgRuaf99LmDYGzDBz@@C2BqL1gY9sWL7h0)

I get the feeling that it could be made smaller, but I can't quite see how...

Answer (score 0):

## **Java (JDK), 238 bytes**

Golfed

```
public static String max(String s){StringTokenizer st=new StringTokenizer(s,",");TreeSet<Integer>t=newTreeSet<>();while(st.hasMoreTokens()){t.add(Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken()));}if(t.first()=t.last())return "";return Integer.toString(t.last());}
```

Ungolfed

```
import java.util.StringTokenizer;
import java.util.TreeSet;

public class max {
    public static String max(String s) {
        StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(s,",");
        TreeSet<Integer> t = new TreeSet<>();
        while (st.hasMoreTokens()) {
            t.add(Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken()));
        }
        if (t.first() == t.last()) return "";
    return Integer.toString(t.last());
    }
}
```

I have already seen this [answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/173592/79883), but I still wanted to share my answer.

Comment: Hey! Few general tips for golfing in Java (especially 8+); You can use the lambda declaration to shave off almost all of the `public static String max(String s)` preamble, try and avoid using if expressions and use ternary operators instead, and any imports (e.g. `import java.util.*`) count towards your byte count, so avoid if possible! Anyway, check out this link for a [whole load of tips](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/6671/tips-for-golfing-in-java) and welcome to CodeGolf!

Comment: @LukeStevens Thanks for the tips! I will work on fixing this answer soon!

Answer (score 0):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/) `-aplF,`, 38 bytes

```ruby
$_=$F.uniq.one?? p: $F.map(&:to_i).max
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##zYxNCsJADIX3c4ouiig8i5nOb0G66zVKBRcF7Yzagl7eMeJGRERwIyFfkveSHKfNJaW8XedNMQ39oQjDtq6zWGUs7Ls4n1VjaPsF9@eUCCQIUqzwHHSnsCjhoDhLeK6G9RIWWhjJnvNsmRKavIa1zkNL4@GcY1MaCVKKT8lL/vQSwpC3Bn9A4Q05DeWk1QqP4TPtV1s/8q1xDXHsw3BKyy7uGtwA)

I'm generally not a fan of extensively using command line switches, but since the I/O format is very rigid - here it goes.

The input is automatically (`-a`) split into an array `$F` using comma as a separator (`-F,`). If it contains only one unique element, we return nil, otherwise, the max value. Finally, the output written into `$_` is implicitly printed (`-p`). The option `-l` isn't really necessary - it is only there to make empty outputs discernible by line breaks.

Update: Almost forgot that we don't automatically get integers from split, just strings, which brings more boilerplate...

Answer (score 0):

## [V](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/V), 22 bytes

```
Ó,/ò
ún
Dç^"$/d
GYVHp
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/v///BkHf3Dm7gO78rjcjm8PE5ISUU/hcs9Msyj4P9/SzNDC1MdEwsjc1MTHQgHP2lOlCoKSawSAA)

Hexdump:

```
00000000: d32c 2ff2 0afa 6e0a 44e7 5e12 2224 2f64  .,/...n.D.^."$/d
00000010: 0a47 5956 4870                           .GYVHp
```

Explanation:

```
Ó,/ò                Replace commas with new lines
ún                  Sort; cursor ends up in first line
D                   Delete line (smallest number)
 ç^<C-r>"$/d        Delete all lines that contain the same number
GYVHp               Go to last line, copy, select all, paste
                    If all numbers are equal, the buffer is empty and nothing will be copied,
                    resulting in an empty output
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) -n -M5.010, 54 bytes

```perl
use List::Util'/.+/';@n=split/,/;uniq(@n)>1&&say max@n
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/7@0OFXBJ7O4xMoqtCQzR11fT1tf3dohz7a4ICezRF9H37o0L7NQwyFP085QTa04sVIhN7HCIe//f0szQwtTnUFJ/ssvKMnMzyv@r5v3X9fXVM/A0AAA)

Answer (score 0):

## PHP, 57 bytes

```php
<?=count(array_unique($a=split(",",$argn)))>1?max($a):"";
```

requires PHP<7; replace `split` with `explode` for current PHP (+2 bytes):

```php
<?=count(array_unique($a=explode(",",$argn)))>1?max($a):"";
```

Run as pipe with `-nR` or [try them online](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/c306698fcb745163efa4472c2d9ba6c3b008806c).

Answer (score 0):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 32 bytes

```ruby
->l{eval(l).minmax.uniq[1,1]*''}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##zY7LCsJADEX3/Qp3VYnFzDOzqD9SilSwpdDWZ0WRfvs4VUZFRAQ3EnKTcA@XbNvFyRaxncyq8/KQVcNqFNVlU2fHqG3KTYKA6TgMO5vHPVIkVbRfzXdpFwTrQZ5c/dSvzK9TeC7s1VsaOBAI1xyMm8rZHDRIDyjmEDKOUBwkGglakwHJlAEiciZTDFAIl4CGPXJf6p6HRiv4A/UPGYUkQRDTUsDt@Kz6K@pHfWu4l@0F)

Answer (score 0):

## [Scala](https://www.scala-lang.org/) (<strike>91</strike> 79 bytes):

```
def f(s:String){val i=s.split(",");if(i.toSet.size>1)print(i.map(_.toInt).max)}
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##DcrBCsIwEATQu18RckoghCRHRcFjD576ARLbRFZiGtxFiqXfHvc2b2ZwiiX25fFKE4lbhCrSSqnOKK6tia3PKYus8DjSB@pTb99YBJzRYitAShqpT5AVWFrGRBbhly5eN/4Sl@/Y1J2noZJmrHrvWUlvgvHOOakPrMAKHPf@Bw)

Answer (score 0):

## [Java (JDK)](http://jdk.java.net/), <s>112</s> <s>108</s> 117 bytes

```java
s->{return java.util.Arrays.stream(s.split(",")).mapToLong(Long::new).distinct().sorted().skip(1).max().getAsLong();}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##zVRNb9swDD07v0LwZTagqrMTfyVbgR4yYMCaHZrbsIMmy4lTRzIsuotR@LdnVOxm3RYUA3YZBFOk@PjwJJDe8Ud@tcsfjuW@1g2QHcashbJiK33fiu2yknupYHkQsoZSq8XkD2DRKmFTbK0/KvgwRheABhrJ9@z@tL1O9EmrzU@m62uy0iDnZL2VRpKh0BDeSLL6vCatkTkpFYGtJFxAyysidI44MLIqmK3q3iBWq6obwIVuTmiQBgQ30rDJpG6/VaUgouLGkDuOfE8TZzw0wAG3R13mZI8pD@9Qqs2Xr6hhY3yLdH4V/W5A3JBCkffkaK5unhoJbaNe3Pe2aXhnxmfx0KmrEjyXur7P9rweCD1r5nMlv/ssLw2UyO/5zOALyNw6D2XtBbbggNFGwq05lfmL/ug4CxR21nq@LSqyih03oIFLRy8cvbf05QqsHTMJndKUzvCb0gz3GLNTmtBozMchItIMAfGURkEW0SRJMxqFcUbTNMVkGIc0mM2QIMjCM@tv65ktyJKY/gd21JPFQRrRWRom0YwOwes2@SvUP9qLiWfFNB29lGYuOv3YDnYKdeGd@8G3IIZDseRi69letQcONN3QJ1jUGZBY1AKrsZugUl6hGK/rqhv7zfj@4oTtieAgtsS7/AMh8oDzcoEPG9bW95amn/THHw)

Either returns a long or throws an exception, which presumably counts as not returning anything.

Edit: Fixed a bug that caused incorrect output if the maximum was the first element of the input. (+9 bytes)

Answer (score 0):

### Bash, 36 bytes

```
tr , \\n|sort -un|tail -n+2|tail -n1
```

takes input on stdin, outputs to stdout

```
$ echo 1,2,3 | ./f.sh
3
$ echo 1,1,1 | ./f.sh
$ echo 123,231,321,312 | ./f.sh
321
```

Answer (score 0):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 53 bytes

```javascript
s=>(s=s.split`,`.sort((a,b)=>a-b))[0]-s.pop()?s[0]:''
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bclLCoAgFEbheRvxXlCpaWAtJILsSSFd6Ze2b9E4zujwHf72mK49JnPKvOTVZbiG4GARw54GPVjIlYi8Htk13ozMXdkb2CiRuMU7tVJ5khMSFhtko5VUpb8Uc/Ev5Uv5AQ)

Worse than [Shaggy's](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/173468/76323)

Answer (score 0):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 86 bytes

```c
a;g(){scanf("%d,",&a);}f(b,c){for(b=g(),c=a;~g();c=a>c?a:c)b&=a==c;b||printf("%d",c);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##pZDdSsMwFMev7VOEDCUdZ2L6mVo78WKCoDfOF8jSZivMtrQdE7b56NbT2U4nIoINPTkfv//JSdRorlTTyHDOzE2lZKYZPY2Bwpk0w51mM1DmRuclm0VIgIpk@IpOiM5YXctLZc7OIhlFKpxtt0WZZvW@AUVZuGsGaaaWqzghV1Udp/n5YmyQB6byrKqJWshySCqTbAyC3@3d/WRIdEEiovMiyRjlFOiamuG@rLveugDUdDm1zKsEU31cJp/KkkJ7ZtbXWOcUq7pitG27MwZxotMsITfT6eTxiSUvhUnQGM8yzfA5jJOuMOIkinBwyoFTE6V9wTrkraN8z1/A18Vbe8QFHeeDDQIc/G0IcPeQtcEH94gWQvidwLNQIgJUeDa4PHDB90UAruUF0GJgW54F3HGwIw@Ohzvcxodva4/1o3mcC7cjMRAuOMLyXQc@gt@t/yfqn/bHwv4Ou@ZN6aWcV81o/Q4)

Read stdin and write stdout