# Generate input for this hardware

Tags: code-golf

I have a hardware that has a 32-bit input register. The register has the following characteristics:

- The 32-bit register consists of eight 4-bit fields.
- Each 4-bit field holds a value in **signed-magnitude**; it can hold an integer between -7 and +7 inclusive, including -0 and +0 (signed zeroes).

For example, the hexadecimal value `0xABCD1234` represents the field values `[-2, -3, -4, -5, +1, +2, +3, +4]`. In fact, one hex digit represents one 4-bit value with the following mapping:

```
Hex    |  Input value
---------------------
0 ~ 7  |  +0 ~ +7
8 ~ F  |  -0 ~ -7
```

In order to operate this hardware, I figured that the most natural inputs would be 8 consecutive increasing values, treating -0 and +0 as distinct. So the input values will be one of the following:

```
field values for 8 fields        => 32-bit register value
[-7, -6, -5, -4, -3, -2, -1, -0] => 0xFEDCBA98 (offset -4)
[-6, -5, -4, -3, -2, -1, -0, +0] => 0xEDCBA980 (offset -3)
...
[-3, -2, -1, -0, +0, +1, +2, +3] => 0xBA980123 (balanced, offset 0)
...
[+0, +1, +2, +3, +4, +5, +6, +7] => 0x01234567 (offset +4)
```

I define the input `0xBA980123` as **balanced**, and the other inputs have an **offset** from the balanced input. The balanced input itself has offset 0.

### Task

Given the offset, output the desired value for the input register for my hardware as described above.

### Input and output

The input (offset) is an integer between -4 and 4 inclusive. You can take it as a string, optionally with explicit sign (e.g. `+4`).

You can output the result value as an integer or a string. If you choose to output as a string (either returning or printing), you can use base 2, 8, 10 or 16. In case of hexadecimal, mixing upper- and lowercase letters are allowed. Base prefixes (e.g. `0b` or `0x`), leading zeros, and leading/trailing whitespaces are also allowed.

You may use signed 32-bit values for output instead (imagine the values being used in a C program); in that case, the output values will be subtracted by `2^32`, except for the input `+4`.

### Scoring

The standard [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) rules apply. The shortest code in bytes wins.

### All test cases

There are only nine possible inputs, so here is the list of all input/output values your program/function needs to support.

```
input =>  output hex | decimal    | signed 32bit
-4    =>  0xFEDCBA98 | 4275878552 | -19088744
-3    =>  0xEDCBA980 | 3989547392 | -305419904
-2    =>  0xDCBA9801 | 3703216129 | -591751167
-1    =>  0xCBA98012 | 3416883218 | -878084078
 0    =>  0xBA980123 | 3130523939 | -1164443357
 1    =>  0xA9801234 | 2843742772 | -1451224524
 2    =>  0x98012345 | 2550211397 | -1744755899
 3    =>  0x80123456 | 2148676694 | -2146290602
 4    =>  0x01234567 | 19088743   | 19088743
```

Comment: It seems you've gone a long way to accept many base representation outputs, are lists of the place values as integers acceptable? (e.g. `0` -> `[11,10,9,8,0,1,2,3]` as a raw hexadecimal notation)

Comment: @JonathanAllan Sorry, but I feel like it's a bit of stretch.

Comment: It is somewhat more natural than a string IMO, but OK, a 2 byte cost to convert from base 16 to an integer for Jelly it is.

Answer (score 4):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 30 bytes

Simple and clean. Outputs a substring of the larger with the right offset because it seemed cheaper than any method I could think of that calculated it properly.

```ruby
->o{"FEDCBA9801234567"[o+4,8]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZvtf1y6/WsnN1cXZydHSwsDQyNjE1MxcKTpf20THIrb2v4auiZ6eiaZeamJyRnVNZk1BaUmxgpKqUYqCgoJydVp0ZmytkoKqQmbtfwA)

Comment: If you would believe it, I came up with the exact same idea that you did, just about a minute later

Comment: @EmbodimentofIgnorance I believe it. This seemed like the easiest option right off the bat, anyways, so it's literally a matter of who sees the challenge first haha

Comment: Am I missing something or should it be FEDCBA...?

Answer (score 4):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <s>35</s> 32 bytes

```c
f(n){n=0xFEDCBA99l*~0u>>16-4*n;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z9NI0@zOs/WoMLN1cXZydHSMkerzqDUzs7QTNdEK8@69r9yZl5yTmlKqoJNcUlKZr5ehh1XZl6JQm5iZp6GpkI1F2dafpGCBkgo01bXxFoh08YWRGpra3JxchYUASXSNJRUjVIUbO0UVA0sImLylHQUMnUU0jQyNTWtuWr/AwA)

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 14 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
12_r8Ḋ;8Ḷ¤ḣ8ḅ⁴
```

A monadic Link accepting an integer which yields an integer.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/QKL7I4uGOLmsgse3Qkoc7FgMZrY8at/z//98AAA)**

#### How?

```
12_r8Ḋ;8Ḷ¤ḣ8ḅ⁴ - Link: integer N     e.g. 4              or     -2
12             - literal twelve           12                     12
  _            - subtract N               8                      14
    8          - literal eight            8                      8
   r           - inclusive range          [8]                    [14,13,12,11,10,9,8]
     Ḋ         - dequeue                  []                     [13,12,11,10,9,8]
         ¤     - nilad followed by link(s) as a nilad:
       8       -   literal eight = 8
        Ḷ      -   lowered range = [0..7]
      ;        - concatenate              [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7]      [13,12,11,10,9,8,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
           8   - literal eight            8                      8
          ḣ    - head to index            [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7]      [13,12,11,10,9,8,0,1]
             ⁴ - literal sixteen          16                     16
            ḅ  - to integer from base     3130523939             3703216129
```

Answer (score 3):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 38 bytes

```javascript
n=>~(p=19088743)*16**(n+4)|p*16**(n-4)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LcZNCoMwEAbQvaf4ljNqxNBglTa5RE8gVsUikxClm/5cPUXo6r1H/@y3IS5hV@LvY5psEuu@FKzu6rY9mxPnuslzksLwO/yvDKfJR5DAQpkLBFeLw6JgvDJg8LL5daxWP5OUmEi4BB3AOYeaq93f9rjITLphzj7pBw)

In two's complement representation, `0xfedcba98` is "not `0x01234567` (19088743)". We first shift `0xfedcba98` \$ 4(n+4) \$ bits left, and shift `0x01234567` \$ 4(4-n) \$ bits right. Then use bit or to add them up.

JavaScript do not support `n << 32`, so we use `n * 2 ** 32` instead. And bitwise or in JavaScript automatically convert operand to int32. The two float value trimed to int32 and calculated the result.

---

Another not quite interesting answer:

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 35 bytes

```javascript
n=>'FEDCBA9801234567'.substr(4+n,8)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/Z9m@z/P1k7dzdXF2cnR0sLA0MjYxNTMXF2vuDSpuKRIw0Q7T8dC839afpGCRp6CrYKuibVCnoKNrQKI1tbWVKjmUlBIzs8rzs9J1cvJT9fI01FI08jT1OSq/Q8A)

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>60</s> <s>56</s> <s>52</s> 37 bytes

```python
lambda n:"FEDCBA9801234567"[4+n:12+n]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/6fZhvzPycxNyklUSHPSsnN1cXZydHSwsDQyNjE1MxcKdpEO8/K0Eg7L/Z/QVFmXolGmoauiaYmF5xjjMwxQuYYInEMkNjI4sgakE0CWvEfAA)

Comment: +1. I had basically the same idea: `lambda n:"FEDCBA9801234567"[4+n:][:8]` (Same length)

Comment: @pizzapants184 i find your solution even more elegant :)

Answer (score 2):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), <s>23</s> 22 bytes (SBCS)

```apl
8↑('FEDCBA98',⎕D)↓⍨4+⊢
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///3@JR20QNdTdXF2cnR0sLdZ1HfVNdNB@1TX7Uu8JE@1HXov9pj9omPOrtA4p7@j/qaj603hioA8gLDnIGkiEensH/gQLVj3q36qQBidpDKw6tN9V@1LvZEgA)

First time trying to use APL for golf. Any suggestions for improvement would be greatly appreciated. I put s← in the code field for testing purposes; is there a better way to do that?

(Edit: Removed the s← and saved a byte thanks to Bubbler)

Comment: You can wrap a line of code into a function [like this](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///v9riUdtEDRPtR71bNR@1TVZ3c3VxdnK0tFDXedQ31aX2f9qjtgmPevuAHE//R13Nh9YbA9UDecFBzkAyxMMz@D9QoBqoXScNSNQeWnFovSnQtM2WAA). Also, [save a byte by going tacit](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///3@JR20QNdTdXF2cnR0sLdZ1HfVNdNB@1TX7Uu8JE@1HXov9pj9omPOrtA4p7@j/qaj603hioA8gLDnIGkiEensH/gQLVj3q36qQBidpDKw6tN9V@1LvZEgA). For general tips, check out [APL golfing tips](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/17665/78410).

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 20 bytes

```
Ｎθ⭆…⁻θ⁴⁺θ⁴⎇‹ι⁰⍘⁻⁷ιφι
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/98zr6C0xK80Nym1SKNQ05oroCgzr0QjuARIpfsmFmgEJealp2r4ZuaVFmsU6iiYaOooBOTA2EBOSGpRXmJRpYZPanGxRqaOggFQzCmxOBViAlSjuY5CJlA8TRNEa2pa//9v9F@3LAcA) Link is to verbose version of code. Outputs 8 hex digits. Explanation:

```
Ｎθ                      Input the offset
  ⭆…                    Map and join over range
    ⁻θ⁴                 From offset - 4 (inclusive)
       ⁺θ⁴              To offset + 4 (exclusive)
          ⎇‹ι⁰          If current value is negative
              ⍘⁻⁷ιφ     Then subtract from 7 and convert to hex
                   ι    Else use directly as digit
                        Implicitly print
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 38 bytes

```hs
f n=take 8$drop(n+4)"FDECBA9801234567"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FYjPC4IwHEfv/hUfhgdFlH6sssCgMk/dOlbEYori3HfMRX/@0sPj8V4rxr5WyneDIetQCieyipQUH1Ujasi@4yAYRKdRYC48Up5l/IUQT430CEkBYL7u7uxNT3ds6QeNJAE7gM1uoP1E4URfIw@lJRPphMesKq@X82mfL5arNd9sd8z7Pw)

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), <s>28</s> 26 bytes

```perl6
{:16[11-$_...^7,|^($_+4)]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJamYPu/2srQLNrQUFclXk9PL85cpyZOQyVe20QztvZ/cWKlQhqQp6mQll@koGuip2fyHwA)

#### Explanation

```perl6
{                        }  # Anonymous block
     11-$_...^7             # Range 11-n down to 7 exclusive
               ,|^($_+4)    # Followed by range 0 to n+4 exclusive
 :16[                   ]   # Convert from base 16
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Wren](https://github.com/munificent/wren), 40 bytes

```
Fn.new{|a|"FEDCBA9801234567"[a+4..a+11]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Ky9KzftfllikkFaal6xg@98tTy8vtby6JrFGyc3VxdnJ0dLCwNDI2MTUzFwpOlHbRE8vUdvQMLb2f3BlcUlqrl55UWZJqgZIs15yYk6Ohomm5n8A)

Simply a port of most other answers.

## [Wren](https://github.com/munificent/wren), <del>70</del> 67 bytes

Horribly long answer; outputs to STDOUT.

```
Fn.new{|a|
for(i in a..a+7)System.write("4567FDECBA980123"[i%16])
}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Ky9KzftfllikkFaal6xg@98tTy8vtby6JrGGKy2/SCNTITNPIVFPL1HbXDO4srgkNVevvCizJFVDycTUzNzNxdXZydHSwsDQyFgpOlPV0CxWk6v2fzDILL3kxJwcDRPN/wA)

### Explanation

```
Fn.new{                                                // New anonymous function
       |a|                                             // with parameter a
                                                       // newline because this is
                                                       // not an expression
for(i in a..a+7)                                       // For every item in the range
                                                       // from a to a+7
                                                       // (Select 8 items in the string)
                System.write("4567FDECBA980123"        // Output the string
                                               [i%16]  // with the index of i modulo'd by 16.
                                                       // Moduloing maps the items in
                                                       // the iteration back to the start
                                                       // of the string.
)                                                      // Pretty self-explanatory.
}                                                      // no need to explain this
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Keg](https://github.com/JonoCode9374/Keg), 19 bytes (SBCS)

```
7Ï89AFɧ(¿4+|")^(8|_
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y05N///f/HC/haWj28nlGof2m2jXKGnGaVjUxP//bwIA)

Comment: Turns out the 22 byter I gave earlier was kinda broken. [Fixed 22 byter](https://tio.run/##y05N//8/xiDG8uTyOCUlR7eTyzUO7TfRrlHS1LCo0fn/3xIA "Keg – Try It Online")

Comment: [19 bytes](https://tio.run/##y05N///f/HC/haWj28nlGof2m2jXKGnGaVjUxP//bwIA "Keg – Try It Online")

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>12</s> 11 bytes

```
4Ø4Ÿα7ÝÂ‡hJ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AR4A4f9vc2FiaWX//zTDmDTFuM6xN8Odw4LigKFoSv//LTM)

Comment: You can remove the trailing `J` and just output as a list of characters, can you not?

Answer (score 1):

## [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/), 35

- 1 byte saved thanks to @79037662.

```bash
s=FEDCBA9801234567
echo ${s:$1+4:8}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0oszvifll@koKFRklpckpxYnKpgq6BrYq0A59rYIvG0tTU1rRVS8rkKijLzStIUlFSNihV07RSUFFRgSriKU0sUdHXhWv4X27q5ujg7OVpaGBgaGZuYmplzpSZn5CuoVBdbqRhqm1hZ1P5Pyc9L/Q8A)

Comment: I believe the last ```8``` in line 1 is unnecessary.

Comment: @79037662, thanks! not sure how that one crept in!

Answer (score 1):

## [Gaia](https://github.com/splcurran/Gaia), <s>12</s> 11 bytes

```
11⁻7N8…+8<h
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0/MTPz/39DwUeNucz@LRw3LtC1sMv7/NwAA)

[Test suite](https://tio.run/##S0/MTPz/39DwUeNucz@LRw3LtC1sMv5XP2qfWFj7qKnzv64Jl64xl64Rl64hlwGXIZcRlzGXCQA)

```
11⁻          11 - input
   7N        Downward range from result to 7 (excluding 7, empty list if first number is 7)
     8…+     Append the range 0-7 (inclusive)
        8<   First 8 numbers
          h  Convert from hexadecimal
```

Answer (score 1):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 38 bytes

```php
<?=substr(FEDCBA9801234567,4+$argn,8);
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@P/fxt62uDSpuKRIw83VxdnJ0dLCwNDI2MTUzFzHRFslsSg9T8dC0/p/anJGvoJSTJ6S9X9dEy5dYy5dIy5dQy4DLkMuIy5jLpN/@QUlmfl5xf913QA)

Answer (score 1):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://codeberg.org/ngn/k), 22 bytes

```
(8':"FEDCBA98",/$!8)4+
```

[Try it online!](https://ngn.bitbucket.io/k#eJxLs9KwULdScnN1cXZytLRQ0tFXUbTQNNHm4tLWyLROU8+00jVR0DVW0DVS0DVUMFAwVDBSMFYw0QQASicK6A==)

- `"FEDCBA98",/$!8` is shorthand for `"FEDCBA9801234567"` (sets up a `raze` seeded with `"FEDCBA98"`, run over a list of strings each containing one digit from 0..7)
- `(8':...)` take 8-length sliding windows of the generated string (creates a list of 9 items)
- `(...)4+` index into that list using the (implicitly) provided index, offsetting by +4 so `-4 => 0`, `-3 => 1`, ..., `4 => 8`

Answer (score 0):

## JavaScript (ES6), 42 bytes

```javascript
f=(o,n=8)=>n&&f(o-1,n-1)*16+(o<-3?4-o:o+3)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TcpNDoIwEEDhvaeYFcxYSqwQQpTiIThBw18wZIaUxo3x7FVXunlv893dw@29X7agWYYxxsmiZGxrsi0nyYSiTcba0NFUCqXRxa3UchFVUJzEI4MFXV6BobHwvVIEzwNAL7zLOuarzMh5kC74hWekfHNDF5wPeCYFKej2EwUTMv2Uqf5cnUF6SokOr/gG)

Answer (score 0):

## [C# (Visual C# Interactive Compiler)](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/releases/5.0.0/#csc), 38 bytes

```cs
x=>"FEDCBA9801234567".Substring(x+4,8)
```

Each valid output is just a rotation of the string `FEDCBA9801234567`

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Sy7WTS7O/O9Wmpdsk5lXolNcUpSZl26XZvu/wtZOyc3VxdnJ0dLCwNDI2MTUzFxJL7g0CaJEo0LbRMdC8781V1p@kQZQq0Kmra6JdaaNqXWmtrZmeFFmSapPZl6qhpJBhZJ2mkampqb1fyXumDxOjhgDRiZmJQA)

Answer (score 0):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 32 bytes

```javascript
f=n=>n+4?f(--n)*16|n+4:-19088744
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RcpLCoMwFIXhuau4M28aEhSCtY@ki3DaSVAjitxIDJ20XXuadlI48PPBWezD7n2YtyjID2NyOo@0Ia5uDoUgdqibV9ZZ1KeqbY9KJecDIIEGoS5AcNXwLecMngVA72n36yhXP@UTh/IeyxyHxP7CH40xUDEZfRfDTBPWDZObHbpoQ0Timax4pw8)

Shorter than hardcode