# Is this a valid input for this hardware?

Tags: code-golf, decision-problem

The (slightly harder, but still easy) sequel of [Generate input for this hardware](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/195009/78410).

### Background

I have a hardware that has a 32-bit input register. The register has the following characteristics:

- The 32-bit register consists of eight 4-bit fields.
- Each 4-bit field holds a value in **signed-magnitude**; it can hold an integer between -7 and +7 inclusive, including -0 and +0 (signed zeroes).

For example, the hexadecimal value `0xABCD1234` represents the field values `[-2, -3, -4, -5, +1, +2, +3, +4]`. In fact, one hex digit represents one 4-bit value with the following mapping:

```
Hex    |  Input value
---------------------
0 ~ 7  |  +0 ~ +7
8 ~ F  |  -0 ~ -7
```

In order to correctly operate this hardware, the 8 field values must be strictly increasing from left (most significant) to right (least significant). For signed zeros, `-0` is considered to be less than `+0`.

The following are the examples of valid inputs:

```
field values for 8 fields        => 32-bit register value
[-7, -6, -5, -4, -3, -2, -1, -0] => 0xFEDCBA98
[+0, +1, +2, +3, +4, +5, +6, +7] => 0x01234567
[-7, -4, -3, -2, -0, +1, +3, +4] => 0xFCBA8134
[-2, -1, -0, +0, +3, +4, +5, +7] => 0xA9803457
```

The following are the examples of invalid ones:

```
field values for 8 fields        => 32-bit register value
[+7, +6, +5, +4, +3, +2, +1, +0] => 0x76543210 // not increasing
[-2, -1, -0, -0, +1, +2, +3, +4] => 0xA9881234 // not strictly increasing, due to duplicates
[-3, -2, -1, +0, -0, +1, +2, +3] => 0xBA908123 // +0 is greater than -0
```

### Task

Given the **register value**, determine if it is a valid input to the hardware.

### Input and output

The input (the register value) is an unsigned 32-bit integer. You can take it as an integer, a string, or a list of digits. A string or list of digits can be in base 2, 8, 10 or 16, least-significant-digit-first or most-significant-digit-first, with or without leading zeros or base prefixes.

For example, if an input value is `0x01234567`, possible representations in base 16 include `"0x01234567"`, `"01234567"`, `"1234567"`, `"76543210"` (reversed order of digits), `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]`, `[7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0]`.

The output is a boolean, indicating whether the given input is valid or not. You can choose to output either:

- Any of the truthy/falsy values as defined by the language of your choice

  - The actual result values may differ between inputs (e.g. output 1 for a truthy input and 2 for another truthy one).
  - Swapping truthy and falsy values is not allowed.
- Any two distinct constant values for true/false respectively

  - In this case, the result values should exactly be one of the two constant values.

### Scoring

The standard [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) rules apply. The shortest code in bytes wins.

### Test cases

#### Expected output: Valid

```
0xFEDCBA98
0xEDCBA980
0x80123456
0x01234567
0xFCB98037
0xEDB12345
```

#### Expected output: Invalid

```
0x76543210
0x1A2B3C4D
0x12345678
0xBA988123
0xBA908123
0x00123456
0xB9882347
0xDC914556
```

Comment: Is the `0x` required in the input?

Comment: @ValueInk No, it's not required.

Comment: In case anyone wants to make us of it, the expression `(~n/8&2**32/15)*7^n` reverses the hex digits `0-7`, putting the digits of a valid input `n` into "normal" decreasing order in hex.

Answer (score 6):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 52 bytes

```python
lambda s:eval("'EDCBA9801234567'.find(%r)<"*8%s+'s')
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY1bC4IwGIbv/RVDELeC2KbzRF54yD9REYaKgpk4Tfv1tnmgu@c7vM/bfvvy3dC58G9znb6eWQq4l3/SGqr6JY7CwHUwoYbJLFs/FVWTQa1DZ/XgaPyocx3NY1nVOSCeArjfD22dwy4dH1XTDj1EV@rdkQLarmp6UECOZjwlm1bB014gcG8RuPcJTKJQnA17@Q2XvUDbYqZBiYyRgIZGZMYS15T0Sqkj5hXxhvhfIayOYOmNI5eYjFk/)

Takes input as a tuple like `('F', 'E', 'D', 'C', 'B', 'A', '9', '8')`.

The idea is to produce out and evaluate a long chain of inequalities like:

```python
'EDCBA9801234567'.find('F')<'EDCBA9801234567'.find('E')<'EDCBA9801234567'.find('D')<'EDCBA9801234567'.find('C')<'EDCBA9801234567'.find('B')<'EDCBA9801234567'.find('A')<'EDCBA9801234567'.find('9')<'EDCBA9801234567'.find('8')<s
```

The `s` at the end of the chain takes care of the extra trailing `<` symbol by giving an always-true comparison of "number < string" in Python 2 logic.

Answer (score 2):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/) `-n`, 36 bytes

Outputs `1` if valid, `nil` if not.

```ruby
p~/xF?E?D?C?B?A?9?8?#{[*0..7]*??}?$/
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Rc25DoJAEAbg3tfQikSYvZdqsge8hLGxswGCmmCMPrrrLGxi9831z/y4PFOaPs3SY4cRA3p02KLF/etUQV2bc4X4xkOTEix9F4N3rd3BUgREC4wLqTSxyBD74GkszLrr1z7RaCUFZ/mMOe5FkDFzu8q5OdRSvREK4f@CUi0558bQMqmU/o7T/ToOt3Qcfg)

Answer (score 2):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), <s>25</s> 24 bytes

```perl6
{[>] ((8 X>$_)X*7)Z+^$_}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NYzRCoIwFIbvz1PsImIrks3pNqEGbuYzSFGioVeJolcSPfuaYlf/d/7z8w3N@Baum9G@RRf3uesHwlihQu9KUhwkuR2fu/LrpmpGLQ5efVdrHQzVODWnupoazAQhqO1HdIb8mlmTJgq2pKAoC3kUC9hSQm6Nf3DpN2btQIo44iGjwNLQcBtlsG0VLBLlrwXoCvQv9BblSUJmExbFvtHuBw)

Takes a list of integers.

#### Explanation

```perl6
{                      }  # Anonymous block
     (           )Z+^$_   # XOR input values with
      (8 X>$_)X*7         #   7 if value < 8, reversing sort order
                          #   0 otherwise, keeping value unchanged
 [>]  # All values strictly decreasing?
```

Answer (score 2):

## [F# (.NET Core)](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core/platform), 91 bytes

```fs
 [for i:char in n->"EDCBA9801234567".IndexOf(i)]|>List.pairwise|>List.forall(fun(x,y)->x<y)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##pZLPa4MwFMfv/hXBk8IUf1Y7qlC1hUFhZTvsUHoI7bML2KQk6aaw/92ltu5U2MhyCXnJ533fe9/UwtkxDj07AUWvnZBwNIwGJDogmvVoUzOOyOPuHauNIurk5qIqi/k09fwgjOJJYrpPdA/tc20Re/uVr4iQ7gkT/kkE3I4qB24aqz5Tq33obCdvZ53db2YLKnm3ZoTKfDtoHrHSwPzwgTIDqXWJcRDnRqJMFWQub9rmcFsyKlgD7hsnElaEgnV9a99lx7J12LFZHfZnThrssixUxWGi128xKP/G3oWTSRyFga81LH8eFGEZVVrsdVZaBl/cTVUCTdbTZb1/fA5lb6pgLYOrcupH8d90x9sXwHvrGvL6bw)

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 9 bytes

```
N>¡€7I>0Ạ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/P7tDCR01rzD3tDB7uWvD/6KSHO2dYP2qYo6Brp/CoYa714Xauw@1ABZH//0dzRRua6igYmgCxMRAbAbEhEBvoKFjqKFjE6gDlccjpKBiApEE0UFBHASgNVAVUDDTPDCSDRVhHwRxspCnCOKhRYFXmKPYZoukHSZqDDTEFCxiDJQ2h7oC6DGoq1L1go6Cy6A6BeQ/FSxZwO9HkDNDlDHD6G@ErCyRZiN@g7rIE64ToAWvjigUA)

A monadic link taking a list of bass 16 digits and returning 1 for true and 0 for false.

### Explanation

```
  ¡€      | For each digit, if:
 >  7     | - Greater than 7
          | Then:
N         | - Negate
     I    | Increments between each digit
      >0  | Greater than 0
        Ạ | All
```

Answer (score 1):

## [PHP](https://php.net/) (7.4), 54 bytes

```php
fn($a)=>preg_match(_.join('.*',$a)._,FEDCBA9801234567)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY7djoIwEIXv@xQTQ9J2Qwi/glE0AvoSuiGEwNaNQkN7Z3x2bItNnKtvZs45M5zxeXfgjCPk9PncD8RpaL7nU/dXPxrZMlJ7/@NtINj7wa7aebV7PlVlcdxkfhBGcbJO6bxVbtkJKSCHC8JWgF2ErVazdWi2Zs3nslCKKF30hdloTtdJHIWB8QbHsIjKuDK8WE2@Ds/U4MO@Zf/rlkrPVGPyq3ITxImZ/6q3@3HqmpYB@fzfCDBE4YlAVdeyEZyeCDnVgt9vchFSCh6srsNqi17zGw)

Input is array of digits in base 16 (example: `['F','E','D','C','B','A','9','8']`);

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 17 bytes

```
Σ•_ćúθœιu0•hSk}ÙQ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//3OJHDYvij7Qf3nVux9HJ53aWGgD5GcHZtYdnBv7/H61kqKSjoOQIIoxAhBOIMAYRziDCBES4KMUCAA)

Explanation:

```
Σ             }             # Sort by 
             k              # the index of each char of the input in...
 •_ćúθœιu0•hS               # [7...0,9,8,A...F]
               Ù            # remove duplicates 
                Q           # and check that it's not changed
```

Answer (score 0):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 8 bytes

```
H8(вÆü‹P
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/fw0LjwqbDbYf3PGrYGfD/f7SSm5KOgpIriHABEc4gwglEOIIISxBhoRQLAA) or [validate all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9TVmmvpKBrp6BkXxn838NC48Kmw22H9zxq2BnwX@e/m6uLs5OjpQUXlDbgsjAwNDI2MTXjgtLmXG7OTkAJY3OgGiewGJe5mamJsZGhAZeho5GTsbOJCxdUrQUXyBALIA/EMAAzDGAGAk2xALLMuVycLQ1NTE3NAA).

Input is a list of hex digits. Output is 1 for truthy, 0 for falsy.

```
H          # convert from hex
 8(в       # convert to base -8
    Æ      # reduce by subtraction
     ü‹    # pairwise less-than
       P   # product
```

Answer (score 0):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 53 bytes

```javascript
f=([a,...b])=>b<f||g(a)>g(b[0])&f(b)
g=x=>x<8?x-8+g:x
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Rc3JDoIwEAbgO0/hwZg2Yil7XYph0ZcwJhQsjQbBqDE9@O44VRLn9M105u9FvMSjvp9vz0XXn@QwNBwdhE0IqY6YJ9Wmeb8VEjhRqDrQI541qMKW4ponesO2esHmaqWHdWlRvd8VeZYuGXAUBTLqen4QRsBRsdnNM3j24@9u9p0D4ygMfM81Z27qZX4eFIa/K5NrQhn0P9KR9P8FpDKwyS3ypRuEMC3JXd5aUUvkkLGmzlXZE8mTuu8efStJ2ysk7QZJjPHwAQ)

## [Python 3.8 (pre-release)](https://docs.python.org/3.8/), 44 bytes

```python
lambda s:eval("((t:=0x%c)^-(t>7))<"*8%s+'9')
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Rc3rCoIwGAbg/16FCOJWBJvzMCUDD3kTHcBKUTAbOsuufm0q9O/5Tu/Hvrx@dYSyXlTRWbTF8/Yo9CEs30ULDAB4GKHJvMPrDvCDD@He2FBz2FqBBcWnbtpSx6GmDxEfWVuCpmMjB/Bkhxeo6axvOg4qMEAo0JQfszSJA6qhaRWSpAjbxHE9yVW@ZJ4mckz8eTeZ@5K@5zrExuoMx3ZCUidTXK5Urgqlsl6IVqL/C5lKpVVulgbYcV3vBw)