# The SBEVE Challenge

Tags: code-golf, string

She said **s(he) be(lie)ve(d)**, he said **sbeve**.

**Input**

- A non-empty string, `s`. It's guaranteed that `s` will have only printable ASCII characters and at least one word (defined as `[A-Za-z0-9]+`) in parentheses, and all parentheses will be closed respectively.

**Output**

- A string containing all non-whitespace characters (whitespaces are defined as spaces, tabs, carriage returns, new lines, vertical tabs and form feeds characters) that are not in parentheses.

**Test cases**

```
Input -> Output
s(he) be(lie)ve(d) -> sbeve
s(h3) (1s) br(0k)3n -> sbr3n
(I) (K)now (Ill) Be
(My) Best (Self) -> nowBeBest
sho(u)lder (should)er
s(ho)u(ld)er s(h)ould(er) -> sholderersuersould
p(er)f(ection) -> pf
(hello) (world) ->
```

The last output is an empty string.

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) so shortest code in bytes wins.

Comment: Are all whitespace characters guaranteed to be spaces?

Comment: @Jonathan Allan No, it includes all the `\s` characters as well.

Comment: I think all answers so far assumed whitespaces were limited to spaces due to the examples :(

Comment: Please specify what characters may be in the non-word portions / what characters may be present in `s`. Also best to add some test cases with non-space whitespace.

Comment: @Jonathan Allan I'm sorry, I tried to demonstrate a new line in examples 3 and 4, but I think it was mistaken for text wrap. I'll make it more explicit, thanks!

Comment: Must we handle non-printable characters?

Comment: @Jonathan Allan No, it's guaranteed that input will contain only printable characters.

Comment: @Expired Data Added, thanks for the advice.

Comment: All parentheses will be closed, But will all of them be opened? (:

Comment: @Post Rock Garf Hunter Yes, read that as "All opened parentheses will have a respective closed parenthesis".

Comment: I think what PRGH is getting at is that that still leaves the possibility of lone close-parentheses e.g. `blah (blah) blah) blah` - maybe you mean to say "all parentheses will be balanced"?

Comment: Is `s` printable ASCII? (I'd recommend so.) Also, `\S` is ambiguous between regex flavours I believe.

Comment: @Jonathan Allan Oh, I get it now. There is no possibility of lone parentheses, every open parenthesis will have a corresponding closed parenthesis and vice versa. I thought I had made a good first challenge, but with all these flaws, it wasn't that good after all. :(

Comment: @JonathanAllan I'll specify that. Consider whitespaces spaces, tabs, carriage returns, new lines, vertical tabs and form feeds characters.

Comment: ...it's not all that easy. It *is* a nice challenge though!

Comment: Welcome to code golf :) Using the [sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2140/31625) can help make your challenges go more smoothly. Also, please consider [rewriting your test cases](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8101/31625) to make them more easy to use (this may also have helped with the spaces confusion).

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman Thanks, I've rewritten the test cases. I didn't know Sandbox, this is something I'll definitely use in my next challenges, thanks for the indication and I apologize for any inconvenience.

Comment: _It's guaranteed that `s` will have only printable ASCII characters_. "Printable ASCII" [means](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#Printable_characters) code points from 32 to 126 (both included), and therefore the only whitespace allowed in the input is the normal space character (so no tabs, newlines etc). Can you confirm, and perhaps edit the challenge text accordingly?

Comment: (Please let me know when you clarify that, so I can un-downvote and re-upvote)

Comment: May we (assume (no) nested) parentheses?

Answer (score 5):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 11 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
>Ƈ⁶Ø(yṣ”)m2
```

A full program printing the result.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ATEAzv9qZWxsef//PsaH4oG2w5goeeG5o@KAnSltMv///3MoaGUpIGJlKGxpZSkJdmUoZClh)**

#### How?

Whitespace printable ASCII characters are `"\t\r\n\f\v "` and non-whitespace printable ASCII are all greater than `' '`, so:

```
>Ƈ⁶Ø(yṣ”)m2 - Link: list of printable ASCII characters, s
 Ƈ          - filter keep those (characters) for which:
> ⁶         -   greater than literal space character
   Ø(       - literal list of characters ['(', ')']
     y      - translate (replace all '(' with ')')
       ”)   - literal ')' character
      ṣ     - split at
         m2 - modulo-two-slice (every other entry)
            - implicit, smashing print
```

Answer (score 4):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 16 bytes

```
ηʒ„()S¢Æ_}€θJžKÃ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AToAxf9vc2FiaWX//863ypLigJ4oKVPCosOGX33igqzOuErFvkvDg///cChlcik0NSgyMSkgZihlY3Rpb24p), or [Verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##HY49CsJAEIWvsqSagRRKbmAXxcrSiBgzweCwK5s/UgREwQN4AAtre60sFBsLD@FF4qzVvPc93syYfBFn1FVN97m@j9/tCXDyOD8P8/a7u3xuw9d99Nx3fttNvRxWhCom4IywIkjQ8x0MUEE/l8RCb42BFgqhsBFqUysImVENKNIwbpzICwUT4vTfXhkokROyCkSXnCDZSMtSgyX8nRKDLgGyrrJxMwVaFpnRDshXzEbu1cZKw5v9AA)

---

#### Explanation

```
η                         - Prefixes of the string 
 ʒ       }                - filter these when...
  „()S¢                   - the counts of ( and ) characters 
       Æ_                 - are the same
          €θ              - get the last character from each of these prefixes
            J             - Join all these last characters
             žKÃ          - and remove any that aren't in [a-zA-Z0-9]
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language), 11 bytes

```
\(.*?\)|\s
```

(Note the trailing newline in the code).

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxLNPz/P0ZDT8s@RrMmppjr//9ijYxUTYWkVI2czFTNslSNFE0A)

#### How it works

```
                 Replace either
  .*             a sequence of characters
\(   \)          in parentheses,
    ?            matched non-greedily,
       |         or
        \s       any whitespace character
                 by nothing
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/) + GNU utilities, <s>36</s> <s>32</s> 28 bytes

```bash
xargs|sed 's/([^)]*)\|\s//g'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/vyKxKL24pjg1RUG9WF8jOk4zVkszpiamWF8/Xf3/fw1PTQUNb828/HIFDc@cHE0Fp1QuDd9KEF1coqARnJqTpgkA)

*Thanks to @user41805 for 4 bytes!*

Comment: I believe `xargs` can take the place of `tr`

Comment: @user41805 Thank you -- great trick1

Answer (score 2):

## APL+WIN, 25 bytes or 30 bytes

Prompts for string.

```
((~x∨≠\x←s∊'()')/s←⎕)~' '
```

[Try it online! Courtesy of Dyalog Classic](https://tio.run/##PY07EoJADIZ7TpFuk8Kx8Bp6AxuEIDtG4rAi2lgqWjg29paeay@CQR2rJN//SLqRUX5IRZejTNIQfNbH22M2jaf7JInduegRj/vYveLlOd8bDbG7OiRH42CXeenowPVm7YvEBSyZYMEonmnHmJNL/hh9MK1GXRFXH47e6IoqbU0UGZKA68MwwxYwsBS/glKxIcm5NlpqIznZarVKDf4PGgTk@puBzbAWyNnWa0UOPh9LFlH72mptOQcAbw)

If I now have to handle none alphanumeric characters this works for 5 extra bytes in APL+WIN but will not work in Dyalog Classic so no TIO

```
((~x∨≠\x←s∊'()')/s←⎕)~⎕av[⍳33]
```

Comment: Fails the test cases containing newline characters.

Comment: @JonathanAllan I have modified my code to handle the newline character but the spec seems to be continually evolving. I think I will bow out rather than trying to keep up!

Comment: You can always delete and come back later, but I think most issues have been ironed out. Printable ASCII in `s`, balanced parentheses, whitespace are ordinals 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, and 32.

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 12 bytes

```
e€Ø(œpm2FfØB
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/z/1UdOawzM0jk4uyDVySzs8w@n////FGhmpmgpJqRo5mamaZakaKZoA)

A monadic link taking and returning a Jelly string. Now handles other whitespace characters.

### Alternative 12 bytes

```
Ø(yṣ”)m2FfØB
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///wDI3KhzsXP2qYq5lr5JZ2eIbT////izUyUjUVklI1cjJTNctSNVI0AQ)

Comment: Fails the test cases containing newline characters.

Comment: @JonathanAllan to be fair they weren’t there until 9 minutes ago!

Comment: They were there from revision 1, just not that obvious.

Comment: @JonathanAllan ok, thanks. Fixed.

Answer (score 2):

## [SNOBOL4 (CSNOBOL4)](http://www.snobol4.org/csnobol4/), 119 bytes

```
 I =INPUT
S I ARB . L '(' ARB ')' REM . I :F(W)
 O =O L :(S)
W O NOTANY(&UCASE &LCASE 84 ** 9) ='' :S(W)
 OUTPUT =O
END
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JY2xCsIwGIT3PMVNzf93cOqggQxVIwRqIk1KcS0NKBQ7FHz9GOp03x133PZZp3VpcoaFtu4xRBEKtv0ZB3SQJHeWLNGbe8ks1I1GFvDQvjQUBRZjcc7H1j2pGi5tMKi6XY4N6honhpYSKvyHQyw3ZS2Mu@a80SsxpkTLO/E30cw/)

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 12 bytes

```
ŒʒÁ„)(å}KžKÃ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HY4xCsJAEEWvMmw1AwpKegU7CVaWamHMhASXXdlNDCkExQuIB7DzGjbBxmN4kXXWav5/nz8z1m@zisOx629TBcMJqGl43z/3/vI9Pwj75yl9v9L@GgZhpTyWTJAx6orpyJiTGkSYEODYS@JwtKfECMW5sJSMbQHnWhPMeG1w0UXha8Al6@LfLi02pHN2gKIbnRO7tZGllhr8OxBDMUF2sXKIs0De1ZU1EchXWlu511onDbX5AQ)

```
Œ               # substrings 
 ʒ     }        # filter, keep each substring if:
  Á             #  after being rotated right
   „)(å         #  it contains ")("
        K       # remove those substrings from the input
         žKÃ    # keep only characters in [a-zA-Z0-9]
```

Comment: Nice didn't realise that `K` would work like that, I didn't try it because I thought it would remove the text in between brackets too.. but I guess it applies each consecutively?

Comment: Yup, `K` (and similar operators like `:`, `.:` and `.;`) applies substitutions one by one.

Comment: Since my [10-byter](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/200829/52210) using the split and uninterleave builtins was quite different from both of your answers, I decided to post it as a separated answer.

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), <s>10</s> 11 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
„()S¡ιнJʒð›
```

+1 byte as bug-fix (`žu` to `„()` and `žKÃ` to `ʒð›`), since apparently all printable ASCII + whitespaces are valid input-characters, instead of only alphanumeric, whitespaces, and parenthesis..

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//UcM8Dc3gQwvP7byw1@vUpMMbHjXs@v9fSUlJw1NTQcNbMy@/XEHDMydHU8EplUvDtxJEF5coaASn5qRpApUBAA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##HY4xCsJAEEWvMmw1AymUHECwi2JlaSyMGTG47MpuoqQQrDxADiB4A1sFG@0sxDPkInHWav5/nz8z1i@ygrtdPVDQnhpQg7prj2ek6fPyuX0fo3fzurbHe3eIupnyuGaCjFEXTDvGnFQUYEyAfS@Jw96GYiMUE2FjMnYPmGhNMOTU4KQOwpeAU9arf3ttsSKdswMUXemc2KVGllqq8O9ADIUE2YXKNswV8rIsrAlAvtLayr29ddJQ8x8).

**Explanation:**

```python
„()S         # Push string "()", and split it to a list of characters: ["(",")"]
    ¡        # Split the (implicit) input-string by that
     ι       # Uninterleave this list
      н      # Only keep the first inner list
       J     # Join it together to a single string
        ʒ    # Filter the characters in this string by:
         ð›  #  Check if the character is larger than a space " " (by ASCII codepoint)
             # (after which the result is output implicitly)
```

Comment: We're only supposed to remove substrings wrapped in `()`, aren't we?

Comment: @Shaggy And remove all whitespaces. But I think the reason you're asking is due to the `()<>[]{}`? The input is guaranteed to only contain alphanumeric characters, whitespaces, and parenthesis. So using the builtin `žu` is 1 byte shorter than string `„()`/`„)(`.

Comment: From the spec: "*It's guaranteed that `s` will have only printable ASCII characters*". Maybe it changed since you posted this, though?

Comment: @Shaggy Hmm, I guess you're indeed right. I do remember the specs changed A LOT with this challenge, but my answer was posted after those changes.. In that case the other two 05AB1E answers are invalid as well, though. Since all three of us use `žKÃ`.. :/ Ah well, I've fixed my answer.

Answer (score 2):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 11 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
û┼╢╕jN&╪º╛╘
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=96c5b6b86a4e26d8a7bed4&i=s%28he%29+be%28lie%29ve%28d%29)

Unpacked:

```
"\(.*?\)| "zR
```

this is just a simple regex replace.  It replaces all strings that match `/\(.*?\)| /` with z (an empty string)

Comment: You can deal with whitespace by splitting on spaces, `j` at the end. The resulting segments are implicitly concatenated when printed, taking you down to [10 bytes](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=d9c70d77477b378b56ee&i=sho%28u%29lder+%28should%29er+s%28ho%29u%28ld%29er+s%28h%29ould%28er%29&a=1).

Answer (score 2):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) + `-lF/\(\w+\)|\s+/ -M5.10.0`, 5 bytes

```perl
say@F
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY49C4NADIb3@xU3JohfiHvpIIg4db2lrRGlwZM7rQj97b3mli553zz5XMlxHYK/n5dGBCZC/SDgmfBNMKASVKGG0gt3ULywWhS0Qjpc7KGhZUZ9JQ39GdVvGm7EowxOFnbkgZwG8TsPKFbWWdzhn2AsADlUa4wj0HOb7YJKPmG2cuewTrq/do3ch5Sb3IA5EoMf45M8pH2dlUVW/AA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <sup><s>47</s></sup> 45 bytes

Saved 2 bytes thanks to [FryAmTheEggman](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/31625/fryamtheeggman)!!!

```python
lambda s:re.sub(r"\(\w+\)|\s","",s)
import re
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PZBBS8QwEIXv/RVDLjuDVVwrCAv1sIKwiCe9GQ9bO6XFbFImyS5L3d9e01Y8BN7M@/Jmkv4cWmeLsSn1aPaHqt6D3wjf@FihKI36dKXpR3uVK5V7yrpD7ySA8BjYB19ihspjywQVo@mYjow1qRyUr/jIivIFKAhw7RMlePtNhV0ISWImcJf8F7LuBLgzhmDL2uLreRI@AL6xaebURGx56v0ltw4jmZoFMOloamLRNg10FHGuIBU0OciyLNa66QKLj@lMzpLVT0CD/BU6Z2eyb/62a9kYlzY8OTHL6yaDMimHd4m8gah0vHtYF8l63hv/37l/UpescQIhZ@gszJ@2ycCXDQbKoJfOBmxWaggXBdePoAafxCAfviz587Ki8Rc)

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 12 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
r"%s|%(.*?%)
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=ciIlc3wlKC4qPyUp&input=InMoaGUpIGJlKGxpZSl2ZShkKSI)

Comment: Why not `r" |%(.*?%)`?

Comment: @EmbodimentofIgnorance, because that would only remove literal spaces and not newlines, tabs, etc..

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 18 bytes

```
Φθ∧›ι ⁼№…θ⊕κ(№…θκ)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bctBDsIgEAXQvaeYsJpJ8ASuDFHjzisgTALpCHZKm/T0WPb@3c9/PySvoXrp/aW5NLxnaaw4W7iWiA9lP2q2YMCQhdu8elnQ1fWwbg/CLtXv4M8SlD9cGkec6KAGx@GPnMZIhkYuvS@YmODNKJlpY4x06udNfg) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
 θ                  Input string
Φ                   Filtered where
    ι               Current character
   ›                Is not whitespace
  ∧                 Logical And
       №            Count of
            (       Open parentheses
        …θ⊕κ        In input string so far (inclusive)
      ⁼             Equals
             №      Count of
                 )  Close parentheses
              …θκ   In input string so far (exclusive)
```

Answer (score 1):

## [sed](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/), <s>32</s> 31 bytes

```
:l;s/([^)]*)\|\s//g;N;s/\n//;tl
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K05N0U3PK/3/3yrHulhfIzpOM1ZLM6YmplhfP93aDygUk6evb12S8/@/hqemgoa3Zl5@uYKGZ06OpoJTKpeGbyWILi5R0AhOzUnTBAA)

*Shaved off one byte by removing the -E option and just using basic regular expressions, surprisingly :-) .*

sed is *almost* perfect for this challenge.  The only issue is that sed is a stream editor, processing one line at a time: the trailing newline on each line is not processed, which doesn't make it straightforward to delete any newline characters.

So here's how this script does it:

```
:l
   Label we can jump to later.

s/([^)]*)\|\s//g
   Delete all parenthetical expressions and whitespace before the first newline.

N
   If we're not at the last line, append the next line to the pattern space.  (The next line is appended immediately _after_ the \n at the end of the previous line.  That \n is still there, now in the middle of the pattern space, where it's available for processing by sed.)

s/\n//
    Delete a \n in the middle of the pattern space, if any.  (There will be one if we weren't at the last line in the previous step already.)

tl
    If the last command found a \n to delete, jump back to label l, and do it again!
```

Comment: Hint: there's a flag in GNU sed (since 4.2.2 or something) that slurps all those newline-delimited lines

Comment: @user41805 Thanks, I'll check it out. I thought I reviewed all the sed flags, but maybe I was looking at old documentation, or maybe I missed it.

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) `-p0`, 15 bytes

```perl
s/\s|\(.*?\)//g
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/79YP6a4JkZDT8s@RlNfPx0okJGvUaqZk5JapKABZJfmpGimFnEVa2Tka5ZqgDkKQI4mSEIjtUjzX35BSWZ@XvF/3QIDAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 70 bytes

```c
f(char*s){for(;*s;)s=*s-40?isalnum(*s)&&putchar(*s),s+1:strchr(s,41);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dY8xb8IwEIX3/IpTKqG7ABURTA1tpW6o6tSVJbUdYvWwkc8GVYjfnjpMHdKb3tP7dO9OLQ9KDUOHqm9DJXTtfMCmkobkuZLlZvVqpWWXjpjD2eyU4giOZiHz@kliUH1AWWxqam7Dg3WKkzawlaitf@xfisK6CMfWOjx7q6m4FpCnw1KwNwRfBtkaOhvUVFIDuUCwzOoPtibAWjIbcPVNazfJ4S5T7@T8BXDHTPBm9g4/fkYhEfDTcPdPQ@8xEWsTALNOrMmEvcvFnhLeHWRDY4ImTC85jUmHRkXr3TSS/2X2@cqLD3z/trgNvw)

Comment: Suggest `index()` instead of `strchr()`

Answer (score 1):

## [Red](http://www.red-lang.org), 52 bytes

```
func[s][parse trim/all s[any[to"("remove thru")"]]s]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HU4xbsMwDNz1CkITObVFto7dgqJLMwoaXIuCjdKSQckJgqBvd@lwOd4dyDvltH9zCtHl9z1vZQwthnXQxtB1Xl4GEWhhKPfQq0evvNSrWZNunnyMLe65Kg/jBB2C8w0nJvhhlJnpypjIP8UTAb41cxRff@lUvHvg2bRPKvUGeBYh@GCHX/cDWwe8sGT6c482VdxIEiug7ZskYnX2stKGTwJG6DCQ1S78emBGHvtcy5FvnUSqpd2qytEoBgc2q87FWi9VkrXP0KOL@z8)

Answer (score 1):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 30 bytes

```javascript
s=>s.replace(/\(.*?\)|\s/g,"")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JY9Bb4MwDIXv/IqoJ3uidBPHKUyqtEM17bRjqUQAU9isBCVAO2377SwJh8ixv6fn50@1KNfYYZz22rS0dnJ1snCZpZFVQ3AoIXt4KfG3dIdrutvh@nyuHPSEoibggXAhaFHsC@FqWqhKk4BzFPDkvMbC4xfmeuM214HDydM31OYm4MSM4kgJvH@H6iYBH8RdNPSCI4VZNO0NzMgtWQH@P3OLZBO/yuAMsRG@wQCA7BaoN0FP1s3@BRKMxoA7oGYajI66sYupemI2PtnNWN4uqi5ZZ@yranq4y@InWZQ9q7S@yHvmRh6mKoqSxmhnmDI2V1BpBwrTOhYpa0z@cP0H)

Answer (score 1):

## [APL (Dyalog Extended)](https://github.com/abrudz/dyalog-apl-extended), <sup><s>21</s></sup> 19 bytes

```apl
∊⊢⊆⍨<>(≠\∨⊢)⍤∊∘'()'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY69TsNQDIV3nsJM15ZaqVVWxEAXogohEdhYCtdpK65yq/xQOiNFIVIqGJAYEWLoxjvwKH6R4DRMXazj79jHnq3c0G5mzs@H/JRzYtm2rVS11F9Sl9LsTk5RXj5vpdopImm@O7P6MEimjaV8lWYr2/fwUurn359AyjftoquJ1uvzMGpjMBkumOCO0S2ZHhktmaMeBwQ4ztRLcfRAQbLnGCqdUuLXgKFzBGdsBqh5N5MIxiMaGLzYdDTLASN28X/cwmNBznIKqLpwljg9WNSTngrcW6ANdWPIaZ@w6lSMfJ8vfdIj/dw5T3AMuPap7pk/)

#### How it works

```apl
∊⊢⊆⍨<>(≠\∨⊢)⍤∊∘'()'  ⍝ Input: string s
             ∊∘'()'  ⍝ Boolean vector (1 if a member of '()')
      (≠\  )⍤        ⍝ Scan by boolean XOR
                     ⍝ (gives 1 between '()'s, including '(' but not ')')
         ∨⊢          ⍝ Include back ')'
     >               ⍝ Bitmask indicating negation of the above,
    <                ⍝ plus each char not being whitespace
∊⊢⊆⍨                 ⍝ Filter s by the bitmask above
```

Boolean filtering uses [this APL golfing tip](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/153435/78410).

Answer (score 1):

## [Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org), 75 bytes

```
{fold(""){a,v->when(v){')'->a.takeWhile{it!='('}
in " \r\n"->a
else->a+v}}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LY4xDoMwFEN3TvGbJflq4QBI0At069CFJYhPiUhDFdJ0iHL29AvVi2U9S/a6BWtcidrCPlKkFu7BG/dsFELd/wN0Jc2bnZQQmPQl1v13IaciJomy7nUT9EqPxVhKJpw6qWSujAMBgx@c4EJFdif2c8w5l/nj4KWN44lUAetYDx468KSnm3HE6NqCEAd@84egjnuKa4hVhrKrhRBGUtYQMpjwBw)

Answer (score 1):

## [Gema](http://gema.sourceforge.net/), 7 characters

```
(*)=
 =
```

Sample run:

```
bash-5.0$ gema '(*)=; =' <<< 's(he) be(lie)ve(d)'
sbeve
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0/NTfz/X0NL05ZLwfb//2KNjFRNhaRUjZzMVM2yVI0UTQA) / [Try all test cases online!](https://tio.run/##lZBRS8MwEMefl09xlrlchNHp8EkKOvBhiAj6uBXZ2qsdi01J2k2Z@@zzkoq6Bx8sNPe/3C93/2S5cOUhp0wvLMHwBhpyzXO2cJSg6M2kw5IULAn1itSGMFcyTaRb0obkV32sAM8dQxZHazWuOsCy8ABOuXynKrMFnGqtYEIC7999dA3gE@kitGRgQn6va1sabJXOyQKybnWuyAoeZlSLIQFOlC8g2c5TaTxP1rX8@0roVPt6gZQ1K1MFsC46YyVpbdjc1ljdXUvC8SeUELVdVU0B8gNOh5cjBz5eHMcLXueVBDmt6rbh@Eiu1V7cvtU8mHKWD2spRGEsrDzEK0T93cn3a8@u0310BbkRPRtOJ1EfgbLSwNCj4VTE02JTN/ELvS5iZ7MgQB7wTCUCkoMEFQnR@4dnNhFax3Ffch7P59U@4t3OhFe7H4@dizQACLPZLy5J/kLTFAaD7ib@EbzD3FR0@AQ)

Answer (score 1):

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip), 14 bytes

```
aRMw,`\(.+?\)`
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gs@P8/Mci3XCchRkNP2z5GM@H///8anpoKGt6aefnlChqeOTmaCk6pXBq@lSC6uERBIzg1J03zv24KAA)

Unweave works really well in this solution.

-2 bytes from DLosc, with the first documented use of `,` for Regex alternation!