# Are All the Items the Same?

Tags: code-golf, array, decision-problem

Given a list of non-negative integers, return whether or not that list is all the same number.

### Rules

- Input and output can be taken/given in any reasonable and convenient format
- Truthy/Falsey values can be represented as any value of your choice as long as it's reasonable and relatively consistent (e.g. `1` for falsey and `>= 2` for truthy is fine)
- There will always be at least 1 item in the input list
- The list items are guaranteed to be in the range `[0, 9]` (\$0 \le n \le 9\$)
- Standard loopholes apply

This is code golf, so the shortest program in each language wins. I've made a community wiki answer for trivial answers, so feel free to submit potentially longer programs.

### Test Cases

```
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1] -> True
[1, 2, 3, 4] -> False
[6, 9, 6, 9, 6] -> False
[6] -> True
[7, 7] -> True
[4, 2, 0] -> False
```

Comment: Relevant: [Default policy for ouput in decision problems](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19202/default-policy-for-ouput-in-decision-problems/19205#19205) (since this challenge doesn't specify the allowed options for the output]. Anyway, it would be better for the challenge to explicitly specify what is allowed and what isn't

Comment: @LuisMendo `Input and output can be taken/given in any reasonable and convenient format`, that's pretty standard for more trivial challenges

Comment: @RedwolfPrograms Sure, but I'm not talking about format. I understand format as outputting string `'3'` instead of number `3`; or producing the output via program exit code. What I mean is what _options_ for output are allowed: two consistent values? Non-consistent truthy/falsy? One consistent value for truthy and any inconsistent values for falsy?

Answer (score 14):

## Trivial Built-in Answers

This is the post for all of the languages where this is a built-in

### Vyxal, 1 byte

```
≈
```

[Try it Online!](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=%E2%89%88&inputs=&header=&footer=)

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 1 byte

```
E
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/1/9HJD3cuftQwR0HXTuFRw9yHOxY93DH/UeO2hzu6Hu6cFna4nevh7i2H2x81rYn8/z/aUEcBHcWCdIYUlaZygWSNdBSMdRRMwIJuiTnFQFEzHQVLHQUoiSKBpNVcR8EciWsCNskAoRoA)

## [05AB1E (legacy)](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/tree/fb4a2ce2bce6660e1a680a74dd61b72c945e6c3b), 1 byte

```
Ë
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f//cPf//9GGOgpQFAsA)

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 5 bytes

```
Equal
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n2b737WwNDHnf0BRZl5JtLKuXZqDg3KsWl1wcmJeXTVXtaGOAjqq1QELG@koGOsomIB4ZjoKljoKUBIsACLMdRTMQbQJWK1BLVftfwA)

`SameQ` also works.

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 1 byte

```
=
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/pfXa6koGunoFRuX/2obcOjpuZHHcuVSopKU/WUakDMtMScYiC79uGuztqHWyf8t/3/PzraUEcBHcXqgESNdBSMdRRMgBwzHQVLHQUoCeIDsbmOgjmQMgGrM4iNBQA)

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 1 byte

```
E
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7/3/X////RhjpAGAsA)

## Haskell + [hgl](https://gitlab.com/WheatWizard/haskell-golfing-library), 2 bytes

```
lq
```

[Try it online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m708I7E4OzUnZ8FN88zcgvyiEoXC0sSczLTM1BSFgKLUnNKUVC6oRABXmoKVlYJPZnGJgmdeiYKunYJTfn7O0tKSNF2LJWm2OYUQ5k1XrtzEzDwFW4WUfC4FhYIiBRWFNIXoWCS2ITLHSAcI0QWMYyGGLVgAoQE)

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/), 3 bytes

```
std
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0tMLskv@h8a7OnnbqWQVlSpkJtYkqFXXJJYkllckplcrFBQlFpSUllQlJlXolCcWliampecWqxgzVXNpQAE1QqGKLAWLmqkYKxgAuebKVhCMUIExjIHQhjbBKjPAMirVYj@X1yS8j8W6J4CBaBzkrP1/gMA)

Outputs `0.0` if they're the same, or something else if not. `all-eq?` and `all-equal?` are longer built-ins that output booleans. `all-equal?` uses `=` (ordinary equality) and `all-eq?` uses `eq?` (strict object reference equality), but they behave the same for integers.

## [Thunno](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno), \$2 \log_{256}(96) \approx\$ 1.65 bytes

```
ze
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72sJKM0Ly9_wYKlpSVpuhaLqlIhDCh_wfpoQx0FBIqFCAMA)

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2), 1 byte

```
ạ
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728JKM0Ly_faMGCpaUlaboWix_uWrikOCm5GMpfsDzaUAcIYyFcAA)

Comment: Why 05AB1E (legacy) and not just 05AB1E?

Comment: @Makonede I don't know, because I didn't edit it in

Answer (score 10):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>17</s> 15 bytes

```r
sd(scan()+!1:2)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/vzhFozg5MU9DU1vR0MpI87/pfwA)

Outputs `0` for truthy and nonzero for falsey.

Using `sd` is a classic R golfing trick: the standard deviation is `0` if and only if all elements are equal. Unfortunately, `sd` returns `NA` for length one input (since it divides by `n-1`). A neat workaround found by [pajonk](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/55372/pajonk) uses R's recycling: `!1:2` is coerced to a vector `c(0,0)` and is added to the input vector. A length-one input is recycled to be length 2 (so the `sd` is guaranteed to be `0`), and for input of length more than `1`, the zeros are recycled to the length of the longer vector, which won't change the standard deviation.

```r
sd(rep(scan(),2))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/vzhFoyi1QKM4OTFPQ1PHSFPzv@l/AA)

Comment: I think that `any(diff(scan()))` also works for 17 bytes

Comment: @user2390246 feel free to post that as your own answer!

Comment: [-2 bytes](https://tio.run/##K/r/vzhFozg5MU9DU1vR0MpI87/pfwA "R – Try It Online") as per [@Dominic's comment and your own golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/225511/longest-sublist-with-equal-occurrences/225538?noredirect=1#comment521805_225538) :)

Comment: @pajonk ah, very nice!

Answer (score 10):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 16 bytes

-12 bytes thanks to [Delfad0r](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/82619/delfad0r).

```hs
f(a:x)=all(==a)x
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XYvNCsIwEITvfYo5eGghij/FYiHePXssOSyapsE0ShOxbx@3pReFnZ2d5ZuOwkM7l1KbUz0WkpzLpaRiTAZ1jWscrDdYn5crM5AI3fODDVpWPmi6/4LNxUdVZD1Zz6z1UQ90i1jh7Z31OnCrpxcM@5xTsxP4H5VN373AQaDkcBQ4CSx7yqxKoGIrZ26rvg)

Another 16 byter:

```hs
f(a:x)=x==(a<$x)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XYvNDoIwEITvPMUcOEBSjT9EIrHePXskHDZaSiNUQ2vs29eFcNFkZ2dn801H7qH6PsY2oyrkMkiZ0SkNedSoKlz9aKzG6rxciYaE654frNGyslHR/ResL9Y3eTKQscwa69VIN48Ub9sbqxy3BnpBs8851luB/2mS6bsT2AsUHA4CR4FlT5lVCpRsxcxtmi8)

Comment: [16 bytes](https://tio.run/##XYvNCsIwEITvfYo5eGghij/FYiHePXssOSyapsE0ShOxbx@3pReFnZ2d5ZuOwkM7l1KbUz0WkpzLpaRiTAZ1jWscrDdYn5crM5AI3fODDVpWPmi6/4LNxUdVZD1Zz6z1UQ90i1jh7Z31OnCrpxcM@5xTsxP4H5VN373AQaDkcBQ4CSx7yqxKoGIrZ26rvg "Haskell – Try It Online")

Comment: @Delfad0r thanks a lot, I don't know how I missed that :/.

Comment: [Pointfree 15 bytes](https://tio.run/##XYvNDoIwEITvPMUcPEBSiD9EIqHePXtEDg2W0lgqoTW@vXUhXDTZ2dnZfNML95DGhI7fgjCGV1XMeZL1UtyDQlni6idtFdLzekUKHK5/vpGhI8UTob9gfbG@SaJBaEustl5OovXY4GWNttJRaxAjFPmSQ71j@J8mmr97hgNDTuHIcGJY95xJBUNBli/ctvm0nRHKhbQdxy8 "Haskell – Try It Online")

Answer (score 9):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 18 bytes

```python
lambda x:len({*x})
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/6fZhvzPycxNyklUaHCKic1T6Naq6JW839BUWZeiUaaRrShDhjGampyoYkZAcX@AwA)

-5 bytes thanks to @hyper-neutrino

I'm lucky.....

Comment: You can remove the `==1` since it was agreed upon that outputting 1 for truthy and >1 for falsy was valid. Alternatively, it can be `<2` since the input is guaranteed to have at least one element.

Comment: Also, `set(x)` is the same as `{*x}`

Comment: @hyper-neutrino thanks!

Comment: You're not lucky, you're wasif

Comment: Beat me to it :)

Answer (score 6):

## [Vim](https://www.vim.org), 8 bytes

```
:g/<C-r><C-w>/d
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/v/3ypd38ZZt8gOSJTb6adw/f9vyGXKZfRftwwA)

This uses the assumption that list elements are one character. <kbd>Ctrl+R</kbd><kbd>Ctrl+W</kbd> inserts the word under the cursor, so this solution applies the `d`elete command to any line which contains the first element of the list. This results in an empty file if they're all the same, or some non-empty lines if they aren't.

If we weren't allowed to assume that items are in the range `[0,9]` then we could give false positives on numbers which are supersets of each other. We could fix this by using a regex instead for one more byte:

#### [Vim](https://www.vim.org), 9 bytes

```
:%s/<C-r><C-w>\n
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/v/30q1WN/GWbfIDkiU28Xkcf3/b2jKBUaGpv91ywA)

Vim doesn't have a concept of truthy/falsey values but if one were to believe that a buffer containing only newlines was falsey, then we could drop the `\n` from this regex to get a 7 byte solution.

Answer (score 5):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 2 bytes

```
IẸ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/z4a4d/49Ofrhz8aOGOQq6dgqPGuY@3LHo4Y75jxq3PdzR9XDntLDD7VwPd2853P6oac3//9GGOgroKBakMaSoNJULJGuko2Cso2ACFnRLzCkGiprpKFjqKEBJFAkkreY6CuZIXBOwSQYI1QA)

Outputs reversed (`0` if all are equal, `1` if not)

### How it works

```
IẸ - Main link. Takes a list L on the left
I  - Increments of L
 Ẹ - Are any non-zero?
```

Answer (score 5):

## JavaScript (non-trivial), <s>22</s> 21 bytes

*Thanks to @l4m2 for -1*

```js
d=>!d.some(x=>x-d[0])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNEts/hfllikkG77P8XWTjFFrzg/N1WjwtauQtE2JdogVvN/QVFmXolGuka0oY4COorV1ORCljfSUTDWUTBBETbTUbDUUYCSqDIoPHMdBXMUAROweUAnaP4HAA)

This one's different from the `new Set` approach because it returns an actual truthy/falsy value. Although it's not as short (by just 4B, surprisingly), it's what you'd probably use if you needed this in real life, so it's definitely worth having here.

You could make it a byte shorter by removing the `!`, but then it returns `false` if all items are the same and `true` otherwise.

Comment: `!=`=>`-` given all are integer?

Comment: @l4m2 Good idea, I forgot about that trick

Answer (score 5):

## Excel, 18 bytes

```
=MAX(A:A)=MIN(A:A)
```

Input is in column A. The formula can be input anywhere not in column A.

Answer (score 4):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 2 bytes

```
QL
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/z/Q5//RyQ93Ln7UMEdB107hUcPchzsWPdwx/1Hjtoc7uh7unBZ2uJ3r4e4th9sfNa35/z/aUEcBHcWCNIYUlaZygWSNdBSMdRRMwIJuiTnFQFEzHQVLHQUoiSKBpNVcR8EciWsCNskAoRoA)

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 2 bytes

```
Lu
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7/36f0////0YY6YBgLAA)

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 2 bytes

```
Ùg
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//8Mz0//@jDXXAMBYA)

## [APL(Dyalog Unicode)](https://dyalog.com), 2 bytes <sup>[SBCS](https://github.com/abrudz/SBCS)</sup>

```
≢∪
```

[Try it on APLgolf!](https://razetime.github.io/APLgolf/?h=AwA&c=e9S56FHHKgA&f=S1MwhECuNAVjBRMFUwA&i=SwMA&r=tryAPL&l=apl-dyalog&m=train&n=f)

Thanks to [Bubbler](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/78410/bubbler) for pointing this out!

---

Outputs [1 for truthy, \$>1\$ for falsey](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/57714890#57714890). These all use the same method: counting the number of unique elements.

If the same approach is also this trivial/short in your language, feel free to edit it in if you don't want to post an answer

Comment: The same also works in APL: [`≢∪`](https://razetime.github.io/APLgolf/?h=AwA&c=e9S56FHHKgA&f=S1MwhECuNAVjBRMFUwA&i=SwMA&r=tryAPL&l=apl-dyalog&m=train&n=f)

Comment: @Bubbler I've edited that in. This is almost as trivial as the builtin, so I've edited in a note for other languages with the same approach

Answer (score 4):

## [Proton](https://github.com/alexander-liao/proton), 7 bytes

```
set+len
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KyjKL8nP@5@mYPu/OLVEOyc1739BUWZeiUaaRrShjgI6itXU5EKWN9JRMNZRMEERNtNRsNRRgJKoMig8cx0FcxQBE7B5BkCx/wA)

Outputs `1` for truthy and anything else for falsy.

Answer (score 4):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 14 bytes

```ruby
->a{!(a|a)[1]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZvtf1y6xWlEjsSZRM9owtvZ/gUJadLShjgI6io3lgkkZ6SgY6yiYwETMdBQsdRSgJFwQxjDXUTCHsU3Aeg1iY/8DAA)

Answer (score 4):

## [Zsh](https://www.zsh.org/) `-o extendedglob`, 8 bytes

```sh
>$@
<^$1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##qyrO@F@cWqKgm6@QWlGSmpeSmpKek5/EBRIzBMH/dioOXDZxKob/bWxsVOz/AwA)

Outputs via exit code; `1` for all the same, `0` for not all the same

- `>$@`: create files according to the input. This de-duplicates elements because a file can only be created once
- `^$1`: find a file that doesn't match the first element of the input (`-o extendedglob` is necessary to enable the `^` feature)
- `<`: and try to read from it. If there is no matching file (because all elements are the same) this will fail and exit with `1`

Comment: You cannot convice me that this is zsh and not befunge or some variant :p

Answer (score 4):

## [Racket](https://racket-lang.org/), <s>37</s> 18 bytes

```lisp
(λ(x)(apply = x))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0pMzk4t@a@ck5iXrlAE5nBppKSmZealKqT91zi3W6NCUyOxoCCnUsFWoUJT878ml0aagkZOZnGJgiEq1ESRMlIwVjBBFjJTsIRgZEFzBXNkrglQmwHQEgA)

-19 thanks to Wezl

This takes advantages of the fact that `=` in Racket can take any number of arguments. Note that the tio seems to run an old version that requires at least 2 arguments to `=` and so fails on the singleton list, but this works on my local Racket 8 installation.

Comment: `(λ(x)(apply = x))` You don't need the check for singleton, it works just fine without it.

Comment: @Wezl hmm you're right for my local isntallation, but tio for some reason throws an error on that. Perhaps they're running an old version?

Comment: probably, but go ahead and take advantage of new features

Answer (score 4):

## [brainfuck](https://github.com/TryItOnline/brainfuck), 40 bytes

Works for all characters, not just 0 to 9! (except NUL)

Returns zero for true and non-zero for false.

```
,[>,]<[->+<]<[[->+>-<<]>>[<[-]>>>]<<<]>.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMxLK03O/v9fJ9pOJ9YmWtdO2wZIgWg7XRubWDu7aKAgkLKLtQFx9f7/NwYCQwA)

Answer (score 4):

## Ruby, 17 bytes

```
f=->a{!a.uniq[1]}
```

Explanation: `a.uniq` is an array with unique elements of a. If all elements are the same, its second element `[1]` will be `nil`, and `!nil` is `true`.

Older answer was more readable:

```
f=->a{a.uniq.size==1}
```

Comment: According to the general input methods allowed on this site, you cannot assume the input is in a variable. You need to wrap this in a function or lambda for it to be valid.

Comment: @Razetime Thank you for warning me; i've edited the answer here (and in the other posts).

Comment: Usually, we omit f= in the submission unless is it reused somewhere else(or for recursion). Feel free to look at other ruby answers for examples. We generally use https://tio.run for hosting ruby solutions supported by version 2.5.5. (it also has a convenient submission generator for this site)

Answer (score 4):

## [Pari/GP](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/), 19 bytes

```
v(s)=gcd(s)==lcm(s)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gsytRNL/j/v0yjWNM2PTkFRNnmJOcCaZBgtKGOAjqK1eSCSBjpKBjrKJhA@GY6CpY6ClASKgShzHUUzCEsE7Aeg1hNAA)

Answer (score 4):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://codeberg.org/ngn/k), 5 bytes

```
1=#?:
```

[Try it online!](https://ngn.codeberg.page/k#eJxLszK0Vba34uLSVwhKLSktyitWMFRIyy9SKCkqTdVRMACz0xJzilO50oAyyFBfQddOIQSoDCxjpGCsYAIRc4MqN1OwhGJk4Wgds1gUveZAiMw3AZplgKQFAA3pJ7c=)

*-2 bytes thanks to ngn*

Returns `1` for true, `0` for false.

Checks if `1` is equal to the length of unique elements in `x`

Comment: trains are allowed here, so `1=#?:` works too

Answer (score 4):

## [Uiua](https://uiua.org), 4 [bytes](https://www.uiua.org/pad?src=U0JDUyDihpAgK0BcMOKKlwpEZWNvZGUg4oaQIOKHjOKKjy0x4pa9wrEu4o2Y4ouv4oav4oqCwq8x4qe74ouv4qe7LOKHjOKItSjihpjCrzHii68rMjU2KSAtQFwwKzEKJnAg4oqCIjggYml0IGVuY29kaW5nOlx0IiBTQkNTICLih4ziio8tMeKWvcKxLuKNmOKLr-KGr-KKgsKvMeKnu-KLr-Knuyzih4ziiLUo4oaYwq8x4ouvKzI1NikiIOKKgitAXDDih6ExMjkiLiziiLY74oiYwqzCscKv4oy14oia4peL4oyK4oyI4oGFPeKJoDziiaQ-4omlKy3Dl8O34pe_4oG_4oKZ4oan4oal4oig4qe74paz4oeh4oqi4oeM4pmt4ouv4o2J4o2P4o2W4oqa4oqb4oqd4pah4oqU4omF4oqf4oqC4oqP4oqh4oav4oaZ4oaY4oa74per4pa94oyV4oiK4oqXL-KIp1xc4oi14omh4oi64oqe4oqg4o2l4oqV4oqc4oip4oqT4oqD4oqZ4ouF4o2Y4o2c4o2a4qyaJz_ijaPijaQh4o6L4oas4pqCzrfPgM-E4oiefl9bXXt9KCnCr0AkXCLihpB8IyIKJnAg4oqCImRlY29kZWQ6XHQiIERlY29kZSAiwqPCsS0xwrjChy7DjMKlwrPCsMKIMcKfwqXCnyzCo8K_KMK1wogxwqUrMjU2KSIg4oqCK0BcMOKHoTEyOSIuLOKItjviiJjCrMKxwq_ijLXiiJril4vijIrijIjigYU94omgPOKJpD7iiaUrLcOXw7fil7_igb_igpnihqfihqXiiKDip7vilrPih6HiiqLih4zima3ii6_ijYnijY_ijZbiipriipviip3ilqHiipTiiYXiip_iioLiio_iiqHihq_ihpnihpjihrvil6vilr3ijJXiiIriipcv4oinXFziiLXiiaHiiLriip7iiqDijaXiipXiipziiKniipPiioPiipnii4XijZjijZzijZrirJonP-KNo-KNpCHijovihqzimoLOt8-Az4TiiJ5-X1tde30oKcKvQCRcIuKGkHwjIg==)

```
≅↻1.
```

[Try it!](https://uiua.org/pad?src=ZiDihpAg4omF4oa7MS4KCmYgWzEgMSAxIDEgMSAxIDFdICMgLT4gVHJ1ZQpmIFsxIDIgMyA0XSAgICAgICAjIC0-IEZhbHNlCmYgWzYgOSA2IDkgNl0gICAgICMgLT4gRmFsc2UKZiBbNl0gICAgICAgICAgICAgIyAtPiBUcnVlCmYgWzcgN10gICAgICAgICAgICMgLT4gVHJ1ZQpmIFs0IDIgMF0gICAgICAgICAjIC0-IEZhbHNl)

```
≅↻1.
   .  # duplicate
 ↻1   # rotate an array by one
≅     # do they match?
```

Comment: Alternative 4 byters: `=1⧻⊝` (length of deduplicated equals 1), `≅⊃⍏⍖` (sorting order and reverse sorting order are equal), `¬∊1⊛` (1 doesn't exist in classification)

Answer (score 3):

## [Arn 1.0](https://github.com/ZippyMagician/Arn) `-s`, 2 bytes

```
:@
```

Outputs 1 if all the same, >1 if they aren't all the same.
[Try it online (works in older version)](https://zippymagician.github.io/Arn?code=OkA=&input=MSAxIDEgMSAxIDEgMQoxIDIgMyA0CjYgOSA2IDkgNgo2&flags=LXM=)

`:@` groups identical values, `-s` takes size. This could be written as `(:@)#` as well, which would be 4 bytes (`«×+0`)

Comment: :D Arn! Very nice!

Answer (score 3):

## [Branch](https://github.com/hyper-neutrino/branch-lang/), 27 bytes

```
1O,[^\,N![o#)]n^=/;^\o^*On]
```

Try it on the [online Branch interpreter](https://branch.hyper-neutrino.xyz/#WyIxTyxbXlxcLE4hW28jKV1uXj0vO15cXG9eKk9uXSIsIjExMTExMTExMTExMiIsIiJd)!

There's got to be a much shorter way to do this...

Answer (score 3):

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip), 3 bytes

```
$=g
```

Full program; takes the items from command-line arguments. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gs@P9fxTb9////RmBoDAA)

Alternately, a function solution that takes a list as its argument (also 3 bytes):

```
$=_
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gs@K/xX8U2/n@0kQIYxmr@BwA)

#### Explanation

Not *quite* a builtin.

Pip, like Python, has chaining comparison operators: `1<5>=3` means `1<5 & 5>=3`, and `1=1=1=2` means `1=1 & 1=1 & 1=2`. Unlike Python, Pip also has the meta-operator `$`, which folds a list on a binary operator. For example, `$+` folds a list on addition, returning the sum; and `$=` folds a list on `=`. Because `=` chains, this returns the result we want: 1 if all elements are equal and 0 otherwise. The program `$=g` applies this compound operator to the full arglist `g`.

Answer (score 3):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <s>35</s> 32 bytes

```c
f(int*l){l=~l[1]&&*l-*++l+f(l);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZU/NToQwGLz3KSY1u4FSDH/rRhG8@QTeWA4NP9qkggHWC8FXRwqakmzSNNOZ@eabFu57UcxzbclmYMoeVfKjMj8/HplymeMop7aUHU/znWwKdS0rPPdDKdv7j5QsExBeliejz3FzXH@KN4v/Zwk4Qo5opwRaeeB45Pi/jRhuoiEiTZw5zjvupLlozfY2mpDvVpYYqn5Y/4RSDMIeCb665VnDohmoHRPUbQftAJOJ9sRMpokXO460CYz7UIJyJvUEdiE53BSHHpfm0lBeW@uWF/rWXSv6RF@F6iu9ZVprfgrZWDaWEmst4em0DfoGBgaGBkYGnjQk0/wL)

- recursive function taking an array -1 ended
- return False if all elements are equal, True otherwise

```
{l=      - return using eax trick
~l[1]&&  - return False if next item is end and skip next part ending recursion 
*l-*++l  - 0 if different 
+f(l);}  - plus check next item
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 5 bytes

```
⁼⌊θ⌈θ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z@gKDOvRMO1sDQxp1jDNzMvM7c0V6NQU0fBN7ECytbUtP7/3xAC/uuW5QAA) Link is to verbose version of code. Takes input as a string of digits by default but you can feed it an array if you insist. Outputs a Charcoal boolean, i.e. `-` for equal, nothing if not. Explanation: Simply compares the minimum and maximum input element.

Answer (score 3):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), 7 bytes

```
D`.
^.$
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/K@q4Z7w3yVBjytOT@X/f0MI4DI0MjbhMrMEQi4zLnNzLhMjAy4A) Link includes test cases. Takes input as a string of digits. Explanation:

```
D`.
```

Remove duplicate digits.

```
^.$
```

Check that only one digit is left.

Answer (score 3):

### x86-16 machine code, 6 bytes

Hexdump:

```
0000:0000  89 F7 AC F3 AE C3                                ......
```

### Explanation

```
                                   ; Routine A. [All The Same?]
                                   ; Expects CX = Length of input,
                                   ;         SI = Initial address of list.

0000:0000  89F7        MOV DI, SI  ; A1 [Load]. Set DI to SI.
0000:0002  AC          LODSB       ;            AL = [SI++].
0000:0003  F3AE        REPZ SCASB  ; A2 [Compare].
                                   ;       ZF = 1
                                   ;       Loop CX times:
                                   ;           If AX != [DI]:
                                   ;               ZF = 0
                                   ;               Proceed to A3
                                   ;           DI ++
0000:0105  C3          RET         ; A3 [End]. End of algorithm.
                                   ;           ZF = 0 if not all same.
                                   ;           ZF = 1 if all same. █
```

Comment: [Welcome to Code Golf](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/20861/66833), and nice first answer!

Comment: Nice, clever way to avoid off-by-one or a `dec`. Copying the pointer *before* `lodsb` makes `repz scasb` scan the whole array of length CX, including the first byte.  The same machine code works in 32-bit mode (with ECX / ESI), or in 64-bit mode with 32-bit pointers.  (Otherwise `push rsi`/`pop rdi` to copy a 64-bit register in 2 bytes.)

Answer (score 3):

## [Ly](https://github.com/LyricLy/Ly), 6 bytes

```
a0I=u;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y6n8/z/RwNO21Pr/fzMuSy4wBgA)

This one works by sorting the list of number and comparing the top and bottom of the stack.

```
a       - sort the stack, implicitly reads the numbers first
 0I     - copy the bottom entry to top of the stack
   =    - compare the top two entries
    u;  - print boolean result, exit to stop from auto printing the stack
```

## [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/), 14 bytes

```
unique[1]//"T"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyr8/780L7OwNDXaMFZfXylE6f//aDMdBUsdBSgZCwA)

This one generates a list of unique numbers, then attempts to print the second member of that list.  The `//` operator catches the exception and substitutes `T` if there's only one number.

Answer (score 3):

## [Fig](https://github.com/Seggan/Fig), \$2\log_{256}(96)\approx\$ 1.646 bytes

```
LU
```

If you test input cases, the Fig site demands no spaces, ie. `[x,y,z]` not `[x, y, z]`. Outputs `1` if all equal, else `>1`.

[Try it online!](https://fig.fly.dev/#WyJMVSIsIlsxLDEsMSwxLDEsMSwxXSJd)

```
LU
 U  : Uniquify with implicit input
L   : Length
```

Comment: You can replace `=1` with `{` for inverted logical output

Comment: Or by using [Julia's output method](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/224077/107299), remove `=1` entirely

Comment: Good catch, I read that specification, but it didn't click.

Answer (score 3):

## dc, 27 characters

```
?[0p3Q]sq[d3R!=qz0<c]dscx1p
```

Sample run:

```
bash-5.1$ dc -e '?[0p3Q]sq[d3R!=qz0<c]dscx1p' <<< '1 1 1 1 1 1 1'
1

bash-5.1$ dc -e '?[0p3Q]sq[d3R!=qz0<c]dscx1p' <<< '6 9 6 9 6'
0
```

[Try all test cases online!](https://tio.run/##lVCxTsMwEJ3jr7haoW6HKElTqBCxgIGBCbWrsVBqu2pElKRxIlUUvj3YjhrKwIAs33t3fme/8zbT@14qUWSNguARWqXbN5FpRWfIYySGi0U4jYfiAhJYmjSy6Q3cgttj4SxcwepMl6YncoI5QnWTl@0OyCdcBfG1BofRL1yY@FoSIM9l3bUGN0p3hSVPx1qJVklDX94JQruqgdyKTATsnybjCOyBf@E7kBXyGtdNsT@DsNNNWFQiK8JtXoZSQKCA9PcsqpM11wcmk82EHj6iVHCpxTGuewJpmpq73TMY5hgh7x8zjI3YH3xYdvqxORwbr2D9MXaho/QvKecwnYIS@8r9gzUlq1L13w)
(Note that choosing `dc` as interpreter and running the test separately fails both in TIO and ATO. ☹)

Comment: ATO/TIO uses dc by running a file instead of `-e`. Why that makes a difference, I have no idea (I can reproduce locally), but it works with `-e`: [ATO](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70oJfmmarSSbqqSjoKSfbRBgXFgbHFhdIpxkKJtYZWBTXJsSnFyhWGBUuyCpaUlaboWaNRKMwVLBTCGCAAA)/[TIO](https://tio.run/##S0n@DwRmCpYKYPxfN/W/fbRBgXFgbHFhdIpxkKJtYZWBTXJsSnFyhWEBAA).

Answer (score 3):

## [sed](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/), 26 bytes

```
$!{N;/^\(.*\)\n\1$/D;Q1};Q
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K05N0U3PK/3/X0Wx2s9aPy5GQ08rRjMmL8ZQRd/FOtCw1jrw/39DLiMuYy4TAA) - Takes input as a newline separated list of numbers, exits with a non-zero exit code for "false" (i.e. not a uniform list).

###### Explanation

```
$!{                    }     if not last line, do these
   N;                          append next input line to pattern space
     /^\(.*\)\n\1$/            if pattern space is two identical lines
                   D;            delete first line, and GOTO beginning
                     Q1        quit with exit code 1 (no printing)
                        ;Q   quit with exit code 0 (no printing)
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf Stack Exchange, and nice first submission!

Answer (score 2):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), 17 bytes

```powershell
($args|gu).length
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/X0MlsSi9uCa9VFMvJzUvvSTj////hhAIAA)

Outputs 1 for truthy and anything else for falsy.

Comment: The script returns 1 for 1,1,1,1 and 3 for 1,2,1,1. Where is true/false?

Comment: @mazzy see Hyper-neutrino's first comment under my python answer. This is perfectly allowed.

Comment: please add to description how you interpret to boolean

Comment: @mazzy done that

Answer (score 2):

## [V (vim)](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/V), 10 bytes

```
:sor u
Gd{
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/v/36o4v0ihlMs9pfr/f0MuCDT5r1sGAA)

Input as a list of lines. Outputs a falsy value (Empty output) for all items equal, and outputs a number otherwise.

Gets the unique lines, goes to the last line and deletes till the beginning.

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript, 21 bytes

```javascript
d=>/^(.)\1*$/.test(d)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNEts/hfllikkG77P8XWTj9OQ08zxlBLRV@vJLW4RCNF839BUWZeiUa6hrohBKhranIhxIyMTVAEzCyBEFUEhWdujsI1MTIA8v8DAA)

Comment: In essence this is only 15 Bytes, since `/../.test` is already the whole function, since the parameter d is the only parameter to this function.

Comment: @Falco No, `/../.test` is `RegExp.prototype.test`, lost relation to the RegEx

Comment: you are right, I though it would capture the object, but without the lambda expression it won't

Answer (score 2):

## [Raku](http://raku.org/), <s>7</s> 6 bytes

<s>2>*.Set</s>

```
+*.Set
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJamYPu/Wi0uXaPGIa7i0G49tbg0zdr/xYmVCmka1SrxhzbV6ihUq8RVKOgqqMRVAjk2ukYKRnaa1goINZt1QQqBhK4hRHXlo8YtukBNIJlKkEwFWKOhgq4hUOd/AA)

`*.Set` converts the input list into a set.  That set's size is then <s>compared with `2`</s> returned.

*-1 byte thanks to Razetime*

Comment: simply outputting the size should work as per the other answers.

Answer (score 2):

## [Red](http://www.red-lang.org), 25 bytes

```
func[s][single? unique s]
```

Doesn't work in TIO - apparently `single?` has been added in the subsequent versions.

[image]

## Using `parse`, 54 bytes

```
func[s][parse s[set t skip(r: reduce['quote t])any r]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TU7LCsIwELz3K4Ze1IPgo1jswY/wuuyhbTZY1KbdpAe/PgZJwV2GebAwq2LiXQxxYZtol7EnzzS16gWevAQE@OcwbbWBill6oc28uCAIvGvHD5Q5WqfS9g90oAJp6Ii/5TU74Ywquwuu@GH1mWvUWVXp/sBFekaHMdDbvUwqKPe3EhZdav0C)

Much longer, but a bit more interesting.

### Explanation:

Red's `parse` works not only on strings, but on all types of series (block! paren! string! file! url! path! lit-path! set-path! get-path! vector! hash! binary! tag! email! image!).

```
f: func[s][
    parse s [                   ; parse the input
        set t skip              ; sets `t` to the first item 
                                ; a literal integer can't be used as a parse rule 
        (r: reduce['quote t])   ; that's why set `r` to `t`'s quoted value 
        any r                   ; zero or more `r`  
    ]
]
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 3 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

Returns `1` for true `>1` for false.

```
â l
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=4iBs&footer=tjE&input=WwpbMSwgMSwgMSwgMSwgMSwgMSwgMV0gLT4gVHJ1ZQpbMSwgMiwgMywgNF0gLT4gRmFsc2UKWzYsIDksIDYsIDksIDZdIC0%2bIEZhbHNlCls2XSAtPiBUcnVlCls3LCA3XSAtPiBUcnVlCls0LCAyLCAwXSAtPiBGYWxzZQpdLW1S) (includes all test cases)

Comment: Does `fU` work?

Answer (score 2):

## [Scala](http://www.scala-lang.org/), 14 bytes

```scala
_.toSet.size<2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K05OzEn8n5@UlZpcouCbmJmnkFpRkpqXUqzgWFCgUM1VlpijkGal4JNZXBLtmVcSq2Brp@CUn5@TmpinYPs/Xq8kPzi1RK84syrVxuh/QVFmXklOnkaaBki9hqGOAghpampyYcoYYREGCdX@BwA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Julia 1.0](http://julialang.org/), 12 bytes

```
length∘∪
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyrNyUw0rPivqGCr8D8nNS@9JONRx4xHHav@OxRn5JcrKEYb6iigo1guJEkjHQVjHQUThJiZjoKljgKURBJGMM11FMwRPBOwGQax/wE)

- outputs 1 if all numbers are equal, >1 else
- `∘` is for function composition
- `∪` is `union`, equivalent to `unique` for a single argument. `Set` would also work for the same number of bytes (but `∪` is nicer)

## [Julia 1.8](https://julialang.org), 8 bytes

```
allequal
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m700qzQnM3HBYkUF26WlJWm6FisSc3JSC0sTcyDcm4UOxRn55QqK0YY6CugolgtJ0khHwVhHwQQhZqajYKmjACWRhBFMcx0FcwTPBGyGQSzE4gULIDQA) <sub><sup>when ATO updates to 1.8</sup></sub>

- the boring solution

## [Julia 0.6](http://julialang.org/), 3 bytes

```julia
var
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyrNyUw0@6@oYPu/LLHov0NxRn65gmK0oY4COorlQpI00lEw1lEwQYiZ6ShY6ihASSRhBNNcR8EcwTMBm2EQ@x8A)

- outputs `0` or `NaN` for truthy, anything else for falsy
- for Julia 1.0+, add `using Statistics`
- `std` would work the same way

Answer (score 2):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) `-p`, 13 bytes

```perl
$_=/^(.)\1*$/
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/18l3lY/TkNPM8ZQS0X//39DCOAyMTUzNDI2NDUz4TIyhEEuIzAwMzLiMgWBf/kFJZn5ecX/dQtyAA)

Since the input is all single digit numbers, this wants the input without spaces.

Answer (score 2):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 5 bytes

```apl
×/⊢=⊃
×/ ⍝ product reduce
  ⊢=⊃ ⍝ three train, each element equal to first element
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///P@1R24TD0/UfdS2yfdTVDOQrGCoYKRgrmHCBWGAIAA)

Comment: you can remove the parens for a 4-train. See [`(f g h k)`](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/43084/80214) here.

Comment: @Razetime Oh, wow. Thanks :)

Comment: alternatively ⍋≡⍒, ≠≡⍷⍨, or any of the solutions presented here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GZuZgCDql6g

Comment: @rak1507 I hadn't committed them to memory yet, this is just what came to my head. That was a great talk though.

Answer (score 2):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 2 bytes

*And thanks to Razetime for some other 2-byters*

(the 1-byte [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk) built-in is `E` (`same`))

```
hg
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7/PyP9////0cY6EGgAImMB)

Returns truthy (nonempty list) if all elements are not the same, falsy (empty list) if they're all the same.  Collects `g`roups of equal values and returns the `h`ead by discarding the last group.

(Other 2-byters with various truthy/falsy & falsy/truthy return values: [ËI](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7//3C35////6ONdSDQAETGAgA), [Ë=](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7//3C37f///6ONdSDQAETGAgA), [#≠](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7/X/lR54L///9HG@uAoAGYNI4FAA), and some 3-byters: [ΠẊ=](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7//9yCh7u6bP///x9trAOBBiAyFgA), [hk=](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7/PyPb9v///9HGOhBoACJjAQ), [hġ=](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7/P@PIQtv///9HG@uAoAGYNI4FAA), [hü=](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7/P@PwHtv///9HG@uAoAGYNI4FAA))

Comment: two other builtin answers: `ËI` and `Ë=`

Answer (score 2):

## [AWK](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/), 18 bytes

```
1,$0=NF~gsub($1,e)
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m704sTx7wYKlpSVpuhabDHVUDGz93OrSi0uTNFQMdVI1IRJQ-QU3tQ0VkCCXoYKRgrGCCZeZgqUCGHOZcZkrmHOZAMUNIHoA)

Revisiting my former answer, I realized that if I wanted `$0` to be printed every time, I can use [range patterns](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Ranges). In fact, if *begpat* (the left part) is always true, then the range pattern is always true. So I substituted the appending `( )e` technique to the range pattern `1,`, saving one byte.

#### AWK, 19 bytes (former answer)

```
$0=(NF~gsub($1,e))e
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzP/v9fxcBWw8@tLr24NElDxVAnVVMz9f9/QwUkyGWoYKRgrGDCZaZgqQDGXGZc5grmXCZAcQMA)

In details:

```
       gsub($1,e)    Searches and substitutes every occurrence of the first number
                     of the input ($1) for a null variable (e). It returns the
                     number of substitutions made.

    NF~              Matches the Number of Fields (i.e., number of items) and the
                     number of substitutions.
                     We expect 1 or 0 as result, but there will be no output when
                     it parses as 0. (AWK skips falsey patterns, and 0 is falsey.)

   (             )e  Appending a null variable converts 1 to "1" and 0 to "0".
                     That's good, because strings are always true.

$0=                  Sets the original input to the resulting "1" or "0".
                     As the pattern is a string, it is printed.
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Golfscript](http://www.golfscript.com/golfscript/), 4 bytes

```
~.&,
```

For the input: a set of numbers should be placed in '[]' without commas.

For the output: 1 is a truthy value while integers greater than 1 are falsey.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8/PSStOLsosKPn/v05PTef//2gDBSiMBQA)

### Explanation:

I hope this does not count as a 'trivial solution'... :)

```
~    # Evals the input to generate a list. 
 .   # Duplicates the list. 
  &  # Does setwise AND. Doing AND on two same lists will have the effect of removing duplicate elements. 
   , # Returns the length of the remaining list.
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Whitespace](https://web.archive.org/web/20150618184706/http://compsoc.dur.ac.uk/whitespace/tutorial.php), 66 bytes

```
[S S S N
_Push_0][S N
S _Duplicate_0][T   N
T   T   _Read_STDIN_as_integer][T   T   T   _Retrieve_input][N
S S N
_Label_LOOP][S N
S _Duplicate_first_input][S N
S _Duplicate][S N
S _Duplicate][T N
T   T   _Read_STDIN_as_integer][T   T   T   _Retrieve_input][S N
S _Duplicate][N
T   T   S N
_If_neg_Jump_to_Label_DONE][T   S S T   _Subtract][N
T   S N
_If_0_Jump_to_Label_LOOP][T N
S T _Print_as_integer][N
N
N
_Exit_program][N
S S S N
_Create_Label_DONE][T   N
S T _Print_as_integer]
```

Letters `S` (space), `T` (tab), and `N` (new-line) added as highlighting only.
`[..._some_action]` added as explanation only.

Takes the input-list new-line separated with -1 to indicate we're done with the inputs. Outputs `-1` as truthy, and the first input as falsey (+4 bytes to output `0` instead if this is not allowed).

[**Try it online**](https://tio.run/##K8/ILEktLkhMTv3/X0FBgQsIObk4QYALwoMgqBhIBERyKoBEgDRIBghAOkHs//@NuEy4jKBQ1xAA) (with raw spaces, tabs and new-lines only).

**Explanation in pseudo-code:**

```
Integer firstInput = STDIN as integer
Start LOOP:
  Integer next = STDIN as integer
  If (next == -1):
    Print next as integer to STDOUT
    (Stop program with error: no exit defined)
  If (firstInput == next):
    Go to next iteration of LOOP
  Else:
    Print firstInput as integer to STDOUT
    Stop program
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Python](https://www.python.org), 16 bytes

```
def f(a):b,={*a}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vwYKlpSVpuhYbUlLTFNI0EjWtknRsq7USayHCN5PT8osUEhUy8xSiDXUMdYxidYC0sY4pkDbSAcNYKy4FhYKizLwSjUSd1LwUWyUrJU2gUElRpRXIQGuIXEhRaSpIOLUiObWgxAoi6JaYU5yqCbEK5hIA)

Signals by exit code.

## [Python](https://www.python.org) NumPy, 16 bytes

```
lambda a:a.ptp()
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vweI025ilpSVpuhYbchJzk1ISFRKtEvUKSgo0NCHCN0Mycwvyi0oU8kpzCyq50vKLFBIVMvMUog11DHWMYnWAtLGOKZA20gHDWCsuBYWCosy8Eo1EHSUrJZ00DbBOvcSiosRKjURNTVtbA6jZCxZAaAA)

Takes a numpy array and returns 0 for True and 1 or more for False.

Answer (score 2):

## TI-Basic, 5 bytes

```
min(Ans=min(Ans
```

Takes input in `Ans`. Outputs `0` for falsey, and `1` for truthy.

Answer (score 2):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://codeberg.org/ngn/k), <s>10</s> 3 bytes

```
#?:
```

[Try it online!](https://ngn.codeberg.page/k#eJxLs1K2t+Li0lcwVLBVKCkqTdVRsAMx0xJzilO50qI1DBWQoGasgr6Crp1CCFAhRNJIwVjBBCbsBtNkpmCpAMboMjpmaCaYK5ijG2oCNNQARSMAWzcm7g==)

*Down 7 bytes thanks to Steffan*

Dead simple. `1` for true, and `>1` for false.

Explanation:

```
#?:    Main function. Takes implicit input
  :    Right (apply what's on the left to the right)
 ?     Unique
#      Length
```

Comment: You can just do `{#?x}` to return `1` for true and >1 for false. And that can be golfed down to `#?:`, which is equivalent.

Answer (score 2):

## [Headass](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Headass), 13 bytes

```
U{N(+)P:R(U)}
```

[Try It Online!](https://dso.surge.sh/#@WyJoZWFkYXNzIiwiIiwiVXtOKCspUDpSKFUpfSIsIiIsIjBcbjBcbjBcbjBcbjAiLCIiXQ==) - prints `1` for truthy and nothing for falsy

###### Explanation

```
U{N(+)P:R(U)} full program
U             ready first
 {N(+) :    } while inputs remain
        R(U)    if readied input != next input, terminate program
          U     (while running this conditional, ready next input)
      P       print 1
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Labyrinth](https://github.com/m-ender/labyrinth), 14 bytes

```
:,:
" }
=*$
@!
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0lMqizKzCvJ@P/fSseKS0mhlstWS4XLQfH/f0Mg@JdfUJKZn1f8XzcFAA)

Takes input from stdin without any separators. Prints a negative integer if the items are equal, a positive integer otherwise.

```
:,:    Precondition: top of stack is either 0 (first iteration)
" }                  or the previous char (the rest)
=*$    First iteration: [(implicit 0) | ]
       :,:  dup; getchar; dup  [ 0 0 c c | ]
       }    move data to right [ 0 0 c | c ]
       $*   xor; mul           [ 0 | c ]
       top is 0; go straight
       =    swap tops          [ c | 0 ]
       top is positive; turn right
       "    no-op

       Next iterations: [ c | ]
       :,:  [ c c c2 c2 | ]
       }    [ c c c2 | c2 ]
       $*   [ c*(c^c2) | c2 ]
       top is zero iff c == c2. if so, go straight
         =    [ c2 | ... ]
       otherwise, turn left to exit the loop
         !    print c*(c^c2)
         the value is negative if c2 < 0 (EOF), positive otherwise
         @    halt
```

Since the main conditional looks like

```
if some value is zero, keep running the loop
otherwise exit
```

there has to be a straight path somewhere in the loop, so a loop of size 8 is unavoidable.

Answer (score 1):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 18 bytes

```javascript
a=>new Set(a).size
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/Z9m@z/R1i4vtVwhOLVEI1FTrzizKvV/cn5ecX5Oql5OfrpGmka0oQ4cxmpqcqHJmulY6oAxUO4/AA)

Couldn't find the name of the `Set` builtint. Thanks dingledooper :P (outputs using the 1,>1 method that pretty much everyone is using now)

Previously...

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 39 bytes

```javascript
a=>a.map(x=>a[0]==x).reduce((x,y)=>x&y)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/Z9m@z/R1i5RLzexQKMCyIg2iLW1rdDUK0pNKU1O1dCo0KnUtLWrUKvU/J@cn1ecn5Oql5OfrpGmEW2oA4exmppcaLJmOpY6YAyU@w8A)

Comment: The obvious `a=>new Set(a).size<2` works too.

Comment: @dingledooper oh that's what sets are called. thanks

Comment: For the non-trivial one, how about `d=>d.some(x=>x!=d[0])`? Should return `false` if all items are identical, and `true` otherwise (unless I've done a stupid). You can put a `!` in front to make it return a more sensible interpretation of `true` and `false`. Also, is it okay if I post this as my own answer? :p

Comment: @RedwolfPrograms i keep forgetting javascript list utilities like map and all are methods and not globals ;-; also sure :P

Answer (score 1):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 2 bytes

```
l{
```

[Test suite](http://pythtemp.herokuapp.com/?code=l%7B&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=%5B1%2C+1%2C+1%2C+1%2C+1%2C+1%2C+1%5D%0A%5B1%2C+2%2C+3%2C+4%5D%0A%5B6%2C+9%2C+6%2C+9%2C+6%5D%0A%5B6%5D%0A%5B7%2C+7%5D%0A%5B4%2C+2%2C+0%5D&debug=0)

Outputs 1 if all elements are equal, and some integer* greater than 1 otherwise.
<sup>* Number of unique elements.</sup>

Answer (score 1):

## [CSASM v2.4.0.2](https://github.com/absoluteAquarian/CSASM/releases/tag/v2.4.0.2), 57 bytes

Pops an `~arr:i32` from the stack, then pushes `true` (all elements are the same) or `false` (some elements are different).

```
func a:
dup
len
swap
newset
conv ~arr
len
comp.gt
push $f.o
ret
end
```

**Explanation + Full Program:**

````
.asm_name AllSame

func main:
    .local i : ~arr:i32,5
    .local j : ~arr:i32,5

    ; Initialize the arrays
    ; i = [ 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 ]
    push i
    push 1
    stelem 0

    push i
    push 1
    stelem 1

    push i
    push 1
    stelem 2

    push i
    push 1
    stelem 3

    push i
    push 1
    stelem 4

    ; j = [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ]
    push [1..5]
    conv ~arr
    pop j

    clf.o

    ; Get the first result
    push i
    call a

    ; Print it
    push "Is 'i' all same? "
    swap
    add
    print.n

    clf.o

    ; Get the second result
    push j
    call a

    ; Print it
    push "Is 'j' all same? "
    swap
    add
    print.n

    ret
end

func a:
    dup
    ; [ array, array ]
    len
    ; [ array, length ]
    swap
    ; [ length, array ]
    newset
    ; [ length, set ]
    conv ~arr
    ; [ length, set elements ]
    len
    ; [ length, element count ]
    comp.gt
    ; If "length" is greater than "element count", then the set had duplicate
    ;   entries which were removed

    ; Push the comparison flag
    push $f.o
    ret
end
```
````

Answer (score 1):

## [K (oK)](https://github.com/JohnEarnest/ok), 4 bytes

**Solution:**

```
1=#?
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y9bNz/7/P83K0FbZ/n@ag7qGoQIStDZUMFIwVjCxNlOwVABjax0za3MFc2sToISB5n8A)

**Explanation:**

Is the count of the unique items equal to 1?

```
1=#? / the solution
   ? / unique
  #  / count
1=   / equal to 1?
```

Answer (score 1):

## MMIX, 36 bytes (9 instrs)

Takes array of bytes and length as two arguments, C conventions

```
00000000: 83020000 27010101 82ff0001 32ffff02  ³£¡¡'¢¢¢²”¡¢2””£
00000010: 52ff0002 f8000000 5b01fffb e3000001  R”¡£ẏ¡¡¡[¢”»ẉ¡¡¢
00000020: f8010000                             ẏ¢¡¡
```

Disassembly and explanation:

```
alleq   LDBU $2,$0,0        // x = *a
0H      SUBU $1,$1,1
        LDBU $255,$0,$1     // loop: t = a[--l]
        CMPU $255,$255,$2
        PBZ  $255,0F        // iflikely(t == x) goto skp
        POP  0,0            // return 0 (abuses how POP works)
0H      PBNZ $1,0B          // skp: iflikely(l) goto loop
        SETL $0,1
        POP  1,0            // return 1
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Mascarpone](https://github.com/catseye/Mascarpone), 25 bytes

```
,['0.]v*1['1.]v*']<[:,>!]v*' <:' >,<:,>!
```

[Try It Online!](https://tio.run/##y00sTk4sKsjPS/3/Xyda3UAvtkzLMFrdEESrx9pEW@nYKYKYCjZW6gp2OjYgPtf//9HmCkAYCwA)

This program accepts strings similar to this one:

```
"[2 8 1 6 4]"
```

and prints either '1' or '0' to stdout, with no newline.

#### Explanation

```
,['0.]v*1['1.]v*']<[:,>!]v*' <:' >,<:,>!
,['0.]v*1                                    First we take and ignore the first input
                                             character '[', and create an interpreter
                                             for which the default operation is to print
         ['1.]v*']<                          '0'. Next we bind the operation "print '1'"
                                             to the symbol ']' under this interpreter.   
                   [:,>!]v*                  Now we push an operation that takes a symbol
                                             from stdin, extracts the operation associated
                                             with that symbol from the interpreter on the
                                             stack, and executes it.                     
                           ' <               We now bind this operation to the space
                              :' >           character.  Immediately, we extract the
                                             operation back out of the interpreter, and
                                  ,<         bind it to the next symbol from stdin, which
                                             is the first number in the list.  Finally, we
                                    :,>!     manually execute the function once, to begin
                                             the cycle.  Now, the interpreter will continue
                                             to take input until it receives a symbol that
                                             is neither space nor the first number.  The
                                             program will print '1' if that symbol is ']',
                                             otherwise it will print '0'.
```

I wrote a solution in 36 characters, however the input/output format is inconvenient enough that I don't think it qualifies:

```
,[$.]v*1['1.]v*']<[:,$,>!]v*,<:,$,>!
```

It takes strings similar to this:

```
"[2 8 1 6 4 ]"
```

and prints '1' if the items are all equal, and '[' otherwise.

As Mascarpone is character-set-agnostic (provided the set contains the 17 symbols used by the initial interpreter) and only 26 unique characters are needed for this program to succeed (the 17 original instructions, the space character, and the characters 2-9), we require only 5 bits per character.  By this logic, the solutions would be 25 bytes and 22.5 bytes in size, respectively.

Answer (score 1):

## [Desmos](https://desmos.com/calculator), 24 bytes

```
f(l)=(l[2...]-l)^2.total
```

Returns `0` for truthy, and a positive number (not `0`) for falsey.

[Try It On Desmos!](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/iecides3dl)

[Try It On Desmos! - Prettified](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/lsnhyekstd)

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 22 bytes

```python
lambda n:len(set(n))<2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/6fZhvzPycxNyklUSHPKic1T6M4tUQjT1PTxuh/QVFmXolGmka0oY4COorV1OGCyBjpKBjrKJhABcx0FCx1FKAkTAxKm@somEOZJmB9BrGamv8B)

Set function takes all the unique elements of the group only.

Answer (score 1):

## [J](https://www.jsoftware.com), 6 bytes

```
1=#&~.
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70wa8FOJT31NAVbKwV1BR0FAwUrINbVU3AO8nFbWlqSpmuxzNBWWa1OD8K5Ga7JlZqcka-QpmCIDBGCRgrGCiYwrpmCJQTDBWAMcwVzGNMEqMcAYvyCBRAaAA)

Outputs `0` for falsey, and `1` for truth.

### How?

```
1=#&~.
   &    Compose:
  #     The length of
    ~.  The nub (of the input)
1=      Is it equal to one?
```

Answer (score 1):

## Batch, 93 bytes

```
@set i=%1
:l
@if %i:~,1%==%i:~-1% (if %i% gtr 9 (set/ai=%i%/10&goto:l)else echo 1)else echo 0
```

Takes input from the command line as a string of numbers. Outputs `0` for falsey, and `1` for truthy.

Answer (score 1):

## [Nim](http://nim-lang.org/), 28 bytes

```
proc(x:any):any=x.min==x.max
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y8vM/V9QlJ@sUKyRZqUAYmlUWCkUpxZGZ@aVxGpaKSTl5@doKtgqcCmkJmfkK6QpOEQb6iigo1hUaSMdBWMdBRNkUTMdBUsdBSiJIoHMMddRMEfmm4DNMoj9X6wBdVtiXqUmiLCt0MvNzLMFUYkVmv//AwA)

```
import sugar
x=>x.min==x.max
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XUxLCsIwFNz3FLNM4CF@isVAxHuULGppNWDy2qRCbh8/uEiFYb4w3ro8Be4RxajwcSIpxGFurV@MVLgyPyQ0Kgz9nTHi0u4I/zDreU84EOqyPRJOhB@vhjI0hKbM9fdra7J1E4cF8XnrQhVF0ue0cdZr/ZYuyZxf)

Answer (score 1):

## [J-uby](https://github.com/cyoce/J-uby), 15 bytes

Same technique as [Sony Santos](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/224150/11261).

```ruby
:uniq|~:[]&1|:!
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m700K740qXLBIjfbpaUlaboW661K8zILa-qsomPVDGusFCGiN5cUKLhFRxvqKKCj2FgFZQVdO4WQotJULpgiIx0FYx0FE5icW2JOMVTSTEfBUkcBSmKTxzTPXEfBHFPUBGyLAYoRELcuWAChAQ)

### Explanation

```ruby
:uniq |     # Get unique elements
~:[] & 1 |  # Get element at index 1 (will be nil if there is only one unique)
:!          # Negate (number becomes false, nil becomes true)
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Arturo](https://arturo-lang.io), <s>19</s> 15 bytes

```
$->a->[]=a--a\0
```

[Try it](http://arturo-lang.io/playground?PRS5M7)

```
$->a->      ; a function taking an argument a
    []=     ; is the empty block equal to...
    a--a\0  ; the input with the value of its first element removed everywhere?
```

Answer (score 1):

**[T-SQL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-reference?view=sql-server-ver16) 75 bytes**

`declare @x table (y int) insert @x values`...

`select top 1 1 from @x a where not exists (select*from @x b where b.y!=a.y)`

will return 1 for true, nothing for false

Answer (score 1):

## [YASEPL](https://github.com/madeforlosers/YASEPL-esolang/), 45 bytes

```
=a=1'±comma=c®1=d¥0,1`1=e¥a,1}7,d,3!+}2,c`3!<
```

input list as numbers seperated by commas (like `5,16,24,26,29,12,1`)

outputs the list's length if true, outputs the first occurrence of a different number if false