# Longest Sublist with Equal Occurrences

Tags: code-golf, array

Given a non-empty list of integers between 1 and 9 inclusive, find the longest contiguous sublist such that the number of occurrences of each element (of the sublist) within the sublist is equal (*not* the number of consecutive occurrences, just the total count). You may return any non-empty subset of the solutions.

### Examples

```
Input                         ->  Output

1, 2, 3                           [1, 2, 3]
1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4                  [2, 2, 3, 3]
1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 3, 3, 2, 1      [3, 3, 4, 4], [3, 4, 4, 3], [4, 4, 3, 3]
1, 1, 1, 1, 1                     [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
1, 2, 3, 2, 1                     [1, 2, 3], [3, 2, 1]
1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 3                  [1, 2, 3, 4], [3, 4, 4, 3]
3, 2, 3, 4, 4, 3                  [3, 4, 4, 3]
```

- this is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest code in bytes wins
- [Standard Loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) are forbidden, as usual
- I/O may be in any reasonable format. You can do I/O with a string of digits since all inputs will be between 1 and 9, for example (this is mostly to allow regex solutions if anyone can figure that out).

Comment: This question was in the [Sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/22288/68942) (visible to 10k+). Imaginary brownie points for matching/beating my 8-byte Jelly solution.

Answer (score 7):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>8</s> 7 bytes

```
ẆĠẈEƊƇṪ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///hrrYjCx7u6nA91nWs/eHOVf8f7lz8qGFu9MMdix7umP@ocVuYzuF2laOTHu6c8ahpTdajhjkKunYKQBVcD3dvOdwOFIv8/99QR8FIR8FYATeIhiqJ5YIwQGwwMsGiFiEPUw5VC0YQNlDQEKocIRmrA@ZB1YF4CC1goxAIpysRCMlyI3w6jKB2QdUhaYPajkUbkisB)

### How it works

```
ẆĠẈEƊƇṪ - Main link. Takes L on the left
Ẇ       - All non-empty contiguous sublists of L, longest last
    ƊƇ  - Keep those sublists S for which the following is true:
 Ġ      -   Group the indices of S by the elements
  Ẉ     -   Length of each
   E    -   All equal?
      Ṫ - Get the last (i.e. the longest) element
```

Comment: Wow, you're very fast at coding in Jelly!

Comment: also yes this is exactly the solution I had

Comment: @hyper-neutrino i am speed :P

Answer (score 7):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), <sup><s>9 7</s></sup> 5 bytes

```
►ṠË#Q
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7//9G0XQ93LjjcrRz4////aEMdIx1jIDQBQhBtpGMYCwA)

-2 using the return value of `Ë` in max by.

-2 from Leo.

### Explanation

```
►ṠË#Q
    Q all sublists (unsorted)
►     max by:
 ṠË       all elements of the list are equal by: (if all equal, returns len+1)
   #      count of occurrences in in the list
```

Comment: Nice use of maxby! And you can save two more bytes with `Ṡ`: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7//9G0XQ93LjjcrRz4////aEMdIx1jIDQBQhBtpGMYCwA "Husk – Try It Online")

Comment: Should remind myself that combinators also work on higher order function

Answer (score 7):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), <sup><strike>8</strike></sup> 7 bytes

```
⊇.ọtᵛ&s
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/pfXa6koGunoFSu9qhtw6Ompoe7Omsfbp3w/1FXu97D3b0lD7fOViv@/z862lDHSMc4VkcBzAAygdAEwlUw0lEwBiMTMIKwgYKGUHkEQtFghC4A1a4AEjRGE4yNBQA)

`s` generates all sublists of consecutive elements, though not in order of length, but in order of prefix (so `[1,2,3] [1,2] [1] [2,3] [2] [3]`). `⊇` on the other hand does generate longer sets first, but only guarantees element order, not that they are consecutive. So we check that later for +1 byte.

```
⊇.ọtᵛ&s  The (implicit) input                        [1,1,2,3]
⊇        has an (ordered) subset                     [1,2,3]
 .       that is the output,                
  ọ      which elements grouped&counted by identity  [[1,1],[2,1],[3,1]]
   tᵛ    have the same number of occurences.         1
      &  The input                                   [1,1,2,3]
       s has consecutive elements                    [1,2,3]
         that is the (implicit) output.
```

Comment: Before the edit, I was about to say "FWIW, identity should be `≡`, but since every element is a single digit `=` does work too"

Comment: @UnrelatedString yeah, I actually intended to use proper identity, but mix the symbols up sometimes – especially if it doesn't change the output. :-)

Answer (score 7):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 86 bytes

```javascript
f=(h,...t)=>new Set(c=[],h.map(x=>c[x]=-~c[x])).size<3?h:f(...t,h.slice(1),h.pop()&&h)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fU9LDoIwFNx7iq7Ia1JKAFfG4iFcEhakFsEgbSxR4sKrY8GSGlNsJun7zEzmXcp7qfmtUX3YyZMYK2YANaGU9phlnXigo@iBs7wgNb2WCgaW8XwoWPiaPoypbp5inx7qXQWTytB023ABMTalkgpwENR45LLTshW0lWeoII8JSghKke8ZVxRFaOEUG692Ws3Y@rSOsCK32hmf2gzjRe62BZk7S5w6p/FZO6xf5bAeLvnrkNgsS@xfm3SxsWF9Nl9XjW8)

Use Breadth-First Search, so you may avoid comparing its length.

A terrible \$O(n\cdot2^n)\$ time complexity. Luckly we only care about its length.

Codes for checking equal number occurrence is copied from [Arnauld](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/58563/arnauld)'s [answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/225523/44718).

---

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 63 bytes

```python
f=lambda l,*t:l*(len({*map(l.count,l)})<2)or f(*t,l[1:],l[:-1])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fY/LCgIhFIb3PcWBNioW6LSS5kkGF9NlKHB0GGwR0bPbjCmniyU/cm6f/me4@pOzVQhdbdp@d2jBcOaVYcQcLbmxvh2IWe/dxXpu6J1uJXUjdIRNaSOUnm61EpqGYTxbTzrSCA6SQwWloymFJeQRvfiA5mLUpgBh/4tLUNQznooicdjUPGZpbs4QeX8T9XMBVMmO/IfK9Hv2iXyV@WSswL8sEB4)

This Python answer is based on [att](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/81203/att)'s [answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/225564/44718) by applying BFS to it.

Comparing to JS, Python is good at creating sets, function auto bind, get length, array slicing when you are golfing.

Answer (score 5):

## Scala, 84 bytes

```scala
_.tails.flatMap(_.inits)filter(l=>l.map(x=>l.count(_==x)).toSet.size<2)maxBy(_.size)
```

[Try it in Scastie!](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/J0DYmqnhQMaWF6Rz8u2hpg)

```
_.tails                //All suffixes
  .flatMap(_.inits)    //All prefixes of those suffixes (all subsequences)
  filter(l=>           //Keep the ones where
    l.map(x=>l.count(_==x))  //The counts of all the elements
      .toSet.size<2          //Has 0 or 1 distinct elements
  )maxBy(_.size)       //Find the biggest such subsequence
```

Answer (score 5):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 8 bytes

```
ŒʒD¢Ë}éθ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9W@f/opFOTXA4tOtxde3jluR3/df5HRxvqKBjpKBjH6ihAmSAeGJkgxKACYARhAwUNofIIhKLBCF0Aqj02FgA)

```python
Œ          # all sublists of the input
 ʒ   }     # filter by:
   ¢       #   counts of each value
  D        #   in a copy of the sublist
    Ë      #   are all counts equal?
      é    # sort the remaining sublists by length
       θ   # take the last one
```

Alternatively, sort first, reverse and take the first sublist that satisfies the condition:

```
ŒéR.ΔD¢Ë
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9W@f/opMMrg/TOTXE5tOhw9/9anf/R0YY6CkY6CsaxOgpQJogHRiYIMagAGEHYQEFDqDwCoWgwQheAao@NBQA)

Answer (score 5):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) [`-h`](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14339/), 10 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
ã kÈü üÊÊÉ
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&flags=LWg&code=4yBryPwg/MrKyQ&input=WzEsIDIsIDMsIDMsIDQsIDQsIDMsIDMsIDIsIDFdCi1R)

```
ã kÈü üÊÊÉ     :Implicit input of array
ã              :Subsections (sorted by length)
  k            :Remove elements that return falsey (0)
   È           :When passed through the following function
    ü          :  Group by value
      ü        :  Group by
       Ê       :    Length
        Ê      :  Length
         É     :  Minus 1
               :Implicit output of last element in resulting array
```

Answer (score 5):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 73 bytes

```python
f=lambda l:l*(len({*map(l.count,l)})<2)or max(f(l[1:]),f(l[:-1]),key=len)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hY7BToQwEIbPy1P0smlnt0ss9UTkSQiHqpBtHNoGuurG@OxY2JqSKNr8h3863z8z7urP1shp6ipU/eOzIljigWFr2MehV45h/mQvxnOET3gowA6kV@@sY1iLsgE@m/Ikgntpr1WIwfR21tgSUWY7zS2piDbu4hnko0PtGSWEcgHZzg3ahHJ/knKke82DK@6C61j7qpDRmh71kTYUgNscRz9oxwAmwUnBiSTbr45Ik93M7Bfd/8Km/jce2UU3Hz5FxFOz4UsVublKkWVU0uaVSavlxV@JIu6K3CoWt2/Hft6cyf/DK/wL)

Answer (score 4):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>9</s> 8 bytes

```
ŒʒD¢Ë}éθ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//6KRTk1wOLTrcXXt45bkd//9HG@ooGOkoGIORCRhB2EBBw1gA)

```
Œ     all sublists
ʒ     keep those such that
D     duplicate
¢     count, vectorizes
Ë     all equal
}
é     sort by length
θ     last
```

Comment: two identical osabie answers

Comment: @Razetime this was actually created before the other one

Comment: @ophact I think I had the 8 bytes a few seconds earlier, but it is fine to keep both answers.

Answer (score 4):

## JavaScript (ES6), 108 bytes

Returns the rightmost solution.

```javascript
a=>a.map((_,n)=>a.map((_,i)=>(b=a.slice(i,i-~n))[new Set(b.map(x=>c[x]=-~c[x],c=[])&&c).size-2+n]?o=b:0))&&o
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fU9RD4IgGHzvV/DkYKGm9tSG/YgeHWtI2GgGLl25HvzrpobDNYzdBvd9d7fjxp6s5g9ZNb7SF9EXpGckZcGdVRCesUILIgcCc8KCupRcQIml3ymEMiVe4CQamE/ClqQ8aynxu/HCnGQUeR5HQS3fwo@3ih41yQ87NEx1z7WqdSmCUl9hAbMIgxiDBLgORQiEIZg1dOP0jqsJe5fXClbsxjvh@x6G0Wy3W4onZoQjsx5XtMX6ryzWy8V/E2LTZa79G5PMMaasK2bxq/4D)

#### Commented

```javascript
a =>                       // a[] = input array
  a.map((_, n) =>          // for n = 0 to len(a) - 1:
    a.map((_, i) =>        //   for i = 0 to len(a) - 1:
      ( b =                //     define b[] as the sub-array of length
        a.slice(i, i - ~n) //     at most n + 1 starting at index i
      )[                   //
        new Set(           //     build a set consisting of the number of
          b.map(x =>       //     occurrences of each distinct entry in b[],
            c[x] = -~c[x], //     using another array c[] to keep track of
            c = []         //     these counts
          )                //     the set will always include 'undefined'
                           //     because c[0] is never updated
          && c             //
        ).size             //     which is why we expect its size to be 2
        - 2 + n            //     make sure that b[new Set().size - 2 + n]
      ]                    //     is defined (i.e. b[] is long enough and
                           //     the number of occurrences are all equal)
      ?                    //     if so:
        o = b              //       update the output
      :                    //     else:
        0                  //       do nothing
    )                      //   end of inner map()
  )                        // end of outer map()
  && o                     // return o
```

Comment: `new Set(c=[],b.map(x=>c[x]=-~c[x]))`

Answer (score 4):

## [Python 3.8 (pre-release)](https://docs.python.org/3.8/), 104 bytes

```python
lambda x:max((a for i in range(len(x)+1)for j in range(i)if len({*map((a:=x[j:i]).count,a)})<2),key=len)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RYzLDsIgEEX3fsUsGSVNLC4MkS@pXYwKSi2PEExojN@O1I3JzV2c@4hLfgQvjjHVogbBoefQ/PCTGDdGnetM7nIjKNJRYYzAhAQWrIdE/q7ZrD0ruNvjyqc/t2gNrOF76yi2oVRlmKQdsbuGl8@c8IOnHvlTL6r1sMZkfWamvWH9Ag)

-1 thanks to @ophact

-24 thanks to @pxeger

-10 thanks to @hyper-neutrino

Comment: Seems like `<2` works instead of `==1`? I'm not as proficient in python compared to js though.

Comment: @ophact yes! thx!!

Comment: `dict(...)` can be `{**...}`. But it's actually shorter counting manually: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RYzBCsIwEETvfsUesxiENh6k2C@pPaya6NY2CaFCivjtMWkPwpzevBm/zE9n1cmHFNuuklBLUBKOa1S/M@0ljTRd7wSxmSgKEbuh4d64AAxsIZB9aDFqKyLuKyx8@HNGNlDKzzY73NzbzoJWj4q38S@ea5QvvbRZxuQDZ8vkS0w/ "Python 3.8 (pre-release) – Try It Online")

Comment: -5 on pxeger's if you [map with `x[i:j].count`](https://tio.run/##RYxNCsIwEIX3nmKWGQ1CjAsp5CS1i6iJTm0nIURIEc8eWxWEt3nf@4lTvgXWh5hqMa2SsJOgJew/0t3Km2Md7Hi6WCjNaIsQpe0b6nxIQEAMyfLVicGxKLhRuPD@zwnJwxI@16ONv@32HB6c5dfgC41RKO9uMnMRa0zEWfj5Dusb)

Comment: Actually a `Counter` already has a `.values()` method because it's a subclass of `dict`, so the `{**...}` is unnecessary (not that it matters any more)

Comment: Aha! thanks to all of you!!

Comment: -5 using walrus and bring ophact's `<2` back: https://tio.run/##RYzLDsIgEEX3fsUsGSVNLC4MkS@pXYwKSi2PEExojN@O1I3JzV2c@4hLfgQvjjHVogbBoefQ/PCTGDdGnetM7nIjKNJRYYzAhAQWrIdE/q7ZrD0ruNvjyqc/t2gNrOF76yi2oVRlmKQdsbuGl8@c8IOnHvlTL6r1sMZkfWamvWH9Ag

Comment: [-1 byte](https://tio.run/##RYrLCsIwEEX3fkWWMzUUbF1IMF9Suxg10dTmQYiQIn57DNkIl7s454QtPb0bTyGWLKeRs4Gz@se2cd5peSkr2eudWBaWMgCQkHlahJmxg1U5@HSWAlB/82@XOOEXzwNqH5lhxrFI7qFal3F/aHz5c4PIX2qT1WMJ0bgEuoZYfg).

Answer (score 4):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>104</s> <s>98</s> <s>96</s> 95 bytes

```r
function(L,n=seq(!L)){for(i in n)for(j in n)if(!sd(table(a<-L[i:j])+!1:2)&sum(T|1)<j-i+2)T=a;T}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bYyxDoIwFEV3v4Iu5r1QhhYnpH/Qkc04INLkNVoChUn99qqlDhqTM5zce3OnYFQwi@tmGhxo7pTvR2Aa8WaGCSgjlzl8q12VDDB/hrk9XXpo60IfqLJHzJmoJG79coXmLrC2BeUSG9Xum0cw0IHgkpeIm9UzGSkju684ZZHVX6H4naT@z2G6SI3k8mOI4Qk)

Ugly straightforward approach. Can't wait for a nice [R](https://www.r-project.org/) solution!

*-6 bytes thanks to [@Dominic](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/95126/dominic-van-essen)*
*-1 byte thanks to [@Giuseppe](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/67312/giuseppe)*

Comment: [98 bytes](https://tio.run/##XYuxDoIwFEV3v6Is5t3YDhQnhT/oyGYcKtKkREugZVK/vWLBQZMznJz73hhNFc3kmmB7R4q7yrcDZQp4mH4ky6xjDh/tFrWGMn@lhkIpgr7cWtKlUCd76M7gAdj66U71M0fZCbuTqCt9rF/RzB85l7wANoszmSgS@5@8tsTic8z/T9Z9zZLLrwHxDQ)...?

Comment: The ```+0*1:2``` trick is *very* clever - and you could [re-use it](https://tio.run/##K/r/vzhFozg5MU9DU9tAy9DKSPO/oYKhgtF/AA) for the ['are the items all the same'](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/224000/95126) challenge...

Comment: Use `!1:2` instead of `0*1:2` to save a byte.

Answer (score 3):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 92 bytes

```hs
last.sortOn l.filter((<2).l.nub.map l.group.sort).(>>=tails).inits
l=length
import Data.List
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hY5NboMwEIX3PoWFKsUW4CqkqxSz6qZSpB6AsjCJIVYHY2Hn@qX8uIKqpbFmMfPme35zFfZDAvSqMW3n8Itwgp2Udaji7z0I65gd9DeNgVUKnOwISRPKgOlbyRphBr3u2puZMMpIlnEnFFjKlFbOIuAgde2uKI5/BvSNUJpfWoSJilqaxtYITR75Lt/R9CGrpTspLREG6bDgnRQXEuRBGKowDIqAPpcrrZ01hE2ntCMSZEMqLCgpj8c8f9WuKGg0CgiPqf0@wkmED3j75R4p0NyM/VRPf7DL/hv37FRzP4h7jy/LIpomz43TYpm@WmrzyqVW4cl/jsRneW5l8@nbtt83o8N98wr/PFcgatvHZ2O@AA)

Either Haskell is *not* the language for this challenge, or I'm not the Haskeller for this challenge<sup>1</sup>.

---

<sup>1</sup> Yup, I know, it's the latter.

Answer (score 3):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), <sup>38</sup> 33 bytes

```
0{(1=&#[:=#/.~)\\.(\:#&>)@#&,<\\.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/qvpKeepmBrpaCuoKNgoGAFxLp6Cs5BPm7/Dao1DG3VlKOtbJX19eo0Y2L0NGKslNXsNB2U1XRsgNz/mlypyRn5CgppCoY6CkZgZAxGJhAJoLiCkYIxnIOsAowgbKCgIUIDFGJoAqlSUMAQhhoElzBGl1D4DwA)

<sup>-5 thanks to xash!</sup>

Comment: With monadic `=` and double `\\.` for less boxing: [33b](https://tio.run/##y/qvpKeepmBrpaCuoKNgoGAFxLp6Cs5BPm7/Dao1DG3VlKOtbJX19eo0Y2L0NGKslNXsNB2U1XRsgNz/mlypyRn5CgppCoY6CkZgZAxGJhAJoLiCkYIxnIOsAowgbKCgIUIDFGJoAqlSUMAQhhoElzBGl1D4DwA "J – Try It Online")

Comment: Very nice.  Thanks @xash.

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript, 122 bytes

```js
f=(n,p=t=n.length)=>n.find((e,i)=>i+p<=t&(l=n.slice(i,i+p)).every(x=>(z=m=>l.filter(w=>w==m).length)(x)==z(e)))?l:f(n,p-1)
```

One must marvel at the sheer length of counting the number of occurrences in a list.

A recursive function which checks all lists of length `p` for one satisfying the OP's conditions, and if there exists one, return it, otherwise return `f(n,p-1)`

Suggestions are welcome for golfing.

Comment: Just a minor golf, but you can use `w-m` instead of `w==m` (counting the number of occurrences of `not m` eventually leads to the same results).

Comment: You can save another byte by using `!some(...X-Y...)` instead of `every(...X==Y...)`.

Comment: @Arnauld I understand your first suggestion, but I'm not sure why your second saves another. Is it not just the same number of bytes as the first one?

Comment: `!some` is just as long as `every`, but `-` is shorter than `==`.

Answer (score 2):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/), <s>63</s> <s>58</s> 56 bytes

```
[ all-subseqs [ histogram values all-eq? ] filter last ]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dZFNT8MwDIbv/RUv91JpSU9w4Ii47II4VT2EKusipR@LXQSa8ttLmhat3YZjyXbyvLElH1TFnRs/3t/2r08gfRp0W2nK9Dc7RWgUHzNixYbYVARF1IVQu27oTVtfBOidZv7pnWkZz0lyThDsjB0EJDy29oBil0KkkOWKm0iJfEUHTszcFTqDeYwi3PgJlZHLg5dprPLocqqWdPPN3/E3k11821TcpcXSQ8b0SjJP6e9IbudchPI/4Rr1YwFl7SMNn2EJhALHsKOudqrBl7JDWMn0rE8vKHEwlrWDVcQox0b1yMZf)

```
              [                          ] filter last   ! Select the last/largest..
  all-subseqs                                            ! ..subsequence..
                histogram values                         ! ..whose elements occur..
                                 all-eq?                 ! ..the same number of times.
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 44 bytes

```
Last@*Select[Equal@@Counts@#&]@*Subsequences
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hY69CoMwFIX3PIUgOJR0MLq2BEq3DgVHyZCGSAWbYk0m0Ve3@ZMEWlvvhZyT@x1vHlTe@YPKltGlOSwXOki8q3jHmazPvaIdxqenEnLAaUb0RN0G3isuGB@W66sVsk73xwanJJsrRsU8gjGHCBYTdEJLXeVqrdFlTgRzd@0rMCg2Fje2iCyYlhwmCCZFsv3VHiHACaNtl1/YMF9xz9p2Wl/mHg9DAq3znHEhYn8VevOVoaPl6FcC@V2ei2J@@3bs882g@B@O8Dc)

Get all subsequences (ordered), select the ones with equal occurrences, take the last of those.

Answer (score 2):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language), 71 bytes

```
Lw`.+
%(`$
¶$`
1%O`.
1%L$`(.)\1*
$.&
)L$`^(.+)(¶.+)\2*$
$1
N^$`
$.&
0G`
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYyxDcJQDET7m8Mf@SeShe3sQBPBAlFkCgoaCoTEZhkgi/3454p38ll339fv/XlqK3yLNv9DRhQOwr5RQMsjJDlTsNRFB5BcUPNcWcbK@5ZcbCCQ4r5mo/@vudTUHGrmPqUlJ3dTaFcP7GSm8NMO) Link includes test cases. Takes input as a string of digits. Explanation:

```
Lw`.+
```

Get all substrings of the input.

```
%(`
)`
```

Loop over each substring.

```
$
¶$`
```

Duplicate the substring.

```
1%O`.
```

Sort the duplicate into order.

```
1%L$`(.)\1*
$.&
```

Get the run lengths.

```
L$`^(.+)(¶.+)\2*$
$1
```

If the run lengths are equal, then keep the substring, otherwise keep nothing.

```
N^$`
$.&
```

Sort all of the remaining substrings in descending order of length.

```
0G`
```

Keep only the longest remaining substring.

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>140</s> 132 bytes

-8 bytes thanks to @hyper-neutrino for space saving and replacing `def` with `lambda`!

I was using python3 to code until I found that it works for Python2 too, not too much, just an iterative solution.

```python
lambda n:max([r for r in [n[i:a]for a in range(len(n)+1)for i in range(len(n))if a-i>1]if len(set(r.count(s)for s in r))<2],key=len)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY3BDsIgEER/ZY9srCagp8b6I5TDqlSJ7dIAJu3XI3A0mcPMy0xm3dPbs8rbMOaZlvuTgPuFNqEDTD5AAMegWbueTM1UcyB@WTFbFowHiZW7f45uAjq6mzTFVBRtEuH08F9OIrZNbBvEqzLdx@5DaWFegyuF8i87UE3npotBzD8)

Comment: You only use `l` twice, so it's better to make this a lambda and just put `len(n)` in twice. Also, you have two extra spaces. https://tio.run/##XY3BDsIgEER/ZY9srCagp8b6I5TDqlSJ7dIAJu3XI3A0mcPMy0xm3dPbs8rbMOaZlvuTgPuFNqEDTD5AAMegWbueTM1UcyB@WTFbFowHiZW7f45uAjq6mzTFVBRtEuH08F9OIrZNbBvEqzLdx@5DaWFegyuF8i87UE3npotBzD8

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 40 bytes

```
ＦＥθ✂θκＦＥι…ι⊕λＦ⁼⌊Ｅκ№κλ⌈Ｅκ№κλ⊞υκΦυ⁼Ｌι⌈ＥυＬλ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dY5BCsIwEEX3niLLBOpC212XRUGwUPAEIY5m6DSxaSJ6@pjU0oXgbmbe/49RWjplJcV4s47xVj74WLALoYI89EIIthIsWPNWBI2283IyysEAxsOVk1ijhzFImniLBocwzM0@NW0wPg85WbBWvv7SJOrCpHnID9SbzmFiRyQPLt8W/xnM3WuOP7IUWMhXJeoYd/uyqsq4fdIH) Link is to verbose version of code. Takes input as a string of digits and outputs all maximal length substrings with the given condition. Explanation:

```
ＦＥθ✂θκ
```

Loop over all nontrivial suffixes of the input.

```
ＦＥι…ι⊕λ
```

Loop over all nontrivial prefixes of the suffix.

```
Ｆ⁼⌊Ｅκ№κλ⌈Ｅκ№κλ
```

Take the frequencies of the elements and check whether they are all the same.

```
⊞υκ
```

Record all substrings that satisfy the condition.

```
Φυ⁼Ｌι⌈ＥυＬλ
```

Output the longest such substrings.

Answer (score 1):

## [yuno (abandoned)](https://github.com/hyper-neutrino/yuno-abandoned/), 7 [bytes](https://github.com/hyper-neutrino/yuno-abandoned/wiki/Byte-count)

```
ッシュフェドゥッキッカ；テ
```

xxd using Jelly's codepage:

```
00000000: 87a0 9a6d 6bfe 0b                        ⁷ɦȤmk“¿
```

Disclaimer: some language features were added after this challenge. However, they weren't really made to be tailored to this challenge, all of these are things I'd planned previously. If I really wanted to, I could've reasonably made built-ins much more suited ot this challenge, but I have those on my wishlist right now as they're a lot more specific.

```
ッシュフェドゥッキッカ；テ   Full Program
ッシュ　　　　　　　　　　   All sublists, in increasing order of length then position
　　　フェ　　　　　　；　   Filter-lambda; keep elements that:
　　　　　ドゥ　　　　　　   (duplicate top of stack)
　　　　　　　ッキ　　　　   special count; if counting occurrences of a list that is not found, but any of its elements are, vectorize (recurses)
　　　　　　　　　ッカ　　   all-equal?
　　　　　　　　　　　　テ   last element
```

Comment: So, it is a code page which render a single byte to multiple katakana?

Comment: @tsh yes, that's how it works. i will admit it's a bit weird and maybe wasn't the best idea :P

Answer (score 1):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 69 bytes

```ruby
->r,*w{r,*w=w<<r[0..-2]<<r[1..-1]while r.map{|x|r.count x}.uniq[1];r}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZvtf165IR6u8GkTYltvYFEUb6OnpGsWCWIZAlmFseUZmTqpCkV5uYkF1TUVNkV5yfmleiUJFrV5pXmZhtGGsdVHt/wKFtOhoQx0FIzAyBiOT2Nj/AA)

Answer (score 0):

## Python 3.8, 98 bytes

Another not-very-successful python3 attempt

```python
f=lambda l,i=0:(a:=l[i%(L:=len(l)):][:L-i//L])*(i%L<=i//L)*(len({*map(a.count,a)})<2)or f(l,i+1)
```

a less condensed version

```python
def f(l, i=0):
 L = len(l)
 a = l[i%L:][:L-i//L]
 return a * (i%L<=i//L) * (len({*map(a.count,a)})<2) or f(l,i+1)
```