# Is this a Permutation of 1..n

Tags: code-golf, array, decision-problem, integer, permutations

Input a non-empty array with \$n\$ positive integers. Test if the input array contains every integer in \$1\cdots n\$.

In case you prefer 0-indexed numbers, you may choose to input an array of non-negative integers, and test if the input array contains every integer in \$0\cdots (n-1)\$ instead. All testcases and formula listed below use 1-index. You may need to adjust them if you choose this option.

### Input / Output

Input is an array \$A\$ with \$n\$ positive integers:

$$ A = \left[A_1,\dots,A_n\right] $$
$$ \forall i \in \left[1,\dots,n\right]: A_i>0 $$

Output if input \$A\$ satisfies:

$$ \forall i \in \left[1,\dots,n\right]: i \in A $$

Output would be two distinct values, or truthy vs falsy values (swap meaning of truthy / falsy is allowed).

### Rules

- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), shortest code wins. And since this is code-golf, don't worry about time / memory complexity of your code. You may even timeout on TIO as long as your program works when giving it more time to run.

### Testcases

#### Truthy

```
1
1,2
2,1
1,3,2
3,1,2
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12
12,11,10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1
6,3,8,12,1,10,4,2,7,9,5,11
16,37,14,15,23,8,29,35,21,6,5,34,38,9,36,26,24,32,28,7,20,33,39,12,30,27,40,22,11,41,42,1,10,19,2,25,17,13,3,18,31,4
```

#### Falsy

```
2
12
1,1
1,3
2,3
3,3
2,1,3,2
1,4,3,1
4,1,2,4
1,2,2,5,5
1,3,3,3,5
8,7,5,3,4,1,6
5,7,1,4,6,1,8,3
6,3,5,4,7,1,8,1,2
6,5,3,8,2,7,9,4
1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1
1,5,9,13,11,7,3
14,6,12,4,10,8,16,2
34,33,38,17,35,11,36,31,28,14,6,15,18,2,19,40,29,41,9,1,27,23,20,32,26,25,37,8,13,30,39,7,5,3,21,4,11,16,10,22,12,24
38,27,20,23,31,6,2,24,21,31,33,7,26,12,14,17,3,2,28,31,5,23,28,27,37,32,7,39,22,6,35,42,19,3,35,17,35,40,22,13,27,7
```

Comment: is empty list falsy?

Comment: @Razetime IMO, empty list should be truthy. But anyway, empty list is excluded from testcases, and it is undefined behavior to your program.

Comment: How do you feel about restricting to n<10? It would make the elements to check finite and all single digit. And *that* would allow lots of wacky tarpits to solve it and not require as high a computational class! I think the spirit would still be preserved, and I can’t think of any way it could be used to hardcode or “cheat” that wouldn’t just be longer than doing it “right,” for the languages that can do it.

Comment: @AviFS If your language doesn't support decimal number I/O, you can use character value I/O. If it doesn't support that either, you can take it in binary or unary. Computational class is not a problem; taking lots of time or memory is allowed by default (even if it can't be run to completion realistically on any machine). You're even allowed to handwave the inputs exceeding the limit of the built-in integer representation. So I don't see any extra benefit of restricting the input size to <10.

Comment: Would outputting `0` for one result or any other integer for the other be acceptable?

Comment: @Shaggy Truthy/falsey output is allowed, so as long as your language treats 0 as falsey and other integers as truthy--or vice versa!--then yes.

Comment: Can we assume the array contains only strictly positive numbers for 1-indexed (instead of just positive numbers)?

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire Positive means n>0. Non-negative means n>=0.

Comment: @tsh Well, [using only "positive" is always kind of ambiguous](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strict), so I prefer to be on the safe side, but thanks for clarifying. Especially since you use "non-negative" later on in the challenge.

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire The consensus on Code Golf, at least, seems to be that [positive means \$> 0\$](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14856).

Answer (score 16):

## [Risky](https://github.com/Radvylf/risky), <s>7 bytes</s> 7 bytes and a palindrome

```
1_??!0:0!??_1
```

[Try it online!](https://radvylf.github.io/risky?p=WyIxXz8_ITA6MCE_P18xIiwiW1s2LDMsOCwwLDEsMTAsNCwyLDcsOSw1LDExXV0iLDBd)

### Explanation

```
1   sort
_
?         input
?     filter by
!       factorial
0         0
: =
0   range
!       length
?         input
?     find first number such that
_
1         1
```

Answer (score 15):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 7 bytes

```
-:/:@/:
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VVHLasNADLznK0wvoSAnXmkf9tJCoNBTT/2IBPr/d2dm1jmUOItWK81oRn/722U636fPPp1tWqaO/3yZvn5/vve5X/vt2vf304Pv91v/6PtjsoR7MsfpRxy6hY0sTmSyFavWbLXN0mIpWdKjK1yQXfFaUZXZL6SKaDWWsCIj21BX0MFOvDZL2VIxZ51vFgiTQAIopIpqjg83NyeDLxZhsRE2FvNmGaemyPgOrrSBzMEEBlRbWi3weprnGdSSdcz/kiz5IdkjftmQJIhVmYYAZFjimLIg5lBFBmFy3Avu7Kk4V2HRBtrSlBmmSiNFy5KB@e@nTKHZQW1NSEmwTq6FUHUsKsuSlWqD7tI1yIVfo6FQv9MUerXRqI1zNBpPQ10mFy5klWELHR66nGK440pSOo1qDgxC1z4AEtwa8yzHBfM0YnL3WXOZ9hfURFL1gi5oALiAWzl81pghHVJzbDdY354)

Ninja'd by hyper-neutrino :(

Takes zero-based input. Applying Grade Up twice to a vector gives a "ranking" of each element, so that 0 is the smallest, 1 is the next smallest, ... up to n-1, breaking ties by giving a smaller number to the one appearing first. A vector is a permutation if and only if the ranking is identical to itself.

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 7 bytes

```
2|C.!.2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VVHLasRADLv3K9JeloITMva8ElooLPTUUz9iF/oN/fdU0mQPZbODx2NLlvxzvCzT5Ta979PFpnXa8Z@X6fr99Xn473V5Xvx4fbrz/faxv@3HfbKEezLH6WccuoWNLE5kshWr1qzbZmm1lCzp0RWuyHa8VlRl9gupIurGElZkZBvqCjrYiddmKVsq5qzzzQJhEkgAhVRRzfHh5uZk8NUiLDbCxmreLOPUFBnfyZU2kDmYwIBqS90Cr0/zPINass75H5IlPyR7xA8bkgSxKtMQgAxLHFMWxByqyCBMjnvBnT0VZxcWbaAtTZlhqjRStCwZmP9@yhSaHdTWhJQE6@RaCVXHorIs6VQbdJeuQS78Gg2F@p2m0KuNRm2co9F4GuoyuXAhXYatdHjocorhjitJ6TSqOTAIXfsASHBrzLMcF8zTiMndZ81l2l9QE0nVC7qgAeACbuXwWWOGdEjNud1gffsD)

Takes zero-based input. `C.!.2` is a built-in for "cycle parity". It gives 1 if a permutation has even number of swaps, -1 if odd, and 0 if not a valid permutation. I take it modulo 2 to convert all nonzero results to 1 (the only truthy value in J).

<s>Even if [error/non-error output](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11908/78410) were allowed, it is too bad that permutation-related built-ins `A.` and `C.` don't error on all possible non-permutations.</s>

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 7 bytes

```
#\-:/:~
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VVG7bgMxDNvzFUY7BAV0qS35cXdApwKdOnXunAD9iP76laSTocjFkGWJFKmf4@mSztf0tqezpZx2/JdLev/6/Diev5f9df89Xk43vl@PW7KCuJjj9HscuoXNLE5kqjXrNmy1zUq2Uqzo0RVmZFe8dlRV9gupI1qNJayoyA7UNXSwE6/DSrXSzFnnmwXCIpAACqmim@PDzc3J4NkiLDbCRjYfVnFqiorvzlU2kDmYwIBqK6sFXk/LsoBasu7zPyRLfkj2jB82FAliVaUhAJmWOKZsiDlUk0GYHPeGO3s6zlVYtIG2DGWmqdJI0bJkYv77KdNodlDbEFIRrJMrE6rPRVVZslJt0F26BrnwazY06neaQq82GrVxjkHjaajL5MaFrDIs0@GpyymGO@4kpdOo5sAgdO0DIMGtMc9yXDDPICZ3XzWXaX9BTSRVL@iCBoALuJ3DV40Z0iE19@0G68cf)

Takes one-based input. `#\` is a golfing trick for getting 1..n, which is compared to the sorted array `/:~` of the original.

---

If output by erroring/non-erroring is allowed:

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 3 bytes

```
C.~
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VVHLasNADLznK0wvoSAbr7QvmxYKgZ566kck0I/or7szs86hxFm0WmlGM/o5Xpbpep/e9@lq0zrt@M/LdPv@@jxuy@/xennw7f6xv@3HY7KEezLH6WccuoWNLE5kshWr1qzbZmm1lCzp0RWuyHa8VlRl9gupIurGElZkZBvqCjrYiddmKVsq5qzzzQJhEkgAhVRRzfHh5uZk8NUiLDbCxmreLOPUFBnfyZU2kDmYwIBqS90Cr5d5nkEtWef8T8mSH5I94qcNSYJYlWkIQIYljikLYg5VZBAmx73gzp6KswuLNtCWpswwVRopWpYMzH8/ZQrNDmprQkqCdXKthKpjUVmWdKoNukvXIBd@jYZC/U5T6NVGozbO0Wg8DXWZXLiQLsNWOjx0OcVwx5WkdBrVHBiErn0AJLg15lmOC@ZpxOTus@Yy7S@oiaTqBV3QAHABt3L4rDFDOqTm3G6wvv0B)

Takes zero-based input. Abuses dyadic form of `C.`, whose left argument must strictly be a permutation. It throws an `index error` otherwise.

Answer (score 13):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 5 bytes

```apl
⊢≡⍋∘⍋
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VZJNSgNBEIX3OUVdQJiu6r9Zu9Gt8QIBiZuAbl0LQRMSdCG41Qu48QQepS8yvlc9ESRDU11df@@rrO43ZzcPq83d7TS13Wd7/miHfXt6xzmt2/alHY5t9/jzZW372o5vy6tznNcXl8tpLUHa4VvCgpbi1Nk2v9nsxQk7SpIsRaqMEgYJQYI/qpsDvBWvGVGR@V4pw6oewogIb0FcQgYz8VokRAlJlHE6isEMXsRQha0si@LDTUXZQQcxExtZ1gbRIhGnTxHxzb3CiGaKTuhgVFLF8Lo4adY/q6s4CXcI5uK7fYIRXBajogOJMxjFrAk2R0uOCfPjnnBnTsZZvRZhEE5xT0frSindwfSa/37uSURuVFi8UvCyyl4DS@W@ruhgKjUbGZMdRINaT0ikoERDYiNxjZyjED@xqqNOXEt1bAM5d11KMdx0ZlPyRjQHRkP1raCIcXf0MxwXzFNYk/@A6HOJb9GoiU09F@2MANALdTOHjz6muQ5XM@/YGF9@AQ)

-4 bytes thanks to Bubbler by turning this into a train and via using `⍵≡` to match the whole array instead of `∧/⍵=` to match element-wise and then reduce by AND.

```apl
⊢≡⍋∘⍋    Train
 ≡         Check equality between
⊢         (Right argument ⍵) and
  ⍋∘⍋    Composed function {⍋⍋⍵}; grade up twice
```

Grading up twice gives the minimum permutation of length X that has the same (non-strict) ordering as the original - so, if the permutation of the right order is the same as the original, then the original was that permutation and thus a permutation.

Comment: You can delete `∧/` and change `=` (element-wise equals) to `≡` (entire array match). The train version is `⊢≡⍋∘⍋`.

Comment: @Bubbler Ah, I should've looked for that built-in instead of using `∧/=` :P thanks!

Comment: May I use this for APLcart? (This entails relinquishing all rights to the code.)

Comment: @Adám Sure, that's cool with me and I checked with Bubbler too :)

Answer (score 12):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 31 bytes

Input is \$ 0 \$-indexed.

```python
lambda a:{*a}=={*range(len(a))}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VVFBbtswELzzFbxFCraFlkuKUgC/JO1BRe1GgKIIjoomCPJ2d2adHALLJJcczuwMt9f94Wm1y@nw47JMj79@T3G6e7ud3g@Ht9vztP45Nstxbaa2fb/8e5iXY9S7EOd1i4e4zM978zhtzbzuwr2/e9N@f96WeW9u5KZt20/k/Uv8FjWens7xBVvc/RnidsbF5oTrW9teNKikkISzYWXCGn9UWYr0UmWQUbQTVVEcJV902Btw1gOTeRMMPeZBCOB5xl4FqgAfFGdVNIsWSUSlUQxLdQIDA0Wsl4QPVZJE9tSJmdhIUuskVckYvYOM70NJR0gl6EABaNFBDKeBzcKKW4NFgznOV6PqbWvINAwwx4ReSqBwcfvoLhRUxPYYwesmabl6zbDcAS25XTJ9@aEuDNDYdQWDOlkif0eKnrFnNzrQgzExZgETSOEKL3SVaJUJjLQ/Ur0yTsaUPLrCmAePoWNuVyeJBvhqPSWZH9A5QC55xqAwvgR3CUaBbioZ@ZrZuxJ/E6MbSvpdiBltQwmsPVvP3qS5C/fy8WJGfP0P)

This is the most obvious implementation I could think of. It compares the set of \$ a \$ to the set of numbers from `0` to `len(a)-1`.

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 30 bytes

As [@ovs](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/64121/ovs) suggested, we can save a byte by switching the definition of truthy and falsey. A valid permutation returns a falsey value, and truthy otherwise.

```python
lambda a:{*a}^{*range(len(a))}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VVHRTtwwEHz3V/iNBC0o67XjBIkvaamUqnclUgjREVQqxLcfM3v0obqc7bXHMzvj7e/@@Lza@Xj//bxMTz9/TXG6e7@ePn68X5@m9fehWQ5rM7Xtx/nP47wcot6FOK9bvI/L/LI3T9PWzOsu3Hvdm/b2ZVvmvbmSq7Zt/yG/vcWbqPH4fIpv2OLuQ4jbCRebI65vbXvWoJJCEs6GlQlr/FFlKdJLlUFG0U5URXGUfNFhb8BZD0zmTTD0mAchgOcZexWoAnxQnFXRLFokEZVGMSzVCQwMFLFeEj5USRLZUydmYiNJrZNUJWP0DjK@LyUdIZWgAwWgRQcxnAY2CytuDRYN5jhfjKq3rSHTMMAcE3opgcLF7aO7UFAR22MEr5uk5eo1w3IHtOR2yfTfD3VhgMauKxjUyRL5O1L0jD270YEejIkxC5hAChd4oatEq0xgpP2R6pVxMqbk0RXGPHgMHXO7OEk0wFfrKcn8gM4BcskzBoXxJbhLMAp0U8nI18zelfibGN1Q0u9CzGgbSmDt2Xr2Js1duJevFzPi6yc)

Comment: If you swap truthy and falsy outputs (as allowed in the post), the `==` can be a `^`.

Comment: This answer is old, but I am pretty sure this would fail for many inputs with duplicated values, e.g `[1,2,1]`

Comment: @des54321 It does? I think it correctly identifies `[1,2,1]` as `False`.

Comment: @dingledooper never mind actually, youre correct, my mental analysis missed that the `len(a)` bit handled checking for non-unique values in the input

Answer (score 12):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/) (1 indexed), 29 bytes

*Courtesy of AZTECCO*

```hs
g l=all(`elem`l)[1..length l]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/P10hxzYxJ0cjITUnNTchRzPaUE8vJzUvvSRDISf2fxpQNl0lN7FAI6ZC165C21Azhys3MTPPNiWfS0GhoCgzr0QlLdowFpmjY4DMNdAx0jHWMdExRBU0BEKgBLpKDHUm2ASNsQlDrDGN/Q8A)

## Haskell (0 indexed), <s>42</s> <s>32</s> 31 bytes

*Lynn saved one byte with the pointfree solution.*

```hs
all.(.fst).flip elem<*>zip[0..]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/P802MSdHT0MvrbhEUy8tJ7NAITUnNddGy64qsyDaQE8v9n9uYmaebUo@l4JCQVFmXolKWrRBLBLHUAeFa6BjpGOsY6JjiCpoCIRACXSVGOpMsAkaYxOGWGMa@x8A)

I tried a bunch of creative stuff with scans, folds and zips, but the boring solution ended up being the shortest.

Both of these check that every integer in the available range is in the list.  The first is `1` to the length of the list, the second is `0` to 1 less than the length of the list.

Comment: There's a shorter solution without import :)

Comment: @xnor Ah indeed.  And much shorter.

Comment: With sorting, this pointfree saves a byte, using flipped output: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/PzO3IL@oRMElsSRRzyezuIQrzTa/SK8qsyA8syRDQ99WM9pQTy9Wrxio6H9uYmaebUo@l4JCQVFmXolKWrSRjrGOiY5hLJKQoY6hDlA4FkUVmhoTHYjQfwA "Haskell – Try It Online")

Comment: Nevermind, my 29 byte solution doesn't work when I duplicate the largest element.  Don't have much idea. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/P02hwja6uDQ32rCmwEa3QqfApjS2phTIirW1rfifm5iZZ5uSz6WgUFCUmVeikhZtoGOkY6xjomMYiyJoCIRAiVg0lRjqTLAJGsOF/wMA "Haskell – Try It Online")

Comment: @xnor I don't know if this is your solution, but it is dead simple and I'm embarrassed I didn't encounter it earlier.  Thanks for giving me the motivation to spend far too much time on this.

Comment: Looks like `all.(.fst).flip elem<*>zip[0..]` is a hair shorter.

Comment: @Lynn Thanks.  I got that from pointfree.io but I forgot to subtract 2 for `f=`.

Comment: If I'm not missing something..[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/P10hxzYxJ0cjITUnNTchRzPaUE8vJzUvvSRDISf2fxpQNl0lN7FAI6ZC165C21Azhys3MTPPNiWfS0GhoCgzr0QlLdowFpmjY4DMNdAx0jHWMdExRBU0BEKgBLpKDHUm2ASNsQlDrDGN/Q8A "Haskell – Try It Online")

Answer (score 10):

## [Zsh](https://www.zsh.org/), <sup><s>18</s> <s>12</s></sup> 11 bytes

```
>$@<{1..$#}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m724qjhjwYKlpSVpuhar7VQcbKoN9fRUlGshIkttbGxU7CHsm-rRZjoKxjoKFjoKhkZADEQGOgomOgpAjrmOgqWOgilQyDAWahoA)

Outputs via exit code: 0 for a permutation and 1 for not a permutation

Explanation:

- `>`: create files called

  - `$@`: each command-line argument
- `{1..$#}`: range from 1 to the number of command-line arguments
- `<`: try to read from each of those numbers as a file

If any command fails, then that means one of the files in the range didn't exist, so it's not a valid permutation, and zsh will exit with status 1.

Answer (score 10):

## JavaScript (ES6), 30 bytes

Expects 0-indexed values. Returns a Boolean value.

```javascript
a=>a.every(x=>(a[~x]^=1)/a[x])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VVHLbtswELzzK4RcJAIbVXzp0cLuqf2BHNMUEBw5VeFKruQGDor2192ZtS@FJFJLDmd2ht/7137dLePxdD/Nz8Nlv7n0m21fDq/D8lacN9uif/x7fvq6cfZd/3h@spdl@PlrXIYi36@5LZehf/48HoaHt2lXVLY8zQ@nZZxeCluux8N4Ku6@THe23M/Lp373rVizzTb7bbJsN0/rfBjKw/yCxY/ZvlhvB3IB7Y/@WEzETtl95qzN3md5bj@YP/bijBNvvHAO@AvCGh@qKElqaaSVTlwlzonDltefCmst9mpgIk@CocbcCgHcj1hrgErAG4e9RlwUl8QT5TsJ@HVKEMBAkVCLx4vKiye7ryQECR1JQyW@kYhRO4h4b0qug5SHDhSAFtdKwK4x7BZe1Bs8BrjjfHXqtG9nIh0DzdGjmaRJ8EmGPSRNAo2ahIqnaoyQUL9032jN3NQM3alzcv73oE7MMtBAAwanZJ78FSlq3kBUzy3tBIbHWOAHgVzhiQY9XTOMjkl0VG@YLBPzmmJi4q0mUjHCqxNPA7zAmpKMEuhoIOc1blAEXgpXCUaBbhoy8mKjdiV6PYFuKKlnIRZoG0pgrdl61CaDulAvt8sLxDf/AA)

#### Commented

We test whether all values are less than the length \$N\$ of the input array and make sure that there is no duplicate. Both conditions are satisfied iff the array consists of all values from \$0\$ to \$N-1\$.

```javascript
a =>             // a[] = input array
  a.every(x =>   // For each value x in a[]:
    (a[~x] ^= 1) //   ~x is -x - 1, which is guaranteed to be negative
                 //   Therefore, a[~x] is a property (such as '-1') of
                 //   the underlying object of a[], which can be safely
                 //   used to store values that were already encountered
                 //   If a[~x] XOR 1 is not equal to 1, we have a
                 //   duplicate value
    / a[x]       //   We also make sure that a[x] is defined, which
                 //   means that x < a.length
                 //   The possible cases are:
                 //     1 / n, n > 0 is a truthy number  \__ success
                 //     1 / 0 is +Infinity (also truthy) /
                 //     1 / undefined is NaN (falsy)     \
                 //     0 / n, n > 0 is 0 (falsy)         |_ failed
                 //     0 / 0 is NaN (falsy)              |
                 //     0 / undefined is NaN (falsy)     /
  )              // End of every()
```

Answer (score 10):

## Julia 1.5, 6 bytes

This is a built-in, so it's quite easy for Julia

```
isperm
```

Use it like this: `isperm([6,3,8,12,1,10,4,2,7,9,5,11])`

Comment: That's almost Mathematica-level surprising!

Answer (score 9):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>26</s> 24 bytes

-2 bytes thanks to pajonk.

```r
all(seq(x<-scan())%in%x)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VVLRSsNAEHzvVxRByMEKud27XAL66hf42JdSLAoloq1QEb@9zmzSi9KQ5nbndnZn9uOyXz@s95/j7vT6Njbn8H3cbceHGgjr82V7ODTH5/fmfH/HZBPC7et4ew6Xn9Vqtz01N08fn6eXr814E1b7ZtfEMP@Lzl8qS8xq1GRB4AuZJFk6KdLLILGVGCVWgPqxRaYHogMysVat3OHUC2FEJWQKsBm3rhWAKBKTxCxKrA5i@IxezFCNtNaJ4sFJRcmkrZiJDSxtrWiRhLd3k/DMfHEAoYINDEBL7MWQBfUk0WbcjI/bw/F5kmlSpY5WRfgjU5XOqlxL7K@M0YW43kwU1Ymvsiqmy/OZA2UXGlPPsYwYa3R495WDclLi4tHFKNeK4rm8C8@/X41mGmnUqtTK0amUPbQs3S0LkVzqnioanaMbkBE@TJcydVWKTQ8GGjCwt0JDaZS6eZlG925ES@emmZVDcoc6EtNBoK8DgFTdaxQybgRzvIIDeiqsy91K3pv4bhjnI7HfBaVRFPChdscBkrdqPotPNG@OEV9CuPwC)

If input is of length at least 2, `seq(x)` outputs the integers from 1 to `length(x)`; if input is of length 1, it outputs the integers from 1 to `x`. Return `TRUE` iff all those integers are elements of `x`.

Comment: I don't think the `!` is necessary here.

Comment: @pajonk Indeed, thanks!

Comment: And now we can do `all(seq(x<-scan())%in%x)`

Answer (score 7):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 21 bytes

```ruby
->a{a|[*1..a.max]==a}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XZDBDoIwEETvfAWJNzMSdrdAOeCPEA41gZMmRiXRqN@Os3Az2TTtdrpvprf59Fqmbjkc0zt9@r0URSou6Tl0Xfou13zqe4HCUCEMQ77LH7d5zLZ@DWsgAVJBDRHawrgV1FRbgEWwU0NZPCk0ooGWMIO1EI4toQ0CV4UIAosbSAlpSdUKQgLVkAjjbfbnwSnmIOrI5gzyKCSJxmq3xpfq45zSOoJkp9KyW9HVXuVR4ooq3VvjCTxK8JlMKptHqrdvmNL5PmbLDw)

-1 byte thanks to ovs!

-3 bytes thanks to Razetime!

Comment: I'm not completely sure, but `->a{a|[*1..a.max]==a}` might work.

Comment: @ovs seems to be working!

Answer (score 7):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/) + `math.unicode`, <sup><s>24</s></sup> 23 bytes

```
[ dup length iota ⊃ ]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VVJBTsMwELz3FfsCVO/aTgIPQFy4IE6IQ1UCVEBaSnpAiBM3nslHyswGEqeNImc9nt2Z8f1q3W/3x@uri8vzU3lq9137LC@r/vHk0G3W27tW3trXQ9ut2zfZ7du@f9/tN10vZ4vFx0Lw@5ClfI6rMK7DrK7Fjs5wXKuYREmSpZJaGgkoFkyBhQY7FRAJSHO@iT/huyKOMMNWBjjy1MiRxLIE7EVRgrUWw3I58JkYOxuI8OALM7FZAB2Gq8mtjWgWw9vniXiGhqGmBLQDXjlZJbbEGJMThZJJ9tyeCayFUTqzU2e2mRv5/21upM1sDZAWxwr1RLeaov@rEVVyJbyroh8tpdHZ62VgyVmqP5dtpqj8T/UIHJyBablUxKaBMzdkS0UL5qGMBJaa54hk4CkyGU5FmhzoPPOoGUZNgzLDZWjBg4wMvfJUGqY4GKDUyyuWZAgzMPKxd0UacIDJ6JTv8sySQ2US80Yah2Mi6nH7tVI/i55Gc9AQ7IkKos@qLsYl/V0jJT6j9@fxRu4OO3luu4f@UTbbfiU/319ye3xZ7eTk@As)

0-indexed to save a byte. Is the input a superset of \$[0..|input|)\$?

Answer (score 7):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 33 bytes

```python
lambda x:max(*x,len(x))^len({*x})
```

1. Check uniqueness: len(x) = len(set(x))
2. For unique set: max(x) == len(x) iff x = 1...n

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VVHRasMwEHv3V@RtSTlGfGfHyaB/MgYtW2kgbcOWsYyxb@@ka19GUzvnU6STPH8vx8vZroft83Xanfavu2p9Ou3WerPK9Hau16Z54f6zWX@b69dxnN6q@BSq8TxX22oaP5b6tJvr8bwIzz6Xunn8mKdxqR/koWmaUM3vaNb7y2WqD8DNOLzGEEWDCnfDmwlr/FElydJJkV4Gia3EKBEt9ZcWZz16HTCJX4Khw94LAewnnBWgMvAholckJolZlCgdxPAancDAQBHrRPGgUlGyaytmYgNJrRUtkrD6BAnPXSkOkFLoQAFoib0YuoHDwopbg0WDOe43o9HHjiHRMMBcFbPkQOHs9jFdyKiI7bCC103ScvGaYbkDWnK7ZPr3Q50ZoHHqAoboZEr@lhQdY09utKcHY2LMAiaQwg2e6UpplQkMtD9QvTBOxqQeXWbMvcfQMrebE6UB3lpHSeYHdAqQU88YFMab4CnBKDBNISNvM/lU4ndidENJ/xZiRttQAmvH0ZMPae7CvdxvzIgvfw)

Answer (score 6):

## [Zsh](https://www.zsh.org/), 13 bytes

```sh
: >$@<{1..$#}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##BcFNCoAgEAbQq3yQhAZKY/85WJcR2rTJVolnn9778iXaFP3c6EJOL2ySHVGdXMg51VQxPrY2MLM6KmYMWEEeBOoxwmPBhglE8gM)

```sh
:              noop command to prevent hanging while waiting for input
  >$@          create a file for every argument
     <{1..$#}  read every file between 1 and the number of arguments
```

Since the redirects are handled left-to-right, we create the files before trying to read them. If we encounter a number for which no file exists (for example on `zsh x.zsh 4 1 2`), we get the following error:

`no such file or directory: 3`

and receive exit code 1. If it was indeed a permutation, we exit cleanly with code 0.

Comment: [Welcome to Code Golf](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/20861/66833), and nice first answer! I've edited your answer slightly to include a link to Try it online! so that others can test your solution. Don't worry about not being able to comment, we encourage new users to post solutions, even if they're golfs of current ones :)

Answer (score 6):

## [BitCycle](https://github.com/dloscutoff/Esolangs/tree/master/BitCycle) `-u`, 91 bytes

```
v 0< <  <
ABv
^/=^?^
v<
Hvv <<
/<CDv
!v /=^
v  =\\\v
 ~~< >+
    <@>G^
 >E\^
>~> \/
 > F//@
```

Outputs `1` for truthy, `0` for falsey. [Try it here!](https://dloscutoff.github.io/Esolangs/BitCycle/?p=sc0wcwc2wrABsrnjonqnrswrHs2cw2rjwCDsrbscjonrsc2oi3srcz2wcetrc4waeGnrceEinrezecijrcecFj2a&i=MSwzLDI_&f=1)

### Explanation

The algorithm is as follows:

- Loop until the list is empty:

  1. Decrement every number in the list
  2. If there is not exactly one zero in the list, halt and output 0
  3. Otherwise, remove the zero from the list and continue
- If the loop ran to completion, output 1

The program contains two main sections, one that accomplishes step 1 and one that accomplishes steps 2 and 3. Here they are as separate programs:

#### Step 1

```
?0 v
v  <
ABv
^/=^
  C\!
```

Subtracts 1 from every number in the list. [Try it!](https://dloscutoff.github.io/Esolangs/BitCycle/?p=q0csrsc2wrABsrnjonrc2Cib&i=NCwxLDMsMg__&f=1)

We prefix a `0` bit to the input so every unary number has a leading `0`. Each time through the `A`-`B` loop, we use the first bit to set the switch (`=`) and then send it into the `C` collector.

- If the first bit was `0`, the rest of the bits go west. We use the splitter `/` to discard the second bit and sent the rest of the bits back into `A`. The second bit is guaranteed to be `1`, since all the numbers in the list are positive.
- If the first bit was `1`, the rest of the bits go east, right back into `A`.

The upshot is that one bit from each of the unary numbers gets discarded, subtracting 1 from each of them.

#### Steps 2-3

```
?0v  <
  CDv
 v /=^
v  =\\\v
 ~~< >+
    < >G\!
 >E\^@
>~> \/
 > F//@
```

Halts if there are no zeros or multiple zeros in the list, otherwise filters the zero(s) out of the list. [Try it!](https://dloscutoff.github.io/Esolangs/BitCycle/?p=q0sc2wrc2CDsrcscjonrsc2oi3srcz2wcetrc4wceGibrceEinarezecijrcecFj2a&i=MywwLDIsMQ__&f=1)

We once again prefix a `0` bit to the input. (In the actual program, this only needs to be done once.) Each time through the `C`-`D` loop, we use the first bit to set the northeast switch (`=`).

- If the first bit was `1`, the rest of the bits go east, right back into `C`.
- If the first bit was `0`, the rest of the bits go west. We peel off the second bit and use it to set the southwest switch. Then we send it through the eastern dupneg (`~`), from which a negated copy goes into the `E` collector and the original copy goes back into `C`. The rest of the bits go through both dupnegs; a negated copy goes into `E`, and a doubly negated copy goes back into `C`.

The upshot is that all the bits after the first go back into `C` unchanged, but if the first bit was `0`, the second bit sets the southwest switch and some bits go into `E`.

Meanwhile, the first bit goes through this structure:

```
 =
=\\\v
  >+
   >G
```

Starting from the northeast switch moving south, it bounces off the westernmost two splitters (`\`) and is sent to the branch (`+`). If it is `1`, it turns right and goes into the `G` collector. If it is `0`, it turns left, bounces off the easternmost splitter, passes back through the other two splitters, and reaches the southwestern switch.

- If the second bit was `1`, the switch sends the first bit back eastward, through all the splitters, and into the `G` collector.
- If the second bit was `0`, the switch sends the first bit westward; it eventually reaches a dupneg, from which one copy goes into the `E` collector and one into `F`.
- If there was no second bit, the inactive switch passes the first bit straight through, which behaves the same as the `0` case.

The upshot is that `G` gets the same list but without any `0` bit that is followed by another `0` bit or the end of the string. Also, `F` gets a bit for each of the `0` bits that didn't go into `G`, and `E` is guaranteed to have at least one bit in it.

Next, the `E` collector opens, dumps its first bit into `F`, and discards the rest. `F` now contains one bit if there were no zeros in the list, two bits if there was exactly one zero, and more than two if there were multiple zeros.

The bits from the `F` collector then go through this structure:

```
   @
> \/
 F//@
```

- If there are more than two bits, the first two bounce off the splitters on the bottom row, allowing the third one to pass through both splitters and hit the southeastern halt instruction (`@`).
- If there are two bits, the first one bounces off the westernmost two splitters and goes west. Meanwhile, the second one bounces off the easternmost two splitters and goes east off the playfield. The first bit is sent back east, goes through the two northernmost splitters, and off the playfield.
- If there is one bit, it bounces off the westernmost splitters, turns around, bounces off the northeastern splitter, and hits the northern halt instruction (`@`).

The upshot is that if there was not exactly one zero in the list, the program halts. No bits have been output yet, which with the `-u` flag means the output is `0`. If there was exactly one zero, the program does not halt; the `G` collector opens and the program continues.

#### Tying it together

In the full program, the output from the `G` collector is sent back into `A`, starting the loop over again.

Meanwhile, the discarded `1` bits from step 1 have been collected in `H`. Once there are no bits left in the main loop, `H` opens. The splitter (`/`) sends its first bit into the sink (`!`), outputting `1`. The rest of the bits go through the splitter and off the playfield.

Answer (score 5):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 3 bytes

```
Ṣ⁼J
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VVK7VQQxEMtdxj5CBZ4Z/7YFCqADEt41QAgJfRATkvAgo5K7RhZp7hLe7dkeWyuN5H16PJ2ej@P89X55@bk/zt@fD79vd5fXj@PYts2KwYtDc3AVUM0/q4aOgYmFHVZhBuOR56Jyb/FsENP0JhkG5wUBdN64N4nqxBfj2YQ1WIcL5TuCS0uCIINEYsD5sHK42L0iArGLNCp8onHMDhqfm5LtlHLqUIFo2ELwtKhZWklrtBg0p/lq1LJtK02GCdbo7KUXCfe0z@5KZyXs4EjeNCnLM2uFlQ5kKe2K6d@PdVeAoa4nGSzJXPxVFEOxtzS65CGUmLKgCaZwhXe5cllVArvs71KfilMxeUbXFfPKGKpyuzpxGdCtDUkqP6JboZxnxqQI3YR2BWbBbqYYdZstu0LeSciNJPNdioVsU4msQ623bDLSRXq53VgIP/nF/QE)

```
Ṣ⁼J   Monadic Link
Ṣ     1-chain: sort the input
 ⁼J   2,1-chain: is (the input sorted) equal to (range on the length of the input)?
```

Answer (score 5):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 27 bytes

```r
any(rank(x<-scan(),,'f')-x)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VVNNb5tAEL37V6zSQ0AaS@wXC1UuvVQ99NSmh0q9IGSiqClEmCquqv52970JXhyDMDs7897Oe8N8fmde5u75@TCbYZrNse/GohTTPT1NL4/jg1kmsxyOi/k1zQfTd8fDcTeYu70Zfo/98jiNxan8uzNa9yZcns7d@KeYu/Fncbrbr7hyO9yW@1N5/rfru6W42eN3/@Xb/afv73@MN@VuKPrCluu/uPXNyRbzOeply8AbdoJEqSVJI63YSqwVmxOcLivsNMiokRmIlZFrrBphGrMCdhJyI6ouCMhIYoPYKI65rhWPV6tgHmik9bU43Fg5cWRylXgvviW0r8QlCXjqaQLulc@2IHRgAwOyxTbisQvqTaePHz5/vZJp6yxrcKVSVs5ntbbYtYpWdbhUBmqqvBdVHZqL65r9RNUZTa@xiBgxajybzEE1qXDS6OaTSkXtVN2N582Vo5E@ekqVMrJVKsczVISut3kIqnRDET2NoxlQETa8FkXK6qg1LWipf8uzJfpJn5x6F@lzoz5UNO61Z8cmOUI1iWkgsi8NgNSp1QDyHAjusQQLnCkRl6MV9Gyio@HZH4m1FpSeooAP2DUbCHpUr71oR@vgeOanqw@CFy06/wc)

Returns FALSE for Truthy, TRUE for FALSY (just to shave one byte)

**Explanation:**

If the array containing the rank of each value is equal to the input array, then it's a permutation of `1..n`

**Note:**
5 bytes are wasted because in `rank` function the default handling strategy in case of ties is "average their ranks" instead of any of the other possibilities... argh!

Comment: -1: `any(rank(x<-scan())-x)` swapping thruthy and falsy. (TIO link too long for the comment)

Comment: @pajonk: I was just changing it while you were posting your comment ! :D

Comment: I think this fails on input `1,3,3,3,5`.

Comment: @RobinRyder: you're right... damn, I always forget that rank default for ties is avg...

Answer (score 5):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 3 bytes

```
o~⟦
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bVJLSgNBEL1KM@uJTFd3z2ejBwlZRPGzCASiEiRGMILozhu4060Iblx6k8xFxqp61TELYYburu@r9@p4MT25uJnNz2kY9Zv77dfLz@dqWbjRoSuWR6v@8aPfPPRP78XV4vr0oLiV69l0dsn39fb7ec0Jw/yuf30bhvHYT0o39qUjOal0@R3MxGf2yqmOWLpUurp0Tena0nUcUvHPfo9AslelzlYDa02KqGx9an21kqdtJCGqu9HMJHW0okSyzbPXs5WQRhwT5Olz/SANgCmwheQXE5ck4CDuETg9dGgb@E1sj3Ia8Cj/HyTfKSYSOAIiKGzP9YIEKnOY22jakWikBmMyv/f49ZkTzYlg24riSjpYEgMmSFkEmVrMSc2oVOultV4gGLw32ZP1rHOpdo/y3PifzzwJigdQ1Vgnb70JyCp0qvMWRSO9BYUhIVs0Eg5Fm1whgVoC7ypLB0k6YG@gvwpJpnHCfrSmTgV9d2QRyNGlrAFPtZZ0nViAkW2HFA/YKML6SLpYZIQGHXVjo02DQNsHW0@yigIrgF6BJG1rEBBtxGB8GC@7RQwo0Ewmvw)

0-indexed. Succeeds or fails.

```
o      The input sorted
 ~⟦    is the range from 0 to something inclusive.
```

Note that this can not be golfed to `⟦p` with reversed input, as it fails to terminate for cases it should reject:

```
⟦     Choose an integer. Is the range from 0 to it inclusive
 p    a permutation of the input?
```

Answer (score 5):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 3 bytes

```
UIS
```

[Try it online!](http://pythtemp.herokuapp.com/?code=UIS&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=%5B0%5D%0A%0A%5B0%2C+1%5D%0A%0A%5B1%2C+0%5D%0A%0A%5B0%2C+2%2C+1%5D%0A%0A%5B2%2C+0%2C+1%5D%0A%0A%5B0%2C+1%2C+2%2C+3%2C+4%2C+5%2C+6%2C+7%2C+8%2C+9%2C+10%2C+11%5D%0A%0A%5B11%2C+10%2C+9%2C+8%2C+7%2C+6%2C+5%2C+4%2C+3%2C+2%2C+1%2C+0%5D%0A%0A%5B5%2C+2%2C+7%2C+11%2C+0%2C+9%2C+3%2C+1%2C+6%2C+8%2C+4%2C+10%5D%0A%0A%5B15%2C+36%2C+13%2C+14%2C+22%2C+7%2C+28%2C+34%2C+20%2C+5%2C+4%2C+33%2C+37%2C+8%2C+35%2C+25%2C+23%2C+31%2C+27%2C+6%2C+19%2C+32%2C+38%2C+11%2C+29%2C+26%2C+39%2C+21%2C+10%2C+40%2C+41%2C+0%2C+9%2C+18%2C+1%2C+24%2C+16%2C+12%2C+2%2C+17%2C+30%2C+3%5D%0A%0A%5B1%5D%0A%0A%5B11%5D%0A%0A%5B0%2C+0%5D%0A%0A%5B0%2C+2%5D%0A%0A%5B1%2C+2%5D%0A%0A%5B2%2C+2%5D%0A%0A%5B1%2C+0%2C+2%2C+1%5D%0A%0A%5B0%2C+3%2C+2%2C+0%5D%0A%0A%5B3%2C+0%2C+1%2C+3%5D%0A%0A%5B0%2C+1%2C+1%2C+4%2C+4%5D%0A%0A%5B0%2C+2%2C+2%2C+2%2C+4%5D%0A%0A%5B7%2C+6%2C+4%2C+2%2C+3%2C+0%2C+5%5D%0A%0A%5B4%2C+6%2C+0%2C+3%2C+5%2C+0%2C+7%2C+2%5D%0A%0A%5B5%2C+2%2C+4%2C+3%2C+6%2C+0%2C+7%2C+0%2C+1%5D%0A%0A%5B5%2C+4%2C+2%2C+7%2C+1%2C+6%2C+8%2C+3%5D%0A%0A%5B0%2C+0%2C+0%2C+0%2C+0%2C+0%2C+0%2C+0%5D%0A%0A%5B0%2C+4%2C+8%2C+12%2C+10%2C+6%2C+2%5D%0A%0A%5B13%2C+5%2C+11%2C+3%2C+9%2C+7%2C+15%2C+1%5D%0A%0A%5B33%2C+32%2C+37%2C+16%2C+34%2C+10%2C+35%2C+30%2C+27%2C+13%2C+5%2C+14%2C+17%2C+1%2C+18%2C+39%2C+28%2C+40%2C+8%2C+0%2C+26%2C+22%2C+19%2C+31%2C+25%2C+24%2C+36%2C+7%2C+12%2C+29%2C+38%2C+6%2C+4%2C+2%2C+20%2C+3%2C+10%2C+15%2C+9%2C+21%2C+11%2C+23%5D%0A%0A%5B37%2C+26%2C+19%2C+22%2C+30%2C+5%2C+1%2C+23%2C+20%2C+30%2C+32%2C+6%2C+25%2C+11%2C+13%2C+16%2C+2%2C+1%2C+27%2C+30%2C+4%2C+22%2C+27%2C+26%2C+36%2C+31%2C+6%2C+38%2C+21%2C+5%2C+34%2C+41%2C+18%2C+2%2C+34%2C+16%2C+34%2C+39%2C+21%2C+12%2C+26%2C+6%5D%0A&debug=0&input_size=2)

Comment: Wow... I had a 6 byter, had no idea `U` had that use. Nice!

Answer (score 4):

## [Red](http://www.red-lang.org), 46 bytes

```
func[a][i: 0 until[alter a i: 1 + i]single? a]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bVJBbttAELv7FUSuvWhndrWSgaJ/6FXQQW2U1oDrBq5z6OtdcpIi1aqwIFiznCF3yOv6eP@8Pk7z4Xm9/jjen14uX6dlnk5HdHi53E7naTnf1isWsJTwAac54SPO6@Xb7fsnLPP9@frzywq1Y0qc8@8nbFsw7BDeYhy7NhaIyyjoUTFgROqQElKLs6h2BAwE9mzIImhZexYHCC1wJqCypbC5mUdgRcpIBaYWG@H8m2K0c7a0eA/jwy@Didc6uMNHMXgHq8h8h7bM5402jeQ1kpKBaKQBztO/Ch6elvOv38eH7f7a@7Z72q@3NcDbbe8Q//EkxR6b4VlGvQt@t8q4nLItay0lPOTutkeFR5rf8z20auSUTKxxuAtG2CBfwsCdlM2vPSyKkcuU2rKmUGNS24m232U0h8ODzHPlRiGge7T/tbfITpPHsn6U76PkV@VI@bDITFG@hvC/U2Bel2Rah4Lci1/BIbq5HLktksZ5rjwKok5@UFrVeAU8h0REMl2XFn/0ktm1N9KSotc9cij2uFJc7C23LnydD4f7Hw)

increments a counter as long as the counter is found in the list, and then checks it against the length.

`1 = length?` is used as a polyfill for `single?` in the latest Red version.

-5 bytes from tsh.

-5 bytes from Galen Ivanov.

Comment: Maybe `i >(length? a)`?

Comment: yes, it works. Thanks.

Comment: Once again, `alter`  (plus reversal of logic) helps to get rid of 5 bytes: `func[a][i: 0 until[alter a i: 1 + i]single? a]`.  (`single?` doesn't work in TIO, must be replaced by `1 = lenght? a`)

Comment: only one more answer for an `alter` hattrick :P

Comment: @Razetime haha, yes!

Answer (score 4):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 38 bytes

```perl
sub{!grep!{map+($_,1),@_}->{$_},1..@_}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dVNda9tAEHzPr1AOUWyyDbovnWST1k99KTQveUuLSSBu06a2UZyHYvLb3Zm1rFMotYy4292buZ1ZbR@6p3goV1eH55f7/fn37mF7vv99t72YlEuxU1ksX99/2JfLV7GXl9gc5meLXfey@/HnanJW4Hdrv0m/EHdaOhlFfY57GRVhiVyQKLUkaaQVW4m1YnOF032FVIOSGqWBcBm9xrYR1rEsIJVQHHFswEBJEhvERnEsdq14LK3CeeCR2dfi8MfOiSOXq8R78S2xfSUuScBb7xPw7wltC0YHOjCgWmwjHtmeewqtVndPz4NUo8ayCGOlsn4@SzaKvhHTqhjD8UBtB25V16HDODaCzxBgm1EdgBanYESQwDXeTaamzhQ/aXhkoopIVVX4EfubJ4cjbfaUMWV0q3yON6kIX48mJqgPDSX29JVWQWOYdDwVKbqjEzSopTstL5joNl106mzkFDTqUkVbj607tsoRq8lMe1E9NAFWp5MAJM95YZJnsMGlEoE5ekEvJzo5ni2SWc@C01MZEAK8ZgdB7@q1GW2pnyvP@pQnZ9s9rneFudFvbfZ1bebFMfSuXE0W5XL60Wx@FWZmvlzfFNefCyM/N4/riREjzIrBkWK16fqvdQD8xIE84v0DeIKaKfT/AHWk54e/)

Comment: [28 bytes using full program](https://tio.run/##VVHLbgIxDLznKwzi2EJs57F7qMSJr0BCRUJVJVRW0HM/vdsZL5dqs0mcODOe8XS5X@s8b05vq4/7ZVrvD@vVz@543pyO592Lbrf7wzxrUrFkwtWxc2GMH1GRKk26DDKKZlEVxZXFJuNswF1DTuFLIDSsgzCB9wVnHVkV@Ulx10WLaBVjlo3i2GoAOBBI4k0MA5GJEd2yuIuPBPUs1qVgjgoKxpNJR1AZeMCAbNFBHLeJxaalaHFodKjjuijVqFtToWJkczYUU8MJfjWxhhpOoNBUEfFVwwyK0Ev1PWL6FmKoLpQT89@HuNJLp4AOBA0wI34mRGMHSmgeKMdpHm2BHhiypFcKNKqmGSOdGMne6Swds3Cx0vEhHMm0cFFiFMAGNlLSSmSXBDoLuwHhbApPmYwA1XQisrElqpJoj1MNKeMtyJyywQTUxtJLFOmhIrQ8m@fM77@36fvz9vWYX9@v0x8)

Comment: @NahuelFouilleul - Nice.

Answer (score 4):

## [Java (JDK)](http://jdk.java.net/), 43 bytes

```java
a->a.sorted().reduce(1,(x,y)->y==x?x+1:0)>0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bVFdb9MwFH3Pr7AqTUrgNortfLQdLQKJhz0gEOMN8eC1zshokypxyia0317uuQ0SSFM@7Pvhc@45fnAnN3/Y/Tw3h2PXB/XAcdp06avr6N/MGJr9i7l6bLeh6doXi0PovTugFG33bhjUR9e06nek1HG82zdbNQQXeDl1zU4duBbfhr5p7799V66/HxJpVepz73fN1gX/5qYNt4K5UbVan91849KBOf0uTlLuGrc@1hQ/0lMy3zyt149vH1/rVZZssvO1QLX@l3o/1rXn5i/e7XwfI3XTHscJecrePg3BH9KmTZJ037R@YIK66z@47Y8YsZpvpumUOrleBT8EtVbv@t49DZNwaUyH474J8YxmjHRwx68di4j58/e@X61Obj/6T3WShk7Oxsn1hDpN0I0hPbIpoY5nV8NKXd1dtTP6SxS6i2Mx@BNSdYpN/P8YUksm4GdZn6Pns440mcgQVss7S4j54yingkqqaEFL0hlpTZpLRjYZ5xZcK7knx0lGKHldEBpQzzlXcVfB/ZHmWkU6J12QQZdZkuWtFgDLCCCxJRl@OTJkgG4yspbsEqA2I1NRzn@ZIOd3YtJLpjLMwwzcTXpBlqsRhmUpIo0lWhaH9SJUy9g6yiGYm/E3PEshRuApIoxQiBE8Z1RwhFMl/5lB5EJ8JTFsEy0QJ8KB@d/DcQErLeavGEELmAF@BogSF5CL5AXUWHgHV1gO@3FpL6DPQDS8WMKIJdgrGAvDjJhYwPCFGJLBwYsSAwG4vxKUcJK784jpjLjNEBZ3giyaOeBpKiDiXnOZiuR2LNSAUs4ymYVsZmLUEqPnMqQVFaJlujuL/uoP)

### Explanations

This answer is a `Predicate<IntStream>` and requires that the input contains no `0`.

First this code sorts the input stream. The reduce method then makes sure that each consecutive number is encountered, and return the last encountered number. `x` always contains the next expected number, or `0` if we got an unexpected number. `1` is the first parameter of the `reduce` method as it's the first expected number. Given that `0`, or any negative number, is not allowed in the `IntStream`, when `0` is returned for the first time, it will always be returned for the remaining of the process.

Answer (score 4):

## TypeScript's Type System, <strike>450</strike> 442 bytes

```
type A<T extends any[]>=T extends{length:infer L}?(L extends number?L:never):never
type B<L extends number,T extends 0[]=[]>=T extends{length:L}?T:B<L,[...T,0]>
type C<N extends number,T extends number=1,R extends any[] = []> = R['length']extends N?R:C<N,A<[...B<T>,0]>,[...R,T]>
type D<T extends any[],U extends any[]>=T extends[]?true:T extends[infer H,...infer R]?H extends U[number]?D<R,U>:false:never
type F<T extends any[]>=D<T,C<A<T>>>
```

[TypeScript Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAECUFMDNIJ0gOwMaQM4C5QAsAuuAHTEAS10UgA9cA6Ege2BIFsCAbSZpXExAcwC0AQzhlsXHsgEB3MbwG4AngXTJRBXGgXLIAtIrS5OwgIwwTAFgAMQgGzR7AKCUrQAQQA8AFVBUjiABM0UCFERQBtAF0APgBeHz8kIIBvDn5cbAxeWDhQABkAXwB%20AAo832ok4MQAV2YAI3givIwKADd4AEpWyA64Zx1QACEPcsTA6rrGuAAaBMqJ0Cso2Ki4%20f8UtL4MjEKirwwRvJnwmnOvGasYgdcAYQ8AOQrNyYb4OZeq0Fr3uFiTDNwF9FqEIpFQLFQGtIRBwgBybYZeGRcZBUCPIrgDAPR4zTxnc4jLzRK4xU7nGjgOY3FyQUAAEW8IPRNUQAGtEPRpIgojMAKos4Jsznc3kxeJCqJFXBwGqQDAbKrhbLwUAACRmlNVuXAkSK6qFoH54V%20031TOp-OiGGgQjYaAV7Xgt3pADFmWjgmC1rEmZcHp4SdFoo5XaAvOhcCZYQ8TFZQyBQMmAHpFMN0iNRgBMsI94UBoGzM1AAGYSxYS7YSwBWG5J1Pp8ORwylvMeAsl4tlisl%20O1%20tgRsZwYt3AWdtrRwN0BpkeuMc1yeF7vl0CV0A1qslgDsJYAHIPk7OikA)

### Explanation

```
// This allows getting the Length of any tuple via inferring its L property
type A<T extends any[]>=T extends{length:infer L}?(L extends number?L:never):never

// This creates a tuple of arbitrary length L (we need to use this later for arithmetic)
type B<L extends number,T extends 0[]=[]>=T extends{length:L}?T:B<L,[...T,0]>

// We can use this to generate an incrementing tuple of length L (e.g. [1, 2, 3, 4]). We use this to compare against the final array.
type C<N extends number,T extends number=1,R extends any[] = []> = R['length']extends N?R:C<N,A<[...B<T>,0]>,[...R,T]>

// This checks if two arrays have the same elements inside them 
type D<T extends unknown[],U extends unknown[]>=T extends[]?true:T extends[infer H,...infer R]?H extends U[number]?D<R,U>:false:never

// Finally, we can use this to compare the chosen array T vs the increasing tuple N
type F<T extends any[]>=D<T,C<A<T>>>
```

Comment: `A` can probably just be `T["length"]`, which can then be inlined.

Answer (score 3):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/), <s>22</s> 20 bytes

```
Sort@#==Range@Max@#&
```

-2 bytes, thanks to @ZaMoC:

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VZJNasNADIX3uUagK0E80vx5YfAFCqU9gSkhzSIpBC8KIWd339NMCsXG9mg070mffFnWr@NlWc@fy3aato/v2zrvp@l9uZ6O8@vyM@9ftrfb@boe5tNhvu/u4SF4iPKl0lfW1iZ9Ay/EoiTJUqTKKGGQECS0XfXvAeGK7Yy0SImmlvFZhTlMiQgXJCYc8bPYLhKihCTKRB3F8BlcxqBDN8uiuLFSUXroIGZiI3VtEC0S8fQ6Iu5uFka4KazggGwJVQy78EWvrfLW3bPtBsFa7331RyN4V54aCcaFHI2i1PQkx8sXrDM5NjTDQEKAIhnP2uQJh7SKhzpt75wonFR3@Xe1UOIcjD2XphZcW@k4UC73MUaHVcnBCJ48AQIk24lEMkpcpDgS4chiCkdC1Or4E0dVHeVA9q09ZUucf6YrZ4BsLxqO6qOCinGg3GA@FiioUJT/RfTCxEdrbIuufhZ@Rgowg3Bm9dHrNG/E2@mDN@aXx@6xbb8)

Comment: [20 bytes](https://tio.run/##VZJNasNADIX3uUagK0E80vx5YfAFCqU9gSkhzSIpBC8KIWd339NMCsXG9mg070mffFnWr@NlWc@fy3aato/v2zrvp@l9uZ6O8@vyM@9ftrfb@boe5tNhvu/u4SF4iPKl0lfW1iZ9Ay/EoiTJUqTKKGGQECS0XfXvAeGK7Yy0SImmlvFZhTlMiQgXJCYc8bPYLhKihCTKRB3F8BlcxqBDN8uiuLFSUXroIGZiI3VtEC0S8fQ6Iu5uFka4KazggGwJVQy78EWvrfLW3bPtBsFa7331RyN4V54aCcaFHI2i1PQkx8sXrDM5NjTDQEKAIhnP2uQJh7SKhzpt75wonFR3@Xe1UOIcjD2XphZcW@k4UC73MUaHVcnBCJ48AQIk24lEMkpcpDgS4chiCkdC1Or4E0dVHeVA9q09ZUucf6YrZ4BsLxqO6qOCinGg3GA@FiioUJT/RfTCxEdrbIuufhZ@Rgowg3Bm9dHrNG/E2@mDN@aXx@6xbb8 "Wolfram Language (Mathematica) – Try It Online")

Answer (score 3):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 5 bytes

```
c%R|}
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#c=c%25R%7C%7D&i=%5B1%5D%0A%5B1,2%5D%0A%5B2,1%5D%0A%5B1,3,2%5D%0A%5B3,1,2%5D%0A%5B1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12%5D%0A%5B12,11,10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1%5D%0A%5B6,3,8,12,1,10,4,2,7,9,5,11%5D%0A%5B16,37,14,15,23,8,29,35,21,6,5,34,38,9,36,26,24,32,28,7,20,33,39,12,30,27,40,22,11,41,42,1,10,19,2,25,17,13,3,18,31,4%5D%0A%5B2%5D%0A%5B12%5D%0A%5B1,1%5D%0A%5B1,3%5D%0A%5B2,3%5D%0A%5B3,3%5D%0A%5B2,1,3,2%5D%0A%5B1,4,3,1%5D%0A%5B4,1,2,4%5D%0A%5B1,2,2,5,5%5D%0A%5B1,3,3,3,5%5D%0A%5B8,7,5,3,4,1,6%5D%0A%5B5,7,1,4,6,1,8,3%5D%0A%5B6,3,5,4,7,1,8,1,2%5D%0A%5B6,5,3,8,2,7,9,4%5D%0A%5B1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1%5D%0A%5B1,5,9,13,11,7,3%5D%0A%5B14,6,12,4,10,8,16,2%5D%0A%5B34,33,38,17,35,11,36,31,28,14,6,15,18,2,19,40,29,41,9,1,27,23,20,32,26,25,37,8,13,30,39,7,5,3,21,4,11,16,10,22,12,24%5D%0A%5B38,27,20,23,31,6,2,24,21,31,33,7,26,12,14,17,3,2,28,31,5,23,28,27,37,32,7,39,22,6,35,42,19,3,35,17,35,40,22,13,27,7%5D&m=2)

Explanation:

```
     ; Implicit input onto top of stack
c    ; Copy top of stack
%    ; Length of top of stack
R    ; Make range [1 .. n]
|}   ; Compare top two elements of stack. Arrays are different orderings of same elements?
     ; Implicit output of truthy/falsy
```

Could probably save a byte somewhere.

Comment: `oc%R-` exists, but i don't think there's away to get this to pack.

Answer (score 3):

## [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/), 20 bytes

```
[range(max)+1]==sort
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VVK7TgQxDOzvS0C4iO28trgvOW1xBUJCAsRBwd8fM5OlQLvKJo494xnv6@f9frld31@eH96uP49Pvp/PXx@3b0R9P13cAmvY2qdOaSuKFZFqzboNm7aZF3M312VoWxCduO3IqqwXUsduGlOYUREdyGuoYCVuh3k1bxbMi80SWxdIAoVU2S3w4hQWZIhimZYbYbNYDKtY1UXFe3D5BrIAExiQbT4tcUuNalqyDrESnhK89n8GuKQwq9IKlfMb6K8dRvHhnq012YT@cW44s75jncKlGTRnKLKslVJKlzEL/9@jSKPlSYVDSC7YIFchVF/jqjJmUnPSY3oH0XBtFTS6ELSGjm20a2Mfg/bT1pDVjWOZsq3Q56UrKIaT7iSl38hmwyAMTQUgydkxznQc0M8gJv@Aqr5MU0xqIqlqQZc0AFzA7Wy@qs2UDqk5ZpzMH/vpFw)

### Explanation

```
       max            # Get the maximum of the input
 range(   )           # Generate the non-negative integers below that
           +1         # Add 1 to each of them
[            ]        # Collect as list
                sort  # Sort the input list
              ==      # Compare the two lists
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Nibbles](http://golfscript.com/nibbles/index.html), 1.5 bytes (3 nibbles)

```
-,,
```

Returns an empty list (falsy) if input is a permutation of 1..n, or a non-empty list (truthy) if it is not.

```
-       # remove 
 ,      #   sequence of 1..
  ,     #   length of
        #   (implicitly) input
        # from
        #   (implicitly) input
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

## Python, <s>43</s> 39 Bytes

```python
lambda x:sorted(x)==list(range(len(x)))
```

0-indexed. Uses `sorted()`, `range()` and `list()`. Surprisingly gives correct answer for empty list.

[Test on TIO.](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/6fZhvzPycxNyklUaHCqji/qCQ1RaNC09Y2J7O4RKMoMS89VSMnNQ8opKn5v6AoM69EI00j2kDHUMdIx1jHJFZTkwsuaggVNUURNQGJ6FjomKOJglQa6higiAI5/wE)

Comment: You can remove the space between `len(x))` and `for y`

Comment: You can also remove the square brackets inside `all`, a generator will work there, it doesn't need to be a list

Comment: Also the answer is invalid: https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/6fZhvzPycxNyklUaHCKjEnRyO6UiEzT6EoMS89VSMnNU@jQlNTIS2/SAEsXBGr@b@gKDOvRCNNI9pQBwXGamr@BwA Returns true on many of the falsy test cases

Comment: @mousetail fixed

Comment: Smart solution, well done

Comment: @mousetail golfed!

Comment: ima see if i can use the walrus operator

Comment: You could do `{*x}=={*range(len(x))}` to save the bytes of `sorted` and `list`. In general there is no real reason to ever use the `list()` function in golfing since `[*x]` exists

Answer (score 2):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), <s>40</s> 38 bytes

```javascript
s=>s.sort((a,b)=>a-b).some((x,i)=>x^i)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DchbCoAgEADA6@zCJr3/7CJRoKVhWBtuRLe35nN28xhZUrju4uTVZa@z6EGUcLoBDFnUgyks/nE4gJfCH@8cMC98CkenIm/gYSypopo6aqmnZkLMHw)

Returns true for invalid and false for valid. Put a `!` before the `s.sort` for the otherway round. Takes input 0-indexed.

Comment: 0-indexed is allowed, so you can remove `++`.

Comment: `(a,b)=>a-b` ->  `a=>b=>a-b` from [this tip](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8424/80214)

Comment: @razetime that wont work for the sort function

Comment: oh, too bad.....

Comment: @RecursiveCo. thanks!

Answer (score 2):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 6 bytes

```
¬⁻Ｅθκθ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##BcFLCoAgFAXQrThUuIH2j9ZgNBcH4iRJLM3a/uscf7jiLxeJ9hJS5dtVuQ7pfbh2N89gpwDLQoiVyJgBLSYoBYkFHRRGzOihpLXUfPEH) Link is to verbose version of code. 0-indexed. Outputs a Charcoal boolean, i.e. `-` for permutation, nothing if not. Explanation:

```
   θ    Input array
  Ｅ     Map over elements
    κ   Current index
 ⁻      Remove values found in
     θ  Input array
¬       Check that nothing is left
        Implicitly print
```

(Mapping over the input indices is golfier than creating a range.)

Answer (score 2):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), <s>4</s> 3 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

0-based

```
Íe¶
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=zWW2&input=WzE1LDM2LDEzLDE0LDIyLDcsMjgsMzQsMjAsNSw0LDMzLDM3LDgsMzUsMjUsMjMsMzEsMjcsNiwxOSwzMiwzOCwxMSwyOSwyNiwzOSwyMSwxMCw0MCw0MSwwLDksMTgsMSwyNCwxNiwxMiwyLDE3LDMwLDNd) or [run all test cases](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=zWW2&input=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)

Saved a byte thanks to Etheryte pointing out one of my own favourite tricks that I somehow forgot!

```
Íe¶     :Implicit input of array
Í       :Sort
 e      :Every?
  ¶     :  Equal to its 0-based index
```

Comment: You can use a shortcut for sorting for 3 bytes: `Íe¶`

Comment: @Etheryte, of course I can :facepalm: One of my own favourite tricks and I fecking forgot it! Thanks :)

Comment: ```[0,3,0,3]``` [seems](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&flags=LXg&code=7S0&input=WzAsMywwLDNd) to incorrectly output 0...

Answer (score 2):

## [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/), <s>20</s> <s>49</s> 36 bytes

```
length==max and max==(unique|length)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyr8/z8nNS@9JMPWNjexQiExL0UBSNvaapTmZRaWptZAJDX//4821DHVsdQxNNYxNNQx1zGOBQA)

*Thanks to `tsh` and `xigoi` for catching mistakes in the previous attempts...*

Third time is the charm perhaps?

Since the rules limit the numbers to "positive integers", there's no need to test the minimum.  Making sure the largest number in the list, the size of the original list and the size of a de-dup'd list are all the same is sufficient.  So that's what this version does.

Comment: Failed on `[1,1,1]`

Comment: Re-written to actually do what the challenge called for...

Comment: Maybe `[1,3,3]`?

Comment: I think it should be `==` instead of `-`.

Answer (score 2):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <sup><s>95</s> <s>73</s></sup> 72 bytes

```c
r,t,i,j;f(a,n)int*a;{for(r=i=n;i--;r*=!t)for(t=j=n;j--;)t*=i!=a[j];n=r;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##nVbbbttIDH3PVygGAtjOGCtydK2q7UPRr0iCwnXkrrW7amF5sUED/3pdcoaSZ4j2pbYjRTwc8vDMkaDd5vNud7kczckcTN/sl1szrA7Dab1tXvdfjstje2iH5rDZNMd1e3tacezU9hTrKbY6rdvDbbt96J@aoT025wstTf7dHobl6ub1JqEPB07deIKHp6RNXuHczCGUkMEgaH0QTZiZTZk2ys192Jq4RDHXpfzM5KYwpalMbSA1AAbC3FJy0SEpJVWUXNCijJtFLCqfWxBQGV7BCzJKKmlZTgWC3FrqUnJpIDOQG@RlWBtL/4JrYakH87KFQfrRFRrk/pgaa42tuYtNDZYmo6PjmNFPWkNNvZEaUwfKNlAZS2jAAlJRM4xNOxEF570IhwA76x5Gs2mLoui8GVG0mLdT7R1Myjuho66ic8bbGo9TX3cWSb88NFN69Qh/I0xGZmlz5wnSP8Rl@pxw5lPQsYrmQHvde7ZG6TJi22E25eTOId4XIX/MZ5XDb5gxezdnv1re8TJmMunmaCLPkjKVIuYiGrLDLJuMPGLZouw1Mgm5zBfI2TXIVmKH1Wyvmucq2a5sQ3TWzNnGlbNZyr70OiKLxfdNwSTYn5RNA0c3PsqmEQl0zqbClv3PuVyCLohjyX34psocV@PuBMs6MBG3lihYFpX6U6@CB8ocdetmcxPKfWI5v7wyWTsqo2firGQ8OX@y/pT5U@5PhT@V/lT5U23kxpKz1AEpBFIJpBRILZBiINVAyoHUQ6mHEy@ph1IPpR5KPZR6KPVQ6mGt1P84@JnHw7fuy37peq7@kKu1vzRJgGKMYozaGLUxmsVoFqN5jOYxWsRoEaNljJYxWsVoFaN1jNYxCqmSI1W4lkvpBUowUIqBkgyUZqBEA6UaKNlA6QZKOFDKgZIOlHagxAOlHij5QOmHSj9U@qHSD7XftOGUfqj0Q6UfKv1Q6YdKP1T6odIPlX6o9EOlHyr9UOmHSj@6Dm7R7uVrtzt1z9NTP/nVL/3tn3Tb/bU9runY7f7ujtQu4YaLx5cP@PhSv6e/fGGS8NouZCW98iVLJnsYnrsXWpY28u/badBpjOuoc6RJ7u9d9irxL4TzE3lLpfxT2eFPTQgnySAwPcF@hn/6b79/GILg1yOF98vFw2J1DfLrKmf3nnZPlAdm1Ids@OPK9bwL/DKbbBJoInyqfjfePZNQ/TtW682CjrIyaHqOiI5U8/Z2v@Q8ere@pkVZHWXNZtDzTs2J15/J3XNyNz4O1Hk08352bTtOFM4358v33f6f7efxsvn/Bw)

Inputs a pointer to an array \$a\$ of zero-based integers and its length \$n\$ (since C pointers to arrays carry no length information).
Returns a truthy value if all \$0\dots (n-1)\$ integers are present or a falsey value otherwise.

#### Explanation

Goes through all the numbers \$0\dots (n-1)\$ (in reverse order) and tests to see if they're in \$a\$.

Saved a whopping 19 bytes thanks to [AZTECCO](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/84844/aztecco)!!!

Comment: @AZTECCO Figured out how to golf it with `t=j=n`, for some reason (overflow/underflow I'm guessing) couldn't get this to work with `t*=i-a[j]`.

Comment: Great! Idk.. It worked for me

Comment: @AZTECCO It fails on the second to last test. Have gone through it and `t` flips to \$0\$ without `i-a[j]==0` while the code is testing for the presence of `41` (which isn't there).

Answer (score 2):

## [Raku](http://raku.org/), 14 bytes

```
{$_∖bag ^$_}
```

0-based.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJamYPu/WiX@Uce0pMR0hTiV@Nr/xYmVCkoq8Qq2dgrVimkKQCElhbT8IoVoAx0jHcNYnWggqWMApA2gpCFQ3FjHVMdMx1zHItb6PwA)

- `$_` is the list argument to the function.
- `^$_` is a list of numbers from 0 to one less than the size of the input list.
- `bag ^$_` is a bag (a set with multiplicity) of that list of those sequential numbers.
- `∖` is the set difference operator.  The left argument, the input list, is coerced to a bag because the right argument is a bag, from which one instance of each of the sequential numbers is removed.  The result will be an empty bag only if the input list contained exactly one number from zero up to one less than its size.  An empty bag is falsey in a boolean context, and a non-empty bag is truthy.

Comment: Dear lord I've got to learn Raku properly at some point. I'm a Perl 5 golfer, and Raku baffles me half the time.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo I love golfing in Raku, since you rarely need weird tricks to keep the byte count down--the built-ins suffice for so many things.

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 3 bytes

```
{āQ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FY4xDoNQDEOvkgNkIMmH0mMwIwaQOnRi6MjE3bjX77P0LceOY/3ztx/fT@/Xcy@9rzG51cstGhjdstxm6I0tGW4kmIpAsdECJwVZCWNTkQOS8yIS2IVO/CZGB11N0MzDDqIqoD/0CV1D9JWC2x8)

```
{āQ  # full program
  Q  # is...
 ā   # implicit input...
{    # sorted...
  Q  # equal to...
 ā   # [1, 2, 3, ..., length of...
     # implicit input...
{    # sorted...
 ā   # ]...
  Q  # ?
     # implicit output
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 3 bytes

```
-ŀ¹
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv6fq2GvlJaYU5yqpFRSVJqq9KipUfO/7tGGQzv///8fHW2oY6RjrGOiY6pjFquDxDMH8sx0DIEsIyDfGMgzR@EZArFxbCwA)

What's left after removing (`-`) 1..length_of_input (`ŀ¹`) from the input?
Empty list = falsy (so input is permutation of 1..n); Non-empty list = truthy (input is not permutation of 1..n).

Answer (score 2):

## [Pyt](https://github.com/mudkip201/pyt), 6 bytes

```
şĐŁř=Π
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gs@f//6PwjE442Hp1pe27B///RhjrGOkY6pjomsQA)

```
ş              implicit input; sort in ascending order
 Đ             duplicate
  Ł            get length
   ř           push [1,2,... length]
    =          element-wise equal with sorted array?
     Π         product of booleans; implicit print
```

returns 1 if permutation of [1,2,...]; 0 otherwise

Answer (score 2):

## Regex (ECMAScript+`(?^=)`<sup>[RME](https://github.com/Davidebyzero/RegexMathEngine)</sup>), <sub><sup><s>37</s> <s>30</s></sup></sub> 28 bytes

```
(:x*)x\b(.*\1x:|(?^!.*\1\b))
```

Takes its input in unary, as a concatenation of strings of `x` characters whose lengths represent the numbers, separated and enclosed on both sides by `:` characters. Example: `:xxx:x:xx:` represents `3,1,2`.

[Try it on replit.com](https://replit.com/@Davidebyzero/Is-this-a-Permutation-of-1-to-n-with-lookinto) - **ECMAScript+`(?^=)`** (RegexMathEngine `-xli`)

Asserts that there exists no element \$n\$ for which there either is a subsequent duplicate element \$n\$, or for which there doesn't exist any element \$n-1\$ anywhere in the list if \$n\ne 1\$.

Returns "match" for falsy and "no match" for truthy **(inverted logic)**.

```
              # No anchor - can match starting at any point in the string
(:x*)x\b      # Start at any list element; \1 = {that element} - 1, including
              # the bounding character on its left side, consuming it without
              # consuming the bounding character following it.
(
    .*\1x:    # Match any subsequent list element whose value equals \1 + 1
|         # or...
    (?^!      # Negative lookinto - assert that the following pattern cannot
              # match the entire input string:
        .*    # Skip to any list element, putting it in tail (Works in concert
              # with the following expression's matching of the left-side
              # bounding character contained in \1)
        \1\b  # Assert that tail==\1, or if \1==0 this can match at the edge
              # of any element in the list (if we didn't need \1==0 to be able
              # to match, we could have used "\1:" instead)
    )
)
```

Using comma delimiting (e.g. `xxx,x,xx`) instead of this input method, would take +5 bytes:

```
\b(x*)x\b(.*,\1x\b|(?^!.*\b\1\b))
```

## Regex (<sub><sup>PCRE+`(?^=)`<sup>[RME](https://github.com/Davidebyzero/RegexMathEngine)</sup></sup></sub>), 29 bytes

```
^:(x*:(?^=.*:((?(2)\2)x):))*$
```

[Try it on replit.com](https://replit.com/@Davidebyzero/Is-this-a-Permutation-of-1-to-n-with-PCRElookinto) - PCRE+`(?^=)` (RegexMathEngine `--pcre -xli`)

<sub>Golfwise, this is obsoleted by the 28 byte version above, but is kept here due to still being close in length, and using a different algorithm.</sub>

Iterate once for each list element: Find a list element whose value is the index of the current loop iteration. (Uses a nested backreference to accomplish this.)

Returns "match" for truthy and "no match" for falsy.

```
^                     # Anchor to start
:                     # Consume initial bounding character
(                     # Loop the following:
    x*:               # Consume one list element
    (?^=              # Lookinto - is matched against the entire string
        .*:           # Skip to any list element, putting it in tail
        (             # \2 = the  following:
            (?(2)\2)  # If \2 is set (i.e., if we're not on the first iteration)
                      # then include the previous value of \2 in its new value
            x         # Append one more "x" (if this is the first iteration,
                      # captures just one)
        )
        :             # Consume one bounding character
    )
)*                    # Iterate the above as many times as possible, minimum 0
$                     # Assert we've reached the end of the string
```

Using comma delimiting (e.g. `xxx,x,xx`) instead of this input method, would take +2 bytes:

```
^(x+,?(?^=.*\b((?(2)\2)x)\b))*$
```

But that regex is incredibly slow, and it takes another +1 byte to give it reasonable speed:

```
^(x++,?(?^=.*\b((?(2)\2)x)\b))*$
```

## Regex (ECMAScript 2018 / Python<sup>[`regex`](https://github.com/mrabarnett/mrab-regex)</sup> / .NET), <sub><sup><s>38</s> <s>31</s></sup></sub> 29 bytes

```
(:x*)x\b.*(\1x:|$(?<!\1\b.*))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dVHLbtswELzrK5SggMiEEURSD9uKmlML5JJD21tdIIpNOWxV2aVkR4Djb3dnaR9aIIEe5HJ3Z3aGP@td3S@c3Qw33Xppjk2VlK76Ylafxg37OjjbrWJXvzwe2Wy84uP8Kb5icznOXj@wu9uLuaQDzo@Pcd/ahWFS3EjOS2f@bK0zLHKmXra2MxGPF9gP5r4bjGtqlO5tt9kOs41bL0zfx/2wtN2Bx@uORb5DtNXH/a66vO92dWuX4ak8vCxtwxr@T9t6O8Qvzg6gm3cRL5tKlkEY2iZkbdyabjU88z2a2Kpq437T2oFFIuL8nLuVfP8m2o6Xb563/GDa3uzBEYbN2jFbJWKsollU2tvVGbW019ee1fYP9QOrq03telLPVt/tD87f5xwx/hO8@lUeqJ2P1x6aljGKndnARlbz8nBO@DFQOV5U7ykZ49/1sHhmjldVt23bu@ib25pZGKL/cw0tsxC@HQ7hO3qR4kcZSKECJWjV2GlBMT5EqchELgoxEVMhEyGlkEgpv0lwNkEuR01KnUDIsU4EFVA@xVmBqgz1gUSuEDIVMhOKqtRUaGylB9BAIBKdC4UXkRKK0FUitBZ6SqA6EaoQKf5@ghTvmUlOQaXAAwZUCzkRGtkgoGmhxWuDRg11tJ6USj@3DFJSjGr6KwyTeSfoyQKaIfNOYNAgQ0RdOf6g8HpJfeFj8s2LIXVeOWH@9yDOyEtNAgogSA@mCD8hiJxuIPWaJyRHk3lkC/TAkFN5RgIVqSYzpuTElNgLcpYcU97FjByfeEcSsvCkRJEAusCcKMlKVKcB6JS3GxCaLoVOqRgBpikIkS429VMJfz2a1BCl7wWZJtlgAmpOo6d@SO1VeC3ny9NUX/wF) - **ECMAScript 2018**
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VVHbjtMwFHz3V5gIKUk5VPElV4h44wt4a3koNMsGhbRKitRd8e9l5nQRoCR2jj2eMzM@P10eT3O4jT/Op@Vi16dVluHbcDWL7e2SJMkt666b/Lr/st1ke3ftfr3OPrx/tXdcyPMbEDvXvXWf39nnvjAPp8VOdpxJtF0vx3HujLXjg33u7HkZ50uW3@tpmLMpt4f5aKcdjvd9up/Tzk79tCvI9y/sz9lhPvbJx8O0Dp1NuK1St@twWL4@ZovYtEvtG47b76dxztJruuG5MbcUNlLYtF3P03jJUknz/A7O7QBKm3xafoLYJpT4t@GU05q7OePEGy@cA/6CsMaHKkopldTSSCuuEOfEYcvrT4G1BnsVMJEnwVBhboQA7kes1UCVwBuHvVpcFFeKJ8q3EvDrlCCAgU1CJR4vKi@e7L6QECS0JA2F@FoiRlUQ8b50ci1aefRBB6DFNRKwawzVwot6g8cAd5zvTp3qdibSMdAcPcSUmgSf0lBDqUlAqClR8VSFES3UL93XWjM3NUN36pyc/z2oS2YZaKAGg1MyT/6CFBVvIKrnhnYCw2Ms8INA7vCSBj1dM4yWSbTsXjNZJuY1xZKJN5pIwQjvTjwN8AIrtmSUQEeDdl7jBkXgpXCVYBRQU5ORFxtVlej1BLphSz2LZoG20QmsFaVHFRnUhXp5ubxAfP0b) / [Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=VVLNjtMwGJQ4-ilMhJSkfFvFdv4h4sYTcGs5dGnKBoW0SrJSt-JNuOwF3oEDD7K8AW_BjLOIRUntfPZ4vplxv34_3c03x-H-R_f5dBxnPd1NMrYf27MadaPHIAi-3c6Hq_JnVJ9X8Xl7vV5FW3Ouv7yI3rx-vjVciOMF8_Ab8I2pr8z7V_rSJOpwHHWvu4Gs62ned0OttO4O-lLr09gNcxQvdd8OUR_r3bDX_QbHmybcDmGt-6bfJOR7Cvt7th32TfB2109trQNue93rqd2NH26iUXRYh_olx_WnYzdE4Tlc8VwXawrrKKxfT6e-m6NQwjhewLFuQamDd-MtiHVAif8a9jGtmcXw_a9nF6OMWGWFs8OXE9b4oUolk1wKKaUSk4gxYrBl_UeCtRJ7OTApT4Ihx1wKAdxPsVYAlQGvDPYKMamYTCxRthKHT-MJHBjYxOVi8aKyYsluE3FOXEVSl4gtJMXoFaR4HzuZCq0s-qAD0GJKcdhVimrhxXuDRwd3nBenxus2KqVjoDlaiMl8EnwyRQ2ZTwJCVYaKp3KMaOH90n3ha-bmzdCdd07O_x7UGbN0NFCAwXgyS_6EFDlvIPWeS9pxDI-xwA8CWeAZDVq6ZhgVk6jYvWCyTMz6FDMmXvpEEka4OLE0wAvM2ZJRAp0qtLM-blA4XgpXCUYBNQUZebGpVyX-ehzdsKU_i2aOttEJrDmlp16k8y68l8fLc8QXy3_wDw) - **Python (with `regex`)**
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VVHLbtswELzrK1iBhSRnHYikHrZcowEK9NZbb0lQuCkTq1BlQ1ZgIY6/3Z1hAhSFJFLLXc7szO53Rz8ctr7rLnpY3w7@yU/3TdP7Y3qTXNJmmmXT3c/rWXpnpuZVp58/fbgzPMiyS3Ij8Zfdn33b@V9xttIv63z1uBv85mGb6k61vdJtv38es1P7mOqX7HQc2tHPt7vDeEaxWSmed9ed75/GbXbSm7Xu5od9146xxCulp3XcxFdpqjfqVX1Up2RKZrdtP97rH@ds/nvX9shnV1hW6h@2mvc79N@1vVexTskxXH/bjA9bf0j1lGWn5OumO/gmOSuPHbjfh2ffqOScKd3F5/PFREZsZIW7w58TxvgQFVJKJbUsZCkmF2PEIGXDT46zBXIVagreBEKFfSEsYL7AWY2qEvWRQa4WU4gpxbLKLsXh1wQABwSSuEosXkRWLNFtLs6JWxLU5WJrKbCGDgq870xmCSoLHjCgWsxCHLJRxG6hJWiDRgd13N@UmtC3iQoqRjVXi2bK4ASfMmIPZXACjUYlIt6qsIIi6KX6OsT0LYihuqCcmP89iEt66SigBoIJYJb4OSEqTqAImheU42gebYEeGPJWXlKgpWqasaQTS7LXdJaO2eBiSccXwZGcFr4psRTAAVakpJWoLiLQ2WA3IByHwlMWI0A3NRE52CJ0JWE8jmpIGe6CzFE2mIBasfUiNOmCiqDlfXiO9fVf) - **.NET**

A port of the <s>37</s> <s>30</s> 28 byte version, using variable-length right-to-left evaluated lookbehind instead of lookinto. Like it, returns "match" for falsy and "no match" for truthy **(inverted logic)**.

```
               # No anchor - can match starting at any point in the string
(:x*)x\b       # Start at any list element; \1 = {that element} - 1, including
               # the bounding character on its left side, consuming it without
               # consuming the bounding character following it.
.*             # Skip to any subsequent position in the string
(
    \1x:       # Match any subsequent list element whose value equals \1 + 1
|          # or...
    $          # Assert that we're at the end of the string
    (?<!       # Negative lookbehind - using right-to-left evaluation starting
               # from the current position (so read this from bottom to top),
               # assert that the following cannot match:
        \1\b   # Assert that head==\1, or if \1==0 this can match at the edge
               # of any element in the list (if we didn't need \1==0 to be able
               # to match, we could have used "\1:" instead)
        .*     # Skip to anywhere in the string, putting it in head
    )
)
```

Using comma delimiting (e.g. `xxx,x,xx`) instead of this input method, would take +5 bytes:

```
\b(x*)x\b.*(,\1x\b|$(?<!\b\1\b.*))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dVHLbtswELzrK9SggMiEEURSD9uKmlML5JJD21tdILJNOWxV2aVkR4Drb3dnaR9aIIEe5HJ3Z3aGP@p93S@d3Q633WZlTk2VlK76bNYfxy37MjjbrWNXvzyd5gs2XvNxvoivmZhLbP68Z/d37@aLuaRDzk9Pcd/apWFS3ErOS2d@76wzLHKmXrW2MxGPl9gP5qEbjGtqlB5st90Ns63bLE3fx/2wst2Rx5uORb5DtNWHw766euj2dWtX4bk8vCptwxr@T9tmN8Qvzg6gm3cRL5tKlkEY2iZkbdyabj088wOa2Lpq437b2oFFIuL8kruT/PAq2p6Xr563/Gja3hzAEYbNxjFbJWKsoqi0d@sLaGlvbjyp7R/rR1ZX29r1JJ6tv9nvnL9NOWL6Baz6WR6pnY83FaYtaRmj2JktXGQ1L4@eHiXju@otBWP8qx6Wz8zxqup2bXsffXU7MwvDaBZ9qqFhFsKv4zF8QydS/CQDKVSgBK0aOy0oxocoFZnIRSEmYipkIqQUEinlNwnOJsjlqEmpEwg51omgAsqnOCtQlaE@kMgVQqZCZkJRlZoKja30ABoIRKJzofAiUkIRukqE1kJPCVQnQhUixd9PkOK9MMkpqBR4wIBqISdCIxsENC20eG3QqKGO1rNS6eeWQUqKUU1/hWEy7wQ9WUAzZN4JDBpkiKgrxx8UXi@pL3xMvnkxpM4rJ8z/HsQZealJQAEE6cEU4ScEkdMNpF7zhORoMo9sgR4Yci7PSKAi1WTGlJyYEntBzpJjyruYkeMT70hCFp6VKBJAF5gTJVmJ6jQAnfJ2A0LTpdApFSPANAUh0sWmfirhr0eTGqL0vSDTJBtMQM1p9NQPqb0Kr@VyeZrqi78) - ECMAScript 2018

## Regex (<sub><sup>.NET</sup></sub>), <sub><sup><s>36</s></sup></sub> 35 bytes

```
^:(x*:(?=.*(?<=:(x(?(2)\2)):.*)))*$
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VVFdj9owEHzPr4giV4m5BcV2PiAUcVKlvvWtb9drha6@I1UaUMgJdJTfTmfMSVWVxM561zM7s/vd0Q@Hre@6qxpWD4N/8afHpun9MbtPr9@b7DRpsvVqNsnWH1eIsnVm9TerdTObaK0n6preS/Jp93vfdv5nopfqbZUvn3eD3zxtM9XFbR@rtt@/jvrcPmfqTZ@PQzv66XZ3GC8oNsuY592s8/3LuNVntVmpbnrYd@2YSLKM1WmVNMldlqlN/Cf@EJ/TUzp5aPvxUf246OmvXdsjr@@wLON/2PG030FF1/Y@TlRGjmH2ZTM@bf0hUyetz@nX4dU3cXqJfXfwwP28wd6kFx2rLrlcriYyYiMr3B3@nDDGh6iQUiqpZS4LMbkYIwYpG35ynM2Rq1BT8CYQKuxzYQHzBc5qVJWojwxytZhCTCmWVXYhDr8mADggkMRVYvEismKJbnNxTtyCoC4XW0uBNXRQ4H1nMgtQWfCAAdVi5uKQjSJ2Cy1BGzQ6qON@U2pC3yYqqBjVXC2aKYMTfMqIPZTBCTQalYh4q8IKiqCX6usQ07cghuqCcmL@9yAu6aWjgBoIJoBZ4ueEqDiBImieU46jebQFemDIrbykQEvVNGNBJxZkr@ksHbPBxZKOz4MjOS28KbEUwAFWpKSVqC4i0NlgNyAch8JTFiNANzUROdgidCVhPI5qSBnugsxRNpiAWrH1IjTpgoqg5X14jvX1Xw)

<sub>Golfwise, this is obsoleted by the 29 byte version directly above, but is kept here due to still being close in length, and using a different algorithm.</sub>

A port of the 29 byte PCRE+`(?^=)`<sup>[RME](https://github.com/Davidebyzero/RegexMathEngine)</sup> version, using variable-length right-to-left evaluated lookbehind instead of lookinto. Like it, returns "match" for truthy and "no match" for falsy.

```
^                     # Anchor to start
:                     # Consume initial bounding character
(                     # Loop the following:
    x*:               # Consume one list element
    (?=               # Lookahead
        .*            # Skip to later in the string (".*$" would be faster)
        (?<=          # Lookbehind - evaluated right-to-left (so read this
                      # from bottom to top)
            :             # Consume one bounding character
            # Assert head==1 (on the first iteration) or head==\2+1 (on
            # subsequent iterations), capturing this as the new value of \2
            (
                x         # Append one more "x" (if this is the first iteration,
                          # captures just one)
                (?(2)\2)  # If \2 is set (i.e., if we're not on the first
                          # iteration) then include the previous value of
                          # \2 in its new value
            )
            :.*           # Skip to any list element, putting it in head
        )
    )
)*                    # Iterate the above as many times as possible, minimum 0
$                     # Assert we've reached the end of the string
```

Using comma delimiting (e.g. `xxx,x,xx`) instead of this input method, would take +2 bytes:

```
^(x+,?(?=.*(?<=\b(x(?(2)\2))\b.*)))*$
```

But that regex is incredibly slow, and it takes another +2 bytes to give it reasonable speed:

```
^(x+\b,?(?=.*(?<=\b(x(?(2)\2))\b.*)))*$
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VVHLbtswELzrKwSDhUh3bYikHn7UcIACvfXWW5wWTsrEKlTZkBXEiOtvd2eYAEUhidSSw5md4WH/EvrjLrTtVfWr2z48hdPdYtGFF32TXb/r08fNvaz1ejUd6/Wn1eZen/RaO7Nxxmzup2NjzFhdsxsZfd7/PjRt@DkyS/W6ypeP@z5sH3ZatWnTparpDs@DOTePWr2a80vfDGGy2x@HC8B2mXK9nbahexp25qy2K9VOjoe2GUYyWqbqtNJabdM/6Yf0nJ2y8W3TDXfqx8VMfu2bDhizTP9xppNuDwdt04V0pDS5@@nX7fCwC0etTsacs2/9c1ik2SUN7TGA88sW8yK7mFS1o8vlahMrLnHC2ePPC2t8qAoppZJaZjIXm4u1YrHl4k@OtRn2KmAKngRDhXkmBHC/wFoNVAl8YrFXiy3EluKIcnPx@LWRwIOBIr4ShxeVE0d2l4v34uck9bm4WgqMsYMC77uSnUPKQQcKQIudicdukrBbeIne4NHDHec3pzb2bZOCjoHm6NBMGZPgUybsoYxJoNGkRMVTFUZIRL90X8eauUUzdBedk/O/B3XJLD0N1GCwkcyRPydFxRsooucZ7XiGx1jgB4G8wUsadHTNMOZMYk71mskyMRdTLJn4LCaSM8I3J44GeIEVJRkl0EUCORfjBoXnpXCVYBTopiYjL7aIXUm8Hk83lIxnIeZpG0pgrdh6EZv00UX08n55nvj6Lw)

## Regex (<sub><sup>ECMAScript 2018 /</sup></sub> Java <sub><sup>/ Python<sup>[`regex`](https://github.com/mrabarnett/mrab-regex)</sup> / .NET</sup></sub>), <sub><sup><s>44</s> <s>37</s></sup></sub> 35 bytes

```
(:x*)x\b(.*\1x:|(?<!(?=.*\1\b)^.*))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dVHLbtswELzrK5RcRCaMIJJ62FbUnFoglxza3uoWUWzKYavKLiU7Ahx/uztL@9ACCfQgl7s7szP8We/qfuHsZrjp1ktzbKqkdNVns/o4btiXwdluFbv65fHIZuMVH@dPLL6ay3H2yu5uL9hdRdH8if@Irzg/PsZ9axeGSXEjOS@d@bO1zrDImXrZ2s5EPF5gP5j7bjCuqVG6t91mO8w2br0wfR/3w9J2Bx6vOxb5DtFWH/a76vK@29WtXYan8vCytA1r@D9t6@0Qvzg7gG7eRbxsKlkGYWibkLVxa7rV8Mz3aGKrqo37TWsHFomI83PuVvL9m2g7Xr553vKDaXuzB0cYNmvHbJWIsYpmUWlvV2fU0l5fe1bbP9QPrK42tetJPVt9s985f59zxPhP8OpXeaB2Pl57aFrGKHZmAxtZzcvDOeHHQOV4Ub2nZIx/18PimTleVd22be@ir25rZmGI/k81tMxC@HY4hO/oRYofZSCFCpSgVWOnBcX4EKUiE7koxERMhUyElEIipfwmwdkEuRw1KXUCIcc6EVRA@RRnBaoy1AcSuULIVMhMKKpSU6GxlR5AA4FIdC4UXkRKKEJXidBa6CmB6kSoQqT4@wlSvGcmOQWVAg8YUC3kRGhkg4CmhRavDRo11NF6Uir93DJISTGq6a8wTOadoCcLaIbMO4FBgwwRdeX4g8LrJfWFj8k3L4bUeeWE@d@DOCMvNQkogCA9mCL8hCByuoHUa56QHE3mkS3QA0NO5RkJVKSazJiSE1NiL8hZckx5FzNyfOIdScjCkxJFAugCc6IkK1GdBqBT3m5AaLoUOqViBJimIES62NRPJfz1aFJDlL4XZJpkgwmoOY2e@iG1V@G1nC9PU33xFw) - ECMAScript 2018
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bVJdb9s2FH3Xr2D0UtJhVUuULH9MC7rCBQK0wTAXfWm6QbbphKkkqyLdOMj827NzKXVYusKyyPt17j3n6q78Vr682355MnW77xy7gx2ZfTRasP96Ds5UP/V1@kYfKdIe1pXZsE1VWsvel6Zhj4PLutLh@LY3W1YjwFeuM80NK7sb@@mzYO62299btjxudOvMHoUBY29NpdmuaPS9v/Iw2uy3OkI8FIvfDrud7vT2D11udcfWPu25k3@vHMydEIuhr5VucX9L@JzbYg0K5fadaTQX4qxoDlUlzI7bSH89lJXl4avRaBQK8fg8tUfg3P0U4BEI7l8EALwCwhp5Xxb2vHhx3byg0y1Ove/0e@mc7hrWFcMNbOuWGlj53fPm9Wr51@XVanm1uvxw@XEpFpBptSmbBhKYpj04VjBiPfj46sE6XUemEdhb45gpxgs2EPf50W1pr/TRYW72yDCyOSvGYijbI95CL1c1nACKmPqhYy9ihWY9SAOEQRNgMH5WRcYu69Y9eNz3pdvcYsIaBV1U9xYP5@F5jxTd7fFJwJbsddeVDzayDqLUvIpsWxnHQwntUNjy5uWv4TGE3K0uHb9sHL69LmrLzmoYvBHIc3uPMnxjnz7P55BEiHM0wHw/cuN1tDPNlgt2wcK3WJaes5Dh/6E74MpQc/p/UQXv6RTQh/HE58eROF6veTS6jo/zv/nFL2f8oiDrei3@jEZCPNH@n@IglkmQSDoVbkqSjT@sVGZyInM5lTMZj2UcyxihxF/G8E0RmyAnpUogTHBOJSVQPIUvR1aG/CBGLJdxKuNMJpSVzKTCNfYACgjURE1kggdWIhNCT8ZSKalmBKrGMsllirefIMUzdIpnaJWgDzogW8ZTqRANApoWXDw3cFRgR2fPNPZzx0FKjJFN7wTDZF4J@mUBzZB5JTBokMGiqgneaOH5Evvc26SbJ0PsPHPCfPaDnZGWigjkQIg9WEL4Y4KY0AZSz3lKdBSJR7KADwTp0zMimBBrEmNGSsyoe07KkmKJVzEjxadekTFJ2DNJiAAtcEItSUpkpwHaJV5uQChaCnkpGQamyQmRFpv6qaRfjyI21NLXopki2ugE1AmNnvohlWfhuQzLU5Sf/wM) - **Java**
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VVHbjpswFHz3V7i8AOkpwjb3Fu1bv6BvSStlG3aXFSURpFJ21X9PZ062aivA5tjjOTPj08v56TiH6/jjdFzOdn1ZZRkeh4tZbG@XKIquSXfZpJfdfZJtdu7S/UruPr1L7npWu/v0W7ZJ0ytwW9d9cF8/2tc@Nw/HxU52nEmXrefDOHfG2vHBvnb2tIzzOUlv9TTMyZTa/Xyw0xbH@z7ezXFnp37a5uT7F/bn7DAf@ujzflqHzkbcVsHZOuyX70/JIjbuYvueY/Z8HOckvsQbnhtTS2EjhU3ZeprGcxJLnKY3cGoHUNroy/ITxDaixL8Np5TW3NUZJ9544RzwF4Q1PlSFlFJJLY204nJxThy2vP7kWGuwVwFT8CQYKsyNEMD9Ams1UCXwxmGvFleIK8UT5VsJ@HVKEMDAJqESjxeVF092n0sIElqShlx8LQVGVVDgfevkWrTy6IMOQItrJGDXGKqFF/UGjwHuON@cOtXtTEHHQHP0EFNqEnxKQw2lJgGhpkTFUxVGtFC/dF9rzdzUDN2pc3L@96AumWWggRoMTsk8@XNSVLyBQj03tBMYHmOBHwRyg5c06OmaYbRMomX3mskyMa8plky80URyRnhz4mmAF1ixJaMEujBo5zVuUAReClcJRgE1NRl5sYWqEr2eQDdsqWfRLNA2OoG1ovRCRQZ1oV7eLi8QX/8G) / [Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=VVJLjtNAFJRY9ikas7Ad3ljubv_Bmh0nYJeAlCEOY2ScyPFImRE3YTMbuANHGW7ALahqBwGy0_Zz16tXVZ2v34_38-1hfPzRfz4eplmf7k8ydR-7s5p0q6cgCL7dzfur6ulF1JxX8XlzEyWrjTk3X6Lr18-j65bV5iZ-n6zi-AL9ha61aa7Mu1f6oU3V_jDpQfcjyZPTvOvHRmnd7_VDo49TP85RvNRDN0ZDrLfjTg9rtLdtuBnDRg_tsE7J9y_sT2837trgzXY4dY0OuO3lJ6duO324jSbRYRPql1yTT4d-jMJzuGJfH2sK6ylsSE7HoZ-jUMI4XsCx7kCpg7fTHYh1QIl_Bw4xrZnF8OPPZw9GGbHKCp8Ob05Y44cqk1wKKaWSWkwqxojBlvUvKb5V2CuAydgJhgLPSgjgfoZvJVA58MpgrxSTicnFEmVrcXg1nsCBgUNcIRY3KiuW7DYV58TVJHWp2FIyrF5BhvsyydQYZTEHE4AWU4nDrlJUCy_eGzw6uONzcWq8bqMyOgaaq4WY3CfBK1fUkPskIFTlqNhVYMUI75fuS18zN2-G7rxzcv53oc6ZpaOBEgzGk1nyp6QoeAKZ91zRjmN4jAV-EMgCz2nQ0jXDqJlEzeklk2Vi1qeYM_HKJ5IywsWJpQEeYMGRjBLoTGGc9XGDwvFQ-JVgFFBTkpEHm3lV4o_H0Q1H-l4Mc7SNSWAtKD3zIp134b1cDs8RXy7_wd8) - Python (with `regex`)
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VVFdb5tAEHznV1B0FeCsLe6ODxvXSqRKeetb3@K0ctJLTEWxhYmC4vi3uzPnSFUF3LG3ezM7s/vdq@sPW9e2Z9Wv7nr37Mb7uu7ca3ITn5N6nKTj@iGZTdZ6rN@T6y@fkusVo/VD@mM2SdNzfCPR192ffdO6X1G6VG@rbPm0693mcZuoNmy6UDXd/mVIj81Tot7S42vfDG663R2GE4r1MuR5O2td9zxs06ParFQ7PezbZogkWoZqXEV1dJUkahO@h5/DYzzGk7umG@7Vz1M6/b1rOuTTKyzL8B92OO12UNE2nQsjlZCjn33bDI9bd0jUmKbH@HbTHlwdn0KHHbjf@xdXh/EpDVUbnU5nHWgxgRHuFn9WGONDlEshpVQyl4XoTLQWjZTxPxnO5siVqMl5Ewgl9rmwgPkcZxWqCtQHGrlKdC66EMMqsxCLX@0BLBBIYksxeBEZMUQ3mVgrdkFQm4mpJMfqO8jxfjDpBagMeMCAatFzscgGAbuFFq8NGi3Ucb8o1b5vHeRUjGquBs0U3gk@RcAeCu8EGg0KRLxVYgWF10v1lY/pmxdDdV45Mf97EBf00lJABQTtwQzxM0KUnEDuNc8px9I82gI9MORSXlCgoWqasaATC7JXdJaOGe9iQcfn3pGMFl6UGArgAEtS0kpU5wHojLcbEJZD4SmLEaCbiogcbO67Ej8eSzWk9HdBZikbTEAt2Xrum7RehdfyMTzL@uov) - .NET

Based on the <s>37</s> <s>30</s> 28 byte version **(inverted logic)**.

Java needs to be "hinted" as to how far the lookbehind should go, thus necessitating the use of a lookahead inside the lookbehind.

## Regex (ECMAScript+`(?*)`<sup>[RME](https://github.com/Davidebyzero/RegexMathEngine)</sup> / PCRE2 <sub><sup>v10.35+</sup></sub>), <sub><sup><s>41</s></sup></sub> 39 bytes

```
^(?*.*(:x*)x:)((.*\1x\b){2}|(?!.*\1\b))
```

[Try it on replit.com](https://replit.com/@Davidebyzero/Is-this-a-Permutation-of-1-to-n-inverted) - **ECMAScript+`(?*)`** (RegexMathEngine `-xml`)
[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=pVbbbttGEAX6VPAr1goQLeW1y4tuFk0Hqa0iBnwJFBlNY7uETK0sIhRJkFTtOPGX9KUvfcxr_yX5ms7MriTKStuH6kLtZW7nzOysfv8cZvG8wG9wG4afL2s7cRbm0tnp1q6_DJ6N5SRKJHt9OOg7weH5UT-4ODseBj8fHw1fsa7xLErCeD6WbJ-UdqcHRjgd5SzILq-Zzwa1H-_u3t-4818-fHg7nLbvpvzPeTnZ6X6p_8pfNHYbvHffMO97Jue7jSv7_urG_Og8fuIvtnAKM1OJf_3-L_OppZpgjcwPsm3bq4RRlHmU3GIcq7UohVU5mh1syB0YUVKyDIZlIPM8zXmYJkXJCENjJotidCtN9rEox71eCBJsf5_pZRzSukzGscdyWc7zhNne44ZNnIfpWAp2k6YxS_3JKC7QLLnR5i6dVvvaMxi8ognjRGdwK7WNQEtxZYerfFwcvno56DZMvSlYET3IdMKXgf-wWKnIm6ZJXvDFU_ZCgQjTecl6bAnURHg1UmMUQY_VnoAn5VoNtGpXSc1c8jGBWpoqJEtSDMXKbBQlHIDTZnYJSYhlwjNzx772LY_NQcZ1ghIospQBMqhyxaIkm5ceU8wgD6yRy8V8NirDaTAelSPI23LsMfSay2Iel0Lh8HQtvzl-16eVyaSQsAn4IZbbcrom0Eh_k2EJWhoO1PTC_yyLYsk1s29eDwdmJrTqu_7gPBj2B6fHZy-H_aPFcv_tsH921D9in_TC6cXJ8Pjk-Kwv2HMKTv_qkCxzVQ9bOaRT01mtLXpquQoH_gYtAcxHpQwmeToLslFZyjzhOdTM2cXJiTZQ1YGDUMr7EthcjPxv7WuzfMMKINCScTSLSr4wI9iObXoVobHMyv8UymU4z4soTb4pSG4nac7oqD1gKVHhwPGJoXtxVdVRIlQNmd6iBBfsPpgM1vE48vpVUgfXD77t0RZp7OIx4qbvWyZDz1Eyl97KAjiF2kG3qnEUq71lVFlagMCa54VuIu8C0BcsAY5HZRppp2EAlQ_HZRuVTdjGvI5uCp7gBIVhZZvxZH9RKVVMqPPEGZ0oUOMYZsOEzMVxGvICGoqOATbxuc1s-CaJqUf2E_tk6BIkt7exzdd79fX9Ryahw_2795lyXvH8P31uMIC8KBVS2HmiMJMzKC1egC-FmRQEq9_XkWsoAhWWDnBdGdiFLZUnuCHHvC5AC1cp8kUGmO9Xe1ivl1BaboD6954S97E9boJ4AnWFw1pJq8a2fjDpTFe7EmSXisuiz6ohwFgfogrRGLayum-x58-1hy1fN7DB4HwQnJ2fvhwevjLX-aj0pEW_LfO5rNjGkljTWV08eJsorQPfwlvlJ7wh8cqB7xDM9Bj79g2zYUfdEqvzl0s4_zqKx3_qcgGJrfjY7J5KYDk3q_eQ2oQGvfwXoLDAraf-vvzx9bsH27CFYzgCf10YuQLn8IVZU7REW3REV-wJ2xK2LWzYcmhgwVoX9tog00RNsNCG365AAdxvwloHpFogb9iw1xF2U9gt4aCUsydcGNpkwAUL6MRtCwc-MHOEg9YdS7iucPfQqGsJpyOa8KQImvDRnuw9cOWAH_AA0sLuChd2DQOjBSyEDTC6gA5_FVKb4raNJiIGaXw6EEyLmMB3y8AYWsQEBGq0YIZabXiCC8KL6Ds0R94IDKIj5Ghz7Q3zFnLpIoAOWLDJmIP2LTTRxgw0CXMX4bhIHtICeIAQJd5CgA6iRjL2kIk99N5BZpExh1hsIeNdYsRCChUSBwFgAtvoEqkE6aYB7hyiG0y4mBRcRWGYQDQdtIiJbVJUgtLjIhp0SbrgzEXY4AmstjH0JgXpEgrCopPnonxH1eDf) - **PCRE2 v10.40+**

A port of the <s>38</s> <s>31</s> 29 byte version, using molecular lookahead instead of variable-length right-to-left evaluated lookbehind. Like it, returns "match" for falsy and "no match" for truthy **(inverted logic)**.

```
^                # Anchor to start
(?*              # Molecular (non-atomic) lookahead - try all possible matches
    .*(:x*)x:    # Skip to any list element; \1 = {the element} - 1, including
                 # the bounding character on its left side
)
(
    (
        .*\1x\b  # Match and consume any subsequent list element whose value
                 # equals \1 + 1, without consuming the bounding character on
                 # its right side (to allow this group to be repeated)
    ){2}         # Iterate the above 2 times
|          # or...
    (?!          # Negative lookahead - assert that the following cannot match:
        .*       # Skip to any list element, putting it in tail (Works in
                 # concert with the following expression's matching of the
                 # left-side bounding character contained in \1)
        \1\b     # Assert that tail==\1, or if \1==0 this can match at the edge
                 # of any element in the list (if we didn't need \1==0 to be
                 # able to match, we could have used "\1:" instead)
    )
)
```

## Regex (<sub><sup>ECMAScript+`(?*)`<sup>[RME](https://github.com/Davidebyzero/RegexMathEngine)</sup> / PCRE2 <sub><sup>v10.35+</sup></sub></sup></sub>), <sub><sup><s>44</s></sup></sub> 42 bytes

```
^(?!.*(:x*)\b.*\1:|(?*.*(:x+)x:)(?!.*\2:))
```

[Try it on replit.com](https://replit.com/@Davidebyzero/Is-this-a-Permutation-of-1-to-n) - ECMAScript+`(?*)` (RegexMathEngine `-xml`)
[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=pVbNbttGEAZ6KvgUGwWIuNLa5Y_-LJo2EltFDDh2oMhoGtslZGplEaFIgqRqx02epJdeesy175I8TWdmVxJlpe2htkTu7vx-38zu6vfPYRYvCvwGt2H4-bK2E2dhLp2dXu36y_DpRE6jRLLXR8OBExydHw-Ci7OTUfDTyfHoJesZT6MkjBcTyfbJaHd2YISzcc6C7PKa-WxYe3F39_7GXfz84cPb0axzNzP_XJTTnd6Xxi_m4ZPdhtm_b_Crm93Gld3_aB42aKXJ7_ucxFdOn3Nl8fX7v_hjZzXBGpkfZE3bq2RSlHmU3GIq67UohVU5nh9s6R0YUVKyDIZlIPM8zc0wTYqSEYzGXBbF-FZy9ltRTvr9EDTY_j7TyzikdZlMYo_lslzkCbO9T1s-cR6mEynYTZrGLPWn47hAtxRGu7t02p1rz2DwF02ZSYwGt1L7CLSWqfyYqiQXRy-fD3sNroWCFdGDTKfmKvEflisVfc45RcE_M2WHCkSYLkrWZyugHOHVyIxRBn1WewSejGs1sKpdJTW-4mMK7TRTSFakGIqV-ThKTABOwuwSihDLxMz4jn3tWx5bgI7rBCVQZCkH5FDVikVJtig9pphBHlgjl8v5fFyGs2AyLsdQt9XYYxg1l8UiLoXC4el2fnPybkAr02khQQj4IZfbcrah0Eh_lWEJVhoOtPUy_jyLYmlqZt-8Hg15JrTpu8HwPBgNhq9Ozp6PBsfL5cHb0eDseHDMPuqFVxeno5PTk7OBYM8oOf3WKVl83Q9PciinprPaW_TUehUO_C1aApiPSxlM83QeZOOylHli5tAzZxenp9pB1QY2QinvS2BzOfK_JdduzS0vgEBrxtE8Ks2lG8F2bO5VlCYyK_9TKZfhIi-iNPmmIoWdpjmjrfaArUSNA9snhgPMVF0dJUL1EPeWLbhk94EzWMftaNavkjqEfvBtj0RksYvbyOS-b3GGkaNkIb21BwgKvYNh1cFRrGWrrLK0AIWNyEvbRN4FYC9YAhyPyzTSQcMAOh-2SxONOYixruObwkxwgsqw0mRmsr_slComtHkUjHYUmJmYZoND5eI4Dc0CDhSdAwjx2WQ2fJOE65H9yD85ugTNZhNP-nq_vin_xCSccP8efa6CVyL_z5hbDCAvyoQMdh4ZzOUcWsssIJbCTAaC1e_ryDU0gUpLJ7hpDOyCSNUJLsmJWRdghauU-bICzPerZ1i_n1BZboD6955S9_F43AbxCOoah7XWVgfb5sakPV09laC61FwWfdYHAoz1JqoQjWkrr_sWe_ZMR3ji6wNsODwfBmfnr56Pjl7yTT4qZ9LyvC3zhaz4xpbYsFlfPHibKKsD38JbZQSmfcbocvkRb0t4f_OG2fKjbon1_ssl7H-dxad_OuUCUlvzsX16KoXVnFfvISWEA3r1K0BhgVtP_Xz54-t3D7ZhC8dwBL5dGLkC5_CFWUu0RUd0RU_sCdsSti1sEDk0sGCtB7IO6LTQEjx04N0TqIDyFqx1QasN-oYNsq6wW8JuCwe1nD3hwtAmBy54wCBuRzjwgZkjHPTuWMJ1hbuHTl1LOF3Rgidl0IKPjmTvQSgH4kAE0BZ2T7ggNQzMFrAQNsDoAjp8K6Q25W0bLUQM2vh0IJk2MYH_bQNzaBMTkKjRhhladeAJIQgvou_SHHkjMIiOkKPPjX-Yt5FLFwF0wYNNzhz0b6GLDlagRZh7CMdF8pAWwAOEKPU2AnQQNZKxh0zsYfQuMouMOcRiGxnvESMWUqiQOAgAC9jBkEglaLcMCOcQ3eDCxaLgKirDBLLpokcsbIuyElQeF9FgSLKFYC7ChkjgtYOptyhJl1AQFl08F_W7qgf_Bg) - PCRE2 v10.40+

Asserts that there exists no element \$n\$ for which there is a subsequent duplicate element \$n\$, and that there exists no element \$n≥2\$ for which there is no element \$n-1\$ anywhere in the list.

Returns "match" for truthy and "no match" for falsy.

This non-inverted logic version is being kept up, despite losing in golf to the inverted logic <s>41</s> 39 byte version above, to show how close it comes in length. This is because the second half of the logic, that asserts there are no non-consecutive elements, cannot be golfed by inverted logic, since the `.*:` must be inside the molecular lookahead.

```
^                  # Anchor to start
(?!                # Negative lookahead - assert that the following cannot match:
    .*(:x*)\b      # Skip to any list element; \1 = the element, including the
                   # bounding character on its left side
    .*             # Skip to any list element, putting it in tail (Works in
                   # concert with the following expression's matching of the
                   # left-side bounding character contained in \1)
    \1:            # Assert tail == \1
|              # or...
    (?*            # Molecular (non-atomic) lookahead - try all possible matches
        .*(:x+)x:  # Skip to any list element that's ≥ 2; \2 = {the element} - 1,
                   # including the bounding character on its left side
    )
    (?!            # Negative lookahead - only matches outside if the pattern
                   # inside fails to match.
        .*         # Skip to any list element, putting it in tail (Works in
                   # concert with the following expression's matching of the
                   # left-side bounding character contained in \2)
        \2:        # Assert tail == \2
    )
)
```

Comment: This is not Rosetta Stone

Answer (score 2):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 2 bytes

```
ż⊍
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/?v=1#WyJBIiwiIiwixbziio0iLCIiLCJbMSwyLDMsNCw1LDYsNyw4LDksMTAsMTEsMTldXG5bMSwyLDMsNCw1LDYsNyw4LDksMTAsMTEsMTJdIl0=)

Uses inverted truthiness (non-empty array for falsy, empty array for truthy)

This follows Vyxal's truthiness conventions, which can be checked using a boolify: [Verify all test cases online! (boolified and logical NOT applied)](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/?v=1#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).

```
ż  # length range
 ⊍ # setwise difference
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2), 2 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
ėṗ
```

Output with inverted booleans (allowed by community consensus). Add the `!` flag if you want `1` for truthy and `0` for falsy.

##### Explanation

```
ė   # Length range
 ṗ  # Set difference
```

##### Screenshot

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Is the bytecount correct? It looks like 2 to me

Comment: @emirps thanks for pointing it out. Either it was a typo or I genuinely can't count :p

Answer (score 2):

## [Nekomata](https://github.com/AlephAlpha/Nekomata) + `-e`, 3 bytes

```
x↕=
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=LZAxTsNQEERFyymQ67H0d_f7f7vgJJYLg0KDAkWClBNwAyqaFImUghNRchJmfiJZlr07O_N2vy9vm9f37bpff-au33Z46PpNtxzPH_uXfjwf_j6_Hk-7p-fdrXL8vVtnGxAFFrAMd1T4iOBnwoCMCEQFKwOcD_8MXsGBCeGIEcbCBC8Ivg2WkPkYEiYY2_AMo97hsIpIiOV-lq_Lmi2mcYoJ7NGbKINgKDY5yHeU6UhP5hBS4daAsuBrc59EU8jsgg95crcrFMUttcqA0_QILah6UyfhFFlSq2MU4QqHrXYYb7NMY3JRFH0HsedG6W2NtsztEC59Wa6n_gc)

Inputs are 0-indexed.

```
x↕=
 ↕    Find a permutation of
x     the range from 0 to the length of the input minus 1
  =   that is equal to the input
```

The `-e` flag prints `True` if there is a solution, and `False` otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

## Python, 39 Bytes

```python
lambda x:sorted(x)==list(range(len(x)))
```

I am an account owned by PlaceReporter99. I am trying to get 20 rep so that I can access the chat rooms.

Comment: This is my bot. Signed, Placereporter99.

Answer (score 2):

## Swift 5.9, <s>50</s> <s>48</s> <s>42</s> 37 bytes

```swift
let p={Set($0+[])==Set(1...$0.count)}
```

[Play the fiddle!](https://swiftfiddle.com/ggyglydn6rgahbpkuflukyuzfi)

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Lyxal/Vyxal) `rR`, <s>5</s> 3 bytes

```
GṖc
```

[Try it Online!](https://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=rR&code=G%E1%B9%96c&inputs=%5B1%2C2%2C5%2C3%5D&header=&footer=)

-2 thanks to lyxal

Comment: [Try it Online!](https://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=r&code=G%C9%BE%E1%B9%96c&inputs=%5B1%2C2%2C5%2C3%5D&header=&footer=) for 4 bytes

Comment: [Try it Online!](https://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=rR&code=G%E1%B9%96c&inputs=%5B1%2C2%2C5%2C3%5D&header=&footer=) for 3

Answer (score 1):

## [C# (Visual C# Interactive Compiler)](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/releases/5.0.0/#csc), 46 bytes

```cs
a=>{a.Sort();int i=1;return a.All(x=>x==i++);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jZE/a8MwEMX3fAqNNnkNOUm2HBwbunTK1kKH0iE1LgiCDY5DAyGf3X1n6FQCRkKcdE/353fN@ak5x@nl0jX7QzyP@9iNNcxX359q881XU03Hqr4dN6/9MCZpSb@JlZRDO16Gzhw3z6dTcq3qa1XF9Tot71O5Wr0PcWwPsWsTDZF07c/Hp7kZMffNW69pkjRNy4cyGLtQmcMFiIdksA4F7A6OpiBHBufhCvAlh@XmzcIWCLBbOAe3g1i4LWyA52khAs9NA7KF7EB9BmEGqiEFHL0PK3tc5tJuluowr4ViTxbs02tLBUhsYRaiszMqgnUK1CpCouWF9IIyZVyFH0hnRkvXPAg7/@VoSDwoaMLNdTLKlgNRU39lf@Cd6sOywhiIWTwDizb0r5/pFw)

Comment: `1,1,1,1,1,1` should be false

Comment: The third test case in your TIO link should be false. That said, removing `Distinct` should fix it.

Comment: I had one of the falsey test cases with my truthy ones, that's what tripped me up, thanks

Answer (score 1):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), 26 bytes

```
\d+
$*_
O`
^
¶
(^¶_|\1_)+$
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VVG7bgMxDNv9HSmQNhxOkh93X9Gha5BLgXbo0qHomO/KB@THrqSSpTifbdkyKVI/n79f3@/b0/7tjO34cSi7l7W8nsup3K5lf7pd18vR1ufDbtusGLw4tAZ3AcX8GVU0dAzMWGATzGC88txMPJt515lT9ZIInesMJei@8mwwqzG/GO8GrMIaXFm@ILi1BAgiiCQ6nIORw4XuEyIQi0Bjgg9UzllB5Xgw2UIqJw8ZmA2bEbwtKpZSUholBsVpvQu1LNtKlWAma3bW0tIIfa2ohJZGsM7SGOlV50yGlCvxI2PZllokLoUL89/HuMnKUP2DCJZgLvxJEF0NqCl5lpqQd3KFcujHPb1Jn0u0vFhkxCL2IWNlmKeJTYbPacgkB@9KXALUvy5KOcnsWkjn6TYhQj3RqZIZsJohRPW1ZlXI7oTUiDLfkiwkm0xE7Sq9ZpGRKlLLo3eh/PEH) Takes input on separate lines but link is to test suite that splits on commas for convenience. 1-indexed. Explanation:

```
\d+
$*_
```

Convert to unary, but using a non-digit character.

```
O`
```

Sort.

```
^
¶
```

Prefix a newline, so that each number is now preceded by a newline.

```
(^¶_|\1_)+$
```

If at the beginning of the buffer, match a newline followed by `1` (in unary), otherwise match one more than the previous match (still with preceding newlines). If the input was a permutation then the buffer will contain an ascending sequence and the match will reach the end of the buffer.

Answer (score 1):

## [Desmos](https://desmos.com/calculator), <s>54</s> 39 bytes

```
f(l)=0^{(l.sort-[1...l.total])^2.total}
```

Test on function `f`. Returns `1` if truthy, `0` if falsey.

<s>To be honest, I thought that the solution would be shorter than this :|. Could most likely be golfed though, with a different strategy than mines.</s>

Ok well I got much better at golfing in Desmos since 2021 and all I can say is that there are some pretty glaring byte saves in my previous version.

[Try It On Desmos!](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/pxv4igc9a8)

[Try It On Desmos! - Prettified](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/wbxexwnc4m)

Answer (score 1):

## [APL(Dyalog Unicode)](https://dyalog.com), <sup><s>11</s></sup>7 bytes <sup>[SBCS](https://github.com/abrudz/SBCS)</sup>

```
∧/⍳∘⍴∊⊢
```

[Try it on APLgolf!](https://razetime.github.io/APLgolf/?h=AwA&c=e9SxXP9R7@ZHHTMe9W551NH1qGsRAA&f=VY/LEcMwCETvroICOAjQzw2lm3STilJJHtg@ZDSDltWyi15i3/fHjpeYONXlwlFd3CwV3GXIlCVbTrEmZmL16AUb7OZ1ouo5X04TtEuSig670A0mjhwl2@/78nria5WoFS78rGTaNTRVXU1de3HOGToKR53EWxdsaCon/aDP@Undmr4zlTCrGHyKy5mN49Lz9v87xQzejEUMVTpZ2XpmtbSa5RUsyzb0qEaqg0hyYGoALpOMoKZOtfRVX@qh3jT4GVZstNIVL7jz/pfnZ/AkjFD3zPd@/AA&i=AwA&r=tryAPL&l=apl-dyalog&m=train&n=f)

- thanks to @ovs for saving 4bytes by using a train!

Old explanation

```
∧/     all
(⍳⍴⍵)  [1..length]
∊⍵     belongs to input?
```

Comment: You can get rid of the parentheses by commuting `∊`: `{∧/⍵∊⍨⍳⍴⍵}`

Comment: and this gets a few bytes shorter as a train: https://razetime.github.io/APLgolf/?h=AwA&c=e9SxXP9R7@ZHHTMe9W551NH1qGsRAA&f=VY/LEcMwCETvroICOAjQzw2lm3STilJJHtg@ZDSDltWyi15i3/fHjpeYONXlwlFd3CwV3GXIlCVbTrEmZmL16AUb7OZ1ouo5X04TtEuSig670A0mjhwl2@/78nria5WoFS78rGTaNTRVXU1de3HOGToKR53EWxdsaCon/aDP@Undmr4zlTCrGHyKy5mN49Lz9v87xQzejEUMVTpZ2XpmtbSa5RUsyzb0qEaqg0hyYGoALpOMoKZOtfRVX@qh3jT4GVZstNIVL7jz/pfnZ/AkjFD3zPd@/AA&i=AwA&r=tryAPL&l=apl-dyalog&m=train&n=f

Comment: @ovs thanks, I still find hard to understand it though.. Trains are so big!

Comment: The [tree representation](https://tryapl.org/?clear&q=%E2%88%A7%2F%E2%8D%B3%E2%88%98%E2%8D%B4%E2%88%8A%E2%8A%A2&run) might help you read the train, and a few links in increasing order of detail that helped me: [1](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/43084/64121) [2](https://help.dyalog.com/latest/Content/Language/Introduction/Trains.htm) [3](https://youtu.be/Enlh5qwwDuY). Trains are definitely one of the more difficult things in learning Dyalog APL.

Answer (score 1):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 16 bytes

```
PermutationListQ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VVLLTsNADLzzG5U4GSlr7ysHEB/AoYgj4hBVreihRSrhVLW/Hma8WySUaLP2emc84xym@XN7mOb9Zlp2j8t6ezr8zAi/ji/77/l1WZ/2x/l99fC0e1593F/fNtPxer47h4tgEeVHpUfWYpN@gA9yUZJkKVJllDBICBLaqfp@QLriOKMsEqKhZWyrsIYlEemCwoQrfhfHRUKUkERZqKMYtsFhDDhksyyKF5GKkkMHMRMbiWuDaJGI1fuIeDtZGMGmoAIDqiVUMZyCF1pb503dTXYzwZr2Hv25EVyVl0Ya40BujaLVdHOOjwfsM7ltEMNEQoIgGWtt8DSHbhVPdbddOa1wpzrLv6elEudg1FwaWnBsJeNAuNzHGN2sSh@MxtNPGAEn241EZ5R20cWRFo5spnAktFrd/sRRVbdyoPdNnlIS55/Jyhmg2psGo/qogGIcKA9YjwANFYLyv4jemPhojbLI6nfBZ3QBZADO7D56n@ZCXE4fvLG@XO4uy/IL)

Answer (score 1):

## [Pari/GP](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/), 31 bytes

```
f(v)=vecsort(v)==vector(#v,i,i)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VVLLTsNADLzzG1waaZCy9j6SA1@CekAIUE6tStXfLzNONgUlSrx@jT2z5/fL8vJ9vt@/Drfh9fb58XO6XGXKvp4uh@cbFiyDEt7ScXjSD7Yaht3j3efYwzTozyioaJgwI41ICanHLU4jAxMTKhOzGvWulYcJylJSZqAxtbBoq2dCQ8pIBaZUm@E0U7Ry9hKmVxhfngwmHBvhDp/V2UdYQ@Y3Zsl8N7g0E88IRgRmI01wRrfF@wJ90QcPnRnvdOyePySlWHQrymKsd5ZpnL48iNWzHTV@CU654@oqdKld5XfqYGJOZLZw7oIELeIpiNwR/z3dWSSXi5TWu6ZAMaGPalt3zXMwOokslz4inWyR7rWmiD4Tp6J6Fs@zxmrSTXpYaFSk5xR8jxJoXda0ni5KFa6EYvY2PDEtFGUfl@4KqYIHjtTUVhcox2iIG@BaTrhRS0QXH4Rj66r5c0zqsUostN0PV347Dr8)

Comment: `v->vecsort(v)==[1..#v]`

Answer (score 1):

## [GolfScript](http://www.golfscript.com/golfscript/), 6 bytes

```
~.,,-!
~      # parse the input string as an array
 .,,   # create an array [0 1 2...] of the same length as the input
    -  # get the set difference of this array and the original
     ! # convert the empty/non-empty array into a 1 or 0
```

[Try It Online!](https://tio.run/##S8/PSStOLsosKPn/v05PR0dX8f//aEMFMwULBVMFEwVjBSMFcwWDWAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 64 bytes

```c
f(a,n,i)int*a;{for(i=n;i--&&a[i]-n;);n=~i?f(a,n,a[i]=a[--n]):n;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VVLLbtswELz7KwgHDcRi5YoPvSoYPbU/UN9cHwTbSgg4cmArCFrD/fSqO@tEUiBBoJbDGe7MbuOH7bbvm6imloIObfe5ri7N8RSFZVuFOL6/r9dhE7eVrtrl3/DthkRtWa/juN3or2117e92@ya0e7X6/nMV1YvFQqvdUV0UE6puvVFLdamvlXo@caGJ5p92v9o5qSbqSJ3Dn/2RV1p9GdbrZKO1rtRVvT6Gw15FiZ7NnurQRlpdZs8v3Tmar04v3ePvua5mImqGBdn3paVJ1Y11RxMQL3nPU0oZ5VRQSSYhY8iMCCv/CW8VDMkY6kE3smf8WxBwgHneyhmc8rGBgyE5GU8mJQuwLcnx0gidYz4ou4wsv/xnyULLJuQcuRLcLiGbk@ev3Mfz@yZoSla0LMcKjCZTkONd1r5Z9aM@nEenJn2NHkyNGu1zo2OT6gcvjXgxHPewVqQHcy03mE5zwDMU0GUqAbAV78WUiyDO@FuM0rAZ3udSnmQoHsJU8X2i/uEZyylSdnAxH9mN6FncJAF9NhkYLzEUcNghViTFFnNGt1MpPLcIAvmUCKfEBXOEjRCtBJtiCAoJKUGqt9YtWsWEZVBGuowemmBVK4PATA7jgk2c4R@@VA5iTJ6Xy5EMjkOLUJazrOngDAsyeYYOvNzVSTPS0ttYOeBzlr72/7bNoX449/Hrfw)

Answer (score 1):

## [BQN](https://mlochbaum.github.io/BQN/), 4 bytes<sup>[SBCS](https://github.com/mlochbaum/BQN/blob/master/commentary/sbcs.bqn)</sup>

```
∧≡⊒˜
```

[Run online!](https://mlochbaum.github.io/BQN/try.html#code=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)

Uses [this tip.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/238023/80214)

Answer (score 1):

## [GAP](https://www.gap-system.org/), 24 bytes

```
p:=l->PermList(l)<>fail;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dZPNbsJADITvfQxOILlS1t6fpLQ8QQ/c2x44tBVSihDl/dMZgwpIRomiJDtej@1vvzf7ado/vYyPq/Xn4ed1@3ucj4vn1ddmOy6n9WG7O87387f0sZDZ@262WD5c/okGf1VirYVqk3gX/EVEliJVmvQySOokJUmhWH2pg6qHuiIqM1/opGKlF4YwIkPVEFewQ7Qz1E1SllREGaeDGF6TJzFkoTWrorjxpaJ0oJ2YiQ1MY51ok4ynu8y4z7nTgOSKzMgAtaReDKsXG1dNDasO@3an@@GkLJxIrL03weS9jrJmzva6npvpKhpY7pDCK1pjb4tzgQEE6wXr9FPx7MM6OH3S0VwRs@ej5aydjNj/zRUqCpk1jryFTpLbVNbS0UqNz0d2knpCYoSUsIESYHbaoBAbJUtEbCBfA@tq5JUcqrNZyHHvnHUE89RHZbN4dCpNEFCoo4JhQB1rbGqEnzqG4wP@GnPwSGX3KX4MjD2gCY9FemNDkRt5KovJbtu8Lq/ufEiM@vbvYvoD)

This is a little trick since `PermList` fails if `l` is not a permutation of `1...length(l)`. However, due to technical reasons this is actually a boolean value. From the [GAP documentation](https://www.gap-system.org/Manuals/doc/ref/chap20.html):

> fail is simply an object that is different from every other object than itself.
>
> For technical reasons, fail is a boolean value. But note that fail cannot be used to form boolean expressions with and, or, and not

The operator `<>` tests for inequality.

Answer (score 1):

## TI-Basic, 17 bytes

```
Prompt A
SortA(ʟA
min(ʟA=cumSum(1 or ʟA
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Thunno](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno) `-`, \$ 8 \log_{256}(96)\approx \$ 6.58 bytes

```
Iz:DLRA=
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72sJKM0Ly9_abSSrlLsgqWlJWm6Fis8q6xcfIIcbSFcqOiC5SZcRlyGXMYQLgA)

Input as each number on its own line.

##### Explanation

```python
Iz:DLRA= # Implicit input. - flag subtracts one.
Iz:      # All inputs, sorted
   DLR   # Duplicate and push the length range
      A= # Are equal?
         # Implicit output
```

Answer (score 1):

## [vemf](https://github.com/selaere/vemf), 8 bytes

```
{α~↨≡│α≤
```

[image]

### Explained

```
{α~↨≡│α≤
{        # Monadic function that checks if
      α≤ # the sorted input
    ≡    # equals
 α~↨     # range(1, len(input) + 1)
```

Comment: -2 bytes using a fork: `└│~↨≡≤`

Answer (score 1):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 4 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
àæ↓Δ
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=859119ff&i=%5B1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,19%5D%0A%5B1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12%5D&m=2)

This is Packed Stax which unpacks to the following 5 bytes:

```
%Rx-!
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#c=%25Rx-%21&i=%5B1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,19%5D%0A%5B1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12%5D&m=2)

```
 R    # range 1..
%     # input length
  x-  # setwise difference with register x (which is set to the input by default)
    ! # logical NOT
```

Comment: I don’t speak Stax. As swapping truthy and falsy is allowed, do you still need `!`?

Comment: @tsh I only used the logical NOT because the setwise difference returns an empty array for truthy and a non-empty array for falsy. If those two values are allowed to be used then it would be able to be removed.

Answer (score 1):

## [PARI/GP](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/), 66 bytes

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jdHPS8MwFMDxe/@Kx7wkkEHTH5eWHj14nnhxImF72wJpWpMXQcS/vbad6Cwd3S2Q5H0/Ia1yen1su@7AFK8@D41jupLiTgl9YB7Jo3K7E9sg9ftC86qKhUMKzrKYc17@rCUvvzrtX1t0dSBFurHDvGFoGUXbLTyiJ9gpjyALeFJG7@HibGS0JwkVPKcCpIBMQPJSRq3Tltjq4i449MFQASsBk9w4ohdBX9ucmmD2cMaBnAiSAh7s@9QAbB9ao3eKENBgjZY8H2HJf9gVW7JgS2Zt8cSWXrHZhsDjW@hVWpmzKx1cchT1rnwOlS6g0ptQWQH3dUsfMFwZ09mQngtmC8Hsph/KC9hoezS/P/FXzsdHz6XzhXR@Jd19Aw)

```
f(a)={for(i=1,#a,if(setsearch(Set(a),i)==0,return(0)));return(1);}
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 12 bytes

```
?£(|)1¥G›r¥⁼
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/?v=1#WyIiLCIiLCI/wqMofCkxwqVH4oC6csKl4oG8IiwiIiwiWzEsIDIsIDQsIDVdIl0=)

Comment: Did you mean to keep the `(|)`? It technically doesn't do anything. [Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/?v=1#WyIiLCIiLCI/wqMxwqVH4oC6csKl4oG8IiwiIiwiWzEsIDIsIDQsIDVdIl0=) for 9 bytes without it or [Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/?v=1#WyI9IiwiIiwiP8KjMcKlR+KAunLCpeKBvCIsIiIsIlsxLCAyLCA0LCA1XSJd) for 8.5 bytes using vyncode

Answer (score 1):

## [APL(Dyalog Unicode)](https://dyalog.com), 5 bytes <sup>[SBCS](https://github.com/abrudz/SBCS)</sup>

```
^/⍋∊⊢
```

[Try it on APLgolf!](https://razetime.github.io/APLgolf/?h=AwA&c=i9N/1Nv9qKPrUdciAA&f=VY@7cQQxDENzVcHsEgYi9d2GrhRn9ji5Tq6ircSP3L3AoxmKhEAAeoqd328rTzFxqsvVt5zajVLpuwyZsmTLIVbFTCwfPdsKunmdsHrsp9Kk20kJRgdd8AYbpZw/r/Pr9/EoIUIKv@9L9RMkQ7UMc/WfcKZdmwarq6lrT8w5Q0f2LU/0Wxdo02BO5sEc@5O6NXRnMEFWIugkFjsbxaXHrf/vJDJ4M4IYrFCylPXwqiE1U6sRljTMsEawG5b4gOQCWDgZRlWdaqGrvtSbetXGz5Ai0QpVtMCO@18en0ETM0zdw997@QM&i=AwA&r=tryapl&l=apl-dyalog&m=train&n=f)

A tacit function that returns if every number from `1..n` is in the array.

### Explanation

```
^/⍋∊⊢
^/    all
  ⍋   (a permutation of) numbers from 1..n
   ∊  are members of
    ⊢ the array
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Lua](https://www.lua.org/), 64 bytes

```lua
load't=...table.sort(t)for i=1,#t do b=b or i~=t[i]end return b'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VVNBasMwELz7FYIemsASLK1k2Qe/pPSQkARMg1NctRRK@vV0ZuUWio0srVYzO7PW5X1/P4/3y3V/fCzjbrcr@8PltHu7LmVTtufr4qbRy0Nxx6s7jAfHwPdYnqbn03x0y6m8L7M7PN6n8av58jfBIIGfIOtK61pl3cAHsShJOsnSyyC@Fe/F191g8xbhHtsd0iIhKlqHaS/MYUpEOCMx4YidxXYWH8UnCUwMgyim3mAUOGTTTgJerIIEcoRWVEUH4morIUvEaHVEvCuZH8AWQAUGZIvvRbFrUmvhVdyv6uqBVunr6s8Mb6IsNdKXisNJQKXp1zg@tmCZyVyDFgYSAgTpMPYVnt7QrGyh1WwTTifMqJXl31NDiW1QSs4VzRt2IGNLuG7tYjSvetqg9J12wgcYWU8kGhPoFk0c6ODAYjI7QqeDuZ/Yqd6cbGl9lRcoie3vyMoWINuKBmOwTgFF2U9uMB8LFJQJyt8iWmFinVXKIqudBZ/SBZABuGP10epUE2Jy1r4r8/OtuTUNL8CLfLhpdvPps8iEe9A497pMc9mcNx/bbYN7cP8B)

Truthy and falsy values are swapped.

Answer (score 1):

### Pascal, 134 Bytes

This `function` requires a processor supporting Extended Pascal as defined by ISO standard 10206 (level 1).

```pascal
type Z=integer;function f(A:array[p..q:Z]of Z):Boolean;var S:set of Z;i:Z;begin S:=[];for i:=p to q do S:=S+[A[i]];f:=S=[1..q-p+1]end;
```

Ungolfed:

```pascal
function f(A: array[minimum..maximum: integer] of integer): Boolean;
var
    members: set of integer value [];
    i: integer;
begin
    { transform an ordered `array` into an unordered `set` }
    for i := minimum to maximum do
    begin
        { form the union of two sets }
        members := members + [A[i]]
    end;
    { analyze: compare `members` to a set of `[1..n]` }
    f := members = [1..(maximum - minimum + 1)]
end;
```

Evidently, the implementation is index-insensitive.

Comment: Will convert return type to Z save some bytes?

Comment: @tsh No, only one Byte. You will then need to use the conversion function `ord()` to convert the final `Boolean` result expression into an `integer` value. [Besides `0` and `1` are not truthy/falsy values in Pascal, only `true` and `false` are.]

Answer (score 1):

## [Kamilalisp](https://github.com/kspalaiologos/kamilalisp), 28 bytes

```
[≡ $(+ 1)∘⍳∘⍴ ⊼]
```

Determines whether the sorted vector is equal to the range [1, length(input)].

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70qOzE3MycxJ7O4YMEyjZTUNIW0paUlaboWe6IfdS5UUNHQVjDUfNQx41HvZjC5ReFR155YiJKbBppcXBqZ-VblRZklqTl5CjFpCuoaZgrGChYKhkYKhgqGBgomCkYK5gqWCqYKhoaamhB9CxZAaAA)

## [Kamilalisp](https://github.com/kspalaiologos/kamilalisp), 24 bytes

```
[≡ #0 ⍋@⍋]@$(^- 1)
```

A port of the APL answer.

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70qOzE3MycxJ7O4YMEyjZTUNIW0paUlaboWO6IfdS5UUDZQeNTb7QDEsQ4qGnG6CoaaEOmbBppcXBqZ-VblRZklqTl5CjFpCuoaZgrGChYKhkYKhgqGBgomCkYK5gqWCqYKhoaaUH0LFkBoAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [C (clang)](http://clang.llvm.org/), 47 bytes

*Input is a null-terminated array of positive integers*

```c
i;f(*a){return!a[i++]?i=0,1:!wcschr(a,i)<f(a);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bVLLbtswELzrKxgHBaRma4iknlHSntofiG9pDoIftQBHCWQZQWH4292ZdSIpQCFCIJfDnd2ZXX5b7ur2z/ncVJvwax0du3V/6Nqr@rG5uXn60dzHYm@v3pb75bYLa2miu01YR9XpfN20y91htTZ3@37VvMy334Pr1XrTtGuz@PmwCOv5fB6Z1Ys5mqbtTf/4ZO7NsRYTnyrz2iG2CWdfVr/bmZhN2EdRZU7mbdvs1iaMoyAAIHiumzaMzDF4PfT7cLboDv327yyqAmWww0bcx9bJJOrHuJcJCFvcJZJKJrkUUopFl1bsiHB6jnFVAJIBmjDdmD3DsRDiCEtwlQOc4tmQA5BcbCI2FUewK8VjazWdRz4y@0wcFk5OHLlcLN6LL5nbx@JySfDXehKsd0JbgtGBDgxAiy3E4xbcF6l@1bv9RKmx7kmL/7mFZqOSfhRvEv0kq1VZhucJVdYqBp0dek2nlvAbAmw4VS@gykcwRZCJM/yLkZqK04ZcwxM7VU7qqxZM2D99Yzil4Z6C5mN2q3yOlcRMn01mJ1FHCort6TBNg9qw6/IqpfyOntCqkj6VLDCn7/TTqccp56FQv2IafGndsVUOW0ZmGg300ARYnc4EMnlODi/5BgcUlTMxhzDR4kRnyLNFMutbcHoqA0Ikz9hBorV6bUZbep8wT3wO6tP5Hw)

---

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/) `-m32`, 35 bytes

*Requires that you also pass the length*

```c
f(a,n){n=!n||wcschr(a,n)*f(a,n-1);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bVLbattQEHz3V5w6FKSyNjoX3TB5bH@gfmv7IGQrNjhqsBVMcPzrVWfWiaRAkBBHu3tmdme2XjzUdd83USVtfGnvv7Svr@f6VO@OGvmmiYWNV9f@brNt9u3WrL//XEfVcrmMzeavuZh925nu1x9zby6VmOS6Mk9HxJpo/nXzu52LaaJODEAP2zbq4jhemas57/aHrYmSeDZ7rPZtFJvL7Om5O0Xz9fG5273M49VMiexwEPd@dDKJ@jHuZVKEI3JBUskkl0JKsYlYK3ascPqfIFWgJENpINyInuG3ENaxLCCVozjFtQEDJbnYIDYVx2JXisfRKpwHHpl9Jg4v/pw4crlEvBdfEtsn4nIJ@Go/Ae8boS3B6EAHBlSLLcQjC@6bVD@qw2mi1Nj3ZMRPstBsVNKP4k2iH2S1KstwPVBl7WLQ2WHWdGoJnyHAgVP1Aqq8B1MECZzhW4zUVJw25Bqe2KlyUl@1YML@4RnDKQ33FDQf0a3yOXaSED6b7E5QRwqK7ekwTYPasOt2K6X8jp7QqpI@lWwwp@/006nHKfehUL8SGnwb3XFULltGZhqN6mEIsDrdCSB5bg6TvIMfNJUTmEsYtDnRHfIckcx6F5yeyoAQ4BknCNqr12F0pLcN86zPQX3t/9XNoXo49Ytzv3j07j8)

Answer (score 1):

## [Scala 3](https://www.scala-lang.org/), <s>36</s> 30 bytes

```scala
l=>l.toSet==(1to l.size).toSet
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=hcq9CsIwFAXg3ae4OCUQhfpPIYJugk7FqXSImpZITGp7FX_wSVx00MlncPEpfBuDmUUu3MM5fOd7ORdaNB9xtSZ3uRbKVJP3y86Wco4wcRWOFYCFTGHlChFFVoYwKAqxjyMslMkSGsLUKAT-lQC5W1EbkpKxKpEErMGarMParEUp_S1a7jp_RJt1vThV3NsKDWkIhERyHY8MJpT3h9ZqKQwFfttgWus9Ne_rOtpIIuckQAu6XqqDpH7z6Hryebn4_AA)

Answer (score 0):

## [RAD](https://bitbucket.org/zacharyjtaylor/rad), 5 bytes

```
<≡⍳∘⍴
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0pM@f/f5lHnwke9mx91zHjUu@X///8mCkYKpgrGCoYA)

```
 ≡       - Check equality between ...
<        - ... the input vector ...
  ⍳∘     - ... and 1 through ...
   ⍴     - ... the length of the input vector.
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Arturo](https://arturo-lang.io), 22 bytes

```arturo
$[a][=sort a 1..max a]
```

[Try it](http://arturo-lang.io/playground?Mf1HdC)

Checks whether the input sorted is equal to \$[1..\mathrm{max}(input)]\$.