# Project Euler 1: Multiples in constant time

Tags: code-golf, number, number-theory, restricted-complexity

The purpose of this challenge is to solve the original [first Project Euler problem](https://projecteuler.net/problem=1), but as the title suggests in [constant time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity#Constant_time) (with respect to the size of the interval).

> Find the sum of all the multiples from a list of numbers in some defined range, in such a way that the running time of your program runs in constant time [\$\mathcal{O}(1)\$] with respect to the size of the range

Let us step through the problem statement with an handful of small examples.

---

**Example 1:** Let `[3,5]` be our list of numbers, and let our range be `[1, 999]` meaning every natural number starting with `1` up to and including `999`. To do this in linear time we can do as follows. The multiples of 3 and 5 are

$$
\begin{align*}
3 + 6 + 9 + 12 + \color{red}{15}+18+\cdots+999=3(1+2+3+\cdots+333)=3\,T_{333}\\
5 + 10 + \color{red}{15} + 20 + \cdots+995=5(1+2+3+\cdots+199)=5\,T_{199}
\end{align*}
$$

Where \$T_{333}\$ is the 333rd triangular number. \$T_n=n(n+1)/2\$. However, simply adding \$3T_{333}\$ and \$5T_{199}\$, makes us *over count*. We will then count every number that is both a multiple of `3` and `5` (15, 30, 45...) twice. Thus, our final answer, *in constant time with respect to the input range* is

$$3T_{333} + 5T_{199}-15 T_{66}$$

Where \$66\$ was chosen because it is the largest value such that \$66\cdot15<999\$.

---

**Example 2:** Let `[6,9]` be our list of numbers, we might suspect that our answer will be

$$\text{Multiples of } 6 + \text{Multiples of } 9 - \text{Multiples of }  6 \cdot 9=54
$$

However this is leads to an error, as the first number counted in the multiples of \$6\$ and \$9\$ is \$18\$ *not* \$54\$. So

$$\text{Multiples of } 6 + \text{Multiples of } 9 - \text{Multiples of }  18
$$

gives the correct answer. Where, for instance, we could have done \$\text{lcm}(6,9)=6\cdot9/\text{gcd}(6,9)=18\$.

---

**Example 3:** Let `[3,5,7]` be our list of multiples, were we again is dropping the range for the sake of brevity. The easiest is now to use the [inclusion-exclusion principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle).

[image]

So our answer will be

$$
\begin{align}
&\text{Multiples of } 3 + \text{Multiples of } 5 + \text{Multiples of } 7 \\
- &\text{Multiples of lcm} (3,5) - \text{Multiples of lcm} (3, 7) - \text{Multiples of lcm} (5, 7) \\ + & \text{Multiples of lcm} (3, 5, 7)
\end{align}
$$

---

**Input**

A list of multiples (or divisors if you will), and a range. You may take input in any  [convenient method](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods)

**Output**

A single number/string/float ( representing the sum of every number divisible by at least one of the numbers in `multiples=[3,5,...]` in range `[start, stop]`)

---

**Restrictions and assumptions**

- **You *only* have to make sure your program runs in constant time with respect to the size of the range we are working over** How, you choose the handle the multiples/divisors is up to you
- The range is always assumed to be non-empty, with inclusive endpoints. Meaning `[10, 10]` contains `10`.
- We are working over the integers meaning every multiple and range will be whole non-negative numbers.

---

**Test cases**

Our test cases will be on the form `list of multiples`, `range`, `sum`.

```
[7]                  [1000,   1000]                0
[3, 5]               [1000,   1000]             1000
[3, 5]               [   1,    999]           233168
[3, 5, 7]            [ 300,    600]            73558
[9,10]               [   1,    999]            99504
[6, 9]               [   1,    999]           111390
[6, 9, 10, 5, 5, 9]  [ 1234,  4321]          3240486
[3, 5]               [10**7, 10**8] 2310000085000000
```

You may use the following code below to test your implementation, note that the implementation below does *not* run in constant time with respect to the input

```
def naive(multiples, start, stop):
    total = 0
    for num in range(start, stop + 1):
        for m in multiples:
            if num % m == 0:
                total += num
                break
    return total
```

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) so shortest code wins!

Comment: It's OK if the code is exponential-time in terms of the length of the list of divisors?

Comment: @xnor Read the first bullet point in **Restrictions and assumptions** =)

Answer (score 9):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 20 bytes

```
+Ø.÷€AĊc2ḋIɓN;æl¥ƒ-Ḋ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/1/78Ay9w9sfNa1xPNKVbPRwR7fnycl@1oeX5RxaemyS7sMdXf8PL9cHSv//Hx0dbWhkbKKjYGJsZBiroxBtpqNgqaNgaKCjYApGlrGxOlwKQFUGEACSgwKQcmOgotjYWAA)

Port of [my own APL answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/230991/78410). Trailing `ɓ` chain trick is indeed strong :P

#### How it works

```
+Ø.÷€AĊc2ḋIɓN;æl¥ƒ-Ḋ    Dyadic link; left=range, right=divisors
xxxxxxxxxxxɓyyyyyyyy    x(left, y(right, left))
            N;æl¥ƒ-Ḋ    y: subset LCMs, negative for even-sized ones
            N           Negate the divisors
                 ƒ-     Starting with -1, reduce by
             ;æl¥         current list ++ LCM(current list, next num)
                   Ḋ    Remove the leading -1
+Ø.÷€AĊc2ḋI    x: range(start, end), subset LCMs -> answer
+Ø.            Add 1 to the end
   ÷€AĊ        Divide each by subset LCMs, abs, ceil
       c2      nC2 of each
         ḋ     Dot product of each row with subset LCMs
          I    Increments (2nd - 1st)
```

Comment: Took me a while to work out how it works, but that is simply brilliant. EDIT: Also +1 for using one of my babies, `ɓ` :D

Answer (score 8):

## [APL (Dyalog Extended)](https://github.com/abrudz/dyalog-apl-extended), 31 bytes

```apl
-/+/(⎕+⍳2)(⊢×2!⌈⍤|⍤÷)\∊(⊢,∧)\-⎕
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jZG9TsMwEMd3P8WxNamt@iNO4sEPwMQDpB0qNWGpKAMDCFhRVRHEgtgREg@AEBJr38QvEnxxQEmrSo0Uf/39u/v7bn65ZIub@XJ1zsrrq/JiUS4a9/RyeuYenjmp/HjbsMl4MnL1z9jVnzIauc3b9lWeuMe1q9/v/L/9jqZuvUGBuvVHNGWu/mruG8E5h3aoICP9nQJNBBhjurXyp@mfgnc7zXjgf5OCIUKqBBIlRdh72d/XKJQZiDLv4jHGCLf7@e2uCamUSHPb95IprXO768gYzRM79CWEMtz27SmZ8CRP7UGbUmFyznPdTp4e@CYkWlUVKbIZ7H0FktQvcN7TOSkUBT07HsKTAxCqCOHL@mKoVoAoDE0WoEImLNtAaQtKCkMFPzoTtPUmRUrBHA2FhgSI@ve1LnWIUAD2xFPYlR7Udexg9eI4w1BxnM9gt3nwCw)

Full program which takes the list of divisors, and then the `(start,end)` pair. Uses a modified [trick to generate all nonempty subsequences](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/211449/78410). Also abuses the definition of LCM which is `LCM(a,b) = a * b / GCD(a,b)` and GCD is always positive, so LCM follows the sign of `a * b`.

#### How it works

```
-/+/(⎕+⍳2)(⊢×2!⌈⍤|⍤÷)\∊(⊢,∧)\-⎕    Input 1: divisors; input 2: range (start,end)
                      ∊(⊢,∧)\-⎕    LCMs of all nonempty subsets of divisors,
                                   negative if the subset has odd size
    (⎕+⍳2)                Add 1 to the right end of the range
          (         )\    Outer product:
               ⌈⍤|⍤÷      ceil(abs(left ÷ right))
           ⊢×2!           nC2 to each of above, times right
                          For each pair of (a,b), this evaluates the sum of
                          numbers in [1..a] divisible by b, following sign of b
-/+/    Sum of 1st row - sum of 2nd row
        (each value was negated because odd subsets should be added, not subtracted;
         the difference order fixes the negation)
```

Answer (score 5):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 229 bytes

```python
lambda d,s,e:sum(-(-1)**len(k)*(t(e//l(*k))-t(~-s//l(*k)))*l(*k)for k in p(d)[1:])
t=lambda x:x*-~x//2
p=lambda k:k and[j+a for j in[[],k[:1]]for a in p(k[1:])]or[[]]
l=lambda a,*b:b and a*l(*b)//math.gcd(a,l(*b))or a
import math
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hY7LbsMgEEX3/opZMhSKH3nUSPkSygLXduPgl2wquZv8umucuFKrVN0Acy/naPpPd@7aZC5Pr3Ntmiw3kLORFXL8aAgnPEJK66IlFilxpBCiJtQickeufNwmpOtddgNYqFroSY4qkhoDd7pLJzlRfp2EiIN@y6y0YNpcXZ4MePaysEppZpWMtPaJudnsKtPdsLQ6qDfeMJrJzCvA@A0yFKIx7vz8/pYTw9YEvSWomr4bHPhy7oeqdaQk6qgZRGEY3k7E4LtJGOz/LRmkafq7YOCtiecOP7HUmx5yhyX5s/DU6t3ff8XJjsEuiaOHCwOlcNweL4jzFw)

-5 bytes thanks to ovs

There's probably a less direct approach. I haven't properly golfed in Python in too long.

Comment: A few (untested) golfs: `~(-s//l(*k)))` -> `~-s//l(*k)`, `x*(x+1)` -> `x*-~x` and `(len(k)%2*2-1)` -> `-(-1)**len(k)`

Answer (score 5):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Lyxal/Vyxal) `s`, 32 bytes

```
$ṗḢƛ:λ₌*ġḭ;R:¹‹÷›"$ḭ:›*2ḭ¯unLe**
```

[Try it Online!](https://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=s&code=%24%E1%B9%97%E1%B8%A2%C6%9B%3A%CE%BB%E2%82%8C*%C4%A1%E1%B8%AD%3BR%3A%C2%B9%E2%80%B9%C3%B7%E2%80%BA%22%24%E1%B8%AD%3A%E2%80%BA*2%E1%B8%AD%C2%AFunLe**&inputs=%5B300%2C%20600%5D%0A%5B3%2C%205%2C%207%5D&header=&footer=)

Answer (score 4):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 25 bytes

```
æ¦ε.¿DIāÉ-s÷D>*2÷Æ®ygmP}O
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//8LJDy85t1Tu038XzSOPhTt3iw9td7LSMDm8/3HZoXWV6bkCt////0cY6prFc0YYGEKCjAGMZxAIA)

```python
æ¦ε                     }  # map over each non-empty subset of the divisors
   .¿D                     #   take the LCM of the subset
      IāÉ-                 #   push the range with the lower bound decreased
          s÷               #   integer divide modified range by LCM
            D>*2÷          #   for both resulting integers, compute the nth triangular number
                 Æ         #   reduce by subtraction (results in negative values)
                   ®ygm*   #   multiply with LCM and (-1)**len(subset)
                         O # sum the resulting list
```

Comment: Did you mean LCM in your explanation? I'm trying to understand this because if GCD works, I can probably golf my Python solution down. It looks like LCM from testing but I don't know 05AB1E enough to know if I messed something up when trying to test parts of the code.

Comment: @hyper-neutrino You're right, this is the LCM, my bad. I think this doing the exact same thing as your Python solution.

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly),  <s>30</s>  29 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

-1 thanks to [caird coinheringaahing](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/66833/caird-coinheringaahing)!

```
’1¦:×‘HIƲḢ×ʋⱮⱮœcⱮJæl/€€Ɗ}§Ṛḅ-
```

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///hjkWPGmZaH@uyOjz9UcMMD89jm4BCh6ef6n60cR0QHZ2cDCS9Di/L0X/UtAaIjnXVHlr@cOeshztadf///x9taKClZa6jAKIsYv9HG@somMYCAA)**

#### How?

```
’1¦:×‘HIƲḢ×ʋⱮⱮœcⱮJæl/€€Ɗ}§Ṛḅ- - Link: [start, stop]; divisors
 1¦                           - apply to index 1 (of [start, stop]):
’                             -   decrement -> [start-1, stop]
                        }     - using right (divisors):
                       Ɗ      -   last three links as a monad - f(divisors):
                 J            -     range of length -> [1,2,...,#divisors]
                Ɱ             -     map with (for n in that):
              œc              -       all ways to choose n of the divisors
                      €       -     for each (list of choices of length n):
                     €        -       for each (way to choose):
                    /         -         reduce by:
                  æl          -           least common multiple
             Ɱ                - map across (for each list of LCMs):
            Ɱ                 -   map across (for each LCM):
           ʋ                  -     last four links as a dyad - f([start-1, stop],LCM):
   :                          -       integer divide -> [(start-1)//LCM, stop//LCM]
                                             call this "[A,B]"
        Ʋ                     -       last four links as a monad - f([A,B]):
     ‘                        -         increment -> [A+1,B+1]
    ×                         -         multiply -> [A(A+1),B(B+1)]
      H                       -         halve -> [A(A+1)/2,B(B+1)/2]
       I                      -         differences -> [B(B+1)/2-A(A+1)/2]
         Ḣ                    -       head -> B(B+1)/2-A(A+1)/2
          ×                   -       multiply -> LCM(B(B+1)/2-A(A+1)/2)
                         §    - sums -> [sum of single-choices, sum of two-choices, ...]
                          Ṛ   - reverse
                           ḅ- - convert from base -1 -> 1×(sum of single-choices)+-1×(sum of two-choices)+...
```

---

With fewer loops using the same approach, also 30 bytes:

```
Ḣ’;Ɗ:×‘HIƲḢ×ʋæl/}¥ⱮⱮœcⱮJ$}§Ṛḅ-
```

---

With no constraint on computational complexity, 7 bytes (-1 thanks to caird again!):

```
r/ọẸ¥ƇS
```

Comment: You can golf the unconstrained one to 7 bytes by replacing `ḍ@` with `ọ`. Also: [29 bytes](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8//9Rw0zDQ8usDk9/1DDDw/PYpoc7Fh2efqr70cZ1QHR0cjKQ9Dq8LEf/UdMaIDrWVXto@cOdsx7uaNX9//9/tKGBlpa5jgKIsoj9H22so2AaCwA) for the main one

Answer (score 3):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), <sup>72</sup> 69 bytes

```
1#.(_1*_1^1#.g)*(_1 0+[)(]*[:-~/(2!>:)@<.@%/)]*./@#~g=.1}.2#:@i.@^#@]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY6xbsIwEIZ3nuJoVBGnxbnz2UlsNcgSEhNTVxQYKqDt0rVLefX0EhMpDGf7/Pn/fN/9k15doA2wgldACFJrDdv3/a6nTOcnKk50lNNVFdIAvhxU3hWHsL6VuVlugopvOj6Xqit0GbPbtdX0p00W4peOxyx2vVqcPz5/RNsCIWJaLlCn67F7JAwuMcNMVTNQ8N7PSc3ODYAlUE2hSem9QztLeRHfPyNijzNUgU@EjUXbVAMybMGyoYQlK2Y3vTM8DInYuHEbXedaqkkz/Pb/)

<sup>-3 thanks to nC2 trick from Bubbler's answer</sup>

There's some more golf's I believe I can port from Bubbler's APL answer.  Will try tomorrow.

Answer (score 3):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Lyxal/Vyxal), 37 bytes

```
$ṗḢƛ:λ₌*ġḭ;R:¹÷$‹$"$ḭ:²+½$*÷-$Lu$e*;∑
```

[Try it Online!](https://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=%24%E1%B9%97%E1%B8%A2%C6%9B%3A%CE%BB%E2%82%8C*%C4%A1%E1%B8%AD%3BR%3A%C2%B9%C3%B7%24%E2%80%B9%24%22%24%E1%B8%AD%3A%C2%B2%2B%C2%BD%24*%C3%B7-%24Lu%24e*%3B%E2%88%91&inputs=%5B300%2C%20600%5D%0A%5B3%2C%205%2C%207%5D&header=&footer=)

This is extremely messy. In case it wasn't clear, I am terrible with stack-based languages.

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 146 bytes

```python
lambda d,s,e:(e*e+e-s*s+s+g(d,e)-g(d,s-1))//2
g=lambda d,n,m=1:g(d[1:],n,m)-g(d[1:],n,m*d[0]//math.gcd(m,d[0]))if d else~n//m*(n//m)*m
import math
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hY5JjoMwEEX3nKKWLlMEjDOBxEkIC7ptCFJMUMwmm1ydUJmkRGn1pqb3/1cN53F/7PXUFLvpULsfU4MhTzYXVtrQRl760IetMGQx4uYjhRjHadAWL31PrlD5TEuVV7zdpM9FmjKp4tjV437R/hrhiA@IXQMG7MHbSz9TKbiidEHnhuNpBNZPw6nrR9GIclMRqCRJ7hUxeBFNsPoXEmRZ9gkIOFWzb/1uyzjpq289X/4E7Lrlrh6qVC8JljpVXx8GKWHzHLaI0xU)

Some tricks explained: `~n//m` is a shorter way to write `-(n//m+1)`, and `e*e+e-s*s+s` is twice the sum of integers in the interval.

---

### Python 3.9, 138 bytes

```python
lambda d,s,e:(e*e+e-s*s+s+g(d,e)-g(d,s-1))//2
g=lambda d,n,m=1:g(d[1:],n,m)-g(d[1:],n,math.lcm(m,d[0]))if d else~n//m*(n//m)*m
import math
```

Uses the new `math.lcm` in Python 3.9. No TIO link because Python 3.9 is not available there yet.

Comment: [144 bytes](https://tio.run/##hY7LzoIwEIX3PMUsO2X4pdbLDwm@CLJAW5DEIrFs3PjqyHhLNBo3c/vOOZnu1O8OrR6qbD3sS7cxJRjyZFMrbWgjL33ow1oYshhx85HC1UoFdfZUt@QylY4wV2nB21X5WKTJ42IycWW/@6u3RjjiA2JTgQG79/bcjlQKrihd0LjucOyB9UN3bNpeVCJfFgQqjuNbRQyeRBPMf0KCJEneAQGnavYtXm0JJ330LcbLV8Cua@78rprqGcFMT9XHh0FKWD6Gf8ThAg) by using bitshift instead of division.

Comment: [140 bytes](https://tio.run/##hY5LDsIwDET3PYWXiXGhIfyKVC4CLApJQyVSKtIFbLh6qflJIBAba@w3M3J9bnaHSrdFtmr3ud@YHAwFsvMQBwzxxaLtOWFJERoZOxFiddeLhYpc9ohU5MlkCeFp7gQveGJzp9AMBj5vdn23NaIzSUZlAQbsPthL1VEUPCX6qPT14dgA@9v6WFaNKMRyuiZQSZLcp5TRi2iC8V9IkKbpJyDgVs25yXss5aavuUl3@Qk4desdP1xDPSIY6aH6@jAgwvQpZlK2Vw)

Answer (score 0):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 41 bytes

```
≔ΠθεＩΣＥＥε⁺×÷⁻⟦⊖ηζ⟧ιεει∧⊙θ¬﹪κλ÷×↨ι±¹⁺Σιε⊗ε
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RU49C4MwEN37KzJeIAWldHKydelgEdpNHFI9NDQm1USh/fPpqYMP7riPx3uv7uRYW6lDSJ1TrYFitM1Uexi4YMiTQzEq4@EqnYfH1EMuP2uhYIWeHDxVjw5uxmdqVg1CrgxdywzrEXs0HhvoSOlXCaZWxa2WOTUNpOYLg2B36yEnX23hLZjmnN675uZxkQ5BERdb6RHihbNGWGJt2tQyO700mdKyIAmhLE@Cnck/jjbsU1SF46z/) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
≔Πθε
```

Calculate the product of the divisors, as it gets used enough times that it saves a byte.

```
Ｅε⁺×÷⁻⟦⊖ηζ⟧ιεει
```

Map over the product, generating an adjusted half-open range of (first multiple below, last multiple not above] for each possible remainder.

```
÷×↨ι±¹⁺Σιε⊗ε
```

Calculating the sum of the integers within the range with that remainder as (last - first) * (last + first + product) / (2 * product).

```
ＩΣＥ...∧⊙θ¬﹪κλ...
```

Map over the list of ranges, calculating the sums for those which are divisible by one of the divisors, and output the overall sum.